# Tips for golfing in Applescript

Tags: code-golf, tips

What tips do you have for golfing in Applescript? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Applescript (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Comment: This question is Too Broad. It can't possibly be answered with a one complete, well-written answer (and the question even explicitly forbids that).

Comment: Still, it's just a funny question :)

Comment: Flagged for conversion to CW (per our convention for 'tips for golfing in x' questions).

Comment: @MadTux Yep, Applescript is not usually the 1st choice in golfing languages ;-).  [But there are occasions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36677/11259), particularly in the [tag:restricted-source] category where it becomes marginally useful.

Comment: @Rainbolt Just to be clear, is your comment aimed at this question in particular, or all *[tag:tips] for golfing in x* questions in general?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma This question in particular.

Comment: @Rainbolt How is this different in nature to other *[tag:tips] for golfing in x* questions?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I never said it was. If you wish to continue this interrogation, please open separate chat room and invite me.

Answer (score 6):

The `of` operator is used to get a property from an object:

```
log words of "Hello World"
```

But in many cases you can use `'s` as a shortcut to save 1 character:

```
log "Hello World"'s words
```

Comment: It seems somewhat ridiculous, but also somewhat awesome, that Applescript parses apostrophes as possessive. I can just imagine one of the language designers pitching that idea to the group.

Comment: @Geobits Those are great adjectives for describing Applescript in general.  I just haven't decided if Applescript is *ridiculously awesome* or *awesomely ridiculous* ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Some words have shorter synonyms. For example, `application` can be written as `app`*, and `string` can be written as `text`.

Also, `every <noun>` can be written as simply the plural, as in `characters of "hello world"` (or `"foo"'s characters`).

*Although Script Editor's compiler will change it back.

Answer (score 4):

The Applescript Editor is a handy little IDE which syntax-highlights and beautifies your code.  However, for the purposes of golfing, it is counterproductive as it adds indentation and superfluous keywords, e.g. after `end` statements.  For example:

```
repeat with w in "Hello World"'s words
log w
end
```

becomes the following when pasted into the Applescript Editor and compiled/run:

```
repeat with w in "Hello World"'s words
    log w
end repeat
```

Obviously the first snippet is better for the purposes of golfing.

Comment: IMO this can be seen as a general tip, not specific to AS. Many modern IDEs do this if you let them.

Comment: @Geobits Agreed.  Though I think the addition of specific keywords after `end` is fairly Applescript specific.

Comment: Yea, that's just baffling to me. The indentation/spacing thing is very common, though, along with unnecessary brackets, etc.

Comment: @Geobits Applescript is all about readability.  I guess the idea is to make it clear which `end` belongs to which block start statement when you have multiple nested blocks

Answer (score 4):

`tell` blocks are common in Applescript:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
end tell
```

However to save space the following is equivalent, when the inside of the `tell` block is just one line:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
```

Comment: Which itself is `tell app "TextEdit" to activate`.

Comment: @WChargin Yes.  Add it as another answer if you like.

Answer (score 3):

#### Quotation Required Operation

For any operation that requires a quote to do something, i.e.

```
log "Hello World!"
```

You can shorten to

```
log"Hello World!"
```

#### Repeating

In repeat loops, one can entirely remove the word "times".

```
repeat x times
end
```

versus

```
repeat x
end
```

#### <= and >=

Any time these operators are called, you can replace them with `≤` and `≥`, respectively. While this may not reduce byte count (unless special byte counting conventions are implemented, which I suggest), it *does* reduce character count.

#### Grabbing from STDIN

You can grab from STDIN in with the following characters:

```
on run argv
end
```

#### Exiting quickly

If you need to exit a code quickly (for whatever reason, i.e. preventing excessive `if`s)...

```
quit
```

Comment: Haha wow, you must have done some trawling to find this ;)

Comment: I use it _a lot_.

Comment: The question or the tips?

Comment: The tips. And AppleScript in general.

Comment: Oh I was talking about the question :)

Comment: Oh! No, it was one of the things suggested for me in the sidebar.

Comment: Lots of good tips here - generally you can add one answer per tip.

Answer (score 2):

Applescript allows some extra keywords to be inserted to help readability:

```
log the words of "Hello World"
```

But the `the` here is completely superfluous and may be omitted for a 4 character saving:

```
log words of "Hello World"
```

Comment: You can have even shorter variants: `log"Hello World"'s words`, because you 1) don't need the space between any expression and quoted item, and 2) because `'s` can be used in replacement of `of`.

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE yes, `'s` is addressed in this answer http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37643/11259.  Good to know about `log"` though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Bracket Shortening

Similar to the post about quotations, I realized later that you can also shorten things like this:

```
if "a"=character 1 of (x as string) then return {true, true}
```

to

```
if"a"=character 1 of(x as string)then return{true,true}
```

It'll space out brackets for you too. In this example, I save 5 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Considering...

In questions that require case sensitivity, it can be difficult to actually deal with cases.

#### UNTIL NOW:

```
considering case
    (something to do with case sensitive stuff)
end considering
```

I didn't actually know this keyword until I really needed it. Using the other tips in this tips page, we can reduce this down to:

```
considering case
(something to do with case sensitive stuff)
end
```

It does require a full statement, as far as I know. (I've tried a lot of things.) See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In a few exceptional cases, the «double angle brackets» or «double chevrons» might be shorter than the English name of a command, parameter, or constant.

The chevron-encoded form would shrink the AppleScript to [delete the clipboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111411/4065) from 20 to 16 characters:

```
set the clipboard to  -- 20
«event JonspClp»      -- 16
```

It would drop 2 characters when fetching text from a dialog (as happens in [metronome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77732/4065) and [Pi Day](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75504/4065)):

```
(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned  -- 46
(display dialog""default answer"")'s«class ttxt»    -- 44
```

(You might prefer to avoid the dialog and use the command-line arguments of [osascript(1)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html), if you have at least Mac OS X 10.4.)

With a US keyboard, « is option-\ and » is option-shift-\. A command `«event abcdefgh»` has 16 characters. A parameter or constant `«class abcd»` has 12 characters.

The chevron-encoded form is almost always too long for golf. Here is an example without double angle brackets:

```
set x to open for access"output"write permission 1
write"One line of text
"to x
close access x
```

And the same with them:

```
set x to«event rdwropen»"output"given«class perm»:1
«event rdwrwrit»"One line of text
"given«class refn»:x
«event rdwrclos»x
```

Changing `_open for access` (16) to `«event rdwropen»` (16) was neutral. Changing `write permission_` (17) to `given«class perm»:` (18) cost 1 character. The other double angle brackets cost more.

To use double angle brackets, you need to know the magic 4-letter or 8-letter code. I found some codes by saving a script file from Script Editor, then opening it in a hex editor. I ran `emacs` in a terminal and used `M-x hexl-find-file`. I found and edited some codes, like `JonspClp` into `JanspClp`, and `ttxt` into `atxt`. I then saved the file and reopened it in Script Editor. `«event JanspClp»` and `«class atxt»` appeared in the script.

A document titled *AppleScript Terminology and Apple Event Codes Reference* lists some codes. I found a copy of it at https://applescriptlibrary.wordpress.com/

Script Editor will translate double angle brackets to English before saving your script. For chevron deference, you must write your script in another text editor, like TextEdit. Save the script as a plain text file in the Mac OS Roman (or MacRoman) encoding. Mac OS X prefers that you name the file with an .applescript suffix.

If you count bytes, MacRoman has 1 byte per character, so each « or » counts as 1 byte.

Comment: Careful though, `«` and `»` are 0xc2ab and 0xc2bb in UTF-8 - i.e. 2 bytes each.

Comment: An especially useful variant is replacing `text item delimiters` with `«class txdl»`.