# Happy Rounded Pi Day

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, date, pi

To celebrate Rounded Pi Day, you must take advantage of today's date to make a program that takes in a circle's diameter and outputs its circumference by multiplying the diameter by 3.1416, where 3.1416 must be obtained using today's date.

```
Input 3
Output 9.4248
etc.
```

Does not take the date as input. You do not have to use all components of the date but the digits of pi must come from formatting a Date object or using a date object to obtain it. The answers so far look good.

Not sure what else to specify. All the answers so far meet what I was expecting.

My constraint was that you must use components of the date to come up with Pi. You can of course use the components, multiply by 0 then add 3.1416, but that's boring and wastes precious chars!

Shortest code wins!

Comment: What's so special about 14/3/16?

Comment: define _using today's date_. I could get the date as a number, divide by itself and multiply by a predefined constant for `pi`

Comment: Should we support a point? I mean, should the code be able to calculate for 0 diameter?

Comment: @manatwork We can assume that the arg is an integer or floating point number > 0.

Comment: @Neil in the US, we format it MM/DD/YY, so today is 3/14 today. The OP is presumably in the US themself.

Comment: I think the challenge would be more clear if the actual task was something like "multiply the input by `MM.DDYY`".

Comment: @Neil: Because 3/14/16 and 31/4/16 are not valid actual dates in D/M/Y format.  There aren't 14 months, and April only has 30 days.  I personally think we should wait until 6/28/32 (M/D/Y) or maybe 6/2/83 (D/M/Y), but that's a whole other holy war.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You're a Tau man I see.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman So close with that 31/4/16...

Comment: Is a floating point number valid? I.E. Input of 3 yields 9.424800000000001

Comment: Sadly, its only PI day in the US cultural area. Europeans, with their silly lexigraphcially-sensible date ordering, don't get to have yearly PI days. Spare a sad thought for them, as you're eating your pi(e) today.

Comment: @T.E.D. But Europeans get Pi Approximation Day, July 22!

Comment: @MikeKellogg - So on "Pi Approximation Day", do they eat Chicago-style pizza? :-)

Comment: What counts as *obtained using today's date*? For example, can I obtain 16 as `2016 % 20`?

Comment: Really should state that "today's date" is in M/D/Y format, as half the world formats date in other ways.

Comment: US date ordering makes a lot more sense than any other system. The terms of possibilities go up, [1-12]/[1-30ish]/[00-99]. Therefore the magnitudes are all increasing.

Comment: Hey everyone! Today is actually `2016-03-14`.

Comment: @WillSherwood That's a strange thing to sort by.  Now, redefining the length of a month so that pattern occurs when sorting by size of an increment might be sensible.

Comment: @T.E.D. Silly? I find european format more intuitive

Comment: @rpax "lexigraphcially-sensible", he was probably was being sarcastic

Comment: I feel stupid for how long it took me to realize why no one was using brainf*ck

Comment: @WillSherwood the [ISO 8601 international standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) YYYY-MM-DD makes the most sense. No one can read it wrongly and it will **always** sort correctly by chronological order. The US way makes the least sense. Why should magnitudes increasing? Sorting and reading is what people care

Comment: @DarrelHoffman some people prefer 22/7 as Pi day

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc the date 22/7 doesn't exist because there are only 12 months in a year though

Comment: @WillSherwood it exists in **most** of the world except those who write 3/14/16 (well, a few other countries who write 16/14/3, too)

Comment: @WillSherwood -_-

Comment: But [this year's Pi day was *more accurate* than last year's](http://vihart.com/pi-day-rant-31416/).

Comment: [Why isn't Pi Day 22/7 i.e. 22nd of July? Wouldn't that be more appropriate?](https://www.quora.com/Why-isnt-Pi-Day-22-7-i-e-22nd-of-July-Wouldnt-that-be-more-appropriate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 05AB1E, <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
žfžežg¦¦J*4°/
```

[Try it online.](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5mxb5lxb5nwqbCpkoqNMKwLw&input=Mw)

Unfortunately a bug with floats makes this a byte longer :/

Thanks to Adnan for golfing off 3 bytes.

### Explanation

```
žfžežg¦¦J*4°/
žfžežg         push month day year
      ¦¦       slice off the first two chars from the year (2016 -> 16)
        J      join them together into a number
         *     multiply by input
          4°/  divide by 1e4
```

Comment: `¦¦` instead of `2000-` is three bytes shorter ;)

Comment: +1 `žfžežg` sounds like a nice Czech word :)

Comment: In UTF-8, this totals 19 bytes.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 05AB1E uses CP1252 for encoding.

Comment: Bug with floats?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I should be able to do `žf'.žežg¦¦J*` (which is a byte shorter), but strings weren't auto-coercing to floats properly.

Answer (score 19):

## C, 32 bytes

```
#define f(d)d*time(0)/464083315.
```

If losing a little more accuracy is fine, I can get it down to about 29 bytes being still accurate to 4 digits past the decimal (as of the time of this posting):

```
#define f(d)d*time(0)/46408e4
```

Comment: `#include<time.h>`?

Comment: Also, where's the executable code? this is just something for the preprocessor to copy/paste; a snippet. We like runnable implementations here.

Comment: @tac most C compilers do not require you to `#include` standard library headers.  Including them manually is almost always a good idea, but omitting them makes code golfing in C a lot easier.

Comment: @tac the answer behaves mostly the same as a function.  Several answers on here are standalone functions as well.  I don't see the point in providing a sample `main` function to demonstrate how to call this single argument macro.

Comment: @tac I think the standard [code-golf] rules is that unless forbidden functions are ok.

Comment: I don't think this is valid; the number being multiplied by is never exactly 3.1416. The question says "multiplying the diameter by 3.1416, where 3.1416 must be obtained using today's date.", not "multiplying the diameter by an approximation to pi obtained using today's date." However, it's unfair to downvote when the question is closed.

Comment: @lirtosiast I understand where you are coming from, but I feel I stayed on the legal side of the grey line.  Quoting the current spec, `You do not have to use all components of the date but the digits of pi must come from formatting a Date object or using a date object to obtain it.`

Answer (score 14):

## AppleScript, <s>122</s> 120 bytes

```
set a to current date
(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned*(month of a+day of a*.01+year of a*1e-4 mod.01)
```

#### Variable a

Variable a is a date object. I call all of my date information off of it.

#### Month, day, and year

The month, day, and year calls actually return an object that normally returns a string. To properly use it as a number, I have surrounded it on both sides with mathematical operations to automatically cast it to a number.

#### 1e-4

`1e-4` is a byte shorter than `.0001`.

#### mod.01

`.` acts as a separator to the AppleScript autocorrect. By using this, I can use modulo and *still* keep it a byte for myself.

#### No return statement/log

The last value calculated automatically is returned by the program. I output the number calculated via the return box.

And here's a gif of it running!

[image: pi day gif]

Comment: Forget Java, *this* has got to be the most verbose language

Comment: @Downgoat I guess that it's supposed to be "readable like English" or something... we use it a bit at one of my jobs and I really dislike whenever I have to make changes to such scripts.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Yeah, no - this language has some annoying pieces to it. i.e. volume system volume.

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica + coreutils, 20 bytes

```
<<"!date +%m.%d%y"#&
```

Luckily, Mathematica interprets the output of an external command as an expression. In this case the output is a valid float, so that multiplication with the function argument `#` is implied.

Comment: That's a combination I didn't know existed.

Answer (score 12):

### Lua, <s>30</s> 27 Bytes

```lua
print(...*os.date"%m.%d%y")
```

Multiply the first command-line argument by the current date in format `mm.ddyy`, which is actually `03.1416`.

Answer (score 9):

### Bash + bc, <s>25</s> 20 bytes

```
date +%m.%d%y\*$1|bc
```

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for saving five bytes.

Usage:

```
$ ./pi-round.sh 3
9.4248
```

Comment: That here-string notation is so long: `date +%m.%d%y\*$1|bc`

Comment: @manatwork you are correct! I was playing around with the same myself but couldn't figure out how to combine it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>46</s> <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
$args[0]*(Date -F "M.dy")
```

Pretty straightforward. Takes input `$args[0]` and multiplies it by the date [formatted as `M.dy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) (the `Get-` is implied). Note that this may take a long time to run on v2 as it iterates possible substitutions for `Date` (e.g., checking your `%PATH%` environment variable, etc.) before settling on `Get-Date`.

Comment: Can you cut the space after `-f`?

Comment: @briantist Sadly, not here. We're abusing PowerShell's pattern recognition, since the actual flag is `-Format`. With flags like this, you just need to be unambiguous (for example, if you had `-Debug` and `-Delimiter` as potential options, you would need at least three letters to differentiate). Removing the space means PowerShell tries to parse the flag `-F"M.dy"` but can't find an argument that matches, and so throws an error.

Comment: ahhh I see it now. That's what I get for reading this on a train after a long day. I was interpreting it as the `-f` operator. Makes total sense now.

Answer (score 6):

## R 3.2.4, <s>55</s> <s>51</s> 47 bytes

**edit** I realized I could use `scan` thanks @FryAmTheEggMan. Reduced 4 bytes thanks to @MickyT.

```
scan()*as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(),'%m.%d%y'))
```

First attempt at a golf. Happy pi day!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) I'm no R programmer, but you don't need to supply a named function, just an expression that evaluates to a function. So I'm pretty sure you can drop the `f=`.

Comment: You can go even further and do `scan()*as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(),'%m.%d%y'))`

Comment: `as.double` instead of `as.numeric` saves an additional byte

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

```
*Qvs[.d4\..d5>2`.d3
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*Qvs%5B.d4%5C..d5%3E2%60.d3&input=3&debug=0)
Only works at 2016-03-14 of course.

### Explanation

```
*Qvs[.d4\..d5>2`.d3   # Q = input

     .d4              # current month
        \.            # dot between month and day
          .d5         # current day of the month
             >2`.d3   # last 2 digits of the year
   s[                 # concat everything into a string
  v                   # eval -> convert to float
*Q                    # multiply with input to get the circumference
```

Answer (score 5):

## GNU Awk, 23 characters

```awk
$0*=strftime("%m.%d%y")
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ awk '$0*=strftime("%m.%d%y")' <<< 3
9.4248
```

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>45</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

Uses Windows-1252 encoding

```
<?=$argv[1]*date(~‘Ñ•†);
```

Run like this:

```
echo '<?=$argv[1]*date(~‘Ñ•†);' | php -- 3
```

- Saved 19 bytes by using `date()` instead of `DateTime::format`
- Saved a byte by using the echo tag
- Saved a byte by using ISO-8859 encoding and negating the format string, so no need for double quotes. Might mess up your terminal a bit when running it from CLI, but works.

Comment: If you assume register_globals to true, you can use `$n` via `/?n=3` in the url.

Comment: @Martijn That requires PHP 4.1 or setting it using the `php.ini` file. aross said before that wants to steer away from such method.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>41</s> 39 characters

This uses a proprietary **Firefox-only** method.

```javascript
d=>new Date().toLocaleFormat`%m.%d%y`*d
```

Thanks to:

- [Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732/ismael-miguel) for the template string suggestion (-2 characters).

Sample run (Firefox Web Console):

```
> (d=>new Date().toLocaleFormat`%m.%d%y`*d)(3)
9.4248
```

Note: this will fail in Firebug Console. Seems that Firebug performs some expansion on the template string, transforming `` `%m.%d%y` `` into `` `%__fb_scopedVars(m).d%y` `` before passing it to the code.

Comment: -2 bytes: ``d=>new Date().toLocaleFormat`%m.%d%y`*d``

Comment: Oh. [facepalm] No idea why, I usually forget that trick. Although I use the template strings regularly.

Comment: I know. I really don't get either. What I'm trying to get is a way to remove that `new` from there.

Comment: I tried it on Firefox and it worked fine. I copy-pasted from the console. Since I've replaced ``('...')`` with 2 backticks, that's 2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 58 chars

```
import time
print float(time.strftime("%m.%d%y"))*input()
```

[Try it!](http://ideone.com/fork/nDZbX3)

Explanation:

```
import time                                   # Import time time module
print                                         # Print the following
      float(                                  # Cast to float
            time.strftime("%m.%d%y"))         # Format the time as MM.DDYY
                                     *input() # Multiply by input
```

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 40 bytes

```ruby
->n{n*Time.new.strftime('%m.%d%y').to_f}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 54

```
.0001FromDigits[Now@{"Month","Day","YearShort"},100]#&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SpecBAS](https://sites.google.com/site/pauldunn/), 39 bytes

```
1 INPUT n: ?n*VAL DATE$(TIME,"mm.ddyy")
```

Nothing out of the ordinary. Formats date as a string then multiplies the input by the `VAL` (value) of that string.

Comment: Interpreter / compiler link?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/pauldunn/

Comment: I've edited the link into your answer

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy + coreutils, 19 bytes

```
'y%d%.m%+ etad',W*N
```

Explanation:

```
'y%d%.m%+ etad',W*N
'y%d%.m%+ etad'       Push 'date +%m.%d%y' to the stack.
               ,      Execute as shell.
                W     Grab input from STDIN and eval it.
                 *    Multiply the top two items
                  N   Output as a number.
```

Cannot be run in safe mode, as this uses the Runtime's exec method.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, <s>74</s> 54 bytes

using the time module instead of datetime like [Loovjo's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75519/49289)

```
import time
lambda n:n*float(time.strftime('%m.%d%y'))
```

**previous solution**

```
from datetime import*
lambda n:n*float(datetime.now().strftime('%m.%d%y'))
```

Comment: @Zenadix The [meta consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1503/31625) is that unnamed functions are OK.

Answer (score 2):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/tree/master), <s>16</s> 15 bytes, ASCII encoding

```
C867wä%J"bT4^/*
```

Explanation:

```
C867            - b,c,d = year, day, month
    wä          - a = base_96("ä") - 100
      %         - a = a%b
       J"       - a = "".join([a,c,d])
         b      - b = base(a, 10)
          T4^   - a = 10^4
             /  - a = a/b
              * - imp_print(a*eval_or_not(input))
```

or 11 bytes (non-competitive), (adds string singles, 2 digit year, string sumables)

```
C856\.R3sb*
```

Explanation:

```
C856        - a,b,c = 2d_year, day, month
    \.      - d = "."
      R3    - a,b,c = b,c,a
        s   - a = sum(a,b,c)
         b  - a = base(a, 10)
          * - imp_print(a*eval_or_not(input))
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a different Pyke than http://pyke.sourceforge.net/ ? Can you post a link to the language spec?

Comment: https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/tree/master

Comment: Just wondering, what encoding does Pyke use? If it's UTF-8, this is 16 bytes.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 It doesn't matter; in this case it uses good old ascii as all code points are below 255. According to http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5879/32686, the answer can define it's own encoding at no cost

Answer (score 2):

### Oracle 11g, <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
SELECT &n*to_char(sysdate,'MM.DDYY')FROM dual;
```

one less byte, thanks to @MickyT

Comment: you can drop the space before the `FROM`

Answer (score 2):

## [APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 19 bytes

```
⎕×0.01⊥⌽⍎2⌽8↑2↓⍕⎕TS
```

`⎕TS` is `2016 3 14 12 34 56 789` i.e. March 14<sup>rd</sup>, 2016 right before 12:35 pm
`⍕` make into string, i.e. `'2016 3 14 12 34 56 789'`
`8↑2↓` drop first two (`'20'`) then take next eight (`'16 3 14 '`)
`2⌽` rotate two characters, giving `' 3 14 16'`
`⍎` make into numbers (`3 14 16`)
`⌽` reverse the list, giving `16 14 3`
`0.01⊥` evaluate in base ¹⁄₁₀₀, = 16 × 0.01² + 15 × 0.01¹ + 3 × 0.01⁰ = 0.0016 + 0.15 + 3 = 3.1416
`⎕×` multiply with input

or

```
⎕×1E¯4⊥⌽⍎2⌽7↑2↓⍕⎕TS
```

`⎕TS` is `2016 3 14 12 34 56 789`, i.e. March 14<sup>rd</sup>, 2016 right before 12:35 pm
`⍕` make into string, i.e. `'2016 3 14 12 34 56 789'`
`7↑2↓` drop first two (`'20'`) then take next seven (`'16 3 14'`)
`2⌽` rotate two characters, giving `' 3 1416'`
`⍎` make into numbers (`3 1416`)
`⌽` reverse the list, giving `1416 3`
`1E¯4⊥` evaluate in base ¹⁄₁₀₀₀₀, = 1416 × 0.01¹ + 3 × 0.01⁰ = 0.1416 + 3 = 3.1416
`⎕×` multiply with input

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but in UTF-8 this is 38 bytes.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5878/what-character-encodings-may-a-submission-use

Comment: What encoding is APL in?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 APL uses its own code page -- each of these characters are one byte. (This was before ASCII mind you...)

Answer (score 2):

### Google Sheets, 13 bytes

Bytes are calculated with one byte per character, zero bytes per cell except for the designated input cell, two bytes. The equals sign to start a formula is not counted. (I don't know if this is standard, please correct me if I am wrong.)

Run snippet to see the code.

```css
table {
  empty-cells: show;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>&lt;input></td>
    <td style="text-align:right">3.1416</td>
    <td style="font-family:'Ubuntu Mono',monospace">=<span style="color:rgb(257,142,29)">A1</span>*<span style="color:rgb(126,55,148)">A2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works because you can define your own date formats in Google Sheets. I made it so that it is `<month>.<day><year>`.

Comment: You might want to ask on meta about this scoring system. ;P

Comment: Will do when I have time (maybe tonight in Maryland)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>68</s> 66 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to dev-null!

```
x=>x*((a=new Date).getMonth()+1+"."+a.getDate()+(a.getYear()-100))
```

Anonymous function. Some uses:

```
f(1)    == 3.1416
f(5)    == 15.708
f(f(2)) == 19.73930112
```

Comment: You should try using `with`

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl/Tk, 58 bytes

```
puts [expr {[gets stdin]*[clock f [clock se] -f %N.%d%g]}]
```

(That's a complete program. If you want to cheat and remove the explicit `puts` statement then it's only 51 bytes -- you'd have to start tclsh and type/paste the following in directly, though:)

```
expr {[gets stdin]*[clock f [clock se] -f %N.%d%g]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 17 bytes

```
Z'2$'mm.ddyy'XOU*
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WicyJCdtbS5kZHl5J1hPVSo&input=MTA)

```
Z'              % get current date and time as float 
2$'mm.ddyy'XO   % format as a string with custom format 
U               % convert to number 
*               % multiply by implicit input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 114 bytes

```
public double p(double d){
  return (d*Double.parseDouble(new SimpleDateFormat("MM.ddyy").format(new Date())));
}
```

Comment: 96 bytes: `float p(float d){return d*Float.parseFloat(new SimpleDateFormat("MM.ddyy").format(new Date()));}`

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 112 characters

```
(define d(seconds->date(current-seconds)))(*(read)(+(date-month d)(*(date-day d).01)(*(-(date-year d)2e3)1e-4)))
```

Reads the number from input in standard reader syntax.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-84 Basic, 30 bytes

*Works on TI-83/84 calculators; E is the scientific notation token and ~ is the negative token.*

```
Prompt D:getDate:D(Ans(2)+E~4Ans(1)-.2+.01Ans(3
```

**Test Case**

```
D=?3
          9.4248
```

Answer (score 1):

## R 48 bytes

```
d*as.double(format(Sys.Date(),format="%m.%d%y"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>16</s> <s>13</s> 9 bytes

```
Xround(π,1+min(getDate
```

We round `π` to a number of decimal places equal to the minimum of `{month,day,year}`, and then multiply it by the input.

This is a function that takes input through X. Store it to one of the Y-variables, for example `Y1`, and then call like `Y1([number])` on the homescreen.

Comment: There seems to be [some disagreement](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8580/42963) that taking input via `Ans` is allowed.

Comment: How is this only 13 bytes? Not counting Input A, I count 22 characters.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 TI-BASIC is token based, each atom is represented as one or two bytes.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 The code page is [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens&ved=0ahUKEwiyrc-tnMbLAhVX_mMKHc2XBQkQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNHqprejHtZx7mjSGuRCU8L8b5QHVQ&sig2=bTa5L8XAq5qVG_e67VNmRw).

Answer (score 0):

## VBScript, 88 bytes

```
D=Date
MsgBox(WScript.Arguments(0)*(Month(D)+CDbl("."+CStr(Day(D))+CStr(Year(D)-2000))))
```

I can probably save some bytes by using an input box instead. Call it like `argument_name arg`.

Comment: Doesn't VBScript implicitly convert to String?

Comment: @DDPWNAGE I don't think it does.

Answer (score 0):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse2002), 45 bytes

```
&MONTH 10000*&DOM 100*+&YEAR 2000-+0.0001*?*!
```

Sample use:

```
> &MONTH 10000*&DOM 100*+&YEAR 2000-+0.0001*?*!
5
15.708
```

Explanation:

- We're going to take the current month, day and year and turn them to a decimal.
- First, we need to add `3 * 10000`, `14 * 100` and `2016 - 2000`, to get one number we can work with.
- Next, we'll need to multiply this integer (`31416`) by `0.0001` to get `3.1416`.
- Then, we'll ask for a number as input `?`, multiply by `3.1416` and print the result.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 41 characters

```groovy
{it*(new Date().format('M.dyy')as float)}
```

Sample run:

```
groovy:000> ({it*(new Date().format('M.dyy')as float)})(3)
===> 9.424799680709839
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 40 bytes

```julia
d->(float)(strftime("%m.%d%y",time()))*d
```

Sample run:

```
julia> (d->(float)(strftime("%m.%d%y",time()))*d)(3)
9.4248
```

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 36 bytes

```jq
(now|strftime("%m.%d%y")|tonumber)*.
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq '(now|strftime("%m.%d%y")|tonumber)*.' 3
9.4248
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=(now|strftime("%25m.%25d%25y")|tonumber)*.&j=3)

Answer (score 0):

## FORTH,  64 bytes

```
: p time&date 100 mod -rot 100 * + 100 * + 4 roll * 10000 / . ;
```

The result is rounded to the nearest integer.
Usage:  `10 p` prints 31

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, <s>120</s> <s>151</s> <s>80</s> <s>84</s> 76 bytes

Holy cats, I love this language.

```
now "%m.%d" strftime now "%Y" strftime 2 tail append [ string>number ] bi@ *
```

Point-free, so expects the number on the stack:

```
(scratchpad) : roundpi ( n -- i ) now "%m.%d" strftime now "%Y" strftime 2 tail append [ string>number ] bi@ * ;
(scratchpad) 3 roundpi print
9.454800000000001
```

Translation of: [Mouse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75513/46231).