# I copied my password to the clipboard! Can you delete it?

Tags: code-golf

Following the [best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197417/why-are-plain-text-passwords-bad-and-how-do-i-convince-my-boss-that-his-treasur) [security](http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/) [practices](http://gizmodo.com/sony-kept-thousands-of-passwords-in-a-document-marked-1666772286), I keep a plain text file with my passwords on my hard drive. In fact, I just copied and pasted one of them to access my PPCG account.

In a lucid moment, I decide that the password should better not remain in the clipboard after its use. Since this happens to me often, I could use a program to remove the clipboard contents.

### Challenge

Write a [program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) that deletes or overwrites any text contained in the clipboard, using a [programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/36398) of your choice.

Additional details:

- If your system has several clipboards, you can write the program for any one of them. The only requirement is that it must be possible for the user to copy and paste text using that clipboard.
- If your clipboard keeps a history of recent copied entries, assume the most recent entry.
- If your answer is specific to an operating system or clipboard, indicate it in the title of your post, together with the used language.
- The clipboard is guaranteed to contain text when your program is run. You can either delete the contents from the clipboard, or overwrite it with something else (not necessarily text). The only requirement is that after running the program, pasting from the clipboard will not produce the original text.
- If you choose to overwrite with some fixed or randomly chosen text, you can assume that the previous clipboard contents are different from that text, so the password is effectively removed. In other words, disregard the possibility that the filler text coincides with the password.
- The program should not have any side-effects like restarting the system, closing programs, shutting down the computer, or freezing it. After your program is run, the user should be able to keep using the computer as normal, only with the password removed from the clipboard. Also, [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: What if the clipboard has an undetermined number of entries?

Comment: @LarsW Can you please ellaborate or give an example?

Comment: Well, on my computer I can access the last ~10 I copied/selected, but I can imagine that number being different on different systems. I don't know if this matters at all, so that's why I asked.

Comment: @LarsW Oh, I see. You can assume the most recent entry. Edited into the text

Comment: On a more serious note: Use something like [keepass](http://keepass.info/) to do that for you.

Comment: "Disregard the possibility that the filler text coincides with the password." Solution: ` `, 0 bytes. Overwrites the password with itself.

Comment: @Challenger5 but that's only _If you choose to overwrite with some fixed or randomly chosen text_

Comment: The very worst part about this question is that I can completely relate to the intro story despite knowing that it's satirical.  ...so, keepass, huh?  Should look into that...

Comment: @Challenger5 That wouldn't be a full Java program or function ;)

Comment: Or you could...you know...copy something else?! Erase the last thing copied??!! Ha. Ha. Ha.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Excel, 1 keystroke

<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>

Works because Excel, uniquely, always has a selection. Probably works in other spreadsheet applications too. As opposed to the other joking entries, Excel answers are actually somewhat frequent on PPCG.

Comment: Isn't this 2 keystrokes?  "A keystroke is a single press of a key on a keyboard. Each key press is a keystroke." http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/k/keystroke.htm

Comment: @Martijn Possibly. I just copied from [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111731/43319).

Comment: I'm not sure it's really valid to score by keystrokes. Also, since you say _As opposed to the other joking entries_, I interpret that as you admitting this is not an actually valid answer. So I won't accept it even if it's the shortest one. If you can point me to some relevant meta-post establishing the validity of keystrokes as scoring method, I will happily accept this submission

Comment: @LuisMendo Your in-between-lines analysis  is correct, but now that I actually took the time ro research on Meta: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4817/43319 would seem to indicate that it is acceptable, as opposed to "Windows" which isn't an editor.

Comment: @Adám My understanding it that that meta-post refers to a hypothetical "editor golf" _challenge category_, not to using the number of keystrokes as a scoring method for "code golf" challenges. I've pinged Doorknob and Dennis to know their opinion

Comment: I'm still not totally convinced that keystrokes are a valid scoring method and are comparable to bytes. But I haven't had any conclusive feedback to settle this, so I'm assuming it is valid and therefore accepting this answer

Answer (score 134):

## PowerShell, 3 bytes

```
scb
```

That's a default alias for `Set-Clipboard`. When called with nothing piped in and no arguments supplied, it blows away the current clipboard contents.

Comment: The shortest answer which actually clears the clipboard instead of setting it to a newline or something not-quite-blank.

Comment: This is very nice.

Answer (score 79):

## Vim, 3 bytes

```
"*Y
```

Sets the clipboard content to a newline.

By default, vim opens an empty buffer on start up. Now the program `Y`anks (copy) the entire line (including a newline) and store it in your clipboard by yanking it the text into register `"*`. The `*` can be changed to a `+` for the other clipboard.

Comment: Aaargh, I was just going to post this answer! +1, right tool for the job. :)

Comment: If there are more installations of vim than of powershell, this should be the accepted answer on the basis of "Universality" ;)

Comment: @JPCF and there are many more 'actual' applications written in C# than there are coffeescript etc. It doesn't make one better than the other when it comes to code-golf

Comment: I doubt there are more installations of vim than PowerShell, since it's installed by default in Windows 8 and up.

Answer (score 62):

## Javascript (Chrome DevTools Console), 6 bytes

```
copy``
```

Note that this is a feature of the console (which also works in the FF console) and is not part of the language standard.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know JS had this function. Works in Firefox too. (The contents of the clipboard become `[\n    ""\n]`)

Comment: Can confirm this as well on Chrome. The clipboard changes to: `[\n
  ""\n
]`

Comment: @ETHproductions Actually, this function doesn't _really_ exist in JS. This is a console built-in. (Which doesn't invalidate the answer. But maybe it should be explained more explicitly.)

Comment: Well doesn't it exist through `Document.execCommand("copy")` or is that an internal-to-browser clipboard? I use that in some tamper monkey scripts, but too lazy to check it

Comment: Okay... this is now my new most upvoted answer

Comment: This copies `[
  ""
]` to my clipboard

Answer (score 59):

### AppleScript, 20 bytes

```
set the clipboard to
```

Sets the clipboard to... nothing.

---

I saved a lot of bytes by removing the code to send me the contents of the clipboard ;)

Answer (score 33):

## Batch (Windows 7 and higher version), 7 bytes

```
fc|clip
```

Note: it will response error message like "FC:..." but it works.

"clip" is a command to copy the output of another program to clipboard (available since windows 7)

"fc" is a command to compare two or more files. in this case we not input any file. it will error, then "clip" will set clipboard to an empty string.

provided that you have a file "a" in your current directory (it can be empty), you can do one better:

```
clip<a
```

---

Edit: See @Matthew Steeples comment for the shorter version (but in powershell not a batch)

Comment: You could use `sc` instead of `fc` to avoid the error message. Then, the `sc` help text would be set on the clipboard. Also, +1 for telling me about `clip`.

Comment: My one used `cd`. :-)

Comment: I guessing clip won't pick up the output of a non-command? So you couldn't just run `x|clip`?

Comment: @djsmiley2k Yes, it will pick up only the output from a valid command.

Comment: The reason why `sc` and `cd` output is passed to the clipboard but `fc` won't is because `sc` and `cd` write its output to `stdout` but `fc` write its output to `stderr` (`clip` pick up an input from `stdout` but `fc` does not write anything to `stdout`)

Comment: You can knock another character off this. `h` is an alias (by default) for `get-history`, so you can do `h|clip`

Comment: Try to post 1 language per answer, so you should probably delete either the batch or powershell code.

Comment: @Riker just edited, thank for a suggestion

Comment: @Divcy feel free to post it as a separate answer!

Comment: @CPoll for later reference: Please don't make edits that add new code. Feel free to comment, but don't make edits.

Comment: @Divcy I saw that you approved the edit, please don't do that in the future (even though it's your post).  If you look, DJ rejected it also.

Answer (score 32):

## Bash on macOS, 8 bytes

```
:|pbcopy
```

`:` could be replaced with almost any other single character.

Comment: `:|pbcopy` works in bash as well as zsh.

Comment: Anyone else think `:|p` looks like a tongue-sticking-out emoticon with a mustache?

Answer (score 29):

### C (on Windows), <s>65</s> <s>62</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```c
main(){EmptyClipboard(OpenClipboard(0));}
```

Note that the Visual C++ command-line needs `/link user32.lib` but the IDE or other compilers may automatically include this. Also this won't work in Win16 because the calling convention is incorrect.

Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Orion. Saved 20 bytes thanks to @KrzysztofSzewczyk. Saved a further byte thanks to @ceilingcat.

Comment: Since it's C, can't you use `0` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: Can you stick the `OpenClipboard(0)` inside the parens after `EmptyClipboard`?

Answer (score 26):

### [AHK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey), 10 bytes `(Windows)`

```
clipboard=
```

Clears text content of the clipboard. If `clipboardAll` is used it clears everything.

From the *[docs](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm#Clipboard_and_ClipboardAll)* -

> Clipboard is a built-in variable that reflects the current contents of the Windows clipboard if those contents can be expressed as text. By contrast, ClipboardAll contains everything on the clipboard, such as pictures and formatting.

Answer (score 23):

## Java 8, <strike>127</strike> 125 bytes

Golfed:

```java
()->java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(""),null)
```

Ungolfed:

```java
public class ICopiedMyPasswordToTheClipboardCanYouDeleteIt {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(() -> java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(
      new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(""), null));
  }

  private static void f(Runnable x) {
    x.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you use an empty string instead of null? Saves 2 bytes

Comment: @Poke yes, that works. I was focusing on "deleting" the contents of the clipboard, as in truly clearing them out. Turns out overwriting is fine too.

Answer (score 19):

### Excel VBA, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
[A1].Cut
```

Overwrites the clipboard with contents of `A1` cell in active worksheet (empty by default but may be any string/expression of your choice - just make sure it's not your password!).

Utilises the Immediate Window.

*One byte saved thanks to [Slai](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59149/slai)*

Comment: Nice! You can save a byte with `[a1].Cut`

Answer (score 19):

## SmileBASIC 3, 10 bytes

Finally, a challenge practically *made* for SmileBASIC 3!

```
CLIPBOARD"
```

`CLIPBOARD` is a builtin that sets the environment's text clipboard to the given string. Here we give it an empty string (closing `"` isn't needed!)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, since that looks like two `'`!

Answer (score 17):

## Google Chrome Language, 2 keystrokes

<kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>

Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111573/61904) Notepad++ answer.

Google Chrome supports Javascript (which in turn supports RegExp), so I hereby claim it to be a superset of Javascript and a language of its own.

How it works:

`Ctrl+S` will invoke the "Save Page" dialog with the "New Tab" text pre-selected, `Ctrl+C` will copy it into the clipboard, displacing the previous content.

Sidenote:

> You can access the Javascript functionality in Chrome, via `javascript:` URLs and the Developer Tools console (invoked with Ctrl+Shift+J)

Comment: Gah, I wanted to use Google Chrome, but I didn't realize that I could argue it as a superset of JS... well played.

Comment: Then I guess pressing the Print Screen button (1 keystroke) is a solution in Windows Language, which is a superset of Google Chrome Lang.

Comment: @MemetOlsen Yep, exactly, feel free to post it. We already have "Notepad++ Language" and "Google Chrome Language", so  "Windows Language" seem like the next logical step to take ! :)

Comment: @MemetOlsen it isn't quite a superset of Google Chrome Lang, since Chrome is an external "library" you have to download. It *is* a superset of IE lang, which *is* a superset of JS.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added my suggestion as my first answer on this SE site.

Answer (score 16):

## **Python <strike>56</strike> <strike>48</strike>  40 bytes (Only works on Linux)**.

8 bytes saved thanks to @wheatwizard.

```
import os as o
o.system("echo|xclip")
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I notice a few golfs you can do.  instead of importing `system` from `os` you can `import os as o` and call `o.system` instead.  You also don't need the spaces around your pipe in the bash command.

Comment: Sidenote, to make this work on OSX you can use `pbcopy` instead of `xclip`

Comment: `print("")` is also the same as `print()`

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks, edited.

Comment: You can add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line to make it code formatting.  I also think you don't need the space after the `echo` (works on my system without it).

Comment: It's 6 bytes shorter without the `as o` part... (`import os \n os.system("echo |xclip"`)

Comment: You can also replace `echo ` with `:` for `":|xclip"`

Comment: Or just one line at 37 bytes: `__import__('os').system("echo|xclip")`

Comment: FYI, this only works for the middle-click paste, not Ctrl-V. (I don't think that's disallowed though)

Comment: @Dopapp Still not as short as Riker's suggestion.

Comment: There's also an alternative to `xclip` called `xsel` on Linux systems, which would save you another byte - and as already mentioned, remove the "as o" import part again, it just makes things longer: `import os;os.system(":|xsel")` (29 bytes).

Comment: @Riker, Of course, you could also use `:|xclip` -- foregoing Python altogether

Comment: @jpaugh that's already been done multiple times though...

Comment: Don't edit other people's code. If you have any suggestions leave them in the comments.

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
CopyToClipboard@0
```

Sets clipboard to the number 0.

Answer (score 11):

### bash + xsel <s>8</s> 7bytes

```
xsel -c
```

### Explanation

<s>`-b`: Works on clipboard selection</s>

`-c`: clears the selection

Comment: +1, but this is not coreutils

Comment: @pacholik Yea you need to install the package, since I operated it on the terminal, I mentioned it as coreutils.

Comment: On Debian, xsel is in the xsel package, not part of coreutils.

Comment: Since we're allowed to use any clipboard we want to, I think you can drop the `b`.

Comment: @Digital Trauma Fair enough

Answer (score 10):

## R (Windows) 18

```
writeClipboard("")
```

Comment: Do you know of a Linux equivalent?

Comment: I think something like `readLines(file("clipboard", "r"))` *might* work. Try looking in the R help docs under "Functions to Manipulate Connections".

Answer (score 8):

## Bash, <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @seshoumara for using `ls` instead of `echo`*

*Thanks to hexafraction, isaacg and Riker for suggesting several 7-byters*

```bash
w|xclip
```

The clipboard is set to the result of `w`. This only works on X11 based systems. For example, on macOS, this clipboard can be accessed by using an X based application like XQuartz.

---

Old answer only for macOS (<s>11</s> 9 bytes):

```bash
ls|pbcopy
```

This sets the clipboard content to a newline.

Comment: How about `ls|xclip`?

Comment: @seshoumara Thanks! (and to think that I `ls /usr/bin | grep "^.\{1,3\}$"`'d to search for a shorter command :P)

Comment: Or `w|xclip` for one less. Dumps list of logged-in users to the clipboard.

Comment: Or `:|xclip`. Actually clears the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I used `w|xclip` since it was the only one that worked on macOS

Comment: Why would `:` not work? It's a Bash built-in.

Comment: @Dennis For some reason, it doesn't change the clipboard content for me

Comment: Huh, works on my machine. And since submissions may expect empty input, so would a bare `xclip` without any pipes.

Answer (score 8):

## Matlab, <s>19</s> 13 bytes

```
gcf;print -dm
```

Set clipboard contents to an empty figure.

Comment: It's 21 UTF-8 bytes

Comment: @LuisMendo This is longer (23): `axes;print -dmeta;close` but also works...

Comment: @EBH That `close` can arguably be removed. By "side effects" I was thinking of things disappearing, not appearing. Also, `print(gcf,'-dm')` works

Comment: @LuisMendo Well, I didn't know that `-dm` is like `-dmeta`, and thought the program should work 'silently', without popping any window :)

Comment: @EBH Feel free to edit your code with the suggestions if you want. That's usual in PPCG. I just realized this is your first answer on this site :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo indeed, it is my first. Now the suggestion is even shorter.

Answer (score 8):

## Applescript, 23 bytes

```
set the clipboard to ""
```

Comment: Ohhh Thanks @DigitalTrauma

Comment: You could remove the quotation marks entirely, but [It had been done already](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111411/64218)

Answer (score 8):

## Notepad++, 3 Keystrokes

<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>

Inserts the letter a, selects it, copies it to the keyboard.

Notepad++ *is* a valid language, it supports regex and is therefore a superset of regex, and we consider regex to be a valid language.

Comment: `consider regex to be a valid language` References ? Apparently RegExp is not Turing complete by itself.

Comment: @zeppelin It doesn't have to be Turing Complete to be a valid language.

Comment: `It doesn't have to be Turing Complete to be a valid language` By that measure, we can claim almost anything to be a "language". 

I.e. XML or HTML do have a syntax too (and even call themselves languages, unlike RegExp), nevertheless I don't think they are acceptable.

Can you provide an example of a pure-Regexp answer, which has been upvoted by the community ?

Moreover I believe Notepad++, does not really "support regexp" in sense that it can invoke it programmatically, and opening the UI "Search and Replace" box to type a RegExp there, is not a "program code" by any measure.

Comment: @zeppelin http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4817/60042 <-- relevant meta post. Keep in mind you can access search-and-replace in N++ with `<c-H>`, and use `<tab>` to navigate through the UI and interact with all the relevant fields. Also note that regex can determine primality of and add numbers. (Both in unary, which is the default numeric representation for regex)

Comment: the meta-post in question refers to the Vim and Emacs class editors, which are extremely programmable, not Notepad. 

And yes, I've seen people use RegExp for primality testing on this site, but that's just a funny corner-case and not a real proof of RegExp being a language. So please provide a reference to any upvoted "pure-Regexp" answer, to prove your point.

Comment: But, even if you think RegExp is a valid language, that does not make Notepad++ a language too, just because you can `you can access search-and-replace in N++ with <c-H>, and use <tab> to navigate through the UI and interact with all the relevant fields`, as that's just an isolated piece of functionality, requiring the UI interaction to launch it.

This way I can claim my IDE desktop shortcut to be a "a desktop shortcut language", just because I can launch my IDE by clicking on it.

Comment: just to illustrate my point, if I were to post an answer: `Windows 7, 10 keystrokes: Win+R, type "echo.|clip", <CR>` would you upvote it ? (and yes, Windows does support regexp and has a built-in shell and lot's of other things, but does it make it a "Windows-7-language" ?).

Comment: @zeppelin I would not, because that yields "Windows cannot find 'echo.|clip'". But in the general case, I wouldn't upvote it, because you're just executing shell commands so it would be a lot shorter if you said your language was batch. But it *would* be valid.

Comment: ok I think I can see your logic, and I've just beaten you by 1 keystroke with the [Google Chrome Language !] (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111731/61904)

Comment: I do this everyday in my real life...

Answer (score 7):

## Python + tkinter, 43 bytes

Python 3:

```
from tkinter import*;Tk().clipboard_clear()
```

Python 2:

```
from Tkinter import*;Tk().clipboard_clear()
```

Comment: is tkinter included in the python distro?

Comment: @Cruncher It is in my Python 3.

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, it's part of the stdlib, even though I believe debian packages it in a separate package (`python-tk`) from the "core python".

Comment: Take a look at [Dopapp's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111380#comment-271385) for an even shorter way.

Comment: @jpaugh If you are referring to changing the import style to `__import__("tkinter")....`, this is 1 byte longer in this case.

Comment: Ok. Missed that, sorry!

Comment: you could save 2 bytes by removing `()` and having an [unnamed function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7614/what-are-our-rules-about-additional-code-accompanying-function-submissions/7615#7615)

Answer (score 7):

## C#, 30 bytes

*Thanks to [Nat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45619/nat), [JMD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66095/jmd) and [BgrWorker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61283/bgrworker) for their suggestions!*

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.Clear
```

## C# without WPF, 36 bytes

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.Clear
```

Built-in function which empties the clipboard.

Full program with test case:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ClearClipboard
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action f =
        ()=>System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.Clear();

        // test case:
        Clipboard.SetText("SomePassword!");
        Console.WriteLine("In clipboard initially: " + Clipboard.GetText());
        f();
        Console.WriteLine("In clipboard now: " + Clipboard.GetText());
    }
}
```

Comment: [System.Windows.Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also, `Clipboard.Clear()` is already a function, so the lambda can be dropped.

Comment: I won't bother adding an answer for LINQPad since this answer would just run in it.
`System.Windows.Clipboard.Clear();`
But, lprun might be a more lightweight way to run this answer than VS or even VS Code.

Comment: @Nat When omitting `.Forms`, it didn't compile on Linux and I don't have a Windows machine at the moment.

Comment: @adrianmp that class is only contained in PresentationCore.dll, a reference added by default on WPF type projects. I have no idea if that dll is included in Mono/.NET Core

Comment: @BgrWorker That explains things. It's not available in my Linux install.

Answer (score 7):

## **Python 33 bytes (Only works on Windows)**.

4 bytes saved from @hubacub version.

3 bytes switching to windows, using @Divcy solution

```
import os
os.system("fc|clip")
```

Just registered in stackexchange, so I don't have the reputation to just comment on @hubacub submition. There is no need to expend 5 bytes with " as o" in the import to save 1 byte to reduce "os.system" to "o.system".

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```
import System.Hclip
setClipboard""
```

Just a boring library function. There's also `clearClipboard` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 6):

### [J](http://www.jsoftware.com) (Windows), 12 bytes

```
wd'clipcopy'
```

`wd` is J's standard library for Windows. `wd 'clipcopy password'` would put the text `password` into the clipboard. Specifying nothing wipes the clipboard.

If you want a program to put your plaintext password into your clipboard, you could use the following:

```
pass =. 'abc123'
wd 'clipcopy ' , pass
```

Comment: This isn't a function or fill program, but rather a snippet. You'd need to make it a verb in order for it to be valid. you could do something like `'clipcopy 'wd@,]`

Comment: Which "this" are you referring to? Both chunks of code are executable .ijs files.

Comment: I might have simply misunderstood. Sorry 'bout that haha. Anyhow, you can remove the space in between `wd` and `'clipcopy'`.

Comment: Thanks! Shaved off a byte. I'm just so used to spaces to help me read J that I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 5):

## HTML + JavaScript, <s>175</s> <s>148</s> <s>139</s> <s>135</s> 69 Bytes

Golfed:

```
<input value="c"onclick="this.select();document.execCommand('copy')">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0sk97ch/)

Ungolfed

Got help from [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-copy-to-clipboard/)

HTML:

```
<input style="display: none;" id="Empty" value="x">
<input id="clipclear" type="button" value="Clear The Clipboard">
```

JS:

```
function clearclip(){
empty=document.getElementById("Empty");
empty.style.display="block";
empty.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
empty.style.display="none";
}      
document.getElementById("clipclear").addEventListener("click", clearclip, false);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kgvwjj3k/

Comment: Tested in FF and Chrome

Comment: Don't post it until you golf it. For now, you can delete your answer, edit it to golf it, and then un-delete your answer.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere, Okay, I went ahead and golfed it. Here's the new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgvwjj3k/2/).

Comment: As my edit history shows, I'm not practiced at golfing. I originally forgot simple things like removing as much white space as possible.

Comment: Instead of commenting, please edit the fiddle into your answer. Also, great job on golfing. I gave you a +1. (FYI, the language is technically HTML + JavaScript.)

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I know, but it's JS that's doing the work.

Comment: Why can't clipboard be erased using js without user event such as clicking a button? Then one could copy something to clipboard and set a timer to wipe it.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8 (JavaFX), 61 bytes

`()->javafx.scene.input.Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().clear()`

The JavaFX API for manipulating the clipboard is a little more terse than AWT's ;)

Answer (score 5):

## Tcl/Tk wish shell (REPL), 5 bytes

```
cli c
```

Wish shell (REPL) allows for the incomplete commands, as long as there is no ambiguity, the full command would be:

```
clipboard clear
```

Answer (score 5):

## Cow, 9 bytes

```
OOOMMMOOO
```

Explanation:

```
OOO set current memory block to 0
MMM if the current memory block is 0, paste the clipboard and clear the clipboard.
OOO set it back to 0
```

Comment: This doesn't work: all it does is copy `0` to COW's internal register, which has nothing to do with the clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP + [PHP GTK 2.0](http://gtk.php.net/index.php?language=en-US), 24 bytes

This assumes you already have the PHP GTK extension loaded.

```
<?GtkClipboard::clear();
```

Documentation reference: http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/html/gtk/gtk.gtkclipboard.method.clear.html

Comment: You don't need the opening `<?` tag since you can run the code without the `<?` tag in the command line with the `-r` switch. See more info here: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/is-the-php-opening-tag-mandatory-in-byte-count

Comment: @KodosJohnson I intentionally left the opening tag there.

Comment: @KodosJohnson He would still have to add the bytes in the flags.

Comment: @ckjbgames No I wouldn't. The flag is free. I didn't change the code because I intentionally left the opening tags.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I have seen people add the interpreter/compiler flags to the byte count.

Comment: @ckjbgames They must be adding other flags. Quoting the accepted answer: `running programs via commands such as php -r "code here" is acceptable without penalty.`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Which accepted answer are you quoting? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @KodosJohnson http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7146/ <-- this answer.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks, I was starting to be concerned that I should go back and add penalties to all my old answers.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 11 bytes (Windows)

```
`echo|clip`
```

Runs the windows `clip` command to replace clipboard contents with "ECHO is on."

Answer (score 4):

**Julia - 13 bytes**

```
clipboard("")
```

Comment: Hardly needing any explanation :-)

Answer (score 3):

### VB.NET, 29 bytes

```
Sub F
Clipboard.Clear
End Sub
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @hvd*

Comment: Can you drop `()`?

Comment: Why? https://dotnetfiddle.net/nZNS1E

Comment: Edit file outside of VS. You can also compile it from command line, but I think VS will compile it unchanged if it was saved from the other program.

Comment: Error: comment chain does not make sense. Please insert information about deleted comment >>

Comment: Parens are optional in vb.net when calling a function if there are no params.

Comment: For further golfing, you can drop `()`. :) They're equally optional in a sub or function definition.

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, 117 bytes

```clj
#(.setContents(.getSystemClipboard(java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit))(java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection."")nil)
```

Basically the Java answer. Gets the system clipboard, and sets it to an empty string.

AWT lets you do so many random things. It's so verbose though!

Unfortunately, trying to put an import in there adds about 30 bytes, so I need to fully qualify everything.

```clj
(defn clear-clipboard []
  (.setContents
      (.getSystemClipboard
        (java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit))
      (java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection. "")
      nil))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/) on Windows, <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```apl
⎕A⎕WC'Clipboard'('Text'⎕A)
```

`⎕A` using the name "ABC...Z",

`⎕WC` **W**indow **C**reate a

`'Clipboard'` object with the

`('Text'⎕A)` "ABC...Z"

---

Alternative of same length, but empties the clipboard and doesn't leave behind a global clipboard object:

```apl
(⎕NEW⊂'Clipboard').Text←''
```

`⎕NEW⊂'Clipboard'` create a **NEW** clipboard object

`(`…`).Text←''` and set its `Text` property to the empty string

Answer (score 3):

## Racket, 61 bytes

Clears the secondary X11 clipboard, or the usual clipboard on other systems.

```rkt
#lang racket/gui
(send the-clipboard set-clipboard-string""0)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Linux shell (text console), 10 (or 6) bytes

```
gpm -k;gpm
```

`gpm(8)` is the daemon providing mouse control for the Linux text terminal (not X11). `gpm -k` tells the daemon to shut down, no further pasting will be possible.

It could be shortened to just

```
gpm -k
```

which shutdowns the daemon but does not restart it - but it cold be argued that this goes against the "user should be able to keep using the computer as normal" requirement.

Comment: Yeah I would say it does. It is just supposed to clear it

Answer (score 3):

### Cygwin (bash), 10 bytes

```
w>/dev/cl*
```

In Linux everything is a file. Except the clipboard. That is part of a program. How impure! Thankfully when Windows became enlightened with true ttys and bash, it was not hindered by the ancient blotch X. On Windows you can use the clipboard as file, the way it was meant to be used. (Ignore that this is worse for golfing).

Needs the procps-np package for `w`. In other mintty terminals (git bash), `ls` could be used.

Comment: Assuming `/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32` is on your `$PATH`, `cd|clip` also works.

Answer (score 3):

## Red, 19 bytes

```
write-clipboard ""
```

writes a null string to the system clipboard

Answer (score 3):

## Rust (Windows), 128 bytes

```rust
#[link(name="user32")]extern"C"{fn OpenClipboard(h:u8);fn EmptyClipboard();}fn main(){unsafe{OpenClipboard(0);EmptyClipboard()}}
```

Calls some Windows API functions improperly, doesn't even close the clipboard afterwards:

```rust
#[link(name = "user32")]
extern "C" {
    fn OpenClipboard(h: u8);
    fn EmptyClipboard();
}
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        OpenClipboard(0);
        EmptyClipboard();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## AutoIt, 11 bytes

```
ClipPut("")
```

Fills the clipboard with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 25 bytes (MacOS)

```
IO.popen("pbcopy","w"){}
```

Launches the MacOS/OS X pbcopy as a subprocess and clears the clipboard.

Comment: This can be golfed down to 11 bytes: \`:|pbcopy\`

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl, 15 bytes.

Not the shortest but the most readable:

```
clipboard clear
```

> note: must be executed with wish instead of tclsh

Comment: I think you should remove the note and change title to **Tcl/Tk**

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 56 Bytes

```
javafx.scene.input.Clipboard.getSystemClipboard()::clear
```

It can be used with an functional interface (for example java.lang.Runnable) just like

```
()->javafx.scene.input.Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().clear()
```

which was accepted as a function on page 1.

Full example:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Runnable test1 = () -> javafx.scene.input.Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().clear();
        Runnable test2 = javafx.scene.input.Clipboard.getSystemClipboard()::clear;

        // both are valid Runnable Objects on which you can call the run()-Method to clear the clipboard
        test1.run();
        test2.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org) 29 bytes

`InteractiveUtils.clipboard(9)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `Win32::Clipboard`, 41 bytes

```perl
$CLIP=Win32::Clipboard();
$CLIP->Empty();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqhCemWdsZGXlnJNZkJSfWJRi/V/F2cczwBZdXEPTmgsso2vnmltQUgnk//8PAA)

Comment: Why do you have to put it into a variable?

Comment: @xigoi I'm not actually sure why I did that. I'm not very well versed with Perl, and I don't have a windows machine to try it on right now.

Answer (score 2):

## Windows 10, 2 keystrokes

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Based on the [excel answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111884/94032), the [Google Chrome answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111731/94032), and the [Notepad++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111573/94032).

Opens Windows Clipboard (this must be enabled in settings) and deletes the current entry.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 139 bytes

```
enum c{;static{java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(""),null);}}
```

No one said that the program can't crash at the end.

Ungolfed version:

```
enum c {;
    static {
        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(""), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, exiting with an error is [allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4780/36398)

Answer (score 1):

## MFC, <s>54</s> 51

```
OpenClipboard(0);EmptyClipboard();CloseClipboard();
```

Perhaps the first MFC submission ever!

---

If inside a method of a `CWnd` derived class I can use `CWnd::OpenClipboard()` which implementation is

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CWnd::OpenClipboard()
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return ::OpenClipboard(m_hWnd); }
```

and I don't have to supply a parameter to `OpenClipboard`. Then it becomes:

## MFC, 50

```
OpenClipboard();EmptyClipboard();CloseClipboard();
```

Answer (score 1):

### AutoIt, 11 bytes

```
ClipPut("")
```

Pretty simple.

### 10 bytes

```
ClipPut(0)
```

Could save 1 byte by setting clipboard to "0"

Answer (score 1):

## HTML <s>50</s> 45 bytes

```html
<x onclick=navigator.clipboard.writeText`x`>x
```

Click on the rendered letter `x` to copy `x` to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 38 bytes

```
""clipboard get set-clipboard-contents
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), 12 bytes

```
A_Clipboard=
```

AutoHotkey allows direct reading and writing to the clibpoard via the `A_Clipboard` global, and allows writing an empty string to a variable with just `=`.