# Application screen shot

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Write the minimal code you need to take a screenshot of your application window. I am not asking for a function or program; just only a code segment.

It has obviously to be a GUI application; console applications not allowed.

**Input:**

None.

**Output:**

The valid outputs are:

- Clipboard. Then post a screenshot of the Paste contents on a drawing program.
- A file. Upload it somewhere and post a link to it here.
- Inside any other window different from the window that was shoot. Post screenshot of the new window here.

As it is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) minimum number of characters wins!

Comment: Sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12564/29325

Comment: Sounds like a VB program

Comment: The odd part about this is what defines "my application window."  Do I have to create a GUI and then screenshot it?  Does my language have to be run in a GUI eg Matlab's GUI?  GUIs don't generally exist for the code on this site, with the notable exception of that guy who uses Operation Flashpoint scripting.

Comment: "It has obviously to be a GUI application; console applications not allowed." - may we not copy the console's GUI window itself?

Comment: I feel like this is a dupe...

Comment: @programmer5000: Me too ...

Comment: @programmer5000: a dupe of what?

Comment: @Shaggy: a dupe of what?

Comment: ? A previous challenge, obviously!

Comment: does `your application window` include the border (e.g. the close/minimize/maximize buttons) or can it be only the contents of the widow?

Comment: @dzaima: It should include the client an non-client area, otherwise is not a screenshot of the window, but of the client area.

Comment: @Shaggy: feels like the dupe of the of sandbox matching post? :S

Comment: @dzaima: unless your application window has no non-client area and when you create it, be default the creation is without the surrounding border.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: fixed input description.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: How do you get a screenshot from a console application?

Comment: The console may be inside some window (it would be on Windows or Mac at least) and you ask only for a snippet - I don't know how, but I also don't see why it would not be possible.

Comment: @DirtyDev : It seems not be a valid reason. The are lots of [tag:graphical-output] challenges which many languages do not support, and frankly, who cares?

Comment: @JonathanAllan: If you mean something like https://cn.pling.com/img//hive/content-pre1/70575-1.png , having the surrounding frame, it is acceptable . If you mean something like https://cdn.pcsteps.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Basic-Linux-Commands-for-Linux-Terminal-Beginners-01.png it is not acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I mean the former (with frame) as I believed was implied by "your application window" - although you may want to add that detail (that including the frame is a requirement) to the post for clarity's sake.

Comment: @programmer5000 [This deleted post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128026/program-that-takes-screenshot/128032) might be the dupe you're thinking of

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>82</s> <s>80</s> 77 bytes

Class that extends `Frame`:

```
ImageIO.write(new Robot().createScreenCapture(bounds()),"png",new File("a"));
```

Regular Class **98 Bytes**:

```
ImageIO.write(new Robot().createScreenCapture(Frame.getFrames()[0].bounds()),"png",new File("a"));
```

Uses deprecated `bounds()` method.

[image]

Comment: seems to me that `f` is not valid and should be something like 
(`this->`) `GetParentWindow()` Java equivalent?

Comment: @sergiol ok I'll do that

Comment: You'll need to fully qualify `ImageIO`, `Robot`, and `File`, or include import statements.

Comment: @sergiol Do I need imports or full names even though it's a snippet?

Comment: @geokavel: no. But you should post also a version of it, without deriving from Frame.

Comment: @sergiol If it does not need to create references then couldn't the code just be `x();` where `x` has been defined to do all the work?!

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Of course, no. The geokavel's code is nice.

Comment: @geokavel: My answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122000/29325 has two versions: one inside a `CWnd` derived class, and another on a global/elsewhere scope

Comment: @JonathanAllan deleted my comment, as I didn't read thoroughly... apologies.