# Shortest Sorted Hello World

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, printable-ascii, hello-world

Write a program that takes no input and prints `Hello, World!` to stdout or your language's closest alternative. The catch is that each line in your program must only contain [printable ASCII characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) and it must be in lexicographical order, a.k.a. sorted.

Here are all 95 printable ASCII characters in order:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

So, for example, the line `!!A0~` would be invalid because the `A` and `0` are out of order. The line `!!0A~` would be valid.

Each line in your program may be any length and there may be any number of lines. Empty lines are considered sorted. Each of the newlines in your program must be the same (no mixing `\n` and `\r\n`). Tabs and other non-printable ASCII characters are forbidden.

**Due to [popular demand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48207/shortest-sorted-hello-world/48211#comment113279_48207), the win condition has been switched around:**
The submission with the fewest *lines* wins. Tiebreaker goes to the shortest program (newlines count as single characters).

Only `Hello, World!` and an optional trailing newline should be output. Note that [HQ9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9+) is invalid since it outputs `hello, world`. I may forbid languages similar to HQ9+ that have one character "Hello, World!" commands due to their triviality.

Hint:

> This is definitely possible in [Unary](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) and [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), though not very concisely.

Comment: It's a bit late now, but somehow I feel like least lines *then* fewest bytes might have been more interesting...

Comment: @Sp3000 We'd need a combined measure, or else Unary and Lenguage would mean that only 1-liners could compete.

Comment: @Sp3000 Maybe, I just wanted to make sure Unary/Lenguage weren't likely to win. I'm open to changing it though (sorry isaacg). Upvote Sp's comment if you agree.

Comment: @Sp3000 I've taken your advice. See updates.

Comment: Can the order be inversed? For example, reading from left-to-right?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies That made things dificult for me, but I managed it!

Comment: Can you please define "or your language's closest alternative"? Does this mean if a language has a specific and different string it generally prints to show its functionality, we can do that instead?

Comment: @mbomb007 The alternative is in place of stdout, not `Hello, World!`. Some languages don't really have a standard output stream (e.g. for Javascript I'd accept `alert` or `console.log`).

Comment: Neither of those are sorted though.

Comment: @mbomb007 I know, I was just giving a general example of an stdout alternative.

Comment: This can be used for testing if your code lines are truly correctly sorted: http://ideone.com/knuIEL

Comment: Trust me, Unary isn't going to win, because of Headsecks.

Comment: Why are "Hello World!" questions so popular, when many more important questions are unsolved

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Headsecks](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Headsecks), 1 line, 366 bytes

````
                                                                        $(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((,000000044888<AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADIIIIIIIIIIIILPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\```diiiiiilqqqqqqqqtyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy|
````

Headsecks is a trivial Brainfuck substitution where the only thing that matters is the code point modulo 8. The equivalent Brainfuck is merely

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++..+++.-------------------------------------------------------------------.------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++.------.--------.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
```

Luckily this naive approach *just* fits. There's some potential for golfing down bytes, but it might be hard.

Tested using [this Python interpreter](https://github.com/TieSoul/Multilang).

---

### Generating code

```py
code = "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++..+++.-------------------------------------------------------------------.------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++.------.--------.-------------------------------------------------------------------."
command_map = "+-<>.,[]"

last_point = 32
out = []

for char in code:
    curr_mod = command_map.index(char)
    last_mod = last_point % 8
    
    if curr_mod > last_mod:
        last_point += curr_mod - last_mod

    elif curr_mod < last_mod:
        last_point += (8 - last_mod) + curr_mod

    out.append(chr(last_point))

print("".join(out))
```

Comment: That was clever! +1

Comment: Could you use a shorter BF program, or is the program built a specific way for a reason? I tried my the BF program I used in your generator, but the output included some unicode.

Comment: @mbomb007 The problem with shorter BF programs is that even this naive method ends at code point 124, so I don't think there's enough wiggle room to introduce new chars...

Answer (score 30):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 7 lines, 22 bytes

```
/
//Hello
,
 Wor
l
d
!
```

A rare chance for /// to be competitive (well as long as no one starts with Unary and Lenguage...).

The code first encounters a `/`, and parses the

```
/
//
```

as a substitution instruction which removes all newlines from the remainder of the program. Afterwards, the program merely reads

```
Hello, World!
```

which is printed verbatim as it doesn't contain any further slashes.

Comment: I didn't even realize that URLs could contain that many slashes in a row.

Comment: @AlexA. It took months to get that URL working, IIRC. We had to keep renaming the article to deal with changes to the server configuration and MediaWiki configuration.

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript (<del>67</del> <del>66</del> 62 lines, <del>227</del> 269 bytes)

(Note: only tested on Firefox 36 and Safari 8, contains minor ES6 features (the `Set` class))

```javascript
Z
=
!""+
(0[[]]
+
(
!!""+Set
));c
=Z[~
-22]
$=Z[
3]
$$=Z[
15]
$$$=Z[
24]
$$$$=Z[
1]
$$$$$=Z[
0]
Set
[c
+
$$$+Z[
5]
+Z[
16]
+
$$$$$+
$$$$+Z[
2]
+c
+
$$$$$+
$$$+
$$$$]
(Z[
14]
+
$$+
$+
$$$$+
$$$$$+
"(\
'H\
"+
$+
$$+
$$+
$$$+
",\
 W\
"+
$$$+
$$$$+
$$+Z[
6]
+
"\
!')\
")
()
```

---

The code above basically does:

```
alert("Hello, World!")
```

Obviously `alert` is not sorted. So instead we need to generate the statement as a string, and "eval" it:

```
s = "alert('Hello, World!')";   // generate this using sorted code
eval(s)
```

How to generate the string? ES5 supports line continuation so that

```
"AL\
ERT" === "ALERT"
```

But the character code `\` appears *before* all lowercase letters, so we have to generate the lowercase letters using other methods.

We borrow some idea of [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) here. The lowercase letters involved in the alert statements are:

```
t e r a o l d
```

all of these can be extracted from characters of standard objects, which may be expressed in terms of some sorted sequence:

```
t, e, r ← true      = !""
a, l    ← false     = !!""
o       ← function  = Set
d       ← undefined = 0[[]]
```

How do we evaluate the string? Surely we cannot use `eval(s)` as it is not sorted. Alternatively we could use `Function(s)()`, but we cannot use `Function` as it is not sorted either. However, `Function` is the constructor of all functions, which means `Set.constructor === Function`.

Adding the identifier `constructor` makes the list of lowercase letters become:

```
t e r a o l d c u n s
```

which fortunately could still be generated by `"truefalseundefinedfunction"`:

```
t, e, r, u ← true      = !""
a, l, s    ← false     = !!""
o, c, n    ← function  = Set
d          ← undefined = 0[[]]
```

---

After prettifying, the code above should read like:

```javascript
// lines 1~8 defines our string containing all lowercase letters we want
Z = true + (undefined + (false + Set))
// Z = "trueundefinedfalsefunction Set() { [native code] }"

// lines 8~20 defines the variables `c`, `$` (e), `$$` (l), `$$$` (o), 
// `$$$$` (r), `$$$$$` (t)
// for the corresponding lowercase letters extracted from `Z`

// the rest calls:
Set["constructor"]("alert('Hello, World')")()
// lines 22~36 generates the "constructor" string
// lines 37~61 generates the "alert('Hello, World')" string
```

---

Update: Renamed `E`, `L`, `O`, `R`, `T` to various repetition of `$` to reduce 4 lines.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! I sure don't know if this is possible to use the same time of strategy in Python (it's case sensitive).

Comment: Very nice! Note that `=Z[3*7]` can be written as `=Z[~-22]` which only needs one line break instead of two.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yeah, but spaces are and they're first in the ASCII set...

Comment: @meandmycat Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 13):

## [Insomnia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/41868#41868), 4 lines, 59 bytes

```
 FFFFGjnnnnooty
FLLddeejkopqyyyyy~~
(<ddjnoppppqrtu
<<Fddfj
```

This program is generated by optimizing for line count.

#### 10 lines, 43 bytes

```
(u
pt
(dppty
p~
j
<Fptt{
(otz
?o
FLu
<?FFu~
```

This above program is generated by optimizing for byte count.

Answer (score 11):

## Cygwin bash, 16 lines, 60 bytes

This only works due to the case-insensitive file name on Windows, and the fact that Cygwin look up the utilities case-insensitively even if you don't set it to recognize path case-insensitively.

```
A\
=Hello
A\
+=\
",
"Wor
A\
+=l
A\
+=d
A\
+=\
!
E\
CHO\
 $A
```

Take note of that `ECHO` at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is 17 or 16 lines (there is a new line at the very end), but either way, this is not going to win anything.

Comment: You won 10 upvotes, that's a lot already. The most upvoted ones (as of now) have 12 upvotes! And the /// solution with 23 upvotes.

Answer (score 11):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 6 lines, 111 bytes

```
  """""""/;;Hello
        &\o
      &++\oooo~~
"++++++++\bbbdlr
    +++++\ccccccccfooo}
    $++66\cfffffooooopr
```

I'm having trouble golfing out an extra line, but in any case I'm happy to have beaten the 7-line method.

### Explanation

><> is a stack-based 2D language where instructions are single chars and program flow can be up, down, left or right. The `"` instruction toggles string parsing, pushing chars until a closing `"` is met, but because of the nature of ><> there's no such thing as "multi-line string parsing" like with CJam's strings or Python's triple quoted strings. This turned out to be a major problem because starting and ending a line with a `"` and having other chars in between (e.g. `"some chars"`) is not allowed!

Note that `/` and `\` reflect program flow, so we actually execute the first line then all of the lines in reverse order, and most lines are actually executed backwards!

```
[Line 1]

""""""              Three empty strings, push nothing
"/;;Hello  "        Push "/;;Hello  ". Note the wrapping - ><> is toroidal!
""""""              Three empty strings, push nothing

[Line 6]
66++$               Turn the top " " into "," by adding 12, then swap top two
rp                  Reverse stack and pop top 3
ooooo               Print "Hello", stack is now " ,"
fffffc              Push some 15s and a 12

[Line 5]
+++++               Sum the 15s and 12 to give 87, or "W"
}ooo                Move "W" to the back and output ", W"
fcccccccc           Push a 15 and some 12s

[Line 4]
++++++++            Sum the 15 and 12s to give 111, or "o"
"rldbbb\++++++++"   Push chars to stack
r                   Reverse stack
ld                  Push length of stack and 13, not used
bbb                 Push three 11s

[Line 3]
++&                 Sum the 11s to give 33, or "!" and put in register
~~                  Pop top two
oooo                Print "orld"

[Line 2]
&                   Put "!" from register to stack
o                   Print "!"

[Line 1]
;                   Terminate
```

---

On a side note, here's an amusing attempt at a ><> least bytes (23 lines, 47 bytes):

```
v
"
!
d
l
r
o
W

,
o
l
l
e
H
"
/<
l
?
!
;
o
\^
```

Comment: In the second code you can save 2 bytes thanks to vertical wrap-around: http://pastebin.com/heqCr1vJ

Answer (score 10):

## CJam, <s>5</s> 4 lines, 162 bytes

```
"Hello
")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))68S\cel
"Wor
")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))@SX\c|
```

Same number of lines as Insomnia! (but a lot more bytes)

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22Hello%0A%22%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%2968S%5Ccel%0A%22Wor%0A%22%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%40SX%5Cc%7C).

### Explanation

```
"Hello\n"        Push "Hello" and a newline
)                Uncons the newline
)))...)))        Increment the newline into a ","
68S\             Push 68 and a space then swap, leaving 68 on top
c                Convert 68 into a char "D"
el               Lowercase "D" into "d"
"Wor\n"          Push "Wor" and a newline
)                Uncons the newline
)))...)))        Increment the newline into an "l"
@                Rotate top three elements, moving the "d" to the top
SX\              Push a space and 1 then swap, leaving the space on top
c                Convert the space (which is an array) into a char
|                Bitwise or the space (32) with 1 to give "!" (33)
```

CJam automatically prints the stack afterwards.

Thanks to @Optimizer for reminding me that `Sc` works, because otherwise `SX|` fails (it does a setwise or instead, giving the array consisting of a space and 1).

Answer (score 8):

## PHP (7 / 17 lines, 36 / 59 bytes):

Due to the amount of invalid answer, I rewrote this answer.

The browser version? Gone.

But I have 2 solutions, both based on bitwise `xor` (`^`) of strings in PHP.

This is an extremely powerful solution! Sometimes, it allows to save plenty of bytes.

First, the shortest answer:

```
Echo
Hello
,AM^mm
,Wor
,OOO^
"#+n
";
```

I know, it looks awful, but it works!

The next one depends on newlines.

Yes, it uses newlines (`\n`/UNIX style is required)!

```
Echo
Bo
.ff
.e
.
"&*]ex
fn
"^
"\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
",B^c
;
```

The newlines on this one are required to work.

It isn't perfect, but works!

---

Both answers were based on [@MartinBüttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner)'s [solution](http://pastebin.com/MskntTra):

```
Echo
Hello
.
chr
(44
).
chr
(29
+3
).Wor
.l
.d
."!
";
```

---

A special thank to [@n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6638/n%CC%B4%CC%8B%CC%96h%CC%B7%CC%83%CD%89a%CC%B7%CC%BF%CC%ADh%CC%B8%CC%85%CC%A1t%CC%B5%CD%84%CC%A8d%CC%B7%CD%80%CC%B0h%CC%B7%CC%82%CC%B3), [@CJDennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29560/cj-dennis), [@MartinBüttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) and [@skagedal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38728/skagedal) for detecting all my mistakes and for their suggestions.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ Thank you a lot for that. I totally forgot to check a 8th time. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I call that bizarre, since browsers usually remove the newlines.

Comment: The output in the browser is `Hello , Wor l d !`. Note the extra spaces! This is not a valid answer, unfortunately.

Comment: @CJDennis Can you tell me the browser you used?

Comment: Tested in Firefox 36, IE 8, Opera 12.17 & Opera 28 (Chromium) on Windows XP. All rendered the output identically. Since any number of whitespace characters are rendered as a single space character (barring no break space, etc.) each newline gets converted to a space. I would be interested to know if any browser renders your output without spaces!

Comment: @CJDennis I've fixed it now. It's a monster, but works as expected. I'll call it *frankencode* (after Frankenstein).

Comment: @MartinBüttner I may sound like a stubborn child, but there is nothing saying that the output can't be the *rendered* output. Also, I make it explicit that it only works in a web-browser. And the *rendered* output matches **exactly** what is required. I really appreciata a lot your solution and I will add it as an alternative answer ans suggestion with the due credit.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've reduced your code. If you want to update the pastebin, feel free to do so.

Comment: Nice abuse of the language! Since the errors it generates technically go to stderr and not stdout, your code is now valid even though in my case I see a lot of errors in my browser! And, incredibly nit-picky, my PHP setup has short tags off so the first line on my computer is `<?php` which is invalid! However, I'll forgive you for this! OK, just tested `<?Php` which works, so I've just learnt that the start tag is case-insensitive!

Comment: You can save 5 characters and one line in your browser version by removing the `<br>` as the newline is optional.

Comment: @CJDennis I can put there the 'long' tags if you wish. Or I can go crazy and use the `<script language="php"></script>` tag (Yes, it works too!). But I'm happy with the result. Actually, I could drop the echo entirelly, if instead of `<=>?` the order had the `?` between `<` and `=`. Also, I can't drop the `<br>`. If I leave the `<br>` out, the browser will render a space at the end, instead of a new line. According to the rules, that is invalid. The errors generated are because the constants `Hello`, `Wor`, `l` and `d` don't exist and PHP is warning that it is assuming them as a string.

Comment: The top two solutions in this answer do not follow the rules. The top one has, as line 8, .`"!<br` - this is not sorted. The second one has as line 10: `."!` - not sorted.

Comment: @skagedal It is indeed badly sorted... I'm trying to find a fix for it and I'm preparing an update, 'cause this answer is getting a mess with so many edits.

Comment: @skagedal I've rewritten the whole answer and it is clean now. I'm sorry for the delay.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'm sorry, but no. Line 7 of the first suggestion is not sorted. Lines 5 and 7 of the second suggestion are not sorted.

Comment: @skagedal Thanks for pointing out. Now they are fixed. But I'm not happy with the fix. I'll look for a better one.

Comment: @skagedal Now they are correct. I've managed to reduce 2 lines from the first answer. The last one will be harder, but it was also just meant as an alternative. The idea was to use as many newlines as possible. But once again, thanks for pointing that out. It was a bit late when I made the edit, so, I kinda expected to mess up somewhere.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The first solution now has correctly sorted lines! :) Line 6 of the second still doesn't work.

Comment: @skagedal You are correct once again. The fix was easy: Just swapped quotes! Since the order is `"#$%&`, this now is correct.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Good job! :)

Comment: @skagedal Thank you. Sadly, I only saw your python code 20 minutes ago. Kinda late on the run, but surelly helped me to check once again if I had screwed again or if everything was well ordered.

Answer (score 8):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 5 lines, many bytes

The code is extremely long, when I say `[6535529689086686142930090 '+' signs]` and `[6535529689086686142930090 'd' characters]` in the first line of the code, I mean that there are literally `6535529689086686142930090` plus signs in a row!

(And for the following lines add the necessary prefix spaces.)

```
'[6535529689086686142930090 '+' signs]^`[6535529689086686142930090 'd' characters]
                                   **,/288
                                     -/:o
                             %**288:;?\
                                   (1:\
```

A shorter testable alternative which only prints `Hi`:

```
'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++^`hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
                                                                                                                               **,/288
                                                                                                                                 -/:o
                                                                                                                         %**288:;?\
                                                                                                                               (1:\
```

Method:

- In the first line we create a huge number representing the string in base128.
- In the rest of the lines (going from bottom to top) we print the following character in every loop until the value of the integer reaches 0.
- The looping code is `:1(?;:882**%:o-288**,`.

(We can print arbitrary 2+ chars long string with this method.)

Comment: Not a valid solution; 6535529689086686142930090 is not ordered.

Comment: @theonlygusti "The code is extremely long, interpret `[6535529689086686142930090 '+' signs]` and `[6535529689086686142930090 'd' characters]` literally in the first line of the code." (If unclear what I mean by that check the second piece of code.)

Comment: Oh, okay! Sorry, silly me :P I took it literally.

Comment: Size is 13 YB, roughly 1000 times the size of the Internet.

Comment: @Charles I get ~40YB including the latter lines.

Comment: @Veedrac You don't know what a "YB" is, do you. [Yottabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yottabyte)

Comment: @Yottabyte I don't know what Veedrac of March 31, 2015 was thinking, but he obviously wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 7 lines, 23 bytes

```
-
"Hello
,
 Wor
l
d
!"b
```

Pretty simple, just use a multiline string and remove the newlines.

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-%0A%22Hello%0A%2C%0A%20Wor%0Al%0Ad%0A!%22b&debug=0)

Comment: @orlp I added multiline strings a few days ago, and Pyth has had support for newlines in the input for ages. This doesn't use multiline mode at all. Try it on the online compiler, which definitely has no multiline mode.

Comment: Its almost the same in CJam, with same byte count too.

Answer (score 4):

## Forth, 41 lines, 143 bytes

[Try it online.](http://ideone.com/rnp5FC)

I'm very proud of this. I whipped it out pretty quickly once I found I could do it, having Google searched for case-insensitive languages, and I already know Forth decently. It can almost definitely be shortened, both bytes and lines. Suggestions are appreciated. :D

This program essentially pushes the decimal value of each ASCII character, then prints each one. I attempted to optimize while I wrote it, hence it is less readable than I'd like.

```
33
99
1
+
DUp
8
+
2DUp
6
+
SWap
11
+
2OVer
SWap
8
9
*
EMit
1
+
EMit
DUp
DUp
EMit
EMit
3
+
EMit
29
3
2DUp
+
EMit
*
EMit
EMit
EMit
EMit
EMit
EMit
```

Comment: The `Emit` lines don't work, as `i` (105) is less than `m` (109).

Comment: It should be "EMit", then?

Answer (score 4):

## Marbelous, 9 lines, 94 bytes

```
3333
    @ADD
    358C
++--29\\
++--3555DE
<<<<<<>>~~
+++++446666D
++++++++../\
      ++------
```

[Test it online here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40808) `Using spaces for blank cells` must be checked.

**Visual representation of source:**

[image: Visual representation of above source]

**Explanation:** Each hexadecimal value in this program moves downward every "tick" (unless it is on `\\`, in which case it moves to the right). `++` will increment the value, `--` decrement, `~~` apply a bitwise not, etc. Values that fall of the bottom are printed as an ASCII character.

For example: The `33` in the top corner becomes `(((0x33 +1 +1) << 1) +1 +1 = 0x6C (l)`.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch - 39 Lines (202 bytes)

I wanted to cut down on the size by enabling delayed expansion by running the code inside of a `cmd` call using the `/v on` switch, but could not get past all the carats.

```
@S^
ET^
LO^
C^
AL^
 EN^
ABL^
E^
DEL^
AY^
E^
DEX^
P^
ANS^
IO^
N
@S^
ET^
 0=Hello
@S^
ET^
 1=^
,^
 Wor
@S^
ET^
 2=l
@S^
ET^
 3=d
@E^
CHO^
 !^
0^
!!1^
!!2^
!!3^
!^^^
!
```

Without the newlines (and carats to escape newlines):

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@SET 0=Hello
@SET 1=, Wor
@SET 2=l
@SET 3=d
@ECHO !0!!1!!2!!3!^^!
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rebol - 15 lines (51 bytes)

```
PRin
AJOin
[
'Hello
Sp 
+
12
Sp
'Wor
'l
'd
Sp
+
1
]
```

Words in Rebol are case-insensitive (eg. `PRINT`, `Print` and `print` would all call the same function).

The above code tidied up:

```
prin ajoin [
    'Hello  sp + 12  sp  'Wor  'l  'd  sp + 1
]
```

NB. `sp` returns the space [char!](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/char.html)

Comment: Your program is invalid, the `{` can't be before any letters.

Comment: @theonlygusti - Fixed (gone from 9 lines to 13).   The only line that caused me a problem was `{,}`.   This is now `Sp + 12` (over 3 lines) which is equivalent of space character + 12 (ie. comma)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 17 lines

```
$_
=
'pr
int
"Hello
,
 Wor
l
d
!"';s
!
!!g
;s
!.
*
!$&
!eex
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Unary](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), 1 line, lots of bytes

Every character in this program is `0`. The source is too long to put in here, but it consists of a string of this many zeros:

```
327380789025192647555922325233404088310881092761595127419003295178342329930050528932118548
```

This is the decimal representation for this binary number:

```
0b1010010010010010010010010110000010010010010110000010010000010010010000010010010000010001001001001011111000010000010000011110001111001011111000000100000011011011100010010010010010010010100100010010010100000000100001011100001100010010010100011011011011011011100011011011011011011011011100000000010100
```

Which was created from this BrainF*** program:

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>-[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.
```

See how I generated it: http://ideone.com/lMT40p

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 lines, 25 bytes

```
`
Hello
,
 Wor
l
d
!`
\
-
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%0AHello%0A%2C%0A%20Wor%0Al%0Ad%0A!%60%0A%5C%0A-&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
`        #
Hello    |
,        |
 Wor     | Push 'Hello\n,\n Wor\nl\nd\n!'
l        |
d        |
!`       #
     \   # Push '\n'
      -  # Remove all '\n' from 'Hello\n,\n Wor\nl\nd\n!'
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 19 lines, 95 bytes

```
$;=
$>
$;<<
:Hello
$;<<
44::chr
$.=
33::
-1
$;<<
$.::chr
$;<<
:Wor
$;<<
:l
$;<<
:d
$;<<
33::chr
```

Possibly the second-hardest code restriction for Ruby I've seen on this site, after the monstrosity [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36639/the-symbols-vs-the-letters/36654#36654).

Edit for explanation: The only Ruby output method that's sorted is the `<<` method on STDOUT. Unfortunately, the constant for STDOUT is `$>`, and `>` is higher ASCII than most symbols, so it's not really possible to call a method on it. We need a multi-line assignment statement to get it into a more tractable variable name, `$;` (semicolon is still pretty high, but most variables of this form are either non-assignable, or can only be strings).

Symbols (`:Wor`, etc. ) are the easiest way to do a literal, and I don't see a way to strip newlines from a string, so I need multiple print statements. The space and punctuation can't go into a symbol literal, but luckily the `chr` method on numbers is legal, so I can get a character from its ASCII value. `::` is an alternate way of calling methods. Space is tricky because I can't write `32`, so I subtract 1 from 33 and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, 12 lines, 29 bytes (non-competing)

The language is newer than the challenge.

```
Hello
$
,
$
 Wor
$
l
$
d
$
!
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8/lkZqTk8@lwqUDxArh@UVAKgeIU4BY8f9/AA)