# Hello World - but alphabetically

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, hello-world

*This challenge sounds too simple to not already exist, so let me know if it is a duplicate.*

### The task

Print `Hello, world!`

### The rules

Your code has to be in "byte order". This means that every character / byte has a higher or equal byte value than the preceding character / byte.

Exceptions to this rule are the [whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace) characters, which may occur anywhere.

The [usual loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are not allowed.

**Edit**: Using built-in functions / constants resolving to `Hello, world!` is not allowed.

**Edit 2**: The output may be a(n anonymous) function returning the string,  an expression resolving to the string, or any other way you think should be allowed.

#### example

`HW` is valid: `0x48 (H) <= 0x57 (W)`
`print` is invalid: `0x72 (r) > 0x69 (i)`
but `PRint` is valid: `0x50 (P) <= 0x52 (R) <= 0x69 (i) <= 0x6e (n) <= 0x74 (t)`

### The scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the score is the number of characters / bytes. The lower the score, the higher the ranking.

Comment: There are many languages with 1-byte Hello World built-ins. Some may even print Hello World for an empty program.

Comment: [Very closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48207/8478) (The difference is that that one allows each line to be sorted independently, and that it's primarily scored by the number of lines.)

Comment: @Dennis Added an extra rule because of that! Thanks

Comment: Still trivial in 23, Headsecks, and Lenguage, but much longer than a couple of bytes.

Comment: Default output like `ans = Hello, world!` is that OK? Otherwise, MATLAB and Octave won't be able to attempt this... `disp`, `printf` and `eval` are all in non-alphabetical order.

Comment: @StewieGriffin That is now allowed, yes

Comment: If not for the lowercase `w`, [Stuck](https://github.com/kade-robertson/stuck) would have done it in 0 bytes, since the rules disallow builtins, but the empty program isn't using a builtin.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer How is the empty program not a built-in? It's a *builtin* constant program that results in `Hello, World!`...

Comment: Is scoring characters or bytes? It's not clear...

Comment: @mbomb007 Well, I wouldn't consider a built-in *program* to be the same thing as a builtin function or constant, unless used as an "eval full program" argument (not just "eval"), which seems to me pretty unlikely.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's a constant. And it's part of the language. AKA a *built-in*.

Answer (score 15):

## WhiteSpace, 146 bytes

Since all whitespace may occur everywhere, this is is just the golfed Hello World program. Since whitespace doesn't show properly here, take the following program and replace all `.` by spaces, `>` by tabs and `;` by newlines.

```
...;..>>..>.>.;..>>>>;...>;...>>>;...>..;..>>.>..;..>>..>.>>;..>>>>>>>;...>..;...>;.;...>>>.;..>>...>>;;..;.;.;>.>;...>>.>.>>;>...>;..;.;;;..>;;;;
```

## Note

I didn't golf this, LukStorms did. His answer can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55447/63774).

Comment: It's not in byte order.

Comment: Indeed, but whitespace didn't have to be in byte order; it could appear everywhere

Comment: Oh. Good abuse of the rules then

Comment: Exactly. That's also part of the reason this is community wiki.

Answer (score 15):

## Headsecks - <s>124</s> 82 chars

*Thanks to @MartinEnder for pointing me to a smaller hello-world!*

Headsecks looks to be the right language for the job, because its brainfuck except that it takes each character mod 8.

```
 +19AISYchpx£¨°»ÁËÐÞàèðøĀĈĐĘĦīİĸŀňŐŘŠŨųŻƀƈƐƘƠƪƲƺǁǏǒǟǣǫǴǸȃȈȐțȤȫȴȼɀɋɓɜɠɫɱɹʃʉʑʞʣʩʴʺ˂ˏ
```

You can try it by going here: https://repl.it/G2I5/1, then here: https://sange.fi/esoteric/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html

Comment: You need to post an actual Headsecks interpreter that will run this, not a Python program to convert to BF and a BF interpreter. Since the program contains non-ASCII, the interpreter you link to needs to handle non-ASCII Headsecks programs.

Comment: @mbomb007 there used to be an interpreter, but it 404s now :( https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headsecks

Comment: https://github.com/TieSoul/Multilang/blob/master/headsecks.py

Comment: @mbomb007 that one handles unicode codepoints, but not the weird wrapping tricks that the bf helloworld uses. I'll try to look for another one, or just rollback to my earlier, longer, answer.

Comment: Maybe someone should create an implementation, then have Dennis put it on TIO. Also, someone should edit Esolangs. I was going to, but idr my login info.

Answer (score 13):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 784 bytes

```
"	 







































	 




































































	 











































































	 











































































	 














































































	 











	 	 






















































































	 














































































	 

















































































	 











































































	 



































































	 
"
"	
"')`er~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6/EqcBFJCBeJT2MGQKmYRjIqUB1C@jk8uEbWUBTlLiUOLmU1DUTUovq/v8HAA)

Not winning anything with that byte count, but this was still fun to make.

**Explanation**

The first large string encodes `Hello, world!` using only whitespace. Each character is mapped to a tab, a space, and a number of linefeeds equal to its codepoint minus 32.

Next, the string is transliterated by replacing tabs with `'` and linefeeds with `)`. This results in many sequences of a literal space character followed by some number of increments. The string is eval'ed with `~`, pushing the spaces and incrementing them to proper characters.

The stack is implicitly output at the end of the program.

Comment: Excellent, finally a truly clever answer!