# The Programming Language Quiz, Mark II - Cops

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, cops-and-robbers, obfuscation

<sub>A repost of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz) challenge. [Meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14272/can-we-revive-the-programming-language-quiz). [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14390/66833). Body of the question similar to the original</sub>

[Robber's challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers)

> This cops and robbers is now (08/03/2018) closed to further competing cop entries, as robbers may no longer be competing to crack answers, but feel free to post new answers.
>
> The Cops challenge was won by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) with his brilliant [6 byte Sesos answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156002/66833)
>
> The Robbers challenge was won by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman), with an astounding [30 cracks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A155019+user%3A68615)!

### The Cops' Challenge

To compete as a cop:

1. **Choose a programming language**. A valid programming language is one which meets all three of these criteria:

   - It has [an English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_programming_languages), [an esolangs article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) or [a Rosetta Code article](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Languages) at the time this challenge was posted, or is on [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#). Having an interpreter linked in any of these pages makes that interpreter completely legal.
   - It must satisfy our rules on [what constitutes a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/8478)
   - It must have a free interpreter (as in beer). Free here means that anyone can use the program without having to pay to do so.
2. **Write a full program that outputs the numbers from 1 to 100, inclusive, in ascending order**. You can output as decimal integers, as bytecode values (`!` to represent 33, for instance), or as unary digits (`1111` for 4, e.g)<sup>1</sup>. If using unary, you should use any *consistent* character for digits, and a different, consistent character as a delimiter. If using integers, you should output with a constant non-digit delimiter between each number. You may also output with leading and trailing characters (such as `[]`) but please be sensible (don't output a thousand bytes of rubbish either side of the count for instance). You must specify your output format in your answer.

   You must not assume a REPL environment or existing boilerplate code. Flags may be used, but you must reveal what flags are used in your answer. The program must be in the form of one or more source files (to rule out quirky languages like [Folders](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Folders)) and must fit into your answer in full (so it must not be longer than 65,536 characters) - this shouldn't be an issue for any serious submission.

   If your code contains bytes outside of printable ASCII + newline, please include a hex dump to make sure your code is actually testable.

   The program must terminate within 5 minutes on a typical desktop PC.

That's it. However, as with everything, there is a catch. You should aim to obfuscate your program as much as possible, as the Robbers' task is to guess the language you used. You should also aim to make sure that your program only works in the intended language (although this is likely to be less of a problem than the [Foo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo) cracks in the original challenge). The output format must be the same as your intended solution in order to constitute a valid crack.

Once **7 days** have passed without anyone discovering *any* language where your program is a valid crack, you may reveal the language and mark it as `safe`. Please note, **your submission can still be cracked until you reveal the language**.

You must not under any circumstances edit the source code of your submission once posted (as this may invalidate a robber's active attempts at cracking your answer). So make sure that you golf it as well as you can (or dare) before posting. If you realise that your answer does not work after posting it, simply delete your answer and post a fixed version if you want to.

The shortest safe submission in *bytes* wins!

<sub>1: If you wish to output in a different way, please ask in the comments</sub>

#### The Stack Snippet

You can use this stack snippet to browse the answers more easily:

```js
answersSafe=[];answersCracked=[];answersUncracked=[];answerPage=1;robberTodo=[];userNames={};robberMap={};robberStats={};robberTimes={};function template($element,data){var $clone=$element.clone().removeClass('template');var html=$clone.html();for(var key in data){html=html.replace('{'+key+'}',data[key])}$clone.html(html);$element.after($clone)}function hideEmpty(){$('tbody').each(function(){if($(this).find('tr:not(.template):has(td)').length==0){$(this).find('tr:not(.empty):has(th)').addClass('inactive');$(this).find('tr.empty').removeClass('inactive')}})}function formatError(obj,reason){template($('.warn.template'),{id:obj.cop_id,cop:obj.cop_user,reason:reason})}function showAnswers(category,selector,sorter){sorter(category);$('#'+selector).find('tr:not(.template):has(td)').remove();$.each(category,function(i,answer){template($('#'+selector+' .template'),answer)});$('code:has(br)').addClass('clickable').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('full')});updateCountdowns()}function getAnswers(){$.ajax({url:"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/155018/answers?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=!*LUzJZNOIUpZsWsZBLe&page="+(answerPage++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp"}).then(function(data){$.each(data.items,function(i,answer){var obj={cop_id:answer.answer_id,cop_user:answer.owner.display_name,cop_time:answer.creation_date,safe_on:answer.creation_date+604800};var $e=$('<div/>').html(answer.body);var $headers=$e.find(':header');if($headers.length==0){return formatError(obj,"no header")}var header=$headers.first().html();var $code=$e.find('pre code');if($code.length==0){return formatError(obj,"no code")}obj.code=$code.first().html().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>');if(obj.code.endsWith('<br/>')){obj.code=obj.code.slice(0,-5)}var bm=/(\d+)\s+bytes/.exec(header);if(bm==null){return formatError(obj,"no bytecount")}obj.size=parseInt(bm[1]);if(obj.size==NaN){return formatError(obj,"bytecount is NaN: "+bm[1])}obj.language=header.slice(0,bm.index).trim();while(obj.language.charAt(obj.language.length-1)!=','&&obj.language.length!=0){obj.language=obj.language.slice(0,-1)}if(obj.language.length==0){return formatError(obj,"no/bad separator before bytecount")}obj.language=obj.language.slice(0,-1).trim();obj.language_text=$('<div/>').html(obj.language).text();var end=header.slice(bm.index+bm[0].length).trim();if(end.length==0){if(obj.language!=="???"){return formatError(obj,"not marked as safe nor cracked, but language is "+obj.language+" (expected ???)")}return answersUncracked.push(obj)}if(!end.startsWith(',')){return formatError(obj,"no/bad separator after bytecount")}end=end.slice(1).trim();if(end==='safe'){return answersSafe.push(obj)}var $end=$('<div/>').html(end);var end_text=$end.text();if(!end_text.startsWith('cracked')){return formatError(obj,"expected 'cracked' or 'safe', got '"+end_text+"'")}var expectedURL='https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/';var $links=$end.find('a');if($links.length==0){return formatError(obj,"no cracked link")}var robberURL=$links.first().attr('href');if(!robberURL.startsWith(expectedURL)){return formatError(obj,"link does not start with "+expectedURL+": "+robberURL)}obj.robber_id=parseInt(robberURL.slice(expectedURL.length));if(obj.robber_id==NaN){return formatError(obj,"robber_id is NaN")}robberTodo.push(obj.robber_id);answersCracked.push(obj)});if(data.has_more){getAnswers()}else{getRobbers()}})}function sortBySize(category){category.sort(function(a,b){return b.size-a.size})}function sortByTime(category){category.sort(function(a,b){return b.cop_time-a.cop_time})}function sortByLiveTime(category){category.sort(function(a,b){return b.cracked_after-a.cracked_after})}function sortByCop(category){category.sort(function(a,b){return b.cop_user.localeCompare(a.cop_user)})}function sortByRobber(category){category.sort(function(a,b){return b.robber_user.localeCompare(a.robber_user)})}function sortByLanguage(category){category.sort(function(a,b){return b.language_text.localeCompare(a.language_text)})}function getRobbers(){if(robberTodo.length==0){$.each(answersCracked,function(i,answer){answer.robber_user=userNames[robberMap[answer.robber_id]];answer.cracked_after=robberTimes[answer.robber_id]-answer.cop_time;answer.cracked_after_str=formatTime(answer.cracked_after)});showAnswers(answersUncracked,'uncracked',sortByTime);showAnswers(answersCracked,'cracked',sortByLiveTime);showAnswers(answersSafe,'safe',sortBySize);hideEmpty();var graphData=[];$.each(robberStats,function(k,v){graphData.push({name:decodeEntities(userNames[k]),value:v})});graphData.sort(function(a,b){if(a.value==b.value){return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)}else{return b.value-a.value}});var graphLabels=[];var graphValues=[];$.each(graphData,function(i,obj){graphLabels.push(obj.name);graphValues.push(obj.value)});var graphColors=[];for(var i=0;i<graphData.length;i+=1){graphColors.push(['#b58900','#cb4b16','#dc322f','#d33682','#6c71c4','#268bd2','#2aa198','#859900'][i%8])}$('#robber-stats').attr('width',600);$('#robber-stats').attr('height',24*graphData.length+66);$('#answer-stats').attr('width',600);$('#answer-stats').attr('height',400);Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor='#839496';new Chart($('#robber-stats'),{type:'horizontalBar',data:{labels:graphLabels,datasets:[{data:graphValues,backgroundColor:graphColors}]},options:{responsive:false,legend:false,tooltips:false,layout:{padding:{right:40}},title:{display:true,text:'Number of answers cracked per robber',fontSize:18},scales:{yAxes:[{gridLines:{display:false}}],xAxes:[{gridLines:{display:false},ticks:{beginAtZero:true}}]},plugins:{datalabels:{anchor:'end',align:'end'}}}});new Chart($('#answer-stats'),{type:'pie',data:{labels:['Uncracked','Cracked','Safe'],datasets:[{data:[answersUncracked.length,answersCracked.length,answersSafe.length],backgroundColor:['#2aa198','#dc322f','#859900'],borderColor:'#002b36'}]},options:{responsive:false,tooltips:{backgroundColor:'#073642',displayColors:false},title:{display:true,text:'Number of answers in each category',fontSize:18},plugins:{datalabels:false}}});updateCountdowns();setInterval(updateCountdowns,1000);$('#loading').hide()}else{$.ajax({url:"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+robberTodo.slice(0,100).join(';')+"?site=codegolf&filter=!*RB.h_b*K*dQTllFUdy",method:"get",dataType:"jsonp"}).then(function(data){$.each(data.items,function(i,robber){robberTodo=robberTodo.filter(function(e){return e!==robber.answer_id});robberMap[robber.answer_id]=robber.owner.user_id;robberTimes[robber.answer_id]=robber.creation_date;userNames[robber.owner.user_id]=robber.owner.display_name;if(robber.owner.user_id in robberStats){robberStats[robber.owner.user_id]+=1}else{robberStats[robber.owner.user_id]=1}});getRobbers()})}}var decodeEntities=(function(){var element=document.createElement('div');function decodeHTMLEntities(str){if(str&&typeof str==='string'){str=str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi,'');str=str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi,'');element.innerHTML=str;str=element.textContent;element.textContent=''}return str}return decodeHTMLEntities})();function formatTime(seconds){var arr=[];if(seconds>86400){arr.push(Math.floor(seconds/86400)+" days");seconds%=86400}if(seconds>3600){arr.push(Math.floor(seconds/3600)+" hours");seconds%=3600}if(seconds>60){arr.push(Math.floor(seconds/60)+" minutes");seconds%=60}if(seconds!=0){arr.push(seconds+" seconds")}return arr.join(', ').split('').reverse().join('').replace(',','dna ').split('').reverse().join('')}function updateCountdowns(){$('tr:not(.template) .countdown').each(function(){var target=$(this).attr('data-target');var now=Math.floor(+new Date()/1000);if(target-now<86400){$(this).addClass('urgent')}else{$(this).removeClass('urgent')}if(target<now){$(this).removeClass('countdown').text('Safe! (according to your computer\'s time)')}else{$(this).text(formatTime(target-now))}})}$('thead, #stats-header').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('hidden')});getAnswers();
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;font:12pt sans-serif;}html,body{background:#002b36;color:#839496;width:100%;height:100%;}body>:not(.i):not(#loading){margin:5px;}#loading{background:rgb(64,64,64,0.8);position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;display:table;z-index:100;}#loading-wrapper{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;font-size:20pt;color:#ddd;}#fullpage-msg,.warn{padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;margin:10px 0px;}@media (min-width:800px){#fullpage-msg{display:none;}}a{color:#268bd2;}code{font-family:monospace;font-size:16px;background:#073642;padding:1px 5px;white-space:pre;position:relative;}.clickable{cursor:pointer;}code:not(.full){max-height:38px;overflow:hidden;}code.clickable:not(.full):before{content:'';background:linear-gradient(transparent 20px,rgba(7,54,66,0.8) 32px,#002b36);position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;}td,th{padding:5px;vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;}thead th,#stats-header{font-size:20pt;margin:10px 0;user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;cursor:pointer;}th{font-weight:bold;}path{fill:#839496;}thead:not(.hidden) .right-arrow,#stats-header:not(.hidden) .right-arrow,thead.hidden .down-arrow,#stats-header.hidden .down-arrow{visibility:hidden;}.hidden+tbody,.hidden+#stats,.template,.inactive{display:none;}small,code{display:block;}small,small a{font-size:8pt;}#stats-header{font-weight:bold;padding:6px;}.urgent{color:#dc322f;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script><script>!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?e(require("chart.js")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["chart.js"],e):e(t.Chart)}(this,function(t){"use strict";var e=(t=t&&t.hasOwnProperty("default")?t.default:t).helpers,n={toTextLines:function(t){var n,a=[];for(t=[].concat(t);t.length;)"string"==typeof(n=t.pop())?a.unshift.apply(a,n.split("\n")):Array.isArray(n)?t.push.apply(t,n):e.isNullOrUndef(t)||a.unshift(""+n);return a},toFontString:function(t){return!t||e.isNullOrUndef(t.size)||e.isNullOrUndef(t.family)?null:(t.style?t.style+" ":"")+(t.weight?t.weight+" ":"")+t.size+"px "+t.family},textSize:function(t,e,n){var a,r=[].concat(e),i=r.length,o=t.font,l=0;for(t.font=n.string,a=0;a<i;++a)l=Math.max(t.measureText(r[a]).width,l);return t.font=o,{height:i*n.lineHeight,width:l}},parseFont:function(a){var r=t.defaults.global,i=e.valueOrDefault(a.size,r.defaultFontSize),o={family:e.valueOrDefault(a.family,r.defaultFontFamily),lineHeight:e.options.toLineHeight(a.lineHeight,i),size:i,style:e.valueOrDefault(a.style,r.defaultFontStyle),weight:e.valueOrDefault(a.weight,null),string:""};return o.string=n.toFontString(o),o},bound:function(t,e,n){return Math.max(t,Math.min(e,n))}};function a(t,e){var n=e.x,a=e.y;if(null===n)return{x:0,y:-1};if(null===a)return{x:1,y:0};var r=t.x-n,i=t.y-a,o=Math.sqrt(r*r+i*i);return{x:o?r/o:0,y:o?i/o:-1}}function r(t,e,n,a,r){switch(r){case"center":n=a=0;break;case"bottom":n=0,a=1;break;case"right":n=1,a=0;break;case"left":n=-1,a=0;break;case"top":n=0,a=-1;break;case"start":n=-n,a=-a;break;case"end":break;default:r*=Math.PI/180,n=Math.cos(r),a=Math.sin(r)}return{x:t,y:e,vx:n,vy:a}}var i={arc:function(t,e,n){var a,i=(t.startAngle+t.endAngle)/2,o=Math.cos(i),l=Math.sin(i),s=t.innerRadius,d=t.outerRadius;return a="start"===e?s:"end"===e?d:(s+d)/2,r(t.x+o*a,t.y+l*a,o,l,n)},point:function(t,e,n,i){var o=a(t,i),l=t.radius,s=0;return"start"===e?s=-l:"end"===e&&(s=l),r(t.x+o.x*s,t.y+o.y*s,o.x,o.y,n)},rect:function(t,e,n,i){var o=t.horizontal,l=Math.abs(t.base-(o?t.x:t.y)),s=o?Math.min(t.x,t.base):t.x,d=o?t.y:Math.min(t.y,t.base),u=a(t,i);return"center"===e?o?s+=l/2:d+=l/2:"start"!==e||o?"end"===e&&o&&(s+=l):d+=l,r(s,d,u.x,u.y,n)},fallback:function(t,e,n,i){var o=a(t,i);return r(t.x,t.y,o.x,o.y,n)}},o=t.helpers;var l=function(t,e){this._el=t,this._index=e,this._model=null};o.extend(l.prototype,{_modelize:function(e,a,r,l){var s,d=this._index,u=o.options.resolve,f=n.parseFont(u([r.font,{}],l,d));return{align:u([r.align,"center"],l,d),anchor:u([r.anchor,"center"],l,d),backgroundColor:u([r.backgroundColor,null],l,d),borderColor:u([r.borderColor,null],l,d),borderRadius:u([r.borderRadius,0],l,d),borderWidth:u([r.borderWidth,0],l,d),color:u([r.color,t.defaults.global.defaultFontColor],l,d),font:f,lines:a,offset:u([r.offset,0],l,d),opacity:u([r.opacity,1],l,d),origin:function(t){var e=t._model.horizontal,n=t._scale||e&&t._xScale||t._yScale;if(!n)return null;if(void 0!==n.xCenter&&void 0!==n.yCenter)return{x:n.xCenter,y:n.yCenter};var a=n.getBasePixel();return e?{x:a,y:null}:{x:null,y:a}}(this._el),padding:o.options.toPadding(u([r.padding,0],l,d)),positioner:(s=this._el,s instanceof t.elements.Arc?i.arc:s instanceof t.elements.Point?i.point:s instanceof t.elements.Rectangle?i.rect:i.fallback),rotation:u([r.rotation,0],l,d)*(Math.PI/180),size:n.textSize(e,a,f),textAlign:u([r.textAlign,"start"],l,d)}},update:function(t,e,a){var r,i,l,s=null,d=this._index;o.options.resolve([e.display,!0],a,d)&&(r=a.dataset.data[d],i=o.valueOrDefault(o.callback(e.formatter,[r,a]),r),s=(l=o.isNullOrUndef(i)?[]:n.toTextLines(i)).length?this._modelize(t,l,e,a):null),this._model=s},draw:function(t){var e,a,r,i,l,s,d,u,f,h,c,y,g,x,b=this._model;b&&b.opacity&&(r=b.size,i=b.padding,l=r.height,s=r.width,u=-l/2,e={frame:{x:(d=-s/2)-i.left,y:u-i.top,w:s+i.width,h:l+i.height},text:{x:d,y:u,w:s,h:l}},a=function(t,e,n){var a=e.positioner(t._view,e.anchor,e.align,e.origin),r=a.vx,i=a.vy;if(!r&&!i)return{x:a.x,y:a.y};var o=e.borderWidth||0,l=n.w+2*o,s=n.h+2*o,d=e.rotation,u=Math.abs(l/2*Math.cos(d))+Math.abs(s/2*Math.sin(d)),f=Math.abs(l/2*Math.sin(d))+Math.abs(s/2*Math.cos(d)),h=1/Math.max(Math.abs(r),Math.abs(i));return u*=r*h,f*=i*h,u+=e.offset*r,f+=e.offset*i,{x:a.x+u,y:a.y+f}}(this._el,b,e.frame),t.save(),t.globalAlpha=n.bound(0,b.opacity,1),t.translate(Math.round(a.x),Math.round(a.y)),t.rotate(b.rotation),f=t,h=e.frame,y=(c=b).backgroundColor,g=c.borderColor,x=c.borderWidth,(y||g&&x)&&(f.beginPath(),o.canvas.roundedRect(f,Math.round(h.x)-x/2,Math.round(h.y)-x/2,Math.round(h.w)+x,Math.round(h.h)+x,c.borderRadius),f.closePath(),y&&(f.fillStyle=y,f.fill()),g&&x&&(f.strokeStyle=g,f.lineWidth=x,f.lineJoin="miter",f.stroke())),function(t,e,n,a){var r,i,o,l=a.textAlign,s=a.font.lineHeight,d=a.color,u=e.length;if(u&&d)for(r=n.x,i=n.y+s/2,"center"===l?r+=n.w/2:"end"!==l&&"right"!==l||(r+=n.w),t.font=a.font.string,t.fillStyle=d,t.textAlign=l,t.textBaseline="middle",o=0;o<u;++o)t.fillText(e[o],Math.round(r),Math.round(i),Math.round(n.w)),i+=s}(t,b.lines,e.text,b),t.restore())}});var s=t.helpers,d={align:"center",anchor:"center",backgroundColor:null,borderColor:null,borderRadius:0,borderWidth:0,color:void 0,display:!0,font:{family:void 0,lineHeight:1.2,size:void 0,style:void 0,weight:null},offset:4,opacity:1,padding:{top:4,right:4,bottom:4,left:4},rotation:0,textAlign:"start",formatter:function(t){if(s.isNullOrUndef(t))return null;var e,n,a,r=t;if(s.isObject(t))if(s.isNullOrUndef(t.label))if(s.isNullOrUndef(t.r))for(r="",a=0,n=(e=Object.keys(t)).length;a<n;++a)r+=(0!==a?", ":"")+e[a]+": "+t[e[a]];else r=t.r;else r=t.label;return""+r}},u=t.helpers,f="$datalabels";t.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels=d,t.plugins.register({id:"datalabels",afterDatasetUpdate:function(t,e,n){var a,r,i,o,s,d=t.data.datasets[e.index],h=(a=n,!1===(r=d.datalabels)?null:(!0===r&&(r={}),u.merge({},[a,r]))),c=e.meta.data||[],y=c.length,g=t.ctx;for(g.save(),i=0;i<y;++i)(o=c[i])&&!o.hidden?(s=new l(o,i)).update(g,h,{chart:t,dataIndex:i,dataset:d,datasetIndex:e.index}):s=null,o[f]=s;g.restore()},afterDatasetDraw:function(t,e){var n,a,r=e.meta.data||[],i=r.length;for(n=0;n<i;++n)(a=r[n][f])&&a.draw(t.ctx)}})});</script><div id="loading"><span id="loading-wrapper">Loading...</span></div><div id="fullpage-msg"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 111.577 111.577"><path d="M78.962,99.536l-1.559,6.373c-4.677,1.846-8.413,3.251-11.195,4.217c-2.785,0.969-6.021,1.451-9.708,1.451c-5.662,0-10.066-1.387-13.207-4.142c-3.141-2.766-4.712-6.271-4.712-10.523c0-1.646,0.114-3.339,0.351-5.064c0.239-1.727,0.619-3.672,1.139-5.846l5.845-20.688c0.52-1.981,0.962-3.858,1.316-5.633c0.359-1.764,0.532-3.387,0.532-4.848c0-2.642-0.547-4.49-1.636-5.529c-1.089-1.036-3.167-1.562-6.252-1.562c-1.511,0-3.064,0.242-4.647,0.71c-1.59,0.47-2.949,0.924-4.09,1.346l1.563-6.378c3.829-1.559,7.489-2.894,10.99-4.002c3.501-1.111,6.809-1.667,9.938-1.667c5.623,0,9.962,1.359,13.009,4.077c3.047,2.72,4.57,6.246,4.57,10.591c0,0.899-0.1,2.483-0.315,4.747c-0.21,2.269-0.601,4.348-1.171,6.239l-5.82,20.605c-0.477,1.655-0.906,3.547-1.279,5.676c-0.385,2.115-0.569,3.731-0.569,4.815c0,2.736,0.61,4.604,1.833,5.597c1.232,0.993,3.354,1.487,6.368,1.487c1.415,0,3.025-0.251,4.814-0.744C76.854,100.348,78.155,99.915,78.962,99.536z M80.438,13.03c0,3.59-1.353,6.656-4.072,9.177c-2.712,2.53-5.98,3.796-9.803,3.796c-3.835,0-7.111-1.266-9.854-3.796c-2.738-2.522-4.11-5.587-4.11-9.177c0-3.583,1.372-6.654,4.11-9.207C59.447,1.274,62.729,0,66.563,0c3.822,0,7.091,1.277,9.803,3.823C79.087,6.376,80.438,9.448,80.438,13.03z"/></svg> Click the "Full page" link in the top right for vastly superior experience</div><div class="warn template">&#9888; <a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/{id}">This answer</a> by {cop} is not formatted correctly ({reason}).</div><table><thead><tr><th colspan="5"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 9 9"><path class="right-arrow" d="M 0 0 L 0 9 L 9 4.5 Z"/><path class="down-arrow" d="M 0 0 L 9 0 L 4.5 9 Z"/></svg> Uncracked answers</th></tr></thead><tbody id="uncracked"><tr><th colspan="3" onclick="showAnswers(answersUncracked, 'uncracked', sortByCop)" class="clickable">Posted by</th><th onclick="showAnswers(answersUncracked, 'uncracked', sortBySize)" class="clickable">Size</th><th onclick="showAnswers(answersUncracked, 'uncracked', sortByTime)" class="clickable">Safe in</th><th>Code</th></tr><tr class="empty inactive"><th colspan="5">There are no uncracked answers</th></tr><tr class="template"><td colspan="3"><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/{cop_id}">{cop_user}</a></td><td>{size} bytes</td><td><span class="countdown" data-target="{safe_on}"></span></td><td><code>{code}</code></td></tr></tbody><thead><tr><th colspan="5"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 9 9"><path class="right-arrow" d="M 0 0 L 0 9 L 9 4.5 Z"/><path class="down-arrow" d="M 0 0 L 9 0 L 4.5 9 Z"/></svg> Cracked answers</th></tr></thead><tbody id="cracked"><tr><th onclick="showAnswers(answersCracked, 'cracked', sortByCop)" class="clickable">Posted by</th><th onclick="showAnswers(answersCracked, 'cracked', sortByRobber)" class="clickable">Cracked by</th><th onclick="showAnswers(answersCracked, 'cracked', sortByLanguage)" class="clickable">Language</th><th onclick="showAnswers(answersCracked, 'cracked', sortBySize)" class="clickable">Size</th><th onclick="showAnswers(answersCracked, 'cracked', sortByLiveTime)" class="clickable">Cracked after</th><th>Code</th></tr><tr class="empty inactive"><th colspan="5">There are no cracked answers</th></tr><tr class="template"><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/{cop_id}">{cop_user}</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/{robber_id}">{robber_user}</a></td><td>{language}</td><td>{size} bytes</td><td>{cracked_after_str}</td><td><code>{code}</code></td></tr></tbody><thead><tr><th colspan="5"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 9 9"><path class="right-arrow" d="M 0 0 L 0 9 L 9 4.5 Z"/><path class="down-arrow" d="M 0 0 L 9 0 L 4.5 9 Z"/></svg> Safe answers</th></tr></thead><tbody id="safe"><tr><th colspan="2" onclick="showAnswers(answersSafe, 'safe', sortByCop)" class="clickable">Posted by</th><th onclick="showAnswers(answersSafe, 'safe', sortByLanguage)" class="clickable">Language</th><th colspan="2" onclick="showAnswers(answersSafe, 'safe', sortBySize)" class="clickable">Size</th><th>Code</th></tr><tr class="empty inactive"><th colspan="5">There are no safe answers</th></tr><tr class="template"><td colspan="2"><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/{cop_id}">{cop_user}</a></td><td>{language}</td><td colspan="2">{size} bytes</td><td><code>{code}</code></td></tr></tbody></table><div id="stats-header"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 9 9"><path class="right-arrow" d="M 0 0 L 0 9 L 9 4.5 Z"/><path class="down-arrow" d="M 0 0 L 9 0 L 4.5 9 Z"/></svg> Statistics</div><div id="stats"><div><canvas id="robber-stats"/></div><div><canvas id="answer-stats"/></div></div><small>Snippet made by <a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/55934/" target="_blank">NieDzejkob</a>, licensed as <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY-SA</a>. "Info" icon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/chanut" target="_blank">Chanut</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" target="_blank">Flaticon</a>, licensed as <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a>. "Arrow" icons made by <a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/12012/" target="_blank">Dennis</a> for <a href="https://tio.run/" target="_blank">Try It Online</a>, licensed as <a href="https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/LICENSE" target="_blank">MIT</a>. Some code shamelessly copy-pasted from <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450">this answer</a> on Stack Overflow by <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/u/24950">Robert K</a>, licensed as <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC 3.0 BY-SA</a>. This snippet utilises <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a> (<a href="https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/LICENSE.txt">MIT</a>), <a href="http://www.chartjs.org/">chart.js</a> (<a href="https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md">MIT</a>) and <a href="https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/">chartjs-plugin-datalabels</a> (<a href="https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/blob/master/LICENSE.md">MIT</a>). Color scheme: <a href="http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized">Solarized by Ethan Schoonover</a> (<a href="https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/LICENSE">MIT</a>).</small>
```

#### Formatting

*(Feel free to skip this section if you're not planning to participate as a cop)*

This is **required** for new cop answers to make it possible for the snippet above to parse them.

- New answers should include a header like this:

  ```
  # ???, [N] bytes
  ```

  where `[N]` is the size of your code in bytes and `???` should appear literally.
- If the answer is not cracked for 7 days and you want to make your answer safe by revealing the language, simply replace the `???` and add `safe` to the end, e.g.

  ```
  # Ruby, [N] bytes, safe
  ```

  Feel free to have the language name link to a relevant website like an esolangs page or a GitHub repository. The link will then be displayed in the leaderboard.
- If another user successfully cracked your submission, please also add the language, along with a notice like

  ```
  # Ruby, [N] bytes, [cracked](crack-link) by [user]
  ```

  where `[user]` is the name of the user who submitted the first valid crack, and `crack-link` is a link to the corresponding answer in the Robbers' thread. Please use the short link format you get from the "share" button. Feel free to make the user name a link to their profile page.

  If the language used in the crack is different from the one you intended, your answer is still cracked, and you shall follow this format. However, you can  mention in the answer that you intended it to be something else. It's your choice on whether you want to reveal the intended answer, or if you want to let Robbers have more fun.

**Good luck Cops!**

Comment: [How not to compete in this challenge.](https://tio.run/##bY/BasMwDIbveYr/tmv6BnNTtRa1rWDJHTmWbbDBcKF5fzJnsENLLjpI//996Hqvt5@P92Vhe1GolzfjSJ2nCYPPrBadwjIRvufwOc/2da27vu8mKVAyFEUZ8ZoEY5Z9oChb3fqU7zs1Hs5wWUo6PKFPLWYC89QwMo6UW99TJrAiTuB0YXPGktp@DTfgrqMk5eRhLpy7dfwjvGuCugV9tG4L1ktoVTkeoRIJauQi9pRS29YH6@A5hL9HvbtQy1CCUY6cnNFhWX4B)

Comment: Note that if you're using a language with an interpreter on TIO, all someone has to do to crack your submission is try every language on TIO.

Comment: @mbomb007 Take a look at [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers#comment378380_155019) comment. Aside from requesting that Robbers don't brute-force, there is nothing more that we can do to prevent this behaviour unfortunately. However, I invite anyone to downvote Robbers using scripts to brute-force submissions as it contradicts the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: If a submission is written in a language (say C), but it only works in a specific compiler (say ELVM 8cc), does the compiler have to have a wikipedia/rosettacode/esolangs page, or is it only required for the language itself?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'd say that the compiler has to be on Wikipedia/Rosetta Code/Esolangs or be on TIO.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Both answers that inspired me to ask that question are a gray area: [This Beatnik answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155052) only works in some interpreters, and none of them have their own page. However, a working interpreter is linked on the esolangs page. In the case of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155533), the language is installed on TIO, but it's not listed on the language list. These answers have already been cracked, but I think that the rules should be modified to be unambigous in the future.

Comment: Also, what about languages that have a free interpreter, but the interpreter requires other, commercial software? Is the ruling different for Windows-only software that does not work in wine or mono?

Comment: @NieDzejkob In the case of the Beatnik answer, the interpreter used was linked on the esolangs page, so I'd say it's completely fine. The C answer, however, doesn't meet the first criteria, so I'd have to say it's invalid. Free means that anyone is available to use it without having to pay to do so.

Comment: @caird I understand that you are talking about free as in beer. However, is the operating system included, or is it an exception? This *could* be important for [the AutoHotkey answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155297), for example (I haven't tried wine, mono, nor ReactOS)

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'll say that the operating system is not included in the 'free' requirement.

Comment: Somebody compete in Piet please.

Comment: Is my safe answer invalid

Comment: Does the leading/trailing character rule apply to codepoint output?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'll say no (codepoint outputs can have any leading or trailing characters, same as the other output forms), because it might invalid a number of answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 6 bytes, safe

```lisp
}%*xg2
```

Output is in decimal.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BN09BvVZVqyLdSF3BTsHQwECvOCkzj0s/v6BEvzi1OL8YQoJk/v8HAA)

Sesos can be written in either binary or assembly format. The assembly file that generated the binary file above follows.

```lisp
set mask
set numout

fwd 1, add 44

nop
	fwd 1, add 1, put
	rwd 1, sub 3
jnz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K04tzi/@/784tUQhN7E4mwvEyCvNzS8t4eJKK09RMNRRSExJUTAx4eLKyy/g4kQSA1IFQGWcRRCh4tIkBWOurLyq//8B)

It took some odd choices (a useless `fwd 1`, a `nop` that could have been a `jmp`, `add 44` and `sub 3` instead of `add 100` and `sub 1`), but I managed to create a binary file consisting solely of printable ASCII characters (so it wouldn't look like a binary file).

Answer (score 56):

## [Beatnik](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik), 114 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155510/66833) by [Johannes Griebler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78164/johannes-griebler)

```
Mit' tää kauniina kelaa?
Mil tää öisin pelaa?
Sun suu kauniina sanoo:
Kroohhpyyh-ZZZ-ZZZZ Z
Nukuttaapi kovin!
```

It's a poem in Finnish! And a program. It prints the numbers as bytes.

English translation:

```
What does that beautiful think?
What does it play at night?
Your beautiful mouth says:
(snoring) ZZZ ZZZ
I feel very sleepy!
```

---

I'm surprised it took this long to crack this, especially as the another Beatnik submission was cracked quickly.

This does not work with the Python interpreter (used in TIO) because of the way it handles special characters. It considers `Kroohhpyyh-ZZZ-ZZZZ` to be three different words, while it should be interpreted as one big. Use the C interpreter to run this.

Explanation:

```
Mit' tää                   | Push 1
kauniina kelaa?            | Duplicate and print
Mil tää                    | Push 1
öisin                      | Nop
pelaa?                     | Pop 2 and push their sum
Sun suu                    | Nop
kauniina                   | Duplicate
sanoo: Kroohhpyyh-ZZZ-ZZZZ | Push 101
Z                          | Subtract
Nukuttaapi kovin!          | Jump 12 words backwards (to the first "kauniina")
```

Comment: Dang, I fell for that trap.

Comment: You love the Finnish language, nice one, making us think Tampio! (No clue what language it is)

Comment: Those "Z"s look suspicious...

Comment: Apparently in Finnish you snore with more Z's than in English...

Comment: What does this output as? (e.g. raw bytes, decimal separated by newline, etc)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155510/66833) by [Johannes Griebler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78164/johannes-griebler)

Comment: This is really Beatnik? The TIO interpreter must not be compliant.... I think pretty much everyone tried it

Comment: @quartata I knew people wouldn't bother to install the C interpreter. That's why I made sure that this program does not work in TIO. :P

Comment: Nice workaround of the rules...

Comment: Looks like I got an advantage from not knowing TIO until know. The C interpreter was the first one linked from esolangs, so I tried that.

Comment: Translating poetry is always precarious, but I have to say the English translation loses a lot of the, eh, poetic ambience.

Answer (score 26):

## [8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file), 58 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155096) by [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)

```
huCX5DBP^h~0_GG1<h32X542P[18F18h42X%AAP[h!.X%OOS`M a@<euws
```

I/O format: raw characters

### Explanation

The basic program looks like this:

```
    mov ax, 0x0e01 ; <b8><01><0e>
    xor bx, bx     ; <31><db>
_loop:
    pusha          ; `
    int 0x10       ; <cd><10>
    popa           ; a
    inc al         ; <fe><c0>
    cmp al, 101    ; <e
    jne _loop      ; u<f6>
    ret            ; <c3>
```

However, this variant uses many unprintable characters, which would be a big hint. Fortunately, some printable instructions include:

```
and ax, imm16    %
xor [si], di     1<
xor [si+bx], di  18
xor ax, imm16    5
inc r16          @ABCDEFG
dec r16          HIJKLMNO
push r16         PQRSTUVW
pop r16          XYZ[\]^_
cmp al, imm8     <
pusha            `
popa             a
push imm16       h
```

First, to avoid the unprintable characters caused by `inc al`, I used `inc ax` instead, since an overflow is not expected. Then I found a way to initialize AX and BX at the beginning with just printable characters.

```
    push 0x3234     ; h42
    pop ax          ; X
    and ax, 0x4141  ; %AA
    push ax         ; P
    pop bx          ; [

    push 0x2e21     ; h!.
    pop ax          ; X
    and ax, 0x4F4F  ; %OO
_loop:
    pusha           ; `
    int 0x10        ; <cd><10>
    popa            ; a
    inc ax          ; @
    cmp al, 101     ; <e
    jne _loop       ; u<f6>
    ret             ; <c3>
```

Then, I employed self modifying code to fix the unprintables in `int 0x10`. That instruction in the final program resides at 0x0131, which is the value in SI these 5 instructions get me:

```
    push 0x4375     ; huC
    pop ax          ; X
    xor ax, 0x4244  ; 5DB
    push ax         ; P
    pop si          ; ^
```

Then, I found the best way to get the value of 0x10cd (x86 is little endian) is to xor 0x3080 with 0x204d:

```
    push 0x307e   ; h~0
    pop di        ; _
    inc di        ; G
    inc di        ; G
    xor [si], di  ; 1

    ; ...

    pusha         ; `
    dw 0x204d     ; M<space>
    popa          ; a
```

Then, I used the same XOR value two more times, on the two final bytes in the program.

```
    push 0x3233     ; h32
    pop ax          ; X
    xor ax, 0x3234  ; 542
    push ax         ; P
    pop bx ; BX = 7 ; [

    xor [si+bx], di ; 18
    inc si          ; F
    xor [si+bx], di ; 18

    ; ...

    cmp al, 101     ; <e
    db 0x75 ; jnz   ; u
    dw 0x7377
```

First 0x7377 is xored with 0x3080 to get 0x43f7. Then 0x??43 (some garbage byte at 0x013a) ^ 0x3080 = 0x??c3, which sets the two final bytes to the correct values.

Comment: [COM file](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155096/44718)?

Answer (score 26):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 62 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155107/77759) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
i=100 while(i>0){p(100-i+"d")!}i=%<>--1;if(_@==0){_@=-100}end;
```

Prints decimals separated by a single lowercase d.

I'd be impressed if this works in any unintended language.

Since this has already been cracked, here is the actually executed code:

```
    i = 1 0 0      * equal to 105100, just has to be above 0 for the first number
   . . . . . .
  . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . .
" ) ! } i = % < >  * prints the number and stops if i % 100 == 0
 . . . . . . . _
  @ . . . . . .
   . . . . . .
    } . . d ;      * prints "d" and stores 100 in the memory edge
```

Everything else is a no-op, denoted by `.`.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155107/68615)

Answer (score 20):

## [???](http://esolangs.org/wiki/%3F%3F%3F), 1167 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155785/12012) by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

```
The Man They Called Dennis (a song).

Dennis: a extremely decent golfer.
PPCG: a group of golfers.

Act I: Chorus.
[Enter Dennis]
"Dennis;
The man they call Dennis.
He took inspiration from J and he made the lang Jelly.
Stood up to the challenges and gave 'em what for.
Our love for him now ain't hard to explain.
The Hero of PPCG: the man they call Dennis."
[Exeunt]

Act 2: Verse 1
[Enter Dennis, PPCG.]
Now Dennis saw PPCG's backs breakin';
He saw PPCG's lament.....
And he saw that challenge takin'
Every answer and leaving no votes
So he said "You can't do this to my people; You can't let long language's answers win your challenges.
And Dennis booted up TIO! - and in five seconds flat,
FGITWed, all your challenges."
[Exeunt]

Act 2: Chorus - revised, since my program is ending soon
[Enter Dennis]
"He took inspiration from J and he made the lang Jelly
Stood up to Python - and gave 'em what for
Our love for him now ain't hard to explain
The Hero of PPCG, the man they call Dennis (song slows with a dramatic high note finish)"
[Exeunt]

With thanks to Dennis for providing a character for this program, and Jayne Cobb for being the original Hero of Canton.
```

Honestly not sure how long this is going to last, but it was quite fun.

Comment: [This is ???.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155785/12012)

Comment: I thought it was shakespeare

Comment: @tfbninja it makes no sense in shakespeare and likely errors out. I haven't tested it. Shakespeare requires you to use only actual characters as well, I doubt that Dennis was part of that. :)

Comment: Yeah it does error out, I had just stumbled on shakespeare before and this reminded me of it.

Comment: @tfbninja yep, that was intentional.

Comment: +1 for the Firefly reference.

Answer (score 19):

## [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace), 369 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155749/76162) by [Adyrem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77759/adyrem)

```
def v(n=[]): #[	  		  	  

  #!"⠖⠔⠄⠑⠃⡆⠊⡬⠀⠞⠈⠀
 #;;;
   	 print(n*chr(33)) 		  	 	
 
for		n in range(100):	
   #
   #"	     
	#"<<;?)*aanlll>1#<-#.:_:*aa@#.#!9fo"
     	v(n)
	>d$/")!;\    
 
		 xXxxxXXXxXXxX>({.<
 xx%c++=t=+~\

   D.+L0~-tt/	  	
	..R;MU
     	]+@x+++++++++[->++++++++++<]>
	    [->+[->+>.<<]>
 [-<+>]
		<.<
]

~-<:<<<<:<||~[:?~-]|
```

This is a polyglot in at least 9 languages, but only one should work. Goooooood luck!

Hint:

> The output format is unary

---

Welp. That was cracked fast.

For reference, the 9 languages were:

- Whitespace (the intended language: outputs in unary spaces separated by tabs)

  - This was intended to be both a fake red herring and ironic, as the output would be completely invisible.
- Python (the clue: would work up to 99 `!`s, but fails due to `inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` ;) )
- Hexagony (prints the numbers separated by their character codes)
- Befunge-98 (prints the 100 numbers backwards)
- ><> (prints odd numbers starting from 10)
- Cardinal (prints 1 through 99)
- brainfuck (prints in unary separated by the character codes)
- Wise (prints *negative* 1 through 100)
- and Braille (prints character codes 1 through 99)

Comment: What's the output format?

Comment: @Adyrem added it

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155749/77759)

Comment: +1 almost skipped over Whitespace because I "didn't get any output"

Answer (score 18):

## [ETA](http://www.miketaylor.org.uk/tech/eta/doc/), 83 bytes, safe

```
n = "e";
is n equh one hundre-
SNACK?! 0v0
   _   M-<
  / \_/
HA|E SNAKE!!! >:(
  T
```

Another one that's more ASCII art than code (though this one should be harder to crack). Outputs in ASCII codepoints.

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy1J/P8/T8FWQSlVyZors1ghTyG1sDRDIT8vVSGjNC@lKFWXK9jP0dnbXlHBoMyAS0FBIR6IfXVtgEx9hZh4fS4PxxpXBaAab1dFRUUFOysNoEzI//8A)

ETA uses the 8 commands `ETAOINSH` (case-insensitive), and ignores everything else. The executing code here is:

```
ne
isnehonehne
SNA
HAE SNAE
T
```

Which means:

```
ne  Push 0 to the stack
is  Increment the top value (get input, where EOF is -1, and subtract)
neh  Duplicate the current value
o    Output the character
neh  Duplicate the top value
ne S   No-op (push 0 and subtract)
NA HAE Push 100
S      Subtract 100 from the current value
NAE    Push 1
T      Pop value and jump to line 1 if the value is not 0
```

Comment: `HA|E TRYING TO CRACK THIS!!! >:(`

Answer (score 18):

## MATL, 46 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155236/31516) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
Flatten[{1,100}] (* From x: 1 To 100: huhu% *)
```

I had fun trying to make this look somewhat like Mathematica, and trying to keep it fairly non-obvious. I only know two languages, so cracking it was probably not that hard.

#### Explanation:

```
F                  % Push False (0)
 l                 % ones. Stack: 0, 1
  a                % any. Stack: 0, 1
   tt              % duplicate last element twice. Stack: 0, 1, 1, 1
     e             % Reshape, last element reshaped into 1 row/column
                   % Stack: 0, 1, 1
      n            % numel of last element on stack. Stack: 0, 1, 1
 [                 % Opening bracket for creating array
  {                % Opening bracket for creating cell array
   1,100           % Push 1, 100
        }]         % Closing brackets. Stack: 0, 1, 1, 1, 100
(                  % Assignment indexing. Put a 1 in the 100th place of the variable above
                   % Stack: 0, [1, 0, ... (98 x 0) ... ,0 ,1]
 *                 % Multiply 0 by array. Stack: [0, 0, ... 0]
  F                % Push False (0). Stack: [0, 0, ... 0], 0
   r               % Push random number. Stack: [0, 0, ... 0], 0, 0.2431
    o              % Convert last number to double. Stack unaltered.
     m             % ismember. Stack: [0, 0, ... 0], 0
       x           % Delete last element on stack. Stack: [0, 0, ... 0]
        :          % Range to 0. Stack is empty.

1                 % Push 1 
  T               % Push True (1)
   o              % Convert to double. Stack: 1, 1
     100          % Push 100. Stack: 1, 1, 100
        :         % Range to 100. Stack: 1, 1, [1, 2, 3 ... 100]

huhu              % Horizontal concatenation and unique twice.
                  % Stack: [1, 2, 3 ... 100]
     % *)         % Comment to complete the Mathematica syntax comment.
```

Comment: [This is MATL.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155236/68615)

Comment: You are taking MATL to unknown levels of expressiveness

Answer (score 17):

## Curry PAKCS, 57 bytes, [cracked by Potato44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155327/56656)

```
f[]=""
f([x]++s)=show x++" "++f s
main=putStr(f[1..100])
```

Looks like Haskell but it doesn't run in Haskell.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I am telling the truth when I say it's not Haskell (at least my intended solution is not).

Comment: @EsolangingFruit It's also not an optimal solution. I have a shorter solution but I like this one better.  Happy hunting!

Comment: I was hoping this worked in Curry (it's a logic language and supports patterns like `[x]++s`), but you need to `import IO` to use `putStr` and it also doesn't seem to have `..` for ranges.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155327/69655). This was Curry but it needs a proper curry interpreter such as PAKCS

Answer (score 17):

## [Whirl](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Whirl/), 3905 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155375/69655) by [Potato44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69655/potato44)

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111   $\       |
|000110011000111100011100100/010 0010 %p0-d% 0+{10000/111    |
|111000100111110001001000011 / 1111000100111110001001  frick |
|000 {01111110001(( 001111100010010000 1111110001()\ () !    |
|001111100010010000111 111000100111 1100010010000111111000100|
|111110001001(0000111)11100010011111!}000100100001111110001  |
|0011111|_0001001000011111100010011111 000100100001111110 001|
|001111100010010000111#1110001 001111100010010000111111000100|
|11111 H) /!00010010000111 1/1 100/0100111110001001000       |
| 011111100  & 01001111100010010000  111111000100111110001001|
|@  00001 11111000100111110 00100100001 111110 001001 111    |
| 1000 1001000011 11110 00100111110001001000011111100010  the|
|the 01111 100010010000111 111000 1001 111100010010 00011111 |
|1000100JO   1111100 010010000111 +=   11100010 011 11 KING  |
| 1000100100001 11111000100111110001 "0010000111111000100111 |
|110001001000011 11110 00100127  : 1111000100100 001   1     |
|11   11000100  11111000100100001111110001001111100010010000 |
|11111100 a  01001111100010  010000111111   000100111        |
| 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1|
|00 01 00 10 00 01 11 11 10 00 10 01 11 11 00 01 00 10 00 01 |
| 111 110 001 001 111 100 010 010 000 111 111 000 100 111 110|
|0010 0100 0011 1111 0001 0011 1110 0010 0100 0011 1111 0001 |
| 00111 11000 10010 00011 11110 00100 11111 00010 01000 01111|
|110001 001111 100010 010000 111111 000100 111110 001001     |
| 0000111 1110001 0011111 0001001 0000111 1110001 0011111    |
|00010010 00011111 10001001 11110001 00100001 11111000       |
| 100111110 001001000 011111100 010011111 000100100 001111110|
|0010011111 0001001000 0111111000 1001111100 0100100001      |
|                      ^1111100010^                          |
|0 111110001001000011111100010011111000100100001111110001    |
|0011111000100100001111110001001111100010010000111111000100  |
|  111110001001000011111100010011111000100100001111110001001 |
|   111100010010000111111000100111110001001000011111100010   |
| 0111110001001000011111100010011111000100100001111110001    |
|0011111000100100001111110001001111100010010000111111000100  |
|  1111100010010000111111000100111110001001000011111100010011|
|11100010010000 111111000100111110001001000011111100010011   |
|11100010010 00011111100010011111000100100001111110001001    |
|11110001+ 00100001111110' 001001111 10001001000011111100010 |
| 011111000100100001  1111100 010011  11100010010 00011      |
|1111JKL5 000100111110   0010010000   11111  1000   10011    |
|111 J 6700010010000111111^& E 00010011 L  11100 L 0 Y? bin  |
|100[print()100001111110   -001001111100010010000111]  111000|
|100 not 1111100 BRAIN010010000 FU1111 11000100CK  111110001 |
| rk:start 0010 0001111110001001 1111  0001001000011111100   |
|0100111110 dckx 001001  000011111  1000100111  11000100 help|
|100001 111110001001111100010010000111111000 1001111100010010|
|000-[111111000100??11111000100100001>1111100 {x=0-100}px    |
|111110001 00100001  11111000100111110 0010010000111111000100|
|1111 1000100100 +++001111  110001 0011111000  100100001 1111|
|100010  011111000100100001111<-1100010011111000100 10000111 |
|111 eval('\b00010011111000100100001111')-110001001--1111000-|
|1001000011]1111000100111110001001000011111100  010011111000 |
|10 +01>0000111 1  1 100 01001 1111 0001001 000011--1111  -  |
|0001001111100010010000111111000 1001111100010010000111111000|
|10011[111-0 0 01001000011 11110001001111100  010   010000111|
|111000 <100  1111100+010010 00 0.11111100010011111000100100 |
|001111110001001111100010>0100001111110001001111100010010000 |
|011000101010010101010111000000101011001]010100101010000 1010|
|111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111|
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is either going to be cracked really fast or not at all.

> This had a lot of red herrings. Totallyhuman fell for the brainfuck one, which outputs every number except 1. Nhohnhehr has a valid 60 by 60 room, and it outputs in bits, but it outputs garbage. Brain-Flak has a few suspicious brackets etc...
> But Whirl is the intended language. This language only cares about 1s and 0s, and since I couldn't figure out loops, I just hardcoded adding one, printing, adding one etc., 100 times.

Comment: @totallyhuman How many tries have you made before the correct one? {**edit**: still wrong} (remember one-guess rule)

Comment: @user202729 I tried only brainfuck.

Comment: What's wrong with the output? (I'm on mobile and I don't have good testing conditions and I'm not very observant either. :P)

Comment: @totallyhuman It's missing the ascii code point for 1

Comment: What's the output format?

Comment: Love this one. So many red herrings

Comment: Is it [Fortuna](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fortuna)? I can't find an interpreter.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155375/69655). The mention of Fortuna reminded me of Whirl.

Comment: @Potato44 Haha awww man I tried Whirl but thought it was the same output as brainfuck!!! Nice job

Answer (score 16):

## [Z80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80) [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), 242 bytes, safe

Reposted, this time with a specified output format.

The code contains a... few unprintable characters, so here's the reversible `xxd`:

```
00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
00000010: 0000 000a 0000 000a 0803 0000 01cd eb0f  ................
00000020: 1900 0000 5450 4c54 451e 010e 02cd 0500  ....TPLTE.......
00000030: 212a 0134 3e65 be20 f0c7 0000 0000 0000  !*.4>e. ........
00000040: c080 0000 c000 00ff 0000 c000 c0ff 00ff  ................
00000050: 0080 0000 8080 8080 0000 c000 00c0 c0c0  ................
00000060: c000 00ff 00c0 c0ff 00ff ffff c0c0 ffff  ................
00000070: 00c0 ffc0 c0ff ffff ffff 0000 ffc0 8cf4  ................
00000080: 0b00 0000 5949 4441 5408 d735 ca41 12c2  ....YIDAT..5.A..
00000090: 300c 04c1 3d4d 1283 1209 61e4 90ff ff13  0...=M....a.....
000000a0: 4315 7be8 dac3 a877 9969 5329 63d5 ddd5  C.{....w.iS)c...
000000b0: 5eaa 4535 c22f adc9 30c5 6da1 8bb9 e327  ^.E5./..0.m....'
000000c0: 7fcb a7c6 1bdc 69a6 469c c120 51d2 67f2  ......i.F.. Q.g.
000000d0: a4be c163 de13 43bb 991d 49db f900 2114  ...c..C...I...!.
000000e0: 04cf a503 d231 0000 0000 4945 4e44 ae42  .....1....IEND.B
000000f0: 6082                                     `.
```

Output format: raw characters.

---

This is a valid PNG, that when enlarged looks like this:

[image: image representation of code]

This image is at the same time a Piet program and a Brainloller program, thanks to the upper left pixel, which is valid in both languages. In Piet, the instruction pointer moves between regions of pixels of the same color, and the differences in the color between regions encode instructions. This means that in Piet, you can start from any color. In Brainloller, it's just the colors of the pixels that are used to encode instructions. Therefore, I chose to start from cyan, which rotates the instruction pointer clockwise in Brainloller, making this polyglot trivial.

As you now know, both of these graphical programs were traps - I hoped at least one robber would state them as their guess, making it less likely that this answer will get cracked. Piet prints numbers 1 through 100, but as decimal integers, not as the raw characters specified. When I first posted this, I forgot to specify this, making it trivial. On the other hand, Brainloller starts at two. Since these are raw characters, I was hoping that someone wouldn't notice. As H.PWiz said, this should not be interpreted as a PNG.

First, I wrote the programs in Piet and Brainloller, as well as the CP/M program, which looks like this:

```
loop:
    ld e, 1         ; system call: output a character
    ld c, 2
    call 5
    ld hl, loop + 1 ; increment the immediate byte of the first instruction
    inc (hl)
    ld a, 101       ; if it's not 101 yet, loop
    cp a, (hl)
    jr nz, loop
    rst 0           ; otherwise, exit
```

Then, I looked at various image formats, and I've found PNG to be the easiest to work with. A PNG consists of a magic number and a sequence of blocks. The program you see above resides in the palette block. At first I wanted to just place the palette block first, to make it easier for the execution to slide through all that nonsense, but the IHDR block has to be first. As it turns out, the image header of a 10x10 indexed PNG does not contain any instructions that write to memory or change control flow... until the CRC of the IHDR block. However, I remembered that the byte 0x01 is a 16-bit load immediate, which could help. The last byte before the CRC was an interlaced flag, so I flipped it, looked at the new checksum and concluded that this will work.

I was trying many different tools to insert the program into the palette. I found in the specification, that the palette block was designed by a sane person, which means that it just lists all the colors, with one byte per channel, R G B R G B R G B. I was starting to dig through the documentation of the Python Imaging Library, when I realised that it should be possible to do this with the GUI of GIMP.

I lied about the load address to the assembler program to get it the addresses embedded in it right. I grouped the bytes of the program in groups of three to get 6 color codes. In GIMP, I converted the image to indexed, created a read-write copy of its palette, converted it back to RGB, added the 6 new colors one by one then painstakingly copied all the colors at the beginning of the palette to the end and deleted the originals, because in GIMP you can't just move the colors. At the end, I converted the image to indexed again with a set palette, and after marking a few checkboxes to prevent GIMP from removing unused colors, I was done.

---

To test this on an emulator:

- Download [z80pack](http://www.autometer.de/unix4fun/z80pack/ftp/z80pack-1.36.tgz)
- Extract the tarball

  ```
  ~/tmp/z80$ tar xf z80pack-1.36.tgz
  ```
- Compile the emulator

  ```
  ~/tmp/z80$ cd z80pack-1.36/cpmsim/srcsim
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim/srcsim$ make -f Makefile.linux
  [...]
  ```
- Compile the support tools

  ```
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim/srcsim$ cd ../srctools
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim/srctools$ make
  [...]
  ```
- Fire up CP/M

  ```
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim/srctools$ cd ..
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim$ ./cpm13

  #######  #####    ###            #####    ###   #     #
       #  #     #  #   #          #     #    #    ##   ##
      #   #     # #     #         #          #    # # # #
     #     #####  #     #  #####   #####     #    #  #  #
    #     #     # #     #               #    #    #     #
   #      #     #  #   #          #     #    #    #     #
  #######  #####    ###            #####    ###   #     #

  Release 1.36, Copyright (C) 1987-2017 by Udo Munk

  CPU speed is unlimited

  Booting...

  63K CP/M VERS. 1.3 (8080 CBIOS V1.0 FOR Z80SIM, COPYRIGHT 2014 BY UDO MUNK)

  A>
  ```
- Copy the xxd above, and in another window, convert it back to a binary file

  ```
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim/srctools$ xclip -o | xxd -r > tplq.bin
  ```
- Now comes the <s>hacky</s> clever part. This is the only way I could find to transfer the file to the emulated machine. First, convert it to an Intel HEX file. Because of how the receiving program works, you need to specify the load address. If you don't, it's going to overwrite some very important memory, and when saving the file, the first 256 bytes won't be written:

  ```
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim/srctools$ ./bin2hex -o 256 tplq.bin tplq.hex
  Input file size=242
  Output file size=592
  ```
- Fire up the CP/M transfer program

  ```
  A>load tplq.com

  SOURCE IS READER
  ```
- Send the hex file to the emulator

  ```
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim/srctools$ ./send tplq.hex
  ```
- You'll see that `LOAD` terminated:

  ```
  FIRST ADDRESS 0100
  LAST  ADDRESS 01F1
  BYTES READ    00F2
  RECORDS WRITTEN 02


  A>
  ```
- You can now run the program:

  ```
  A>tplq



  123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcd
  A>
  ```
- To exit, run `BYE`:

  ```
  A>bye

  INT disabled and HALT Op-Code reached at 0101
  ~/tmp/z80/z80pack-1.36/cpmsim$
  ```

Comment: I tried [Brainloller](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainloller), but got [2..100](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pOW9tGFwRite2AZLSNtp6dbuz//wA)

Comment: @H.PWiz intended

Comment: Nice. I'm starting to wonder if it should even be interpreted as a png

Comment: @H.PWiz As you've guessed, no.

Answer (score 16):

## C (8cc + ELVM), 34 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155554/12012) by [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz)

```c
main(X){while(X++<100)putchar(X);}
```

This prints 100 ASCII characters.

Comment: 16 C compilers later... +1.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155554/71256)!

Comment: For those who don't understand why this has so many upvotes (I 5 minutes ago): The normal signature of `main` function is `main(int argc, char** argv)`, `X` takes the place of `argc` here. Normal C compilers take `argc=1` and `argv[0]` is the path to the executable.

Comment: Why a specific compiler?  I get this to work with both GCC and Clang on amd64 and GCC on armhf.

Comment: @OskarSkog: With most ways of running a C program this will output starting at 2. The starting value of `X` is the number of command-line arguments, and the name of the program being run usually counts as the first argument, so in order to start with `X` as 0 (and thus start counting from 1), you need to find a compiler, or a way of running a C program, that defies that convention somehow.

Answer (score 15):

### [The Powder Toy](http://powdertoy.co.uk/) Save File, 529 bytes, [cracked by tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155121/77964)

Fix of my last (now deleted) answer, which I missed a part of.

```
00000000: 4f50 5331 5c04 9960 961c 0c00 425a 6839  OPS1\..`....BZh9
00000010: 3141 5926 5359 b855 1468 00c2 eaff f6ff  1AY&SY.U.h......
00000020: 5446 0c4a 01ef 403f 2f5f 74bf f7df f040  TF.J..@?/_t....@
00000030: 0203 0000 4050 8000 1002 0840 01bc 16a5  ....@P.....@....
00000040: 61a2 6909 18c1 4c64 4f22 7a83 4030 08c9  a.i...LdO"z.@0..
00000050: a323 6932 0c8f 536a 0d0a 34f4 a635 31aa  .#i2..Sj..4..51.
00000060: 7a4d 0c8f 5000 0006 4681 ea00 3469 e90e  zM..P...F...4i..
00000070: 1a69 8219 0d34 c8c9 8403 4d00 6134 6993  .i...4....M.a4i.
00000080: 0008 1a09 1453 4ca0 311a 7a9a 68d3 468d  .....SL.1.z.h.F.
00000090: 0003 d4c8 000d 000d 0f98 debe 75b8 487f  ............u.H.
000000a0: 2256 900d a121 2107 bb12 1208 4409 e89e  "V...!!.....D...
000000b0: ddeb 1f17 e331 5ead 7cec db16 65d5 6090  .....1^.|...e.`.
000000c0: 2422 b0ca cc2a 5585 c9c9 dc44 4ac0 f14d  $"...*U....DJ..M
000000d0: 6076 5a40 8484 536a 953b b44b 190a 90f0  `vZ@..Sj.;.K....
000000e0: 8a20 310e 95ad ca24 2d4b 0097 1a69 a919  . 1....$-K...i..
000000f0: 8d5b 0010 0242 1c59 8981 409a ec10 9024  .[...B.Y..@....$    
00000100: 2369 e1d8 a222 53dc 8231 dc4f a891 4b0b  #i..."S..1.O..K.
00000110: cf61 20d8 c1b4 4269 e25b 072d 5fb4 f1c4  .a ...Bi.[.-_...
00000120: a66b 62c8 069c ebc6 0225 9900 9852 21e9  .kb......%...R!.
00000130: d2e3 63d8 069a 7a69 124e eafc 3c5d 4028  ..c...zi.N..<]@(
00000140: dd15 6f81 0d2b 8007 816d f581 36f9 e58f  ..o..+...m..6...
00000150: 8cec 30e0 0378 40f9 b52c 4a17 b999 808d  ..0..x@..,J.....
00000160: d583 106f fd5e aaf5 ea8f a01b f5fc 9be5  ...o.^..........
00000170: 8e40 e05d 3a0a 2470 964d ef31 4c17 45da  .@.]:.$p.M.1L.E.
00000180: 3242 6692 251a aacc 6523 220c 73a7 7e3b  2Bf.%...e#".s.~;
00000190: cecf 635d 3cb6 08a0 7930 9566 0833 1d90  ..c]<...y0.f.3..
000001a0: 993a 5b8a e548 b34c 3fa8 0cbe 84aa d23e  .:[..H.L?......>
000001b0: 0129 c73b 1859 afa8 a984 990d cb0c db77  .).;.Y.........w
000001c0: 8fa8 df2f eda2 b779 72a7 4333 9382 0794  .../...yr.C3....
000001d0: 1f14 2340 c199 344a 48e1 6214 85a8 82a9  ..#@..4JH.b.....
000001e0: 5f6a 5a55 6993 6395 4350 41a2 396f 3613  _jZUi.c.CPA.9o6.
000001f0: 20f1 4d52 d289 b60f 2ea1 0040 8009 08ea   .MR.......@....
00000200: e782 4084 847f 8bb9 229c 2848 5c2a 8a34  ..@.....".(H\*.4
00000210: 00
```

Download: https://hellomouse.cf/moonyuploads/golfmagic

Output format: Unary value drawn on the screen

Comment: Can you provide a reversible `xxd` hexdump instead of that one please?

Comment: sure. One moment.

Comment: It seems like a save of some simulate game. But I don't know if this is a language defined by OP...

Comment: @tsh Here, we'll take this up in chat as you've figured it out. I've scanned the rules and it seems to count.

Comment: OK, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155121/44718)

Answer (score 15):

## Jolf, 7 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155273/31957) by [DevelopingDeveloper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76365/developingdeveloper)

```
Lazy!~1
```

Output is numbers separated by a `|`.

How this works:

```
Lazy!~1
   y!     define a canvas (no-op)
  z  ~1   range 1..100
La        join by `|` (for building regexes)
```

Comment: I don't know what language this is but the code makes me think that it won't stop after 100. Is that the case? If so, is it allowed?

Comment: @NieDzejkob The solution is not unorthodox in any way :)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155273/76365)

Answer (score 14):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 69 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155132) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
#define ss "/}O'=){/'HI}-){"
+1<2+3
"}@"$>!'d'/1
> ss ss {<}
1/1=2-1;
```

Output has decimal numbers followed by `f`, i.e.:

```
1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9f10f11f12f13f14f15f16f17f18f19f20f21f22f23f24f25f26f27f28f29f30f31f32f33f34f35f36f37f38f39f40f41f42f43f44f45f46f47f48f49f50f51f52f53f54f55f56f57f58f59f60f61f62f63f64f65f66f67f68f69f70f71f72f73f74f75f76f77f78f79f80f81f82f83f84f85f86f87f88f89f90f91f92f93f94f95f96f97f98f99f100f
```

Real layout:

```
    # d e f i
   n e s s " /
  } O ' = ) { /
 ' H I } - ) { "
+ 1 < 2 + 3 " } @
 " $ > ! ' d ' /
  1 > s s s s {
   < } 1 / 1 =
    2 - 1 ; .
```

How this works (click images for larger versions):

[image: Initialisation]

In the initialisation stage, the IP passes through the `#`, rerouting to the same IP since the cell is 0, and grabs some junk letters before adding the two empty cells in front it (getting 0) and then changing to 1:

[image: Main loop]

After this, the IP enters the main loop. It outputs the current number with `!`, places a `d` (100) in the memory and shuffles the memory pointer around a bit, before placing an `f` in the memory and outputting it with `;`.
[image: Memory state 1]
It then moves around a bit more before subtracting the d/100 from the current number and incrementing the result, giving -98 through 0 if the number is 1 to 99 or 1 if the number is 100. Next, the IP enters a branch.
[image: Memory state 2]

[image: Loop re-entry]

If the value of the incremented subtraction is 1, the count has reached 100 and the IP takes a weird path - we'll come back to that later. Otherwise, the IP moves the memory pointer around again before returning it to the central value and incrementing it, now pointing the opposite direction. The IP jumps over a `>` to re-enter the loop at the print stage.
[image: Memory state 3]

[image: Finalising]

By the time we have printed everything, we now take the second branch. The memory looks like this:
[image: Memory state 4]
The IP goes along the gold path, altering the memory a lot, and hits the `<` where it started and bounces back, going all the way back to `#`. The memory looks like this:
[image: Memory state 5]
Since 101 is 5 mod 6, the IP switches from 0 to 5, on the grey path. More memory shuffling occurs until the IP runs into the `#` again:
[image: Memory state 6]
Since 110 is 2 mod 6, the IP switches from 5 to 2, and immediately hits the `@`, terminating.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155132/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman I'll edit when I have access to a computer. What made you think of that language?

Comment: I did immediately rule out C and others since every line but the first look *quite* esoteric. The `@` and `/}O'=){/'HI}-){` just looked a lot like Hexagony. :P Seems that Hexagony just can't get away with that, although I don't quite know what it does.

Comment: @totallyhuman if you didn't notice I edited in how it works.

Answer (score 13):

## [Ternary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ternary), 310 bytes, safe

<sup>First safe cop!</sup>

```
8605981181131638734781144595329881711079549089716404558924278452713768112854113413627547471131116115809411874286965083536529893153585314407394776357097963270543699599954585373618092592593508952667137969794964363733969333908663984913514688355262631397424797028093425379100111111111111111111111021001112000120012
```

I'm surprised this ended up safe, considering what you see if you look at the end. I got lazy during the obfuscation :P

If you look at the end, you see a bunch of 1's, 2's, and 0's. That's base three—*ternary*.

> Q: Do we know any languages that use ternary?
>
> A: [Ternary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ternary) uses ternary.

Ternary's spec only considers programs consisting only of the given digits, but the interpreter linked to on the Esowiki page has some strange behavior:

- Consider overlapping pairs of characters of length 2 in the code.
- For each of these pairs:

  - If they do not form a valid instruction and are not `22`, ignore them and move to the next pair.
  - If they *do* form a valid instruction, execute it with the semantics outlined on the wiki page, and then skip the next pair.
  - If they are `22`, skip the next pair.

This means that only contiguous groups of `([01][012]|2[01])+` in the code actually have any significance.

Comment: What's the output format?

Comment: @MDXF Raw characters.

Comment: Congratz on being the first answer that has lasted a full 7 days!

Comment: @JoKing Added explanation.

Comment: Oh damn. I did notice the numbers at the end, but I assumed the 2s were lazy decoration, and went looking for languages with only 1s and 0s (*ahhh*, i'm only just noticing all the `11`s in the code)

Comment: @JoKing You were correct in assuming I was lazy, just underestimated *how* lazy.

Comment: Malbolge also uses ternary.

Comment: @user202729 As do some versions of Intercal, I believe. The comment about Ternary using Ternary was mostly a joke about the obviousness of the title.

Answer (score 12):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 189 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155228/76162) by [Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings)

```
/@<<<<<<  >>>>>>@\
v       \/       v
%       ^^       %
?      \  /      ?
>1+:455*  * -+?^:>
?v     /^^\     v?
^      \oo/      ^
^ \!/ ______ \!/ ^
^  v  \____/  v  ^
^<<<          >>>^
```

It's going to get cracked way too easily, but I had fun making it.

> Both the bottom and the top half are pretty much useless. A much smaller program with identical output:
>
> ```
> v%<@<<<<<<<<<<
> ?>^<
> >1+:455**-+?^:
> ```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155228/9365) Thought it looked a bit like that quine! :) - Updated to the right code... Oops!

Comment: The code looks a bit like the top view of a tank

Comment: Nice insect you made there!

Answer (score 11):

## [Ethereum VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum#Virtual_Machine), 170 bytes, safe

The hex-encoded program is:

````
00000000: 6073 6068 5234 1560 0e57 6000 80fd 5b60  `s`hR4.`.W`...[`
00000010: 0180 9050 5b60 6581 60ff 1614 1515 6067  ...P[`e.`.....`g
00000020: 577f 6375 726c 2068 7474 7073 3a2f 2f68  W.curl https://h
00000030: 656c 6c6f 6d6f 7573 652e 6366 2f63 677c  ellomouse.cf/cg|
00000040: 7368 8180 6001 0192 5060 4051 8082 60ff  sh..`...P`@Q..`.
00000050: 1660 ff16 8152 6020 0191 5050 6040 5180  .`...R` ..PP`@Q.
00000060: 9103 90a1 6014 565b 5060 3580 6075 6000  ....`.V[P`5.`u`.
00000070: 3960 00f3 0060 6060 4052 6000 80fd 00a1  9`...```@R`.....
00000080: 6562 7a7a 7230 5820 114d ddac fde1 05a1  ebzzr0X .M......
00000090: 3134 c615 32a1 3859 c583 7366 dba7 a339  14..2.8Y..sf...9
000000a0: 1187 d2ac ab19 9224 0029                 .......$.)
````

[Its in the blockchain!](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xfccc712af583add8347ee7164fd0519cda161b7642fc77bb32ece25f82f0e6a0#eventlog)

The program emits one event per number, using a string designed to confuse that looks like a command as topic, and the number as data.

Comment: Can you post a reversible `xxd` instead of just the hex?

Comment: @MDXF That *is* a reversible xxd. [You just need the `-ps` flag.](https://tio.run/##PU9bjgMhDLtKL1ApD2LCcRgYtJ@r9qe3nxqNdhXJmMTO4@jvn@v6fObj@ft@PF/XBakOQYZ50YDIGZUoKWvGQaYpTUI2R6RC1lIotVuNGrUuOB/DMPaphcGe3m3ZQiIwGAsTiypH2AkHWHPUOpjJ5Iw9SbRZkBUJZtLuWTemBv9GVVNu869qKt6kcy8tgTh2xWP3q/saFjcuF2Zwu@zvPtm@gNXOMJdIE9Uy5@xjzVMlurp6GdBwI89oI9K5M@ZBk3tTzTqtj35oa2ZFxNoX "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: I see a URL in there, does this code download stuff from the internet? If so I believe this violates one of out Standard Loopholes

Comment: @Potato44 it does not download and/or run code from the internet.

Comment: @Potato44 Actually the URL content is 'Nope.' and a trailing newline.

Comment: @user202729 it contained some characters that look like code earlier. / This is now safe. You should reveal the language.

Answer (score 11):

## [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), 6348 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155551/61563) by MD XF

```
      +     .  :     +   .        +       .         +     .    v      +           .           +     .            +   .    ^         +  
 .              +   .               +     .                +   .                 +   .        ;          +   .               
    +   .                    +           .                     +         .                      +     .   "           "         +   .    
                    +     .                         +   .                          +     .                           +  
 .                            +       .             @                +   .                              +     .                           
    +         .                                +   .               (       "           +   .                               
   +   .          )                         +   .                                    +   .                                     +   .      
                                +           .                                       +   .                                    
    +   .                                         +   .               ;                           +     .                           (      
          +         .    )                                       +   .                   
                          +     .                                              +   .                                )               +   
  .                   |                             +   .                                                 +   .          
                                        +   .                                                   +   .                                      
              +     .                                                     +   .  ^                                   
          (       +         .                                                       +       .                                         
               +     .                              "                           +       .                                        
                  +   .           :                               :                 +   .                                            
                +       .                (                                             +     .       
                                                ^       +       .                                                               +  
 .                                              |                 +   .                                             (                
    +     .                                    ^|^                              +   .                                                       
            +   .                              |||                     )                 +   .                                 
                                    +     .    AAA                                                                  +     .             
                                               VVV           +       .         "                                                     
          +       .                                                      "                   +     .                                                           
               +     .                          ;                                                 +   .   
                                                                         +     .                                                   
                          +   .                 )                                                             +         .         
                                    )                        1         +   .                          (                                 
                     +       .                                              (                                   +     .            
                                                                      +     .                                                     
 ^                             +     .                                                                 ;                   +     .     
                                                                                +         .    ;                                         
                                         +   .                                                         )                      
        +             .                                                                                        +     .                  
                          "                                             +         .                                          
                                                +   .                                                                                      
     +     .                   ^                                                                         +       .            
                                                                                 +     .                                                      
                                        +   .                                                                              
                 +   .                       ;                                                    ^                     +     .                   
                                                                              +     .                                 
                                                     (            +   .                        )                                     
                                      +     .                                                                                        
            +     .    "                                                                                          d       +   .             
                  )                                                                       +     .             )               
                                                                           +         .                                    )              
                                                      +   .                          )                                          
     (           "                     +       .
```

Quite an easy/long one, but pretty.  You even get to see the rocket move up the screen as you scroll down.

Output is raw.

Comment: This is [Starry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155546/76162)

Comment: [It looks very nice on TIO.](https://i.imgur.com/EdlRUG5.png)

Comment: @joking sorry it's not.  Duplicate : and &

Comment: [This is Brainfuck.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155551/61563)

Comment: @MDXF damn I forgot to disable that.  Got to involved in making it look nice.

Comment: Forgot to disable Brainfuck? What was the intended language?

Comment: @MDXF [OneFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/OneFuck) was intended.

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](http://www.05AB1E.xyz), 5170 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155763/71256) by [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz)

```
2̵̨̛̆̈̈́̂ͦͣ̅̐͐ͪͬͤͨ̊̊ͭ̑͛̋͏̠̰̦̥̼̟̟̀3̶̵̨̥̜̼̳̞̺̲̹̦͈̻̫͇̯̬̮͖̔̅ͮͭͨͧ̾͑ͣ̑̑̃̄̚͝5̸̸̧͖̼͚̩ͧͦ͋ͭ̐ͤͣ̄̆ͦ2̶̢̻͕̼̹̟̦̮̮͇͕̥̱͙͙̻͔̫̞̈̓̿̎ͦ͑ͩ͐̔̿̓͟͠A̴̺͍̮̠̤̫̙̜̹͎͒͂̌ͣ̊ͤͨ͂͒ͣ̉͌̄ͭ̑͟͠͡͝à̄̍̿̎ͯ̑̀̃̂ͣ̆̂̓̂ͬ̉̉͝҉̹̠̤̻s̏̓̓̃ͮ̌͋̅̎҉͈̝̩̻͡a̵̛̬̩̙͈͍̙͇͖͈͔̝̘̼̤͚ͨͣ̍̇̐ͧͥ̅̊ͥͅs̷̡̝̰̟̲͚̱̦͓͙̖̅̊̉̒̀͡A̢̛͓̜͇̻̦̮̭̣̮̱͎͒ͪ̿̇̓ͫ̍ͯ̀R̵̴̴̸̹̰̪͎̹̗̹̟̱̘͊̋̎̋̅ͫͬ͐̐͌A̸̧̝͍͍͔̣̮̾̓ͣ̓̍́ͬ͝g̨͕̣͎͕̳̟̱̭̲ͭ͛̎͆̔̃́8̶̬͓̱ͧ̄͌́̉́̀͜6̢̡͈̭̟̳̮̦̞͖̘͍̗ͩ̑̎̄̑ͮ̊̉ͯ̓̽͝8̾ͪ̉͊̑͏̤̩͈̤̣͙̭̟̳̮͎̣͈͖̖͕͕̫͠͠5̶̳̲̹̳̣̪͈̝̝̯̩̲̰̭̘̭̗ͮ́ͯ̐ͧ͑͛̇̂ͩ̓ͫͦ̔̽͐ͯ̅ͦ̕͠͠͡6̴̪͇̣͙̦͖̝̠̤̻̩̰̣͉̰̯̟͕ͯͩͮ̋̒̍ͦ̎̇ͦͮͣ̉̃͗8̷ͨͬͫ̌̀̅͊͐̇͐̚͝҉̰͔̫̤̱̦̯̟̼̝̼̣̀͡6̸̫͔̜̾̓̒̚ͅ7̀ͮ̄̊ͧ͐͗͑̾̊ͨ̚̕͞҉̣̮͙̝͔̻̯̫̥͔8̶̮̭̭̪̯͖̯̭͖̆ͣ̊ͩ̊ͨͧ͗̋̐ͧͫ̅́͘ͅ
̨̛̝̬̠̯̗͓̦ͦ̀͂̐͛̆ͬ̏̀ͣͭ͊̒͌͝3̶̧̡͇̤̩̘̦͍̜ͦͣ̋̚5̶̴̨̥̩̭̩̰̀̌̽͒̃̋ͭ́͛͠1͕̺̺̩͖̾̃̾̈̑͂ͣ̉́́́̚2͇̻͙̖̮̖̩͓͚̣̞̯̦̱̤̝͍̩̔ͪͦ̾͆͐͐͒͗ͧͦ̿͗́̓͜ͅ5ͣ̒͂̆ͦͥ̑̕҉҉̜͈̮̳̟̺̤̥̰̹̮̺̣̻̞͕̟1̢̛̃̉̔̽̊ͣͮ͋ͪ͗̆ͪͦ̐̇͑ͧ̚͘҉̛̫͕̙͕2̸̣̫̳͍͎̼̤͚̱̲͓͌̀͗̈́̓̈́̂̄ͪ̉̄̄̉̋͗ͩ̅̆͢͞͝4̴̢̺͙̺̞͕̻̥͍͆̿̄̐͒͗̈́ͫ̑ͫ̇͐͠͠ͅ2̸̛͕̩͕ͣͫ̒́6̴̵̢̘̫̟͖͙̲̲̮̣̘͈͉͖͓̮͖̊́ͬ̆̎͒ͩ̏ͨͥͧ̿̆̄͐́̏T̛͕̟̫̮̊̇̾ͦ̋̋̎̆̄͗̕͝n̴̡̤̞̣̦̱̻̰̟̻͈͈̠͇̣ͮͭ̐̎ͭ͋͛͌ͩ͡L̎ͮ̐͑ͫ̃ͪ̌͆̂̂ͯ̕̕͏̢̢͚̥̰̹̫͍̠̼̩̟̲,̨̨̘̱͚̗̖̺͓̘̼͍̘͚̹ͫ̂̏̈́ͥͬͥ̃̅͐̐͞q̨͍͕̠͍͖͇̠͉̮̭̦̜̣̼̜̩̠̓̊̀̈́̊͆̀̎̌͋̅̐͊͘͘͟͡ͅe̵̶̡̛͎̱͕͉̞̳͗ͭ̇ͪ͋̓̚͡r̨͚̘̖̝̫̳͂̈́ͣ͂ͧ͒̎ͧ̍͆̏ͪ̓ͥ̇̾̏͘ļ̴̴̝͉̪͎̊͂̾̑ͬ̐͡2̷ͯ̓̓͂̈͠҉̦̤̹̻͚̠̘̘͓̫̤͚̣̬̙͉͙̜3̸̮̝̮̰̘̰̇̿ͫͪ̑̈́ͦ̇̿̏̿ͥ͞͡5̶̲͔̣̞͚͇͒ͨ̂ͪ́̓̐̅͊͋̎͋̅́ͨ̿͟͞jͯ͂͋̉ͯͣ̃͊ͫ̋͊̊ͪͭ͏̸͠҉̝̣̬̥̻͉̖̮̫̘̤͕̭ͅģ̵͖̯̠͉̟̬̗͎͈͍̪̙̲̙͓̳͂͑̏̉͐͊ͩ̽͗̍͜͡ͅr̴̵̡̓̓̂̕͏̰̟̩̪g̶̡̢̠̲̱͚̋͊͆̂̔̑̕͜
̂͐ͥ̇҉̬͇̥̪͝ͅ2̴̸̷̞͕̦͚̪̩̺͇̭͖̪̫ͮ̈̃ͭ̓̾̓͂͑͊ͭ́̔̍ͭ3̶̸̼̤̩̣̤̆ͤ͊̂͆͘ͅ4̋̐̍̅̐̓͂̽͊ͥ̒͆ͮ̌ͫͧ͘͟͡͠͏̠̬͚̬͕̤͇̤̣͖͇̠̰͚͙̘͎͕̥6̓̄ͥ̂ͦ̽͌͋̍̓̄̈́͑̋̎ͧ͂͘͜͝͠҉͕̼͕̮͔3͎̤͖̦̟̱̟͍̺̞̜̞̳̳̯̾͛̓̇̾̒ͫͮ͌ͩ̄̓̔̔̓ͯ̐̀̀́͘͠2̷̡̰͚͙͙̤͎̺̜̳͍̩̋̍ͫ̔ͦ̉́̎ͣ͒̈͑̽́͢͞ͅͅ6̨̯͇̼͚͇͉͈̼̩̮͍̣̖ͭ̎ͯ͑̓͆͋͑ͅ3̳͉̥̰̖͓͇̞̩̳̩͙̜͇̗̼͖ͩ͑ͫ͛͊̋̈͌̋ͯ̔͛̀͛͟͞ͅ2̆̃ͥ̓ͪ̍ͯͨ͜͝͝͏̗͍͚͕͔̝̟͚̦6̭̤͕̰̙̼͌̎̇̓̽ͤ͌ͫ̀͠ḫ̷̢͔̪͈̠͖̪̹̮̣̩͊̽̿ͭ͋̂̊̂͝e̶͕͔͍̙̟̟̱̤͓̯̪̮̠͉̖ͧͩ̋̂ͤͦͭ̽̎͗̅͊̅̽̅̀͜͞r͊̀̍ͨ̀̍̓ͤ͗ͨ̊̅͊̿̚҉̴̪͖̝̙̭̖̹͔̻̦̖̳͔5͚̻͕̪͓̹̼̎ͥ̍̈̓̇ͬ̊ͧ̏̾͑̚͘͝2̶̸̖͙̟͉̜̤͔̦͍̖͖̝͖̳̝ͦͬ̅͒ͭ͆͊́3̴̻̺̮̞̖͛̌̇ͨ̆͒̊͛ͯ͐̇6̭͙͇͇̘̭̫͖̣̲̬͕͔̜̰̽̒ͮ͑̒ͩͨ̎̒̃͛ͦͥͭ̏̇́ͅ5̴̷̙̠̙̝̭̼̥̝̼̞͉̱̟̰̠̖͚͓̑͂̿͗͑ͭͬ̒ͣ̅̓̏ͥ̅̚͜ͅ2̷̾͛̈́ͯͭ̿̏̇̒͛ͧ̀͝҉̡̯̦̜͔̱̰͓͍̲̣̳3̢̡̈́͆ͯ̚͢͜͏̖͓͖̥̻̗̭͉̤̗̗2̸̸̨͎͉̥͚̜̗̩̰̮͙̟̳ͥ̑̉̊ͤͧ͑̊̕2̃͊̓͒̂͐̏ͭ͑̅͂͂ͤ̚҉͙͈̞͖̪͓̹̰͕̹̮̰̼͎̦̪͜2̸̿͆͊́̔́҉̧̙͇͚͍̗̝̤͚̝̻̣͉̳̹͟2̡̛̗͖̟͔̳̹̭͇͕̼͉͓̙̑̌̆͑̔̒̎
̇̈́ͯͫͫ͐̎͒͆̎̌͐̾ͧ̈́͐ͭ̆҉̬̯̳̮͖͚̭̼̱̳̪͉̥̪̞̱̘̹̖̀3̢̡̡̟̰͙͉̪̰̱̱͕̟̼͚̟̭͉͔̌ͭ͗ͨͮ̀̂́͂ͯ̔̿̈̉͜͜4̴̢͚̫͉ͥͭ͛̿́̽͛̄͐͝6̡̾͐̿̄͌̒́͜҉̶̯̩̟̼̯̰̙̝̟͕̬̳̳͖̹̱2̨̤̝̮̞̺̟̪̠̱̺̱̠̹͉͍̺̩̈ͯͬ͘͟͜ͅ3͗ͨ̅̋̆͆͌̾ͪͪ͛͆̐ͣ҉́҉̱̖̫͍̣̤̬̱̬̠̫̠̻͔̞̰6̶̢̖͕̻̾̅̔ͧͧ̇̑͗̂͊̿̓̐̍̂ͪͪ͟3̈ͨͤ͐̅̏̋ͬ̄͊̅̀ͦͭ̇ͤͩ̇̈҉͓͚̮̲̣͕͙̣͙̮̖̫̟4̵̧͙̠̱̟͐͗ͦ̓̍̎̾̈̽̆̈̈ͥ̾͗ͫ̐͠2̴͕̳̗͈̟̲͖̝̙̼̭̲̳̹̬̈́̎͂̅̆͌̇ͣ̑̏͜͞6̋͋̀͛̓ͭ̿̊͂̍ͤ̃̎̓̃̌̏҉͎̰̬̟̲͙̼̪̯͍͕̭̦4̸̢͔̱͔̖̝̪̙̼̻͍̗̟̳͔̱͑̈͒ͤͬͅ2͖̯̫̂́ͧ͆͛̄̆ͦͨͧ̅͘͢ͅ3͚̟̱̖̖̯̳̰͎͓͍̮̝͍͊͗̒́̀͞4̨̨͓͔̲̝͎̣͇̲̹ͨͨͯ͂̈ͤ̈́̈́̇̈́̀͟͠6̡̛͍̤̩͖̰̙͇͖̀̇͐̊̆̽̏̍͢͢gͨͩ̆ͮ̈ͩ̍ͩ̑̀̎̌ͭ͏̵̝̯͎̜̭̟s͉̥̥̣̗͍̭̩͍̮͉͓̲͕͍̱̗̮̟ͩ̑͋̓̂ͭͤ̉̕͞ť͍̩͚̹̠̥̥̳̩̻̦̬̤͓̞͓̄̄͒ͫ̀̽́̎ͥ̍̌̚͘͡3̷̬̝̘͍͊ͯ̈́ͮ̀̋̓ͩͧ͂̆͐̂ͤ̓ͮ̚̕͜6̷̘̖̻̤̟̗̦̼͎͕̳̥̫̘̲̥́̄̊ͪ͂̈́͐͛̓́̚̕4̶̷̛͕͇͎̲̺̤̯͈̱̹͉̮̭̳̗̤ͣ̏ͣ̾̀͠3͖̟̳͓̲͓̫̝̗̟̮̺̮̭͈̿ͬͫͣ͐̾͗ͧ̓̌̅͛́͘͟͡2̛̹͓̫̫̮̺̙̟͙̳̤̺̠̞̩̠̞͙ͩͪ̀ͬͪ͌͗̽ͣ̈́͜ͅ6̴̳̪̩͉̳͓̞̘̙̦̏ͭ̃͊ͭ͑̀̚
̵̙̝̘̝̲̳͖̣̝͕̥͍̥͖̗̹͉̎̽ͥ̑̾̎͢ͅḧ̶̵͇̭͍̠̣̗͖͍̜͕̰̘̰̑̃̀͒̈́ͤ̏̓ͩͬ̐͐̑̽ͯ̚̕͠͠4̫̬̦̜͕̺̱̖̼͋̄ͨ̾̔ͤ̓͊̐ͧ̔ͤ̎̄̀̏́͢ͅe̶̡ͯ̓ͮͤ̏ͦͬ͗̈́̽ͯ̌̽͌͆͊ͭ҉̡̝̺̜̝̗̗5̢̳͔̯͍̰̗̻͖͎̜͕̺̙͙͙̬͂͐̽͗͝ͅẆ̵̤̣̠͉̩̳̗͈̆̃̀̈́̋́̉̒ͯͭͥ͒̀ͭͦ́̓͗͘ͅR̴̍ͩ̓ͮ́̿ͨ̇̊̾̃̄̌̍͞҉̖̻̹̙̯́D̸̨̛̝̹̮͇̣̿ͧ͌̍̚ͅ3̨̛̛̫̫̣̝͈͔̰̖͕̮͉͔͖̈́ͨ̉̌̇́̃̍ͧ̈̈͐ͨ͛̚2͎̟̱̪̖͈͕͔͓̘͉̙̍̃̓ͪͦ͋͆̃̈̄̂̄ͦͥ̍̏̃̀͢͢͟5̸̶͛̀̿̄ͦ͊̏҉̷̼͇͍͚̘̺̱̜̤̻̞̲̜̰͙͔yͨ͐̍ͪ̑̀̾̌̊ͤ̿͗̄͑͐̑͌͋̽̕͏̰͔̮͈̦̤̫̗̫̯w̵̧̗̣̙̠̬̺̩͚̬̎́ͭ̃͛̈́2̴͚̫̮͍̼̠̺̠͕̬̳̮͕̱̟̙̘̹̑ͮͧ͗̓̎́́ͯ̓̐̉ͮͫͪ͢2̥̯͚̼͉̦͙ͧ͌͛̒̃ͯͭͥ͋̚̕̕͜͡ͅ2͇̖̭͆̒ͪ̾̎ͥͣ̂ͨͩ͋͒ͪ͊́̚͠͠2̑͗ͬ̃͆͂̓͗̏ͯ͟҉̴͘҉̳̭̗̘̤̝ͅ3̴̵̲̗̘̹̠̰̳͙̮͙̍̉̓ͦ̐ͧ̾̍̚̚̚̕ͅ4̨̲̜̱̦͓̝͍̳͕̩͌̔ͪ̾͗̉̇͗͐͛͆̀ͅͅ2̵̱̦̬̜͓̻̥̲͓̀͐ͫ͟͝6͔̮̣̮ͩͨ̀ͭͯ̏ͣ͂͡5̷͕̠̭̜͕͙̦̘̦̱̖̬ͤ̌ͫ̈̅͒̇ͯ͢
̸̵̵̡̛͓̻̗̖̻̗̼̤̰̂͛̆͌͗ͯͭ̂ͥ̈̂ͤͪ͐3̤̘̫͉̘̗̜̲̝͇̙̫̯̲̥͙̦͐̈̇̏͊̓̇̈́ͫ́͘͡ͅ2̛̣͓̪̖͔̺͍̝̫̳̱͊ͦ̿ͨ͌̀6̗̪̠̻̤̤͓̜̫͈͓̐͂̎͗̆͗̂͋͋̊̈́̃́3̰͈̠͚̙͉̲̗̭̤̝͇̩͔͖̦͓̹̯̉̊ͩͧ͐̃ͦ̾̀͘͟͢2̵̧̡̧̻̟̰̻̰̪͔͔̲̮͚̝̖̹̣̞̠̍̿̄͆͌́ͤ̀̅6̴̜̩̝̯͌͊̿ͫ̆̕͘5̵̡͓͍̬͔̒̍ͩ̅̎̍ͩ̉̈́ͫ͐͊̓̄͊̒͠͞ụ̡̜̥͙̗̻̺̤͇̥̦̗̠̪̳̗̼ͤ̈̓̾̆ͥ̅ͥ̿̿̒̇̓͟n̵̑͂̎ͪ́̾̃ͨ͗͛́́̚̚҉̶͙̰͓̱̳̯͓̟̺̤͈̥ͅn͒̿̏̆͏̳̯͍͎̫͇̮̳̼͎͚̜͓̦̝͜͟͡5ͨ̃͐ͬ̔̉͜҉̨̯̥̗͕̪̙̭͚̳͚͇͎̭̪͙̣̺́e̶̡̧͈̬̻̼̮͕̯͈̖͚͙̬̗͕̲ͬ̾̾̓̔͑͊ͨ͂ͪ̅͋̀ͪ̂̑̚͟ͅb̸̧͉̝̜̗͉̫͕͎͓͖̙̱ͩ͌ͪ͒̊̓ͦ͂̎͗ͨ̀̀ͮ͊̿͐͜y̅ͦͮ̽́ͥ͆ͫ̊ͩͪ̿ͩͭ͋͟҉̶̧̰̦̳̥̬̼̩̟̹͖͕̟̞͈͓̰̠͈ͅ3̷͕̮̤̩̳̙̳̮̹͕͇̱͖͖̋ͦͩͧ̃͊́ͩ̽̉̓̌̋́͟͝2̴̗̯͉̦̪̯̠͙̩̩̦̝̪̯̘̈ͨ̏́ͅ4̧̡̣̮̖͚̫̙̿̃ͫͫ̊̍̄̀̓̔̏͒ͦ́ͅͅ6̷̼̳͇̱̖̙̯̲̤͈̼͍̤̰̬̺̺͕ͭ̂͗̇̆̿͋ͥ͛̏ͫ̀ͣͧ̏̈́͞ͅ2̨̰̺̬̮̤̬̬̰̄̇̔̽ͫ͛͗̓ͯ̌ͫ̑̈́͘ͅ3͍͈͇͔̯͍͓͙̺̮͈̖͍̮̟̗̝̝͂ͫ̃ͤ̏͐̌́́́ͩ̀͘͡ͅ6̺̞̦̻͕̪̫̹̩͓ͫ͌̋̃͋̀̕͡͝ͅ3̏̈́ͧͬ̈́́̊̈̿ͯ̑̆̇̊̽̌͐́҉҉̡̨̪͉̖̖͇̯͉̥4̴̧̰͈̭̼̗̹̻͕͉͈̱̜̺̳̘̣̠̼̹̓ͩͮ̾̎̅̂̉̾̐͑̿͋͆̋͐̏͘
̴̢̭̰͚͎̦̟̜̫̟̰ͣͦ́͗̓̄̒͘͟3̢͙̹͍̹͖͈̙͚̱̰̝͙̗̙̹̗͖̺̟ͦ̑́̒̆̊̐̀͠͠4ͬͪͤ̏́҉͡͏̦͚̮͚̖̩̖̞̱̹̥̫̥͉6̡̡̛̜̮̭̞̰͗̾ͧ̇̃ͩ́͊͘͞3̜̘̘̤̬͚̫͉̹͖̘̰̩͇̖̳̺͇͙̆͐̈ͤͥ́ͬͩ͌̂̌̂͗͗͒̆̔̀͟͡͡2ͨͦͥ̓ͪ̎͏̵̵͈̯̩̼̬̦4̭̼͚͕̪̤̱̹̞̩̤̬̞͇̭͔͔̰̰͋̎͑ͫ͌̐̑͑̿̄ͯ́͡6̉̋́̾̌̍̒͌ͮ̕҉̯̘͙̳̲͙͍̞v̨̢͊ͦ̀҉̧̺̳͚̫̟͚͍̘̼̹̳̘̱̥͙͕͍͍̀w̵̨̳̭̖̘̮̩͔̘̱̭͍̰̗ͤ̇͊ͣ͂̆̋͢͠t̪̯̹̯̩̝̝̪͖̯ͭ̒̍̔ͤ̈̈̿̍̌̆ͮ͌ͯͮ͜͞ͅͅͅj̦̳̫̙̫̝͇̟̩͉͇̲̻̙̼ͬͯ̾̀ͫͦ̾̑̇̔ͪ͜͡r̴ͧ̈͗͋̑ͩ̾̽ͧ̌͌̉̋͛͗̔̔ͦ͏͇̦̥̝̮̳̦̺͕̫̹͍͔̞͝ͅͅͅw̴̛̖̙̻̞̭̼̘̹̼̫̲͕͓̗̘̹̋̏̅͊̎͋̉̾ͅt̡̧̳͇͚̲̮̻̣̺̝ͧ̏͂̅ͤ̕͝ả̗̜̯̻̗̝̜̼̪͕͓̭͍͂̇̐ͦͨ͌̽́́͝ͅ3̶͉͕̹̥̟̺̘͍̗̾̂ͫ̌ͯ̿̋̇͛ͪ̾ͭ͒͛̄̂̓̚͜͞7ͧ̒͂͊̆̽̓͏̵̢҉̞̭͖̼͙͎͚̟͉̻̹̙͉̣͎͍̪4̇ͫͧ̃́̾̎͛͆̿̈́ͭͪ͑ͭͤ̚҉̨͚̙̝̺̯̪͕̬͇̠͖̘̞̬̩̣̲͜͡͝5̵͓̘̝̻̺̺͈̟̯̟̬̲̘̠̜̥̻̦̬̓̋ͪͪͦͫ̚͘6̵̧̺̟͈̜̱͚̜̱̪̯͖̞͙̳̲͍̃͊ͫ͊̽̒̐͢͝8̶̷͔̦̹͙̔̂͐̈̆́̆ͤͪ̽̇̆͜͞5̸̴͉͈̺̮̥͇͍͕̦̗̏̂̐͒ͦ̃̌͌ͧͨͮ̆́͘͢7̹̤̪̺͕ͮͫ͊ͤͣ͛̉́͢3̷̨͍͓̱̼͓̥̘̼͔͎̲̗͈͕͖̭̽̑ͧ̃̏ͤ̊̂
̵̲̖̪̜̫̱̫̻̜̫̞ͭ͆̈́ͯ̋̆̓̀5̢̢̱̺̞͇̭̩͇̹̙̰̰̳̰̫͓̮̙͈̘͒ͮ̄̎͛̓͊̌ͩ̚͢͝4̷̩̱͈͓̺̘̓̉͐̑͗̉ͩ̆͊̂̒̑̈͑̑͌ͤͥ͘͘̕͝6̡̫̭͍̤̝͔̯̟̗̬̣͈͉͇̜͐ͯ͆̌3̸̷̨̦͚̱̭͈̖̖̈́́̎͛̒͌̽ͫ͢͠4̵̏̐̄̍ͦͭ͒̒҉̢̠̯͕̱͢͡ͅ6̨̯͖͎̮͖͈̩̤̺͚̥͚͈̰͔̭ͫ͆̽̀̿͡7̱̩̹̟̖̭̗̤̮̦̭͕̳͒̑ͫ̊̉̄̇ͥ̈́̽̊͆͝v̷̴̛̟̮̳͈̘̰̿͂ͤ̀̄̀ͤ̍͊ͯ͗́ͨͭ̊̏s̗̬̜̥̟̬̅ͬͣ̇̐̒ͭ̇́̓̍̅̀̕ķ̷̺͈̬̺̠̩̣̭̗͈̪͆ͩ͑ͦ͗̈ͧͧ́̚͡͡h̴̢̧̛͍͍̗̻̘̮͍̀̽̾̓̏ͅb̨̳̜̘͕͛̀ͫͦ͐ͮ͛́͛̏̇̀̕r̛͔̦̼̀̔ͮ͛͋ͪͧ̃͛̂͛̂̉̐́̚̕4̢̡̻͚̮̹̹̙͖̙͓͚̮̘̟̼̝̮̂̇͛̃̈ͮͧ̊̎̿̽ͯͥ́͟͠͝5̨̨͎̪̮͎͖̩̙̫̤̫̹̟̩̮ͨͭ͋ͯ͋ͮͯ̋ͪ̑̄ͧͭ̆ͤ̈́ͭͩ̚̕͠3ͤͭ̎͆̽͒̈́̌̈̽̍̓̏҉̫͓̗̩̺͕̬̼̦̘̦͎7̨͎̮̯̼̙̜̪͕̭̺̞̯͚ͫͤ̆̋͑ͮ̉̅̇͐ͫ̀3͊̀͆̈́ͩ̊͛̍́ͣͤ̓ͬ̿ͨ̓͑͗͗͘̕҉͉̗̥̮ͅ4̴̴̢͈̦̤̼͎̼͍͔̝̳ͣ̾́͑͗̒̎̐ͤ̀ͯ̋̚̕͝7̡̡̛̻̩̺͉͆ͦ͗̒ͦ̽͒͊̉͌͌̌̏̇́4̨͛ͩ̍̽̋̉ͪ̅͛̄͐̈ͩ̄̚̕҉̻̘͔͕̤̬̗̹̟̫3͈̥̘̼͙̤̖̬̺̥̠̜̖̯̦̐ͪͮ̈́̐͗ͤ̔ͯ̈́̐͊̚͟͡ͅ5̢̘̭̬̺͚͔̱͓͇̘͙̗̫̮͙̲̜̃͂̈́̏ͥ̐̇̐̈̇͆͂ͅ6̵̷̛͍͇̥̺̼̻̺̥̦͕̆ͧ͐̓͐̏ͦ͌̾ͫͭ́ͫͦ͆͛̍̕͝
```

*Laughs in Zalgo* - Good luck (yes, this executes, believe it or not lol).

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZpJb2vXcoXn/i0ZxOqupw/IMKOHABnbgGHjJTAQ@@UZb8ZepCRSFHtSJEVJbMReEq@kq/4P7D3xH3K@tXQDgaQknrN3NauqVtU@/7r7/Q/f/vjnn1shF/IxE1JxHC9DNpRjOc7iIg7jVTgIB3EZTuJpOAxX4TTcxeOYCINwHcZhFF7CWTjbDrWQjau4jFdxEt7iSeiwzAk/6ZAJ9@Eq9sIdF3e5fBP64SnchscwjvnwHOZxP6zDIqxiYzdO2P@Q3crsfMmtuTgOk/AlfImN8BI7YbqFmOnwHkpceBKnsczO76EaLuJZHLDTc6yzxyNCjcOKNff5exRuYju2@a4W5qH/l1iJqXDE@gfSL6b4@zIU4lHISM/wOQ7ieezFs/AUiywyCENuayP8Yyx9HxKIVbQEay5OoGGK23O867dFKLBU748CMujG59/CcajyVTqu2PMQ25b@KLB@PvTCNDx/jwCXrLePypM44usD3jEyFpmGdswjQhstGvxW45YW2g1jNnZ@06VsVmGtRHgI53x5jdq3WOkG01ZRuCFVZ8i6H9NxHopxzaWn2Koaulj92TZahkveb2Lpr/EAD5d4ZeMc35cR6QhBPvPzBXWuwyyW@GzavDeh9Rc8nUb6KvIn0fxLmODnXizyU9OqPwGIUwyVw0npmAQG9XAZS7xvvMIy3H4HXjJsk8RqXS65R8IF8t3sxSnmLWHsEyyHppi7Gl4RvhdkvSUrbBB8HPpgo4WZmt8hz4wLD7jlGCfK/lMuHbJp@/9vQIVLbNkIjVhHkPkuqydZW@YXxvdx4lTmAnm18EocrLHHONQFLyGDRQTeDQrO7MUe8J3yv2u2aPFq7mHnKcsehgo2H6PEPmhdCWSYoYk5Z1hfMo2Ro/eBE5a45n8F3tfhLNa/AxgLnHYExDpIcIA/9nk9CFwxgRzXhvNQ3tYtAKPH63JPXmHnDv6Yc0k3Zj@FBOJ0sOUBWpZjkwB94/er2A91oIqrEKbHxc@sNA@jWPuO0FOATH3ZBKkPbaI5sLuPydgScmIWdWdhjRZr/mp8g7IJYquMHXMA4pi/LsHAASg9AnhKAz2APeDyJk4ebzvdHCLaBADfYxU8hhHHuLO7i@ZHeKBCiCknJFn1Sj7AgCMuW8pk36JImlcn5PF6yoGc9E@dLPOE/xtboUYuG2OWXFReq6A/eSa8o1SS2HQoKFpQqcENVSLokiS1xq43CjZBOkx3WVuJg5REhJ7IcJiuCwRWhvMTso/w3iN/P7HAM8Csh7NvEa8Akjpg9wBrrMhvM3bOWSb59IQQUFC2WO4Ul9UJ@PoWBksgaAYokpaJEZCNAzO8H/L/KX7IxYvYx6Rf2G0eNkRdydlBCeA2VneIu3du@NA4g@tOeIEhWZDXBfmtjaiIiY7PeL24hYBztEyy5imCTGN9j9hTcOeI4wrbHgOHERK/858MeEzi5c@sdYfb5gC3wZq3/KwQqkWgFfhPVcn9P1hoHyeM8bfSjG5vIv1pUByecfPqF5UQbFICM4fxNB6x32eQfo5p@6wnfzw7yz2zcj4MFEb/zuUrlJRyaax0hNopgngd6qx8jGgXWOTDM3McOcBGUyXKf@GGFPpk0GeBS9NEGTkvKCqu0OaG25og4gn5Sbvc2uI/j/9DdB3gGwVTDoiWvqb1MiHaogq1WOAcX9QRr4jy@xh3QFwr044pIpfs30WCwY@goIO@@yDhkNx2R14jCDB8ib3r3NIPm1/BdAavpIBsBU0nZJQcQs8A7kj2xPxXUYK1gnIJOPhvBEvxxQleK7PixBm8x3rk7y1yU5qfFHV0EB6A3BjjPmLQDpZpoWJVScUhsACIBdzZ3WajdzLijDUzOJC/2PYdu/WpzOeo1uN1ze3Xu4DkCuvPFFoYU4kLb9tCSb55p6zec9utK0Q/duL@3xApxQVkeEIszQ1zIC7WMQMHJPLwBTF7FmiEoAVFKkads98QMy9/4vYTBCpE@WBKymhipfPYxaQT5ybZ/4zbmxQfVdRZEEjbhHoWEyNoFSScY6W62I0RNg2znySG0VRD8S4XXOAe/Mq9gOMb1CzLCeRjshpYHGHh7BZozKPGEpyoPiJbFIFKskqRTxXTB@eGMVaesdETt5I9@X2@TVAP0T3FtvfY9mu556LLMNxRDqbWCmvy4GsUV6iQ1kQt5iDk3AgcoMIAgTq86ty@7woIEkXasHgbL6sIj/YQEfSL9bGYYFzEEhl8fKIQZcEUPGhAhiQ3iVjxWsXaNnqdcqHQV2HflQOVTIWGNSRTMU3wM0CaJGAeotvYBf8M25NwwD/Q5me9xT5F/F1DggImKgH1CtA8IVs@cHOfmLj4EBqxhyz2xM0bCFBRVtnDnvAwLq9ihUM@r6hGirgXIQv05h3tK/a9DI1tyjJpgswippMnxR4ibA1lEvyvDzQ3AEWpgpyFufq2/IY02DZharJsQ1Q5jdGqYFyMiqKGgXrYvIlQHQJXPO0M64/32IHiL96CV@UijEIaEGqvgeDLzwjySkyQ7kCZ3N4DGxcyssnFwKh4dDKd/og/psidYq0xir@ielMBBiBe@UwAUUJLAog0ipe7flUJgJl4rCLnVy5PIPeV39NxSApqmuRroXcCTexEmUSMqQHlrZknNjBNbZcdR2Akb@d3yC/wCQIPwo@re6gs@j1jx8fwsoWQC1atoF2Ote9dVVQezhCki2A11/mGduO1Cb1tPHFEPrwiCiqsfYp5qZCI9IzfV4CmsYeqFRB3wvuUC0swnTQXUpMxyTE3J4klMeYsDhMdm7P2JRG7sGe6pCgRBVV/pF4ioti/GFaatCoC/hk7PqD@gFePBV5ABMwKLPQRHBDjuwFid2J1S5FAuKzZWylxn8VOcVNCfsSW5yYRXfa9AcRVtL1Fls02xaODUdYU8C7uPgc8QlxD@Q2ULdlnyGdzy0yj4EYFeoqX6iBc7VBJQMXgXS4TcxSBA75bzp9pVq8oO6HRktuyxDGo@UMUm5bCjPnDS9f469G5@4XYGofZFoaRt8hW8he3nFFAZM@OKDaGUG3oIaa46iY8biHgEf46IfgpUKh8SiA0cHJNX6PLvjNHgf3a3@AfWWvOT9mEIuf6WcaOE74pY8ec6C25em22jpntghv@mjk4Z8CA5oOlG9vcuhR8SYAJAigZVfbVEOYxmuza9QuPoTf1Dz1vVFvFlln4TJaOtR1hB@i9o/Urn6I1ajM@c8k8FkSoy2JSRHNF68Ukrr036xfrXjuWFfJ1xCatof1juFGnugZeV@IECDF0kVTve4YgAwR54jUgwrIIobw43XYoZonxHE44UjvDzylGKsdLzKJ9bwjFudPZkN1uzKbnvNTc9sM1wrJADWtOQOMJCSKluAYSqhwpL0gFxjj0P@F5GyGvABeFGvgeIm7G@SThDLPPN1OWybO3WPFK8CWM2m5exJZhfDtuKMbuAkvsnidCc7znwe4b38yDCKcqcdtan22B/hIRKAKraNeg4Ji81cXg6gybIFR97EcSelGXaCQt9hDwUKma3Kt4E80pksHSLEeDDQyPEbSEOxZeQDerOxEXg3vtgNE8kBu6Vb1QUJIps6ZNM@/0bIirCtTkPwFqgiNOPwYRnm1kCdkWqMyqUdom1ppggjpFyHecb2ksDd1rQrTq@QHdww73XonmIMAQnGccBwmwMTA@qmx4y4XqTffVXu6BZ3V7B5jyFc8UqYJEFpsX3dQ2hDmNBX5i3WkQA8jzWXTT/MFJoU5YneaUVbvqfn/Tl2aaKb4cEiH12HdIjUATxUsdlSR2rN7i5yL6NNHg7O8kyCN1H5hvzvqvLtUqBUfmHLRHosb4V4ttNNggmSxcfPqxKjutUVhRekjRmYpZIHRZtYxcpdlInXrf5Zaeevk91v9oV2fmv2XzjQcETprnPmOEM0QbK20ZNCPTwdsw2gFPx7zeMO89aw7UyGCpEl@qRVuDrhuC7oOQg7Yw3CY@aLWhHmUjdsJeR3j6VH0u3jlXOgMUMorYcc8gWbkkLWN@C31mwHKBsEfg4ZXd8x5mnLKPbpj7YhW@NjsO@X1ArE71TvC395Sm0Vepm3SN4J@V7bBpwbv20awdxt/g1lcXhDd@uwMRbQ@EeooPF7meSB3OGPFXUzrG7M/qi4mNBJ7LYOxjdOsgsFqDMt@8kjDvWUzTkrp5qDokwaGhHtxEBVq/A24y5KY3UsuQ8DvQMMC/a0KTQIEk8swJi4ULXt3JrRFeftTYhnrNzuIDakS955EJZ87M@D6cu1b2TO5k3eZuVPUSkVci3jhOCWSEaRKlDUHae7TNCxf/SZLKWcsMyTPpsRg1mbxe4X9LslMSkDWh03fiwqZCU9FIJZu/OmyqmgMBhCuWOvBQIYOQRXJSX5nXoHvE4ut/46JJ1Fcd1@JTzJ5VEVUzSmVnhYJYDF8nWaWInZQMywTqqeenp0aEvKWR3rUTsWKuJm5Z5JaqRgOwWWmUDx/d/9jRdgxGLkg1mnaWnG5mQZNBUT6aVLRq74rNulqN8dIxAt5j3AcCZV/0FGfKM12PnGjDRIiwYe2fiEeFUIvH7W8oAOfwiIRmQEhxe/DqjlqDpxVhNPZgtMlr/Ts4SOJKUbGMkj3/vjSHWngIQyuypUGeJknkai720E0dYoH/0loCH9dbc/UXbiRIvhbUFZ@iXW1V/S0ZHx1F@@xi4HzoVl@VfgRKOmIbUEsiawsbagL6pmxlmpdSvsS2/BfsJYV7/NYIS4nXJCzSgDIlsADYdTwTIfZkZuNxV1M9J0SVlTr4o4CvNMTpaOotsKiBxKhcZkxoSL5RqYztHSBTkyisXCC3N5XU2IsiYC98zGw/Zk0bj16yW2C3TL698zD6xhm1i5@fUZNMtGcCLHivlfGQ@lyO0TRvF9/RboAe@DebrUmEF5pIkPK6LuBjTdkcogv1sZrXkbtMZFPYNO8uY4bjv6DQnWtP1dy04Xe60nC9zdd5gH4M0KquaHNnTI1rWmJOvDdRTZVtH@@BE@TOkp7YfwvzawZ3pckgVrhkfYG55qm7BxnhZo80k3KbkzOTUf0/AGAaJjfNolQJVGW67Jen0pgsq76UuUgzvzMX7ASgVTvV0UjDDlrKj4g1VdzJ9rhrveXJfsbkK4kNE5CUidWfsJOI/7PH4DXX65WZsMiexoUDuj1TrTmpqC7UeMxDAd71HFgTu5I/C7ZU2VbLeDg6YIc7irEIwyLW/petdczxhtp0JLze@al4jH/GpZesLCM23RcNPXkY89cAk6iivfziFqfkKYxSWQczN3EyKQnL3Ym@cvs1IVI1s17z6QkmRhr9AmTUzOTisWJKXbFJVMlHNRp2quh2DMVx6O0CwjTaLCDeNBisfcUea0RqqhlUH8nFG/fjJc2LRR/D04/c8OZRdQ3xNCLRScwMbUXxZiS9E4SUthMcq7ryDOqUClTBGx5jLLzF7Q84/Aiw0jIqHj8Q4w43QW6RS4AxyWESNUaiY@JzThSU3HK1w80/NeEn/0NrSBM5PHjgmv7OuyaRygITypROvEQ1Fl9HiI@x4dnpGXUc8KkvjPltKM5YEFQ9Z8EpyxbMKFSZHhTLSviedG9C24cYj6Io0NGGSgCMXPWUZNJEVw3oZqabAzSe8jM2X12H1g5u0kEF4oJbleEqxjwmt425XRP1S25c2Vgal7X3HN1NF8t39BoBiWMROrLHxJPQvioFztp3amgrYA0KTT81h7p2Pn@K9S322/cBicYpTey@dsYRxW4ZAddcuJCedt5C6SLlEa2oQDnoyCdp8ySUMsBXHoDUjLSq59Ir@1kMWlRPRba3x26yYxrhdQRSjz3Pk8YfgwcTkEeN8LetzQTCkWGXA9LUu4/rcq7ur2o51U2Zdly5sdSB0L7tPdpBG53fiGZlAWKB38o0D@@uyYduq1u4Z@Kkou606Qlq3fMmFdcnvNoSz9BZ5DdYVwSkqXAnipWPzrh96blWyaOxrjopmWiMkEkuyiFmOWhcdBHl@EcMIbjlSWCa719jECWAtg7kQPGTGjExUFG8pE8Yjz1gVJJqgJqG2@ZHE@URTS3ivLlHhI4j3AG05NzjNqUtUWOayW1zdLUsI50BKMwwx5EwxI@ErLHPOa6QBi3XxsVH0yxhRRxxhsrrRkNO1eMrT2o0py@5P7lDIzXSLyKOOx4Vn9jJohwnTsZrdkjKzBqu4eSh9RB/VgfcN2mtmUnR/RYcZW@mbhWywsoHXASLqTc9IXbs/8O1R5X3QpFNdXhSgvL5hcYcLR8hy4U3yrPqhGLxd0y7H3WEQ@sCCujcTMI3npPpPIxS4luWH0T170Qbid8sOS8Eql1Sq4ZYa967UfNFRTKVx5PGnlGu8dv6b5h7jR4JH0S@gYp9H2OJ5CgJzV1PVcDO1Ce4a3xWE/ur@CbeOcR@U2585e8j7KljIwVqzbPWz@R23Tz2bGtlKjxWXLPoo6erYtz937HmsSeDmuArDj5TrLNODaKPwr4mMS/cpoaxaoL0@HdnEzp8kNOjFqp8bjRC8rnQs9J/6H1PtUj53HtsEvCKQEnX9S4mefasqatJLgbRylh1GwGUQ7Af1jzEHadmVEvNu9ym6xBeM9BuLHiyNXJZ8@nwJ4SqRE1D1FJXjT65v@/Z@wtuVlHTbNJEn08dVRfDbId95krnBlbJ85h3sssSd5x4b03WyCMeA3fclT1p5ir6qqG7I6HvA/3LcLtLGjhE7I5ZvthdywdMPRfzJw8/1j6tuOW/A5X6j2567@NsxCPjCvEhWniBZQl9bur6vKrrlkAHsv2vgC9@h8tTZmo5FNDxwowFVALUHstUNVZ/jO1dXJ3yaeFYwxRQOvFkLWdSdwET/OwEp7Z35G6iLtbxyfxdE8pLXFCAbiWx3xAxgNM2W53YdsdEwQHrP2CnomnHC@8jn6zV3J033chAxb/xxJjA9yAsjaIJvtYkXGnyhtezf@vrsOnjXFteUbk9Ikf1fOR34QGbs4NzkHq3a9FxXnOdSOrhCtXQqs6NPCkreJIiISuuYyfuekh@qN/y9EGPbNy41AOqPT0bABaOwPfcQT/0Gfra9WrhxwwUmN1tF6GSmhbjfK4TIE9@LpyilTHyKkA7eKCsx0s0fSO/VkTVMKgOngZ4lTYoZlUDhWCaPIFOzsZ8K9cGpcQnnXaSxvLu05afWOfEFEHHx/sok/FJdA5lbrhBz3I09NQCt@ppiqXGKf9g7ZT5L6yCz6IHOE2d4AF4tZUP1IvPnoJsZMZw/RvRvqDFIqBRc8ln0iPBLGZL2B5dR@Piv9haxzBj1ssDDXonAHbug8oH43/hAYmCZelh4Oxnj5zEFT/Omk/J2UXP6p5JEC21jD/4EIdciVNW/K6HBTSPv/L2G5WnWP@VdWr62mfwImin7n1U4jvIrfHSqcPhZYd/kl7UgatrRecSKecVK6gUDih4fhDF56bwN2eMhk8U9Xfr6@MYq11Tb3HINa@VIO0WW9xk6WBUHplqrG9AlHRSQ9pRxW776Y65PTQNq20uXvphmlfNcoCdJq06sDv@o2BIN32WWDc9dX8XS58wydDlSk/RFPCGzv/nHj0CGrD64iebZh6RikrRP2/rjMgRqKc/Tv10zyW7p6HsatjS8cQEoKXaSp5sqqcLK03e3rj0xDPRkp7hwqoJ66yYrOsc@uvYQKcNL35MqBc2n2LOaKj4GLIS9bCPStaRPajWMylLW7vCDt6bItJr0Imx@oWPgb3Gn8oEWPIPpfAWWaVuhvDxvNJ8O@iRtlXUAxFNRKtpJKlTe1x0DifPqvdxOmpzW8MoHDn/aqA73g06ys34jKhslNP6alaAZjpmWijwPFPWyWFL0wePRlZ@HqK7h7P16E3a7HHs4f7cD7UIs5oxF/0sxJ0HoUW3dE8aSVuKcaz/@ef/AQ)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155763/71256)!

Comment: When I viewed the cracked post, Google Chrome asked, "Would you like to translate this page?" Goodness knows what language it thought it was seeing. :P

Comment: @DLosc please go back and translate it, Zalgo has summoned you.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn the same happened to me; Chrome told me the page could not be translated.

Comment: @DLosc chrome seems to think that it is in vietnamese for me

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Maybe I'm missing something, but why does the link you included for 05AB1E's documentation go to neopets?

Comment: @DavidArchibald I blame Russian hackers.

Answer (score 10):

## [Befunge-96](https://github.com/TryItOnline/befunge-97-mtfi), 25 bytes, safe

```
#<h2%fZ<[[+!/8]]!><[8!,]>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNPNLUnL/P9f2SbDSDUtyiY6WltR3yI2VtHOJtpCUSfW7v9/AA)

Surprise! Like a horror movie with a bad twist, the murderer was Befunge's deformed older brother all along!

The biggest trick of this code is the `h` instruction, which I found through James Holderness' answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153156). `h` sets the *Holistic Delta*, which changes the value of the instructions encountered before executing them.

#### Explanation

```
#< Skip over the <
  h Set the holistic delta to 0 (doesn't change anything)
   2%fZ Does nothing
   2%fZ< Goes left and adds a 2 to the stack
  h Sets the holistic delta to +2
```

Now (to the pointer) the code looks like:

```
%>j4'h\>]]-#1:__#@>]:#._@
```

Going left at the `j`

```
>j4'h\>  Pushes 104, 4 to the stack
      >-#1:_ Initially subtracts 4 from 104 to get 100
             Then repeatedly dupe, decrement and dupe again until the value is 0
            _ Pop the excess 0
             #@> Skip the terminating @ and enter the loop
               > :#._@ Print the number until the stack is empty
```

The hardest part of this was figuring out which aspects of -96 are inherited from -93, which are precursors to -98, and which aren't. For example `]` (Turn Right) is in -98, but isn't in -96, while the `'` (Fetch Character) is. Thankfully, this version does not bounce off unknown instructions.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 494 bytes, safe

```
[]
^1#
^2#
^3#
^4#
^5#
^6#
^7#
^8#
^9#
^10#
^11#
^12#
^13#
^14#
^15#
^16#
^17#
^18#
^19#
^20#
^21#
^22#
^23#
^24#
^25#
^26#
^27#
^28#
^29#
^30#
^31#
^32#
^33#
^34#
^35#
^36#
^37#
^38#
^39#
^40#
^41#
^42#
^43#
^44#
^45#
^46#
^47#
^48#
^49#
^50#
^51#
^52#
^53#
^54#
^55#
^56#
^57#
^58#
^59#
^60#
^61#
^62#
^63#
^64#
^65#
^66#
^67#
^68#
^69#
^70#
^71#
^72#
^73#
^74#
^75#
^76#
^77#
^78#
^79#
^80#
^81#
^82#
^83#
^84#
^85#
^86#
^87#
^88#
^89#
^90#
^91#
^92#
^93#
^94#
^95#
^96#
^97#
^98#
^99#
^100#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NdK9TQMwEIZh0WaN1Ei5P9_dLIgUIFJE6ZIUzEKTgizFEMyAXwPF5-p7LNvnj_vx7XR6v93u18vhsb4evp-eN3vZbvY6YzM-EzNjJmdqpmdkx0JTqApdoSy0hbrQF4AgFKFrb4QiFKEIRShCEYowhCFsHQdhCEMYwhCGMIQjHOEIXzdAOMIRjnCEIwIRiEAEItalEYEIRCACMRADMRADMRBjvRNiIAZiIBKRiEQkIhGJyPW0iEQkohCFKEQhClGIQtSaBqIQjWhEIxrRiEY0ohG9Bvg7wd328_zyev4b_v8n-AE)

Outputs as an array of integers.

---

Explanation:

- All lines except the last are essentially ignored
- `100#`: find the first 100 integers such that:

  - `^`: the integer, `xor`d with 0, is not 0 (which is always true for positive integers)

Answer (score 9):

#### BrainCurses, 12 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155479/31957) by [Rlyeh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78059/rlyeh)

```
' !'d[:-%_%]
```

Hmmmmmm :)

Output is space-separated (with a trailing space).

Comment: The syntax looks like if someone mixed Japt and Python...

Comment: This is [forobj](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Forobj), but I can't find an interpreter anywhere. Do you have one?

Comment: @MDXF This is _not_ forobj, actually. Unless you can provide the interpreter, of course.

Comment: Huh that's odd, it really seemed like it was

Comment: @MDXF Note that if it works in that language, it could be cracked.

Comment: @mbomb007 The language spec was too confusing to be sure and it's unimplemented, so I'm not going to pursue it.

Comment: Is the language BrainCurses?

Comment: @Rlyeh Yes, it is!

Comment: @Rlyeh Time to post your crack answer. (And if it's posted, time for Conor to update this!)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155479/78059)

Answer (score 9):

## [???](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%3F%3F%3F), 145 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155085/21830) by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

!!!

```
......";........-,'";'";.;;.---,'"....'"-........;,'".........'";.!--!;,'".........'";;;.--,,,,,,,,,,;..........";!--.!--!;;;,'"--,";,,,,,,,,!,!!
```

Outputs the numbers cleanly in one line.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155085/12012) This is ???.

Comment: Very good! This was undeniably a softball, but that speed is impressive.

Comment: Well, [I know the language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54936/12012). ;)

Comment: It wasn't really obfuscated, either.

Answer (score 9):

## Z80 (anagol-flavored), 47 bytes, safe

```
main;;<o,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)))))))))0;v
```

Outputs bytes from 1 to 100. I'm not *entirely* sure this satisfies the requirements for a language in the OP, but it sort of technically does.

**Post-reveal clarification:** The Z80 chip has a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80), its machine language is certainly a programming language, and an interpreter for the Z80 machine used is freely available on [golf.shinh.org](http://golf.shinh.org/version.rb); Z80 is often used for code golf there.

The machine is very simple: 64k of memory + all registers are zeroed; code is placed at `$0000` and execution starts there. A `putchar` routine is executed when the PC reaches `$8000`. (There is also `getchar`, but it's irrelevant here.)

The iffy part, of course, is that this "putchar at `$8000`" behavior isn't inherent to the chip and isn't itself defined by Wikipedia/Esolangs/Rosetta. You *could* see it as an "interpreter quirk"... but that's maybe a stretch. I'll leave the decision to the OP.

Here is the program disassembly:

```
  ld l,l                  ; Red herring. ('main')
  ld h,c                  ; Well, the whole program being printable ASCII is a red herring.
  ld l,c                  ; Arguably, clearing H is the "right thing to do", but it turns
  ld l,(hl)               ; out not to have been necessary.

  dec sp                  ; "Push a zero" (make SP point at $fffe, which is zeroed out)
  dec sp

  inc a                   ; Increment A, the argument to putchar.

  ld l,a                  ; Compute (A + 27) << 9.
  inc l      (27 times)
  add hl,hl  (9 times)

  jr nc, $0069            ; Halt if carry is set. This occurs when A = 101.
  halt                    ; Otherwise, run from $0069 to $7fff (all NOP).
                          ; Finally, putchar(A) and return to $0000 (which we pushed).
```

[Try it online](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb): click "use form", pick z80 from the dropdown menu, paste in my code, and Submit!

[image: submitting my code]

I expected this to get cracked fairly quickly, but now I feel a little bad. I had fun writing a Z80 program constrained to printable ASCII code, though.

**EDIT 2018-02-23**: I described the Z80golf machine on [esolangs](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Z80golf).

Answer (score 8):

## [pb](http://esolangs.org/wiki/pb), 21 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155256/41024) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
w[T!100]{t[T+1]b[T]>}
```

Output in raw chars `0x01`-`0x64`.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155256/61563)

Comment: @MDXF added link to crack

Answer (score 8):

## [2B](http://esolangs.org/wiki/2B), 38 bytes, safe

```
+9+1::{-1^1+9+1v1**}^1: :{-1v1+1)^1* *
```

Output is raw chars.

Comment: If the interpreter is in VB.NET, can it be really considered free as in beer?

Comment: @NieDzejkob Sure, I have tested this submission without paying for anything (not paying for VB either).

Answer (score 8):

## [Glass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Glass), 212 bytes, safe

```
{     (M)        [
    m     v   A
   ! o   O   !
  <     0   >
 m     <   1
>  =/m<     1>  v
 a.    ?0o
 (on)      .
         ? "
           ,
           "
         o  o.
?0<100>v
(ne).?m 1=  ,
\
          \^]}
```

> Glass is a stack-based, object oriented esolang that was previously featured on Esolangs. I intended to make this look like a 2D language.
>
>  If we strip out extraneous whitespace in this submission, we get this:
>
> ```
> {(M)[mvA!oO!<0>m<1>=/m<1>va.?0o(on).?"
>                 ,
>                 "oo.?0<100>v(ne).?m1=,\^]}
> ```
>
> Glass begins executing from the `m` (`main`) method of the class `M` (`Main`). Because of Glass's syntax, this would be written as `{M[m 'Method body']}`. In order to avoid this being too recognizable as Glass, I wrapped the `M` in parentheses (which are mandatory for multi-character names).

Comment: Not ><>, Gol><>, Befunge-93 or 98, Prelude, Whitespace, CJam, Golfscript, Brain-Flak or Pain-Flak...

Comment: @MDXF Edited. This was Glass.

Comment: Geez on a roll!

Comment: @tfbninja I had a list of languages I wanted to use beforehand, so I was able to write and post a bunch of submissions quickly...

Answer (score 8):

## [Festival Speech Synthesis System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festival_Speech_Synthesis_System), 1708 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155504/66323) by [fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66323/fergusq)

```
;#.#;‏⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​
;echo {1..99};
(SayText "")
(SayText "hs sh (but which?) fl")
(SayText "link herring obscure, blame2 premier")
(SayText "don't forget to look up")
(define(f x)(cond((> x 100)())((print x))((f(+ x 1)))))
(f 1)
```

[Hexdump (optional, if you don't like copy-pasting)](https://pastebin.com/mvnzc1z6)

---

The concept behind this is that there are three languages going on here: Headsecks (`hs`), zsh (`sh`), and the actual Festival Lisp (`fl`). The intent was that running the program in one would help gain insight into the others:

### The herring (zsh)

`bash` doesn't like having the semicolons by themselves at the top (hence "but which?"), however `zsh` will happily take them and skip down to the `echo {1..99};` line, which will expand into 1 through 100... except for 100, of course.

This was supposed to be the most obvious one, and the intent was to tip off the robber that the fourth line hints are referring to languages.

### The link (Headsecks)

This seems to the thing that most people started on instead: the unprintable blob ([`blame2`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)) after the first line (`premier`). This is a (completely ungolfed) Headsecks program that outputs this:

```
:26726392
```

Go to that message in the transcript, and [you get this delightful conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26726392). But if you `look up`, you get [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26726365#26726365).

## The obscure (Festival)

Festival "Lisp" is really just an embedded Scheme interpreter; if you took the numerous `SayText`s out, this program would run correctly in almost any flavor of Lisp (semicolons are comments). As it is, it requires that `SayText` be already defined... which it is in Festival. You'll hear it rattle out the hints if you have an audio device, after which it will then correctly print out 1 to 100.

Comment: ...That's... Could we have a hexdump?

Comment: What's the output format? (I'm assuming those strings don't actually get printed...)

Comment: @DLosc Regular STDOUT. It might take a little while though.

Comment: Aha! Is this [Anguish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155477/76162)?

Comment: @JoKing No (and I'd be surprised if it worked by some coincidence).

Comment: Just a reminder you only get one guess per cop, so definitely make sure it runs first. This has a couple layers to it.

Comment: @DLosc Newlines.

Comment: The challenge requires a downloadable file or a hexdump. You should at least mention the encoding.

Comment: @Dennis It's UTF-8.

Comment: [cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155504/66323)

Comment: @fergusq Correct.

Answer (score 7):

## [Beatnik](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik), 187 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155414/68615) by totallyhuman

```
aAaAa>>u<<TWELVE>>ooooooooo<<if(i < 100); print("oOOoOooOoOoO");
done:
    PutNumbersFromOneToOneHundredInclusiveFunctionZD<GOTO 100>;
    executes(print); language(CPlusPlusE::PublicUI);
```

Outputs raw bytes.

Comment: [This is Beatnik.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155414/68615) *So* pissed it took me so long...

Comment: @totallyhuman nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 7):

## [brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), 220 bytes, [cracked by tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155103)

Yes, feeding into a brainfuck interpreter does the work, but polyglots are sweet.

```javascript
// Calculate the digit sum of 2^64
var sum = 1 + 8 + 4 + 4 + 6 + 7 + 4 + 4 + 0 + 7 + 3;
var b = " "[2 > 1 && (sum = sum + 7 + 0 + 9 + 5 + 5 + 1 + 6 + 1 + 6) + 0 < -88];
var c = "a" > [2 < +3 ? console.log(sum) > -1 : 0];
```

Yes, this is a full program. Prints all ASCII codepoints from 1 through 100.

Intended to be funny.

P.S. Prints 88 in JS.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155103/44718)

Answer (score 7):

## [SuperCollider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperCollider), 22 bytes, [cracked by Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155178/21034)

```
for(1,100,"% "postf:_)
```

Outputs decimal integers, space separated. The output has a trailing space but no trailing newline.

---

Explanation: SuperCollider is a domain-specific language for sound synthesis and music composition, so I thought it might obscure enough in this community to escape being cracked. I used to golf in it regularly though, in order to post [music on Twitter](https://twitter.com/headcube). (The link has audio recordings as well as the 140-character code that produced them.)

In addition, I used a couple of tricks to make the code not look like typical SuperCollider. A more paradigmatic approach to this task would be

```
99.do {
    arg i;
    (i+1).postln;
};
```

which prints the numbers newline-separated.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155178/12012)

Answer (score 7):

## [Literate CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#literate), 429 bytes, safe

```
##For# ###@### #####

 ###(# ##i# ### ### ##=1###

###whiLe# ##lEss###than###
   
 ###||##equalTo## ### ###100#&&##doing#pLusplUs##i###
  
# #####)##{#### # ###x=exp i##

 ### ###console###stdout###

### #this###Next###exPresSion##

 ###plz###.###----# #-----## ##-----###
  
####instead## ###Of##loop-the-loop########

 ### ###log x###fRom##math###for x###Gold# ###in### ###[1###evelaTingTo###..100]###}###

run program mode 100
```

Numbers are newline separated.

Hint: some interpreters are file extension sensitive.

---

#### Explanation

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVFNT4QwEL3zK5pMstEDZPcHrPGiXjZqdD0ZDxUGaFI62BYluv52nCmgiZNM33z0dR7Dqw7tNJU6qgtVUoWFNbGkukbMZvhXnSaAa/KgAOCSXRAgywTPJDOptPh@l5p8fLTmgFKyVyFwHlvtpKeUStzTCQDfBm2P9MuG3XYLmw1ARcY10B@G0NunIDMSM1umnwN8QaJIPu5x7JVZRYmX5AJZ5CjEioa4ilIsw4iaWxyliOO9x/BoyK3s3n7yWbDnbEzIE8qrSzQLYTMuRNTVPPGu5i8l6vPYYi4BLPYnylKjRsb6gTqATsdWEvKpeEO2SreMW64/yyrxHa0@8jJkS1AUvKAXDr7Tw35wqvfUeN2pjn@a4u4P)

The CoffeeScript compiler recognises files that have a `.litcoffee` extension as being literate CoffeeScript (as mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript#Latest_additions)). These are meant to be markdown files where the indented code is treated as CoffeeScript. So with the now extraneous newlines removed the code looks like this after it has been tranformed to non-literate CoffeeScript

```
###(# ##i# ### ### ##=1###
###||##equalTo## ### ###100#&&##doing#pLusplUs##i###
### ###console###stdout###
###plz###.###----# #-----## ##-----###
### ###log x###fRom##math###for x###Gold# ###in### ###[1###evelaTingTo###..100]###}###
```

In CoffeeScript the block comment character is `###` so most of this is either whitespace or inside a block comment. The actually functional code is

```
       console
         .
       log x for x in [1..100]
```

This code is equivalent to `console.log x for x in [1..100]`

Answer (score 6):

## [xEec](http://paulo-jorente.de/poncho/esolang/xEec/), 47 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155041) by [MD XF](/u/61663)

```
h#1 h#0 >a p o# h#10 o$ p h#1 ma t h#101 ms jna
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0hNTf7/P0PZUCFD2UDBLlGhQCFfGcg2NFDIVwFyQDK5iQolYCEgs1ghKy/x/38A)

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155041/61563)

Answer (score 6):

## [Unbalanced](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Unbalanced), 130 bytes, [cracked by user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155112/56656)

```
)<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<)<){>{>}<({)<}}>(>((>(<{>}<<(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9f04YOQNNGs9qu2q7WRqNa06a21k7DTgOIbEAiNhr//wMA)

Well I thought I'd give this a go.  Can't be terribly hard to crack but should be some fun (I had fun writing this program at least).

For ease of cracking the important parts of the program are first a single parenthesis

```
)
```

Then 100 `<`s

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Then some junk

```
)<){>{>}<({)<}}>(>((>(<{>}<<(
```

### Explanation

Unbalanced is a programming language about using the imbalance of braces in the program to do computations.

The first part of the program

```
)<<<<....<<<<)<
```

Creates three cells set to `1` with an ocean of 99 `0`s between two them.  We then use the subroutine

```
{>{>}<({)<}}
```

Which will add travel incrementing each cell until it hits a zero at which point it resets itself back to the begining of each line.  This will run until all of the 99 `0`s have been filled with ascending numbers.  Once that's done we do a little clean up

```
>(>((>(<{>}<<(
```

to remove all of the markers we placed.

Comment: What output format does this use? Unary, bytes, numbers etc.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing It can use either bytes or numbers.  I'm not picky.

Comment: This really looks like Pain-Flak, I was rather surprised when it wasn't. +1

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `<<<<<<...<<<<<<` is not the same as '100 `>`s'?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/155112#155112).

Comment: Does this have an Esolangs article ([nope](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unbalanced)), an English Wikipedia article ([nope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbalanced)), a Rosetta Code article ([nope](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Unbalanced)) or a TIO implementation ([nope](https://tio.run/#unbalanced))?

Comment: @MDXF Oh I thought it had a Esolangs article.  My bad.

Answer (score 6):

## TacO, 31 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155527) by totallyhuman

```
$ 100
@(%
  #XX
&^0
  *i	*j
F=1
```

The output is a list of unary numbers with `1` representing the digit. The delimiter between the numbers is `\t0` (a tab and a zero). There is also a single leading `0`. The raw text of the output can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/S1mX7kpC). The raw text for the source code is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/RT8ShZ5N).

TacO is a 2D language. The instruction pointer begins at the `@` symbol and follows the chain of nonwhitespace. The only active code in this program is

```
 100
@%
 0
 *i
 1
```

The `%` symbol creates a loop where the first branch yields the number of times the second branch should be executed. The zero gets added to the eventual output then the `*` symbol which in this case works mostly the same way as `%`. The `i` yields which `%` loop is being run then the `1` gets added `i` times.

In the original program I through in `XX` to try and throw people off, hoping they would be looking for languages that where `XX` would mean `100`. The tab+`*j` was also meant to be a red herring since there is a tab in the input (which is the default output for `%` I guess). I included the other symbols because there needed to be spaces anyway so they didn't cost any  bytes.

Comment: Replacing the tab character with `&#9;` makes it display properly in the Markdown.

Comment: [This is TacO.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155527/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman nice

Answer (score 6):

## [Giac/Xcas](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/giac.html), 43 bytes, safe

```
a:=[];for(n:=1;n<101;n:=n+1)a:=append(a,n);
```

I hope this isn't too easy

Comment: Note that for this challenge only full program submission is allowed. I'm not sure about REPL.

Comment: It is not Go, and it does not need to be run in a REPL.

Comment: Note that languages must have free interpreters. Matlab can't be used. If this is Matlab then the answer is invalid.

Comment: @user202729 If it works in Octave (it doesn't) it's fine though.

Comment: It's not Matlab either, and the interpreter is FOSS.

Comment: But does this actually *print* the list of numbers?

Comment: Yes, the list of numbers is printed.

Comment: Does this have an esolangs article or a rosetta code article or a wikipedia article?

Comment: @MDXF It does. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcas#Giac

Answer (score 6):

## [AlphaBeta](https://esolangs.org/wiki/AlphaBeta), 8 bytes, safe

One last crack at a short one.

```
gD[Lxe]O
```

Outputs as raw

Explanation

```
g         adds 1 to register 2
 D        sets register 3 to value of register 2
   L      outputs a character to the screen
    x     clears register 1
     e    adds 100 to register e
       O  goto the position register (0) if register 1 != register 2
```

The `[]` are no-ops.

Unfortunately, after I posted this answer I discovered that the interpreter linked on the esolang page has a bug where it increments the instruction pointer immediately after the `O` command.  This was discovered and fixed by @Dennis in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36758/31347) and fixed in [this interpreter](https://pastebin.com/zEJkABZV).  I would have changed it slightly to work with either, but I thought it was too late by then.  If this invalidates my answer, so be it.

Dennis has added the fixed interpreter to TIO so :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8wpyEhMSi1J/P8/3SXapyI11v//fwA)

Comment: Nice misdirection with the brackets. (Who expects no-ops in 8 bytes of source code?) I've added the modified interpreter (fixed `w` as well) to TIO. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8wpyEhMSi1J/P8/3SXapyI11v//fwA "AlphaBeta – Try It Online")

Comment: @Dennis Thank you, to be honest I thought you may crack it.

Answer (score 6):

## [oOo CODE](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 161 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155761/31347) by [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934)

My apologies to all the young people here and us older one's as well :).  Had some time to kill and this was just a bit of fun.  Should be cracked rather quickly.

```
If UR lEEt `NUfF 2 W0rK 0Ut W0T 'd4 L4NgUAgE Is It Will 5h0W y4 ZEr0 T0 NiN37Y nIN3 pLUs 0NE, bU7 Us A AsCIi Ch4rACt0r 4 tH3 Numb3r Rath3R ThAN Th3 numB3r itS3Lf
```

> This is brainfuck encoded using the case of each set of three letters.  Once decoded the brainfuck program looks like ++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>[<+.>-]

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155761/55934)

Answer (score 6):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 6 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247384/100664) by UnrelatedString

```
`|\X]-
```

<s>I seriously doubt this is gonna get cracked, but I'm offering a 50 rep bounty to whoever cracks this.</s> never mind.

As I revealed in chat, this language currently has nine answers, all by its creator.

When running this, make sure that there is not a trailing newline at the end of the file.

As @UnrelatedString figured out, this corresponds to `-0/(*(*%*)2)` in [HBL's codepage](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md).

The challenging part of this was keeping the bytes within printable ASCII. I could only use the characters between 2 and 7 in the codepage for every other byte. That means that `0` (the 1 range builtin), `%` (10) and the parentheses are difficult to use. Worse, I can't at all use `'%` (100).

As you can see, those hard-to-use builtins take up every second byte - I crammed it in well.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247384/85334)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155135) by Conor O'Brien

```
+\100\1
```

Decimal output.

Comment: This _seems_ to be APL, but if it were, it would violate the "may not assume REPL" environment. AFAICT, [this](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HvvEdtE7RjDA0MYgz//wcA) works. I am probably missing a language, but I'm posting this comment just to make sure

Comment: @ConorO'Brien that's indeed APL. AFAIK this form is considered a full program (as the assignment to stdout is a part of the way it works in tio). If you want to run it as is, you can use the input section rather than the assignment in the code section.

Comment: Well, then [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155135/31957)

Comment: You didn't obfuscate it enough: [`+\1/1/10/1/10/+\1/1`](https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html#code=+%5C1/1/10/1/10/+%5C1/1)

Comment: @Adám I figured that in that form it would be less likely to be spotted as APL, and could look like the instructions are push 1 (\1), push 100 (\100), and range (+)

Comment: Still right-associative, so it smells of APL.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brainf*ck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 322 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155057/51820) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
c="[,]"[1];f=[eval("str.format")][0];p="1+1"
late=eval(p)+sum([((-1)>1)+0+(0>1)+0+1<<4]);ml=160>>2
ml*=([(7-1)<7+1+1+3*(9>1)]<[(5-1>1+1+1>2)+2+1<<2]);xn=42>>1;ss=sum(eval(f("[10-5{}(4<7)+7+8{}(6>8)]>>>["[:24],c,c)))#]<<<
lol=(7<42)+late+ml+xn+ss#[
m=-9;g=(str((2>m)+x) for x in range(lol));print("\n".join(g));1 < 2 or e#]
```

<s>This is way too long to win, but it probably won't be safe anyways.</s>

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155057/68615)

Answer (score 5):

## [Forth](http://forth-standard.org/), <s>74</s> 48 bytes, [cracked by Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155146)

```
: | 0 do i 1 + 0 do 42 emit loop cr loop ; 100 |
```

Unary output

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've added a formatted header to this post including a byte count.  Feel free to roll this back or edit it further.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155146/45941)

Answer (score 5):

## [Spiral](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Spiral), 136 bytes, safe

```
2^,*v~******v^v+.@
     X          3X&#%!;
 R"";!>+>+>-[>>>]?
    >--[-[<->+++[-]]]<[++++++++++++<[
"123 0******v^v+^v+^v+^v+*****v+*v1"
```

Output is newline-separated.

[Interpreter.](http://web.archive.org/web/20060223041000/http://quintopia.net:80/JSpI.java)

**Unobfuscated (67 bytes):**

```
2^,*v~******v^v+.3
     X
     !
123 0******v^v+^v+^v+^v+*****v+*v1
```

The additional characters in the obfuscated version are not no-ops (except for the quote marks), they just are never reached.

**Explanation:**

The instruction pointer of the program begins at the `0`. At each step, the IP tries to turn 90 degrees right from its current direction. If there is whitespace in that direction, it turns left until it finds something that is not whitespace. Once it has found a non-whitespace character to move to, it moves to that position and executes the command that the character represents.

So, in this case, the IP starts moving right from the zero on the last line:

```
0******v^v+^v+^v+^v+*****v+*v1
```

`*` increments the value in the register by one. This happens six times, and then `v` pushes the number 6 from the register to the stack. `^` copies the value from the stack to the register, and the second `v` pushes the copy to the stack. Then `+` pops the two values from the stack and pushes their sum to the stack.

At the end of the line (just before reaching the `1`), there are two numbers in the stack, 1 (on top) and 100. `1`, `2`, and `3` are labels. When one of them is reached, the IP jumps to the second occurrence of the same character in the code. So, from the end of the last line, the IP jumps to the beginning of the last line, to: `123`. From there it immediately jumps to the first line of the code:

```
2^,*v~******v^v+.3
     X
     !
```

`^` copies the number 1 from the stack to the register, `,` pops it from the stack and prints it as a decimal number. `*v` increments the register by one and pushes it into the stack. `~` compares the two topmost values on the stack, and pushes a zero into the stack if they are equal (-1 or 1 otherwise, depending on which value is larger).

At this point, for the first time in this program, there is a character 90 degrees to the right from the instruction pointer's current position and direction. The IP tries to move to the `X`, which pops the value of the comparison from the stack. Compared to the other commands, `X` is special in that way that the IP only moves to it if the value popped from the stack is 0. Otherwise the IP treats it as whitespace and turns left until it finds some direction to go. Therefore the `X` branch is only entered when the two values in the stack are equal, that is, the counter (the number just printed) reaches 100. After that `!` ends the program.

When the counter is less than one hundred, the IP resumes going eastward on the first line. `******v^v+` places number 10 in the stack, `.` pops it and prints it as an ASCII character (a newline, in this case). `3` jumps back to `123`, from which the IP jumps back to the first line and a new iteration begins.

(In the obfuscated version the `3` is under the `.`, this doesn't affect the behaviour, because the IP turns right always when possible (unless it's in left-turning mode, but this program does not change the mode at any point.))

Comment: Not Prelude, Hexagony, Brainbool, Boolfuck, Brainfuck, Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck, Random Brainfuck, Fisson, Fission 2, Self-modifying Brainfuck, Symbolic Brainfuck, ><>, Gol><>,Triangular, Lost, Befunge-93, 96, 97 or 98, in case anyone wants to try to crack this.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Seems that the obfuscation worked, as I tried to make it look a bit like some of those languages.

Answer (score 5):

## [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), 30 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155303/44718) by [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)

```
i=1
loop,100
 send % i++ . ","
```

Output is comma separated numbers

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155303/44718)

Answer (score 5):

## [Alarm Clock Radio](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Alarm_Clock_Radio), 62 (+3 for `-O2`) = 65 bytes, safe

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++@[+++>+>]+>[+>.+>]
```

<s>This is totally brain[bleep]! Metaphorically speaking, at least :D</s>

It is a BF derivative, however!

### Explanation

Alarm Clock Radio is a BF derivative without `<` or `-`, but it has a cyclic tape. `-O2` is used to limit the tape size to `2` cells.

`-O2` specifies the

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ set pointer to 44
@ wait 44 seconds
[+++>+>]+   set tape to (156 1)
>[+>.+>]    until 156 is 0 (by overflow), output increasing characters
```

Since 256 - 156 == 100, this loops 100 times.

Comment: (there are 44 `+`s before the `@`)

Comment: Is this braincurses?

Comment: @Noone no it is not, I don't think anyway

Comment: So this is probably a well known language with so many interpreters, and the problem is to find out which interpreter had the right command line option?

Comment: @jimmy23013 I doubt the flag is necessary, considering it was edited in 10 hours later.

Comment: @totallyhuman No, it is necessary, it was simply a copying mistake

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 494 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155442) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
#define/*+[--->++<]>+++.[->++++<]>+.+++++++++++.-[->+++++<]>+.------------.-[--->++<]>-.+++++++++++.+[--->+<]>.-[->+++<]>+.+[---->+<]>+++.+[->++<]>.---[----->+<]>-.+++[->+++<]>++.++++++++.+++++.--------.-[--->+<]>--.+[->+++<]>+.++++++++.[->++++++++++<]>.>++++++++++..[------>+<]>.++++++++++.++++++++.+++++++++++.[++>---<]>...>++++++++++..*/\
print =cat   ( c (  1  :  100  )  ) 
#define print(x)main(){for(auto i=.5;i++<sizeof('i')*101;printf("%d ",(char)i));}
#include<stdio.h>
print("1 "*100)
```

Without all the polyglot obfuscation:

```
cat(c(1:100))
```

Comment: +1 for the Easter Egg when run in the 'obvious' language :D

Comment: [This is R.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155442/68615)

Answer (score 5):

## [Io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(programming_language)), 71 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155497/69655) by Potato44

```
a := "+++++++++[>+.+.+.+.+.+.d.+.+.+.+.<-]";for(q,1,a at(23),q println)
```

Comment: How does this output the numbers? E.g. raw bytes, decimals separated by newlines, etc.

Comment: (Brainfuck is not my guess) but if this is supposed to be Brainfuck or any derivative (e.g. Agony, Self-Modifying Brainfuck, Xeraph, etc) it doesn't work; it only prints up to 90.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155497/69655). I think. Untested.

Answer (score 5):

## [Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(programming_language)), 35 bytes, safe

A little late to the party, but here's one:

```
2T5*=
(A1.1
+=1.!
B2.1-
=2.^"
")B$$
```

### Explanation

Mouse is a simple stack based language that was described in Byte magazine in 1979 or so.  Expressions are postfix.  Single letters represent variables.  When a variable name is scanned in the code, the address of the variable is pushed on the stack.  The code above works with the Pascal version of the interpreter which pushes a '1' for A.  A C version of the interpreter pushes a '0' for A.

The `.` operator retrieves the value in the variable indexed by the top of the stack. `=` pops the top two values from the stack and stores the value from the top into the variable indexed by the second from the top.

`(..^..)` is a loop; the`^` pops the top of the stack and exits a loop if the value is zero
`!` pops and prints the top of the stack.
`"..."` outputs the characters in quotes.

Because `1` and `A` both cause the value 1 to be pushed on the stack, `1.` is equivalent to `A.`.  This is used to obfuscate the code, e.g., `A1.1+=` instead of `AA.1+=`.

```
2T5*=(A1.1+=1.!B2.1-=2.^"\n")B$$

2T5*=                             var[2] = T * 5 (i.e. B = 20*5)
     (                            loop
      A1.1+=                      A = var[1] + 1  (i.e. A = A + 1)
            1.!                   push var[1] (i.e., A) and output it
               B2.1-=             B = var[2] - 1 (i.e. B = B - 1)
                     2.^          push var[2] (i.e. B) and exit loop if zero
                        "\n"      output a newline
                            )     end of loop
                             B    junk filer
                              $$  end of program
```

Comment: This is safe; please reveal the language!

Answer (score 5):

## [Replace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Replace), 473 bytes, safe

Output is space separated, and is prepended with `OUTPUT:\n`.

```
1?2v ?-[>++<-----]>--[.-]>
Print=>{not Palindromic[_]or#String[_]<2}\1:100
"    *
     b
     a
     :
     o
     a
     n
     :
   >1^
     +
     1
     ^                                       \
\D+/ 
2 1/3
3 1/3 4
1 1/8
3 3/9
00/ 5 6 7
9 3/t1
1 4 3/1 t2
4 8/t3
8 9/t4
(?<=8 )(?=t)/9 
9  5/t5
(.) 7 5|6 (.) t1/t\1\2
4 1/t8
t2 4.+/t9
9$/9100
 t/t
t(.)/\1_0\1_1\1_2\1_3\1_4\1_5\1_6\1_7\1_8\1_9
_(.)(.)/\1 \2
910/9 10
     >                                       /
     ;"
```

[Interpreter](https://github.com/icedvariables/replace-lang)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not ><>

Comment: @NieDzejkob nor Gol><>, which misses some of the numbers; this is an impressive polyglot.

Comment: This is safe; please reveal the language!

Comment: I tried /// and itflabfriugherigoerujg (idk) but I didn't know of others. Nice one!

Comment: @totallyhuman thanks! It was an interesting task to find "deja vu" languages

Answer (score 5):

## [Alphabetti spaghetti](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Alphabetti_spaghetti), 11 bytes, safe

```
JuvlikaJoEs
```

Outputs decimal with newline after every number.

Comment: "If your code contains bytes outside of printable ASCII + newline, please include a hex dump to make sure your code is actually testable" -> `0x0A` is not printable ASCII.

Comment: There shouldn't be a line feed and I can't seem to find it. The code is only those visible letters.

Comment: My bad, it was due to me messing up the `xxd` invocation.

Comment: This is safe; please reveal the language!

Comment: The provided interpreter on esolangs does not build correctly: `main.c:34:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘init’`

Comment: @quartata It works in [the second latest commit](https://github.com/gitwalrus/AlphabettiSpaghetti/tree/d2717c6e912401ebcccaf8c1823ca5e0cdcf04a8). At least on my machine, in REPL mode.

Answer (score 5):

## Literate Python, 162 bytes, safe

```
def define_i():

    global i

    i = 0

define_i()

while i < 100:

    i += 1

    print(i)

def ruin():

    for i in range(99):

        print(i + 2)

ruin()
```

[Literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) is a programming style where a program is written as a document that describes the behavior of the program along with its actual code, so programs mostly consist of paragraphs of prose followed by a few lines of code. Needless to say, being on PPCG, I'm not particularly interested in this concept :)

I'm not sure whether this counts. I'm heavily basing the validity of this answer off of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155533/61384) by Dennis, which uses an implementation of C with different behavior that is not present on Wikipedia or TIO.

Here, the "compiler" is [this Ruby script](https://github.com/stewart/literate-ruby), which extracts the actual code from a literate programming file (it is intended for Ruby programs and as such generates `.rb` files, but the Python interpreter doesn't care). When converting a literate program to a real program, the script simply searches for indented sections with blank lines around them. This means that the code that is actually executed looks like this:

```
global i
i = 0
i += 1
print(i)
for i in range(99):
    print(i + 2)
```

For some reason, a top-level `global` statement is not an error and is simply ignored, so this program prints out the integers from 1 to 100.

Comment: Does this print anything outside of the 1-100 area? (i.e. are there trailing characters)

Comment: @Solver There is a trailing newline, just like there would be if Python was the correct answer.

Comment: One more day to be safe...

Comment: This is safe now.

Comment: @Christopher Revealed the language.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/lyxal/vyxal) `-HASKELL-RANGES`, 20 bytes, [Cracked by a stone arachnid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/237772#237772)

```
100...0 do I 'p I;';
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=-HASKELL-RANGES&code=100...0%20do%20I%20%27p%20I%3B%27%3B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

The `-HASKELL-RANGES` flag is a spoof for `H` and `S`. `H` pushes 100 to the stack at thte start, and `S` joins the stack by spaces at the end.

```
100...0 do           # ??? Somehow leaves 100 on the stack
                     # 100...0 on its own segfaults or something
                     # So idk why this works but it does
           I         # Coerce to integer
             '   ;   # Filter by (auto-converts to range)
              p I    # Prepended to itself is truthy?
                  '; # NOP
```

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237772/80050)

Comment: @astonearachnid Nice :P

Answer (score 5):

## PARI/GP, 20899 bytes, safe

```
print('a')
print('a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
print('a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a'+'a')
```

Prints numbers from 1 to 100 in decimal digits, separated by newlines.

This trick is found by [Charles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2605/charles) in [the PARI/GP answer to Showcase of Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44779/9288):

> Length 1: `'`
>
> This command can be used to quote, but not in the usual way. `'x` means "the literal polynomial x, not the value in the variable x". In postfix, it means the derivative. Tricky example: `'x'` is 1 -- the derivative of the polynomial x.

Comment: This is Python.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Outputs are decimal integers in the intended language, not unary. I'll edit to clarify the output format.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/), 148 bytes, cracked by emanresuA

```
START
#IMPORT `\EMPTY\`
#IMPORT `\COMPLEX\`
#IMPORT <LINEBREAK>
`\REGEX\`
REGEX-REPLACE[COMPLEX-MATH[`0 100(1+:,)`], EMPTY-STRING, EMPTY-STRING]
END
```

This is probably most crazy code.

Comment: Safe for a while now, what is it?

Comment: This is [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJTVEFSVFxuI0lNUE9SVCBgXFxFTVBUWVxcYFxuI0lNUE9SVCBgXFxDT01QTEVYXFxgXG4jSU1QT1JUIDxMSU5FQlJFQUs+XG5gXFxSRUdFWFxcYFxuUkVHRVgtUkVQTEFDRVtDT01QTEVYLU1BVEhbYDAgMTAwKDErOiwpYF0sIEVNUFRZLVNUUklORywgRU1QVFktU1RSSU5HXVxuRU5EIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Comment: @emanresuA too late

Comment: You didn't declare it safe, therefore it's a crack.

Comment: @emanresuA wait, is there a rule?

Comment: If you haven't declared it safe, it's not safe and it can be cracked. There's a certain time period after which it *can* be declared safe, but it's not automatically safe after that time.

Comment: @emanresuA I mean Meta post

Comment: [Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10027/100664).

Answer (score 4):

## Commentator, 223 bytes, [cracked by totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155035/66833)

```
print "H e l l o, W o r l d!", end = 10
for i in range( 1 0 0 ):
        print i
;{-Haskell ?-}
#Python?
(({- Execute some# brainflak here#}))
;-}Perl: bvgk,l/;'juhedwsed/*{-:
05AB1E: 12DD/* Way to convert to float, nice :)
```

I might as well join in the fun! I'm pretty sure this doesn't work in any other languages, but Perl can be weird, so you never know. This outputs in bytes, so the output should look like:

```
	

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcd
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155035/68615)

Answer (score 4):

## Foo, 30 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155066/61563) by MD XF

It wouldn't be the Programming Language Quiz without Foo!

```
@10+10*+10(10@1>+$i<$c10-1)+@0
```

Outputs in decimal, with a newline after each number.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155066/61563) (didn't see that coming)

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 40 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155046/68615) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
"0" < q <= s' * 1e' * g * 1061 * 19 * 77
```

Outputs as decimal integers.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155046/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman that was faster than I expected

Answer (score 4):

## [ELVM IR](https://github.com/shinh/elvm), 587 bytes, [cracked by Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155068/61563)

```
	.text
main:
	mov D, SP
	add D, -1
	store BP, D
	mov SP, D
	mov BP, SP
	.file 1 "-"
	.loc 1 2 0
	mov A, 1
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	store A, B
	.L0:
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	load A, B
	mov D, SP
	add D, -1
	store A, D
	mov SP, D
	mov A, 101
	mov B, A
	load A, SP
	add SP, 1
	lt A, B
	jeq .L3, A, 0
	jmp .L4
	.L3:
	jmp .L2
	.L4:
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	load A, B
	mov D, SP
	add D, -1
	store A, D
	mov SP, D
	putc A
	add SP, 1
	.L1:
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	load A, B
	mov D, SP
	add D, -1
	store A, D
	mov SP, D
	add A, 1
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	store A, B
	load A, SP
	add SP, 1
	jmp .L0
	.L2:
	exit
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155068/12012)

Comment: @Dennis Knew you'd be the one to crack this, nice job

Answer (score 4):

## Underload, 659 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155637/61563) by MD XF

```
lpvO`.U%C$j<{YNXzbF[=/n'A5 7KYL3$3IZvrP>P%LJ&`fv[5]$3(
){u}Z'K7s{lA8}pNZvmLwE`GevRo?I>H38{q}[d/hJrkcp7F]e7$H[
L(]WCrrWxbb[M][6]m\[DH]j98Ki&H<n=Nn=|{f}UMs-`_5b?-ixC/
5V_M{R}w@+[N2P]eg998dq;[Qq]-od|XoX{P}{N,}#G($)%tdZN*?[
Z];fUK{_H26DY'R|sdQy;%P#g}|X{IQvM}cXDMmvG1O[i-][{s}]3I
L:hw2s ="dY0g/4YS14#>Y.GIs=KMm"H[&]r3[G])VgE(hCLyP8cs[
V]j[W]jg:cvp6X8:lNchdg8;55{o}P]{*Q}qc[y$]sZ?P60EI[_]wt
:6TIyK'XRfR<[>HG]*|Xz]o[z]0A[T]t{"}*}[8#N5wy[{nU}[W]N;
+h?p{nRgy}W{[u]vIJX?{sl,};4>.}Z/Km>1]]:pMp-0<[[,].Q$J`
*&nL0Jg]{/{J),[[{[s]j}]]=f7f B:5k}"B{1A}}{*T}1Tr/cRX w
lBKJ_6UoC^QBC{8}/G'x2&Le3w[u]&T-hpUA2/c.>Zb[N]|pX[8,]X
t2@^.{h}K7lo{<d}xozh>wb?Hello worldHello worldHello wo
```

> This is [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload). The Underload interpreter on TIO ignores invalid commands (anything other than `:*()^aS!~`), so the program looks like this:
>
> ```
> (
> )(($)*:S)::*:**:*:*^
> ```
>
> I wrote a Python script that generated random ASCII (excluding Underload commands) with matching brackets. I then filled in the result with my Underload program.

Comment: Is this Gammaplex? Can't find a working interpreter to test it out

Comment: @MDXF I'll just answer your question to save you time: No.

Comment: [Cracked, finally!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155637/61563)

Comment: @MDXF nice crack and EsolangingFruit nice obscuring ( I can't spell obfuscation)

Comment: The matching brackets/braces/parenthesis gave it away for me.

Comment: @MDXF Nice! Note that the brackets aren't actually perfectly matched everywhere; there are a few deliberate mismatches to provide confusion (although staring at the code now I can't remember where they were :P)

Comment: @EsolangingFruit nice! I didn't manually check them but they appeared to be balanced so I tested underload.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 54 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155140/16766) by ovs

```
False T
For nnz(100) T+1 
'cout <<' T
)o:
bux bux Q
hu
```

Well, there's an emoji in there... **)o:**

It's actually the `c` in `'cout'`(code-point 99) that makes the range end at 100, not the number 100 in the code.

Outputs as a list of numbers, separated by spaces.

#### Explanation

```
F             % Push False (0)
 a            % any(). Stack: 0
  l           % ones(). Stack: 0, 1
   s          % sum(). Stack: 0, 1
    e         % reshape(). Stack: 0
      T       % Push True (1). Stack: 0, 1
F             % Push False (0). Stack: 0, 1, 0
 o            % parity(). Stack: 0, 1, 0
  r           % Push random number. Stack: 0, 1, 0, 0.4234..
    n         % numel(). Stack: 0, 1, 0, 1
     n        % numel(). Stack: 0, 1, 0, 1
      z       % nnz(). Stack: 0, 1, 0, 1
       (      % Assignment indexing. Stack: 0, 0
        100   % Push 100. Stack: 0, 0, 100
           )  % Reference indexing (nothing there). Stack: 0, 0
             T     % Push True(1). Stack: 0, 0, 1
              +    % Add last two numbers: Stack: 0, 1
               1   % Push 1. Stack: 0, 1, 1
'cout <<'        % Push string, 'cout <<'. Stack: 0, 1, 1, 'cout <<'
          T      % Push True (0). Stack: 0, 1, 1, 'cout <<', 1
)                % Reference indexing using T as index to the string. Stack: 0, 1, 1, 'c'
 o               % Convert to double. Stack: 0, 1, 1, 99
  :              % Range from 1 to 99. Stack: 0, 1, 1, [1, 2, ... 99]
b                % Bubble. Stack: 0, 1, [1 2, ... 99], 1
 ux              % Unique, and delete last element. Stack: [0, 1, [1, 2, ... 99]
    bux          % The same again. Stack: 1, [1, 2, ... 99]
        Q        % Increment. Stack: 1, [2, 3, ... 100]
hu               % Horizontal concatenation and unique. Stack: [1, 2, ... 100]
```

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155140/64121)

Comment: Yeah, `nnz` is very revealing.

Comment: In hindsight, I should maybe have chosen something else than those functions as `nnz` is a common MATLAB function, and that makes you think of MATL. But `nnz(100)` is something **very** different in MATL than in MATLAB.

Comment: Explanation added. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Width](https://github.com/stestoltz/Width), 249 bytes, safe

```
Oml, my GL :G
      		  MM :Z 
	  	  i'm GR8 ;]
GL mom! 	
	  	  F#$! i'm my RAG3! >:[
 	 	  111'M Gr8! =] 

11/01/18:
  	
w0W i'm IQ=1
 	  	  Ik! ;]
*IQ=100
	 	  tUt!
11/02/18:

  __
 (Gl)
  .
 . 
:W 
		  i Wi11 
                  WOw! 1 RAN and WON
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9PC8IwDMXPy6d4RcE/yFz0MioTvFgEpziQgTKGsIPDVUEGw08/0@LBkEPal1/y0tVVe@/7o21msB@YPbQh@AgCIE2hLyCpJOuRhclirAqSPvuyCsFP2g6GyusyI9uYpcJaX0kU0Zh5lMK8Y4WkABHzPOI5x1r2BNRFuQd3p4Qd4HL3UG7J1P1FEfkp7blVHl14VNiyJIxNM5EyJIQgnYtT5xN5zYzfGf@RHzsFFocH3J6VPA99/wU)

Is this a program, or did I accidentally screenshot my text history?

Output is in the form `[1, 2, 3, ... 99, 100]`

---

Width gives you a lot of leeway by:

- Only executing alphabetic characters
- Allowing you to choose between sets of characters for each command (for example, command 3 can be any of `a b d e g h n o p q u L`, though command 9 can only be `W`)

All the whitespace nonsense, the `IQ=100` and the emoticons were red herrings.

The executing code is

```
OmlmyGLGMMZimGRGLmomFimmyRAGMGrwWimIQIkIQtUtGlWiWiWOwRAN
```

Which pushes the string `print(list(range(1,101)))` and evaluates it using the inbuilt Python eval command. BTW, I'm pretty sure the looping mechanism for that language is broken, since it kept hitting a recursion limit when I tried to use it... :(

Comment: This is safe; please reveal the language!

Answer (score 4):

## [VoidLang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/VoidLang), 2627 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156155/31347) by moonheart08

```
"11"!"|"!"111"+!."|"!"1111"++!."|"!"11111"+++!."|"!"111111"++++!."|"!"1111111"+++++!."|"!"11111111"++++++!."|"!"111111111"+++++++!."|"!"91"!."|"!"911"+!."|"!"9111"++!."|"!"91111"+++!."|"!"911111"++++!."|"!"9111111"+++++!."|"!"91111111"++++++!."|"!"911111111"+++++++!."|"!"9111111111"++++++++!."|"!"991"+!."|"!"9911"++!."|"!"99111"+++!."|"!"991111"++++!."|"!"9911111"+++++!."|"!"99111111"++++++!."|"!"991111111"+++++++!."|"!"9911111111"++++++++!."|"!"99111111111"+++++++++!."|"!"9991"++!."|"!"99911"+++!."|"!"999111"++++!."|"!"9991111"+++++!."|"!"99911111"++++++!."|"!"999111111"+++++++!."|"!"9991111111"++++++++!."|"!"99911111111"+++++++++!."|"!"999111111111"++++++++++!."|"!"99991"+++!."|"!"999911"++++!."|"!"9999111"+++++!."|"!"99991111"++++++!."|"!"999911111"+++++++!."|"!"9999111111"++++++++!."|"!"99991111111"+++++++++!."|"!"999911111111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999111111111"+++++++++++!."|"!"999991"++++!."|"!"9999911"+++++!."|"!"99999111"++++++!."|"!"999991111"+++++++!."|"!"9999911111"++++++++!."|"!"99999111111"+++++++++!."|"!"999991111111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999911111111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999111111111"++++++++++++!."|"!"9999991"+++++!."|"!"99999911"++++++!."|"!"999999111"+++++++!."|"!"9999991111"++++++++!."|"!"99999911111"+++++++++!."|"!"999999111111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999991111111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999911111111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999111111111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"99999991"++++++!."|"!"999999911"+++++++!."|"!"9999999111"++++++++!."|"!"99999991111"+++++++++!."|"!"999999911111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999111111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999991111111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999911111111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999111111111"++++++++++++++!."|"!"999999991"+++++++!."|"!"9999999911"++++++++!."|"!"99999999111"+++++++++!."|"!"999999991111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999911111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999999111111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999991111111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999911111111"++++++++++++++!."|"!"99999999111111111"+++++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999991"++++++++!."|"!"99999999911"+++++++++!."|"!"999999999111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999991111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999999911111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999111111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999991111111"++++++++++++++!."|"!"99999999911111111"+++++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999111111111"++++++++++++++++!."|"!"99999999991"+++++++++!."|"!"999999999911"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999999111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999999991111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999911111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999999111111"++++++++++++++!."|"!"99999999991111111"+++++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999911111111"++++++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999999111111111"+++++++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999991"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999999911"+++++++++++!."|"!
```

I couldnt resist to use my own toy language.

Comment: This was really a pain to copy so I could paste into an interpreter. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/AKAFEqJm) where you can select-all.

Comment: @MDXF double clicking it selects the entire text on my computer

Comment: What's the output format?

Comment: @totallyhuman the output format is numbers with | as separator

Comment: I know what this is, and you know it @iovoid. Cracked when I wake up tommorow

Comment: @moonheart08 did you forget about it?

Comment: Yup. Leme do it right now.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156155/77964)

Answer (score 4):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 244 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155867) by [Dennis](/u/12012)

```
p = print; r = range; one = 1; hundred = 100; i = 'index'  # set up variables 
  
for i in r(one, hundred + one):  # loop over each number in interval [1, 101) ∩ ℤ to print	  	
	if i==hundred:

 	  p(i) 		 
 	else:p(i,end=chr(44)+chr(32))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY47bsNADETr3VMMkEJaWIWVuJKgk7haS1S0gMJdUB/kAClyEDe@li8iU7DhijME53Ha2EZe5m1LaJAk8FxDVIrnb6oRmdSUNYaFO6FuN8djjaAiC9zRbwZ8YKIZS8LqJfjLSBMsYPsoehcYkiumeCMOO9VVe26MMSGuJCDfDuDl56JaI9qDZPUjzmWhH0uH@/8N978r5visaQBjTegRmuZFrqyFrlMeHIzRDobGiSr1BXHXtIPkp5M77PPr0zlrtu0B)

Comment: Damn, that's sneaky! +1

Comment: To save some TIO computing power: Python 2 complains about 'print' (it's a command, not function); Python 3 complains about inconsistent tab/spaces.

Comment: [This is Coconut.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155867/12012)

Comment: @Dennis ...Wait, it works in Coconut? o0

Comment: Fictional cookie to anybody who can figure the intended language out. :P

Comment: That wasn't intended? Yes, *all valid Python is valid Coconut* and, apparently, Coconut is less picky about indentation.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, the funky whitespace isn't obfuscation. :P It's just a less popular whitespace-based language.

Comment: [One cookie, please.](https://tio.run/##PY47DsIwEERr@xQjURArKQhQJcpJqAzZEEvBtjYfOAAFB6HhWlwkbASi2pnVztu59s08R1SI7PxQgkWy9WcqETyJyUu0o6@Z6sVsNiWciLXzNd3WwAo9DRgjJsvOHjvqoQHdBJY758GJYLI/Il2oplhyXQgRYSIG2VMLP16OoiUiPYgn2@GQZ/IxN3g/XnjfnxjCt6YClFaugauqH7nQGrKOiTNQSjoo6noqxGfk6@rUcrLfm3SZu60xWs3zBw "wsf – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 167 bytes, safe

```
"What is this code?"
{1 in!1to100{_1()+l-
t}100l=:!(l,e,t,h)=
"enl_"; _1=func e,n:
print1 if+e||n||$0+
"\n"-_f1_="";#eval;
;;;};"\-";# Author:
main;# @HermanLauenstein
```

#### Unobufscated code

```
"
{1
 }100 =:!
    _"; _1
     1   +
     _ 1_=
     "\-
       @
```

The code works by hiding a loop inside the mess of random characters made to look like some sort of programming language.

Answer (score 4):

## mmo (MMIX executable), 92 bytes, safe

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 9809 0100 9801 0001 584b 4344 e355 0064  ........XKCD.U.d
00000010: 3737 3637 e437 2000 af55 ff0b a255 5537  7767.7 ..U...UU7
00000020: 2755 5501 5555 fffe e055 2000 ad55 ff03  'UU.UU...U ..U..
00000030: 0000 0601 0000 0000 980a 00ff 2000 0000  ............ ...
00000040: 3755 5500 980b 0000 204d 2061 2069 246e  7UU..... M a i$n
00000050: 584b 4344 8100 0000 980c 0004            XKCD........
```

Hexdump (xxd -p):

```
9809010098010001584b4344e355006437373637e4372000af55ff0ba255
5537275555015555fffee0552000ad55ff030000060100000000980a00ff
2000000037555500980b0000204d20612069246e584b434481000000980c
0004
```

Output is bare characters to stdout.

I'm surprised no-one got this. I thought the 0x98 characters appearing at five separate positions, all multiples of four, would give it away quickly.

A tetrabyte-by-tetrabyte explanation (including loader instructions):

```
98090100 lop_pre 1,0         (preamble, mmo v1, 0 tetras)
98010001 lop_loc 0x00,1      (the next tetra says where to load)
58484344 "XKCD"              (because why not?)
E3550064 SETL  $85, 100      (i = 100)
37373637 NEGUI $55, 54, 55   (data = -1)
E4372000 INCH  $55, 0x2000   (data = [instruction segment start - 1])
AF55FF0B STOUI $85, $255, 11 (store 100 to octabyte after M₈[$255]¹)
A2555537 STBU  $85, $85, $55 (data[i] = i)
27555501 SUBUI $85, $85, 1   (i--)
5555FFFE PBPB  $85, @-16     (jump back two instructions if i > 0)
E0552000 SETH  $85, 2000     ($85 = data+1)
AD55FF03 STOI  $85, $255, 3  (store $85 to M₈[$255]¹)
00000601 TRAP  0, 6, 1       (write first 100 data bytes to stdout²)
00000000 TRAP  0, 0, 0       (halt)
980A00FF lop_post 255        (begin postamble, rG = 255)
20000000
37555500                     ($255 = 0x2000000037555500)
980B0000 lop_stab            (begin symbol table)
204D2061
2069246E
584B4344
81000000                     (val["Main"]="XKCD")
980C0004 lop_end 4           (symtab is 16 bytes long)
```

Footnotes:
1) Octabyte storage disregards the last three bits of the location to store.
2) Syscall 6 is fwrite, which takes as arguments the Z operand for file descriptor (1 is stdout), `M₈[$255]` as the buffer pointer, and `M₈[$255+8]` as the buffer length.

I didn't obfuscate this at all, except by arranging for a lot of repeated bytes (all the Us and 7s); I just wrote a simple algorithm and hand-assembled it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/), 250 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/235158#235158) by pxeger

```
5<4# ++++++++v++{++{+<     v:-1  <"d"\"i"
I=((print))#d+"100"ci}$'mai n'  \ " > *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
n=""#printf  >-}++++=^;-#  >,   :|1h:  ^         -1<
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
##-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][>^<++++>]1@3 \\iiiiidiisiodso
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LTsMwFET3@YrRdaXauIYYysZ1DNuuWeYhpZiAheqgBGUD/fZgIziazVzd0ZnPp2Fd7@2eQf6xSPmVY5FZjNKAJU8NBSqOFecfU4ifQjAvSZclPYfLZnvuA@IWaEBwuHImDTZqNFo9LIciVkTsdzYATl2ypuoOiqW2SxLzrd8M0OEfpW0xjBOe3vcIEVMfX194kgmDI4@7dJZc39yijx4a6bEUomBM1U5KqzKtq5WT17atXWezz7X68Q5NEzI@hDmMfh7X9Qc)

## Explanations

### SMBF

The actaul code executed is

```
<+++++++++++++<-<+>>---++++>-<,+-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][><++++>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LTsMwFET3@YrRdaXauIYYysZ1DNuuWeYhpZiAheqgBGUD/fZgIziazVzd0ZnPp2Fd7@2eQf6xSPmVY5FZjNKAJU8NBSqOFecfU4ifQjAvSZclPYfLZnvuA@IWaEBwuHImDTZqNFo9LIciVkTsdzYATl2ypuoOiqW2SxLzrd8M0OEfpW0xjBOe3vcIEVMfX194kgmDI4@7dJZc39yijx4a6bEUomBM1U5KqzKtq5WT17atXWezz7X68Q5NEzI@hDmMfh7X9Qc)

The bit up until  the `,` is a red herring, parts of code for other languages. The `,` takes input, setting a null byte, and somehow `[>++<-----]>` results in 100. Then, `[->+.<]` prints the characters up to that in ascending order.

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

```python
5<4# ++++++++v++{++{+<     v:-1  <"d"\"i"
I=((print))#d+"100"ci}$'mai n'  \ " > *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
n=""#printf  >-}++++=^;-#  >,   :|1h:  ^         -1<
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
##-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][>^<++++>]1@3 \\iiiiidiisiodso
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LasMwFET3/opBCkSKotZqko0iq91m3aUfYKo8RKkUnGAIab7dlUp7mM1c7nDOt@sphtU0bcyaQvwxCnHPMciMWirAEEca4kmxqxg7Dz5cOadOEFWW5MM/ZvOv3iPMgQYEFgur02Amo1byddwWoSKE/s4OgJWPrKm6raSpLZNEf6uTBjr8I5UpDnHA@@caPmDow3HPkoxr7FhYprNg6vkFfXBQSI8l5wWlsrZCGJlpbS2teDJtbTuTfbZVbys0jc847y8@ukucph8)

The actual code executed is:

```python
5<4
I=((print))
n=""
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
```

A lot of this is for polyglotting with Vyxal, which has the same comments so executes the same code.

The `i` command in Vyxal is indexing, which errors if the first argument isn't a number. We deal with this by aliasing `print` and putting it in double parentheses, so Vyxal never executes it.

The `n=""` is so printing it doesn't error.

The `(1/2 and 1 or 0)` is just a red herring to make you think it's python 2 or something.

So in the end, we're just printing every number between 1 and 100. But it's as numbers, and there's a space before each one.

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal)

```
5<4# ++++++++v++{++{+<     v:-1  <"d"\"i"
I=((print))#d+"100"ci}$'mai n'  \ " > *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
n=""#printf  >-}++++=^;-#  >,   :|1h:  ^         -1<
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
##-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][>^<++++>]1@3 \\iiiiidiisiodso
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=5%3C4%23%20%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2Bv%2B%2B%7B%2B%2B%7B%2B%3C%20%20%20%20%20v%3A-1%20%20%3C%22d%22%5C%22i%22%0AI%3D%28%28print%29%29%23d%2B%22100%22ci%7D%24%27mai%20n%27%20%20%5C%20%22%20%3E%20*%3E%3A%22d%22%24-o%3A1-%3Fv%3B%0An%3D%22%22%23printf%20%20%3E-%7D%2B%2B%2B%2B%3D%5E%3B-%23%20%20%3E%2C%20%20%20%3A%7C1h%3A%20%20%5E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-1%3C%0Afor%20Sk4%20in%20range%28100%29%3A%20I%28n%2CSk4%2B%281%2F2%20and%201%20or%200%29%29%0A%23%23-%5B%3E%2B%2B%3C-----%5D%3E%5B-%3E%2B.%3C%5D%5B%3E%5E%3C%2B%2B%2B%2B%3E%5D1%403%20%5C%5Ciiiiidiisiodso&inputs=%5B%5B%5D%5D&header=&footer=)

The executed code is the same as Python's:

```
5<4
I=((print))
n=""
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
```

As stated before, `i` indexes, and often errors. `Sk4` takes care of the `i` in `in`. `range` ends up pushing a 1, so `(100)` pushes 100 once. `: I` does nothing, so `(n,` prints the iteration number of looping over that 100 times, printing 0...99 inclusive.

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

```
5<4# ++++++++v++{++{+<     v:-1  <"d"\"i"
I=((print))#d+"100"ci}$'mai n'  \ " > *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
n=""#printf  >-}++++=^;-#  >,   :|1h:  ^         -1<
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
##-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][>^<++++>]1@3 \\iiiiidiisiodso
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LTsMwFET3@YqRXal2XUMMZeM6hm3XLPOQIkzaK4SDEpQN9NuDjeBoNnN1R2eg@bKuD@7Aof5YlPrKccgsVhvAscAaRqw4VUJ8TBQ/peRBMVOW7IWum@17T4hboAGDx87bNNjo0Rr9uByLWDHGf2cD4PU1a6ruqHlq@ySx3@ZigQ7/aOOKYZzw/HYARUx9PL@KJJMWJxH36ayEub1DHwMM0mMpZcG5rr1STmdaX2uvblxb@85ln2/N0z2ahjKBaKYxzOO6/gA)

The executed code is:

```
5<                                   \"i"
                                      *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
                                    :  ^         -1<
                                    a
                                    \\
```

The `"i"` is for Deadfish~. Basically, the  bit up until the `*` on the second line pushes 100 to the stack by multiplying `a` (10) by itself. The bit after that on lines 2 & 3 is a simple looping counter, outputting each character. But this prints `0x00` to `c`, not `0x01` to `d`, so it's completely invalid.

### [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-)

```
5<4# ++++++++v++{++{+<     v:-1  <"d"\"i"
I=((print))#d+"100"ci}$'mai n'  \ " > *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
n=""#printf  >-}++++=^;-#  >,   :|1h:  ^         -1<
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
##-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][>^<++++>]1@3 \\iiiiidiisiodso
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LTsMwFET3@YqRXak27oUYysZ1DNuuWeYhRXVDLYSDEpQN9NuDjeBoNnN1R8efez@E@ULr@mj3HOqPRamvHIvMYkgDlnnWsMCKYyXExxTip5TcK6bLkp3CdbN97wPiFmjA4HDjTBpsaDSanpZDESvG@O9sABxds6bqDsRT2yWJ@dYXA3T4h7QthnHCy9seIWLq4@tZJJk0OIq4S2cl9N09@uihkR5LKQvOqXZKWcq0rianbm1bu85mn2v18wOaJmR8CHMY/Tyu6w8)

Deadfish~ *almost* works, but the `o` and `d` in the ><> program completely (intentionally) throw it off.

The actual executed code is:

```
{{di(i)dci}doi}h
```

The `iiiiidiisiodso` at the end is a red herring, and isn't even executed.

This almost prints 1 to 100, but doesn't quite work.

### [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93) (And several variants)

```
5<4# ++++++++v++{++{+<     v:-1  <"d"\"i"
I=((print))#d+"100"ci}$'mai n'  \ " > *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
n=""#printf  >-}++++=^;-#  >,   :|1h:  ^         -1<
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
##-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][>^<++++>]1@3 \\iiiiidiisiodso
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LTsMwEEX3@Yoru1LtugMxlI3rGLZds8xDCrgpFsJBKWQD/fZgIziazVzN1Zmn4/AZT8dlubM7DvXHrNRXHovMbEgDlnnWsMCKQyXE@xTih5TcK6bLkj2Hy2r91gfENdCAwWHjTCqsaDSa7ud9ESvG@G9tABxdsqbq9sTTtk0S861fDNDhH9K2GMYJj687hIipT2@KJJMGBxG3KVZCX9@gjx4a6bCUsuCcaqeUpUzranLqyra162z2uVY/3KJpQsaHcA6jP4/L8gM)

The executed code is:

```
5<                         v:-1  <"d"\"i"

                           >,   :|

                                 @
```

We start by pushing 100 on the stack with "d", then decrement and print until it reaches 0, at which point the redirect `|` sends the IP to the `@`, which terminates the program. This prints `c` to `0x00`, which is wrong.

`\` is a mirror for ><>, but rotates the stack in Befunge-93, which does nothing important.

### [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck)

```
5<4# ++++++++v++{++{+<     v:-1  <"d"\"i"
I=((print))#d+"100"ci}$'mai n'  \ " > *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
n=""#printf  >-}++++=^;-#  >,   :|1h:  ^         -1<
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
##-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][>^<++++>]1@3 \\iiiiidiisiodso
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LTsMwFET3@YqRXak2riGGsnEdw7ZrlnlIaU3gqsJBKWQD/fZgIziazVzd0TlMPcXh83halnu35VB/zEp95ThkZqsN4FhgDSNW7Csh3ieKH1LyoJgpS3aky2r91hPiGmjA4HHlbRqs9GiNfph3RawY47@zAfD6kjVVt9M8tU2S2G/zaoEO/2jjimGc8HTagiKmPr48iySTFnsRN@mshLm5RR8DDNJjKWXBua69Uk5nWl9rr65dW/vOZZ9vzeMdmoYygehMYziPy/ID)

The executed code is the same as SMBF's:

```
<+++++++++++++<-<+>>---++++>-<,+-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][><++++>]
```

However, because the tape's full of 0s instead of the program's codepoints, it does the wrong thing and prints `0x00` to `0xff`.

### [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade)

```
5<4# ++++++++v++{++{+<     v:-1  <"d"\"i"
I=((print))#d+"100"ci}$'mai n'  \ " > *>:"d"$-o:1-?v;
n=""#printf  >-}++++=^;-#  >,   :|1h:  ^         -1<
for Sk4 in range(100): I(n,Sk4+(1/2 and 1 or 0))
##-[>++<-----]>[->+.<][>^<++++>]1@3 \\iiiiidiisiodso
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LTsMwFET3@YqRXak2riEuZeM6hm3XLPOQrLgFC9Wpkiqb0m8PNoKj2czVHZ3eTb3zx2V5MTsK8ccsxC3HIDNrqQBDPGlIIMWhYuwyhnjlnHpBVFmSPtxX67MLiGugAYHFg9VpsJKDVvJ13hexIoT@zk6Alfesqbq9pKltkkR/q08NdPhHKlOchhHvXzuEiNHFjyNLMq5xYHGTzoKppy1c9FBIjyXnBaWytkIYmWltLa14NG1tO5N9tlVvz2iakPEhTGHw07AsPw)

I'm not sure this counts. I intended to do this with an actual loop, but I couldn't figure out how to make it small enough, so I just went with printing `0x01` to `0x03`.

Executed code (Unwrapped):

```
 @
 <
\ "
 |1
 /2
  3
  "
```

### Red herrings

The `(1/2 and 1 or 0)` resembles something used to determine Python 2 from Python 3. Of course, this won't work in Python 2, because `print` is a statement.

The `$'mai n'` is intended to look like [Rail](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail). This doesn't work because of the space, and if it did, it wouldn't do anything.

The `printf` is just an excuse for an extra `i` for Deadfish~.

The `iiiiidiisiodso` was a double red herring, because originally I wanted the actual lang to be Deadfish~. But I decided that was too obvious. I later added the brainfuck as a red herring, then realised it almost worked in SMBF, and tweaked it a little

The `[>^<++++>]` is just a mess to fill space, but looks like it could do something in some bizzare BF-derivative.

The area with all the `+-{}=` near the first 100 was meant to resemble my new language [Tarfish](https://github.com/chunkybanana/tarfish), which I thought people might think I'd use.

This took several hours to make, and I'm proud of it.

Comment: @wasif One, it's not Befunge-93 - the letters need to be *ascending*, and there needs to be a `d` and no `0x00`. Two, please don't bruteforce, it's against the spirit of the challenge, and Dennis has specifically asked not to do it.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235158)

Comment: EOF is SMBF is -1 (actually 255), though `+-[>++<-----]` then results in 102, not 100

Answer (score 4):

## [Unsure](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/unsure), 519 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247464/92689) by [Komali](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247464/92689)

```
UMMMMM PLEASE START THE PROGRAM
UHHHH HIDE ALL ERRRRR
UHHH, PLEASE SET VARIABLE n TO 99
DISABLE ERRRR FOR ABOVE LINE
UM PRESET VARIABLE y TO 0
START A LOOP
HEH YOU BETTER START WORKING
WHAT IN THE WORLD
BUT ANYWAY, INCREASE y BY 1
UM YOU ALSO HAVE TO PRINT y
YEAH CHECK CONDITION y IS GREATER THAN n
ERR IF y IS GREATER THAN 100
SO IF THAT CONDITION IS TRUE, THEN, UH, EXECUTE THIS
OKAY UM TERMINATE THE LOOP
IF ERR OR CONDITION NOT TRUE, THEN
DO NOTHING
CLOSE IF
CLOSE LOOP
NOW PLEASE WAIT FOR THE PROGRAM TO TERMINATE
```

Finishes with array from 1 to 100.

Comment: This is `unsure`; will post crack in a second

Answer (score 3):

## Element, 15 bytes, cracked by [RIyeh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155116/48922)

```
1 100'[2:`1+a`]
```

Not too hard.

Comment: Was this meant to work in Surface? If so, it counts up forever.

Comment: @MDXF Nope. 15char

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155116/55934) by [Rlyeh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78059/rlyeh)

Comment: Oh hey, it's my language!  Also, here's the same thing in only 12 bytes: `d,'[1+2:\`a\`]`

Comment: @PhiNotPi oh nice. I'd never used Element, and I just read the dovs. It looks really cool.

Answer (score 3):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 17 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155064/8478) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
[##!]
[\X_]
@-99@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P8/WllZMZYrOiYiPpbLQdfS0uH/fwA)

Output is decimal and linefeed-separated.

#### Explanation

`[]` and letters aren't commands in Labyrinth, so they act as walls and they might as well be spaces:

```
 ##!
 \ _
@-99@
```

The final `@` is also a red herring, because the control flow never gets there. The main program is just the following loop:

```
#    Push the current stack depth. This is i-1 (where i is the number printed in the
     current iteration).
#    Push the current stack depth. This is i.
!    Print i as a decimal integer.
_99  Push 99.
-    Subtract it from i-1. This gives 0 iff we want to terminate the program. In that
     case the IP moves to the @, otherwise it continues the loop.
\    Print a linefeed.
```

`@` terminates the program.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155064/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman and now with an explanation of the code, please. ;) (I'll edit the post tomorrow when I'm at a PC again.)

Comment: Hah, no. I tried three of your languages before I got to this one. Remarkably like Retina (I assume that's what you were going for) though. Maybe I'll go through Labyrinth's docs though. :P

Answer (score 3):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 4 bytes, [cracked by ErikTheOutgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155250)

```
⌶tIv
```

This is in the Dyalog APL classic codepage, if that's acceptable. [APL snippet that can be used as a code page](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ud9UT/9HbRMMuIAsIA0kHcN0Dq141AtEm41Mzf7/BwA).

**Note, the code uses the byte values of characters in its source, not the APL characters.**

Output format: Array of integers

Here's the hex if you need it:

```
0a24 4926
```

Comment: You changed the codepage to mislead us >_>

Comment: I did, because if I had it in the original codepage, it'd be too easy

Comment: So `⌶` is really 0x0a, a newline?

Comment: Yes, that is really `0x0a`.

Comment: [Gotcha.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155250/41024) I have to swear it wouldn't have been easy if the language's encoding was used instead of Dyalog's.

Comment: I would've stated the encoding, and yes.

Answer (score 3):

## MiLambda, 52 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155118/41024) by @ErikTheOutgolfer

```
v
E
Ξ
ς
v<
E`A:*[>+.<]
υ^
ε
Ξ
ς
v<
Δ
Θ
>σλ
```

The output format is raw characters.

> This is [MiLambda](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MiLambda), a 2D language where most of the commands are Greek letters. I tried to make the program look non-2D by putting each command on a separate line and deflecting the IP down at the beginning of the program. The loops don't necessarily look like loops (since `υ` isn't exactly an obvious conditional direction change); this could have been better hidden if I had been able to get vertical conditional directionals to work. To obfuscate it a bit, I just put `A:*[>+.<]` on one of the lines (`A:*` looks like something from a stack-based language to compute 100, and `[>+.<]` looks like a character counting loop in some BF derivative).

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155118/41024)

Comment: Removing the language name from the title messes up the leaderboard snippet

Comment: @JoKing Realized that just after changing all of my answers over :(

Answer (score 3):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 58 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155098) by [Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings)

```
??MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution
Map[Print,1..100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/397etzSnJLMssSgzsSTVo7IgtSg9NT83taQoM9klsxhIJZWWZObncfkmFkQHFGXmlegY6ukZGhjE/v8PAA)

Verbose languages are pretty cool :>

*Fortunately, Attache is pretty short*

Prints newline-separated list of numbers.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155098/9365)

Answer (score 3):

## Brain-Flak (Brainhack), 445 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155381/59487) by [Christopher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63187/christopher)

```
#begin(
 #import(Integer)
 #import(String)
 #import(STDOUT)
 #define(Name:Main)(In:None)(Out:String,Int)(Mixed:TRUE)(Flags:None)(Requires:"String.format")(Coding:"UTF-8"))
 #begin Main(
  Integer.ranges.from$100.forEach{STDOUT.write(String.format{$0 }.with*$0=Self)(dropWhere{!$0}[ignoreIf:(0)])}
  Except{OutOfBounds}
 )
STDOUT.stream.read.forEach{with*$0=Self(Integer.ranges.from$100.filter(by:{1...101~=$0})[ignoreIf:(0)])}(if!Error){exit$0;}
```

Output is a **space-separated** list of integers in decimal.

Comment: Hehe i think  i know

Comment: [Cracked (first one I have done!)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155381/63187)

Answer (score 3):

### [Prelude](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), 41 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155148/8478) by [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)

```
for{# [1+1];
64+(1-v(1-)++);
100^x; rev!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKzSlNSf3/Py2/qFpZIdpQ2zDWmsvMRFvDULcMiDW1tTWtuQwNDOIqrBWKUssUa///BwA)

Output as code points.

Comment: [Cracked! :D](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155148/31957)

Answer (score 3):

## Eitherfuck, 35 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155561/61563) by Ryleh

```
#+,<<+-----<-----0+++++[+++++<][+<]
```

This is definitely Brainfuck. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fWVvHxkZbFwRswKSBNghEg0mb2Ggg/v8fAA)

Comment: It looks like Eitherfuck

Comment: @Rlyeh Link to crack?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155561/78059)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise), 41 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155363/69655) by Potato44

```
   ~-<<:>>-~
||<<<:<:>:>>>||
   |[: ?-~]|
```

Outputs as decimal numbers.

Wise has only bitwise operators. The executing code is:

```
~-<<:<<<:<||[:?-~]|
```

and everything else is decoration or countering the decoration.

```
~-<<:<<<:<|| Creates the number 100 
[            While the number is not 0
 :?          Dupe and push the copy to the bottom of the stack
 -~          Decrement the number
]|           End the loop and pop the extra 0 by OR'ing it with the 1
             And output implicitly
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155363/69655). I suddenly realized your answer is Wise when I thought one of the other answers might have been Wise.

Comment: You might say your answer has been *wisecracked*....... I'll see myself out.

Answer (score 3):

## 23.dezsy, 35 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155535/25180) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
22,1,16,10,10,-1,1,10,2,12,27,0,211
```

Outputs one number per line.

Comment: Prints `01234567891011121314151617181920210012345678910111213141501234567890123456789` in CJam, hope that isn't what you were going for... Edit, does the same thing in Convex.

Comment: @MDXF No, it's not CJam or Convex.

Comment: [This is 23.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155535/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman Correct. I thought this is one of the most obscure languages that is eligible and has been used on PPCG.

Answer (score 3):

## [1+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/1+), 35 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155364/78059) by [Rlyeh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78059/rlyeh)

```
11+""*""*"+""+++1\1<#":1+^"/^"\^<#:
```

Outputs numbers separated by newlines. This one is probably going to be easy, but I had some fun with it nonetheless.

Explanation time!

```
11+""*""*"+""+++                 [construct 100] [stack: 2 100]
1\1<                   [push a 1 and create a 0] [stack: 100 1 0]
#   [loop start, 0 required for first iteration] [stack: 100 x]
":                         [duplicate and print]
1+                                   [increment]
^"/^"\^ [duplicate both the counter and the 100] [stack: 100 x 100 x]
<                             [compare x to 100] [stack: 100 x (0 or 1)]
#    [jump back to first label if counter < 100]
:                      [print 100 one last time]
```

The basic idea for this program was to use a counter starting at 1 which would be printed, incremented and then compared to 100, using 1+'s only built-in comparison operator `<`, sending program flow either to the first or second `#`.

In the posted version, the 100 is constructed once (1+, as the name may suggest, only has the constant 1, any other value must be created somehow), then stored below the counter on the stack for the duration of the printing process.
I later (after posting) realized that this was unnecessary, because doing so requires a long sequence of operations; I managed to get it down to 27 bytes by reconstructing the 100 every time (and using a shorter path for constructing it):

```
111+1<#":1+"11+"1++"+"*^<#:
```

Comment: Is the language 1+?

Comment: @Rlyeh Yes, it was.

Comment: It looked like it but I wasn't sure, couldn't find an online interpreter and ended up installing the wrong python.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155364/78059)

Answer (score 3):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 212 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155318/61563) by Dennis

```
int f(int x_1)
{
    int i, foóßar = 1;
    int *arr = 0x23d3f44e >> 0xa;

    for (i = ']'; 100 % foóßar++, *(arr+i/1234) += ']'; 0-101)
        putchar(&arr[i]);

    return -8;
}

int main(void)
{
    f(42);
}
```

- [GCC doesn't like Unicode](https://tio.run/##PY5BDoIwEEX3PcVslEIhtrQLk0YuYohpCtUuBNOAITGcxUN4BA5WW4PMYpI/8@bP18VVa@9tN4DBsU8XlqIXglBR2hxMv3yWt3JwAia3RaZcnNCp5A03QrRQVUEpiX6I6R1gG4CkTiQwSmG3GRGSQ4bDPbEHVnKRAlk5WjAa3sNaj3HQN@XwPrBnW6ert2uH0XVQHCWaEYph7sp2@Nnb5h/dYFEGfPb@Cw) D:
- [Clang doesn't like `0x23d3f443`](https://tio.run/##PY5BCoMwEEX3OcVsWqNRmmgWhVAvUqQENW3AxhK0CMWz9BA9ggdLk2KdxcCfefPn11ndSXN1TpsBFA59urAYvRD4ClKnoPrls7ylhRMwsS0SacOETnnRFIrzFsrSKynQD1G9Baw9EFWRAEYp7DYjQlJIsL8n@sDygsdAVo5mjPr3sNZjHOqbtHjv2bOu4tXbtsNoDWRHgWaEQpi71AY/e938oyvMc4/Pzn0B) D:
- [TCC just rolls with whatever you throw at it and then seg-faults](https://tio.run/##PY5BCoMwEEX3OcVsWqNRmmgWhVAvUqSEaGgWagmxCMWz9BA9ggdLk2KdxcCfefPnq8Ip5b0ZHGgc@3xjKXohCBWlyUGP62d9SwsXYGJfZNLGCZ3Lqq005x3UdVBSoB@iRwvYBCBpEgGMUjjsRoTkkOFwT8yJlRVPgWwcLRgN72Grx@TUXVp8DOzVNOnmbTs32QGKs0ALQjFML82An6Np/9E15mXAF@@/) D:

---

Obviously this is not C, it's my language. Stripping no-ops gives us this:

```
intf(intx_1)inti,foóßar=;int*arr=x23d3f44e>>xa;for(i=']';%foóßar++,*(arr+i/1234)+=']';-101)putchar(&
```

The `&` ends the program.

All alphabetical characters push their codepage value to the stack. Let's replace every run of alphabetical characters we don't care about with Z.

```
Z(Z_1)Z,ZóßZ=;Z*Z=Z23Z3Z44Z>>Z;Z(Z=']';%ZóßZ++,*(Z+Z/1234)+=']';-101)Z(&
```

`(` starts a loop and `)` ends it. The loop continues while the top of stack is nonzero. Pushing an ASCII character and then performing `_1` always sets the top of stack to zero, so we can completely ignore the first loop.

Pushng `Z` and then dividing by `1234` also always results in zero, so we can ignore the inner loop (and all the code inside it) too.

The last loop is only an open-loop and immediately exits, so we can kill that too. Our code thus becomes:

```
Z,ZóßZ=;Z*Z=Z23Z3Z44Z>>Z;Z(=']';%ZóßZ++,*+=']';-101)Z&
```

`;` means 'pop'. If we take out any code that pushes to the stack and then is immediately popped, the code becomes:

```
Z,óßZ*Z=Z23Z3Z44Z>>Z(=']%ZóßZ++,*+=']-101)Z&
```

- The first comma swaps the top two stack values, but there's only one, so we can remove it.
- The `Z23Z3Z44Z>>Z` just pushes a ton of `Z`s to the stack, which are never used, so we might as well just be pushing `Z`.
- Most of the mathematical operations are never used, so let's replace those with `Z` too.
- `'` (read string) is useless because we never provide any input.

Our code golfs down to:

```
ZóßZ(Z]%ZóßZ]-101)&
```

Okay, so now we reveal what's really going on.

- `ó` is equivalent to `].[` (pull register to stack, increment, push to register).
- `ß` is equivalent to `@10` (print ASCII 0x10).

Since we pull the register every time we actually care to interact with memory, we can completely ignore everything non-register-related that interacts with the stack when the register isn't the top of stack:

```
óß(]%óß]-101)&
```

So, the program increments the register, prints a space, opens a loop, pulls the register, prints it, prints a space, pulls the register, subtracts 101, and loops while `register - 101` is nonzero. Then it exits.

:)

---

Side note: The shortest Implicit program to perform this task would be `(;.%ß<100ö`.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155318/12012)

Answer (score 3):

## [O](https://esolangs.org/wiki/O), 9 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155475/2867) by [PhiNotPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2867)

Shouldn't be difficult, not trying to obscure it, so it may work in other than the intended language

```
['d#,;r]o
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155475/2867)

Answer (score 3):

## Lily, 27 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155373) by [Cowabunghole](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56470/cowabunghole)

```
for i in 1...100:{print(i)}
```

Seems simple, but I feel like this is fairly (maybe) obscure. Prove me wrong!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155373/56470)

Answer (score 3):

## [BitCycle](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BitCycle), 140 bytes, safe

```
exec("""
0v&~2*50
0v~^1|+x
00~110=m
0v~^e:'d
+:(~100)
v[~^aCC]
0}~1{Xv#
v&~^|25~
(v4*25+)
+H-x-_+_
e^2,|b@5
1mXv,100
Y^_~+,h.
n!`"<"`~
""" )
```

Outputs in unary, with `1` for the numbers and `0` for the separator.

*Or, you can add the `-u` flag to get output in decimal, separated by commas.*

---

Here's the code I started with pre-obfuscation:

```
     v ~
     v~^
00000 ~
     v~^

    +  ~
    v ~^
00000>~
v   < ~^

    >  v
 v    <
>A\C\ ^
 ^  / @
1BCv
 ^ ~+
 !  <  <
```

This element:

```
 v ~
 v~^
> ~
 v~^
```

is one of the best ways I've found to generate large numbers. It takes one or more zero bits in at the `>` and sends four times as many zero bits out the bottom `v`. Here, to get 100 zero bits, I fed five of them into this "quadruplicator," and then fed the output plus five more into a second quadruplicator.

Then the bottom part counts up from 1 to whatever number of zero bits it gets in the `A` collector. (Detailed explanation available on request.) Once `A` is empty, a bit hits the `@`, which halts the program.

For the obfuscated version, I packed everything in a little tighter, replaced the spaces with various no-ops, changed some of `> <` to `} {` or `+` or `~` and `\ /` to `- |` (equivalent under certain circumstances) to look less like a 2D language, and finally threw in the `exec` for good measure.

Answer (score 3):

## [MashedPotatoes](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MashedPotatoes), 641 bytes, safe

```
synchronized(std::ignore){std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Hello,world!"<<std::endl;goto nullptr;WHILE 0.0f>`uniq-c`
s/++i//g
WEND goto __dict__;(format t"goto void(0);WHILE <> <(int)std::ignore
use strict qw/Object/;
WEND goto nullptr;goto __dict__;proc $ARGV{STDERR} {OUTPUT=*read-eval*}")}
```

Prints 1 to 100 as numbers, separated by newlines. <s>Probably not too difficult but whatever.</s>

I was worried it would be too easy since I used a language of my own design, but I couldn't resist the opportunity to actually use this language for one of the few things it can actually do without being too awful.

Comment: This is the safe answer that uses the *most* bytes. That makes me the winner, right?

Comment: Haha, this language is awesome. Perfect for obfuscation challenges (too bad it's kind of a one time thing).

Answer (score 3):

## QuakeC, 144 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155532/68615) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
$flags as spam
void(string s)dprint=#25;string(float f)ftos=#26;void()main={local float j;j=1;while(j<101){dprint(ftos(j));dprint(" ");j=j+1;}};
```

Outputs decimal numbers, separated by spaces.

---

As an aside, in QuakeC, built-ins are assigned numerical IDs which you can then forward declare as proper functions in order to use them. [`#25` and `#26` are the IDs used for `dprint` and `ftos` in actual Quake](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/master/qw-qc/defs.qc#L659), but some less-compliant (but significantly easier to use than booting up a real Quake server) VMs [have different IDs](https://github.com/graphitemaster/gmqcc/blob/gh-pages/doc.html#L859).

The `$flags as spam` is a no-op: `$` is deliberately ignored by Quake C compilers, since it's used for pragmas by the `modelgen` tool.

Comment: [This is QuakeC.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155532/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman Correct.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 82 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155725/66104) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

```
def i = 1 ** (1+0): {if i == 99, $g = ?#: {$d or $n} i -> 98 + 0.0: put i++: loop}
```

Prints numbers in decimal, separated by carriage returns, including a leading one.

> This lasted a long time considering that ><> is my main language to golf in…
>  
>  Ignoring the extra stuff pushed to the stack and the meaningless shuffling, this is how it works:
>
> ```
> def i = 1 ** (1+0)   Push 1 (rather circuitously)
> :                    Duplicate
> {if i == 99, $g      Push 1,0 and get the char at
>                         that position (it's "e"=101)
> = ?#                 If the thing on the stack equals
>                         101, crash the program
> : {$d or $n          Print CR then the number
> } i -                Increment (by subtracting -1)
> > 98 + 0.            Push 17,0 then jump back to that
>                         position (the first ":").
> 0: put i++: loop}    And the fish never reaches here!
> ```

Comment: [This is ><>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155725/76162)

Answer (score 3):

## Java (OpenJDK 8), 166 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155578/61563) by Jo King

```
/*‮*/ inter\u0066ace S‭{/*//Hello World!‮*/static void main(/**/String[]a‮){for(char b‮=0;b‮++
<10/*‮*/*10;)System\u002e/*‭*/out/*‮*/.print(b‮);}}
```

‮!ti tnaw uoy erehw ti gnitteg no kcul dooG
‮.TUODTS ot 46x0 ot 10x0 morf sedoc iicsa eht stuptuo tI
  ‮... sseug ot ysae ytterp eb dluohs sihT

Comment: hex dump please? I can't even select the code, and when I try to navigate  `‮);}}
` with the arrow keys, it gets stuck in an infinite loop :(

Comment: This is [Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155578/76162)

Answer (score 3):

## [Glypho (shorthand)](https://web.archive.org/web/20060621185740/http://www4.ncsu.edu/~bcthomp2/glypho.txt), 39 bytes, safe

```
11+dd*1+*d*d1-+[d1-+>-+o11+dd*1+*d*1+>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8@pLMjI1y3OyC8qyUjMS/n/39BQOyVFy1BbK0UrxVBXOxpE2Olq5yOJG2rbxf7/DwA)

I like using languages that are in plain sight but somehow manage to evade what people think of. That's why every cop of mine is on TIO.

Comment: This is safe; please reveal the language!

Comment: Aw dangit, I could have easily identified this but I didn't see it in time.

Answer (score 3):

## [CPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPL_(programming_language)), 80 bytes, safe

```
N(s)=value of§if(s=100)then Join(100,NIL)result is Join(s, N(s+1))§Main()=N(1)
```

One caveat: The only interpreter for this language I could find has an issue: it only allows programs to be used as libraries providing a set of functions, not as a full program. To make a full program that gives output possible, once you've transpiled this to a Python program, add `print(Main())` to the end of the intermediate Python program before running it.

If this makes this answer ineligible, that's fine, I'll mark it as non-competing, but I think it's a fun challenge nonetheless.

---

The wikipedia page links to this translator into Python: http://norvig.com/sciam/cpl.g

If you dig around on Peter Norvig's site, you can find his full description of the language: http://norvig.com/sciam/sciam.html

Comment: This post is safe now.

Answer (score 3):

## [ELF (x86/x64, Linux)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf), 383 bytes, safe

```
0000000: 7f45 4c46 0101 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
0000010: 0200 0300 0100 0000 b080 0408 2c00 0000  ............,...
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 3400 2000 0100 0000  ........4. .....
0000030: 0000 0000 0080 0408 0080 0408 7f01 0000  ................
0000040: 7f01 0000 0500 0000 0010 0000 31c0 5068  ............1.Ph
0000050: 2a01 0000 b0a2 89e3 89e1 cd80 4074 f583  *...........@t..
0000060: c408 b964 0000 0051 9185 c07d 1450 6a2d  ...d...Q...}.Pj-
0000070: 31db 4389 da89 d8b0 0489 e1cd 8059 58f7  1.C..........YX.
0000080: d831 dbb3 0a53 31d2 f7f3 83c2 3052 09c0  .1...S1.....0R..
0000090: 75f4 89e1 31db 4389 da89 d8b0 04cd 8058  u...1.C........X
00000a0: 3c0a 75ee 5949 83f9 9b75 bce9 ca00 0000  <.u.YI...u......
00000b0: 31c0 b002 cd80 09c0 7592 5958 09c0 75fb  1.......u.YX..u.
00000c0: 31db 31c0 b02d cd80 89c5 ba5f b8f6 ea81  1.1..-....._....
00000d0: f20f f9a2 a231 c949 418b 048c 09c0 0f84  .....1.IA.......
00000e0: 9600 0000 3910 75f0 8078 043d 75ea 8d70  ....9.u..x.=u..p
00000f0: 0556 31db 31c9 ac3c 3a74 0708 c074 0341  .V1.1..<:t...t.A
0000100: ebf4 39d9 0f47 d908 c075 e98d 5c1d 0c31  ..9..G...u..\..1
0000110: c0b0 2dcd 805e 89ef ac3c 3a74 0708 c074  ..-..^...<:t...t
0000120: 03aa ebf4 b874 6447 df35 5b1c 23b8 ab35  .....tdG.5[.#..5
0000130: 0217 1402 ab35 436f 41f3 ab89 e2b8 7a00  .....5CoA.....z.
0000140: 8728 5035 1e38 c15d 5035 0354 6914 5035  .(P5.8.]P5.Ti.P5
0000150: 0003 404f 5035 1455 4001 5035 1b4e 5b5f  ..@OP5.U@.P5.N[_
0000160: 5089 e331 c050 5355 89e1 89eb b00b cd80  P..1.PSU........
0000170: 89d4 8a46 ff08 c056 759b 31c0 40cd 80    ...F...Vu.1.@..
```

I think you can see that I like hiding my programs in binary files. Output format: decimal numbers. Oh, and to save CPU time on TIO: the obvious "language" timeouts.

---

... since this was explicitly designed so that it does not work on TIO - the numbers are printed after waiting 4 minutes and 58 seconds, as per

> The program must terminate within 5 minutes on a typical desktop PC.

The separator used is 0A 2D, or

```
-
```

> If using integers, you should output with a constant non-digit delimiter between each number.

Outputs 295 leading bytes, and a single trailing one. Much less than a thousand (*evil laugh*).

> You may also output with leading and trailing characters [...] but please be sensible (don't output a thousand bytes of rubbish either side of the count for instance).

Also, try running it on a desktop computer. You won't regret. I promise.

Comment: The funny part is that I ran this, but discarded the solution because of the garbage output.

Comment: @Future readers: 2a01 at offset 0x50 is the timeout, change it to 0100 if you want it to run in TIO. (Setting it to zero removes the easter egg.);  Pedantic edit, it's probably 2a010000 little-endian but whatever

Answer (score 3):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GrayJoKing/Cascade), 59 bytes, [cracked by exedraj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233389/100664)

```
v>@/<
1%_\|
/]8\<
d+^}|
_/{-/
^*d|1
9#h\/
k-Q.|
e3d+/
4!5|5
```

Have fun! Output is newline separated integers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/v8zOQd@Gy1A1PqaGSz/WIsaGK0U7rraGK16/WlefK04rpcaQy1I5I0afK1s3UK@GK9U4RVufy0TRtMb0/38A)

### Explanation

After deobfuscating, the code becomes:

```
  @/ 
  _  
 ] \ 
d ^ |
 / -/
^ d|1
 # \/
 - .|
e d+/
  5|5
```

And here's a sort-of explanation:

[image]

It's complicated, but I'm quite proud of myself for making this.

Comment: [this is cascade](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233389/78850)

Comment: @exedraj How did you get it?

Answer (score 3):

## [Braincrash](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Braincrash), 104 bytes, safe

```
   !  ! ! !       !      ! !       !       !       !       !   !!  !       !  !    !    ! ! !    !     !
```

Have some more fun, while you're at it...

Comment: This is safe now, so what was it?

Comment: @pxeger Lol, this has been safe for two and a half months.

Answer (score 3):

## [res](https://github.com/Lyxal/res) (safe), 307 bytes

```
+- 2 3 4 5 6 7 @2@ @1@ @9=| 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 |89| )88) 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 ~
```

[Get the raw version here (it's not /// btw)](https://tio.run/##DY87agRBEMXwMTZTuhhD178qMMxVHCxs4GzSwVcfd/BSSe/8/Tnfr/O@H4/Pjy8UwwmS4tCDQ/bm@0IEUcQQRwJJpJBGBl1cPRfP7idqqKOBJlpoo4MtTLANN8yxwBIrrLHBFy644tvteOCJF974EIsQQgkjdloQSRTRxJCLFFJJI53c5UkW2eRQixJKKaOcCmofK6qpoRcttNJGOx100kU3PcxihFHGGGeCSaaYZgZZi7/7/gc)

Glhf getting this one lol.

Answer (score 3):

## Burlesque, 87 bytes, [Cracked by steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247394/92689))

```
proc gen_range {r1%add!}

fancydef add:
    \\/\.+
end

cnt := 100
gen_range(cnt())
end
```

Comment: [cracked, burlesque](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247394/92689)

Comment: i honestly just googled "site:esolangs.org fancydef" lol

Comment: Ah, darn, I thought by using some un-(poorly-)documented stuff it might not show up. Ah well.

Answer (score 3):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 47 bytes (safe)

```
(/>d.v#
_--_-_-
d)(o[e]
*!100d(
/-;.m|<
d(1'o>^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X0PfLkWvTJkrXlc3Hgi5UjQ18qNTY7m0FA0NDFI0uPR1rfVya2y4UjQM1fPt4v7/BwA)

Output as newline-delimited integers with a leading newline.

I'm not sure how to explain this so I won't.

Answer (score 3):

## Literate [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 42 bytes, safe

```
n = 100
for index in range(n)
 print index
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJsIiwiIiwibiA9IDEwMFxuZm9yIGluZGV4IGluIHJhbmdlKG4pXG4gcHJpbnQgaW5kZXgiLCIiLCIiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

Output as newline-separated decimal integers.

Vyxal 3 has a literate mode, which allows writing builtins as words instead of single characters. Without the NOPs, this is just

```
100 for n print
100             # Push 100
    for         # Loop the context variable `n` over the range 1 to 100
        n       # Push n
          print # Print it
```

Everything else is just to make this look like python, although I wouldn't be surprised if there's a python-esque lang somewhere that doesn't require the `:`. Even then, though, it would output the range from 0 to 99 instead of 1 to 100.

Answer (score 2):

## Deadfish~, 7 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155044/65326) by [Uriel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65326/uriel)

```
{{iow}}
```

The output should be this:

```
1Hello, World!2Hello, World!3Hello, World!4Hello, World!5Hello, World!6Hello, World!7Hello, World!8Hello, World!9Hello, World!10Hello, World!11Hello, World!12Hello, World!13Hello, World!14Hello, World!15Hello, World!16Hello, World!17Hello, World!18Hello, World!19Hello, World!20Hello, World!21Hello, World!22Hello, World!23Hello, World!24Hello, World!25Hello, World!26Hello, World!27Hello, World!28Hello, World!29Hello, World!30Hello, World!31Hello, World!32Hello, World!33Hello, World!34Hello, World!35Hello, World!36Hello, World!37Hello, World!38Hello, World!39Hello, World!40Hello, World!41Hello, World!42Hello, World!43Hello, World!44Hello, World!45Hello, World!46Hello, World!47Hello, World!48Hello, World!49Hello, World!50Hello, World!51Hello, World!52Hello, World!53Hello, World!54Hello, World!55Hello, World!56Hello, World!57Hello, World!58Hello, World!59Hello, World!60Hello, World!61Hello, World!62Hello, World!63Hello, World!64Hello, World!65Hello, World!66Hello, World!67Hello, World!68Hello, World!69Hello, World!70Hello, World!71Hello, World!72Hello, World!73Hello, World!74Hello, World!75Hello, World!76Hello, World!77Hello, World!78Hello, World!79Hello, World!80Hello, World!81Hello, World!82Hello, World!83Hello, World!84Hello, World!85Hello, World!86Hello, World!87Hello, World!88Hello, World!89Hello, World!90Hello, World!91Hello, World!92Hello, World!93Hello, World!94Hello, World!95Hello, World!96Hello, World!97Hello, World!98Hello, World!99Hello, World!100Hello, World!
```

The OP explicitly allowed this [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42715533#42715533). Pretty trivial, but I wanted to see how the community reacts to such solutions.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155044/65326)

Answer (score 2):

## [Locksmith](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Locksmith), 492 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155073/31957) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155073/31957)

*Perhaps it wasn't too smart to use a language of my own.*

I wanted to see if I could secure a victory through obfuscation...

```java
import java.util.Random;
interface Main{
  public	static void  main(String[]args){
for(int	i  	=0; i  <		90*  11; i ++)
System. out.println(i);
f(   	 	7);
g();
}
public static 	int f(int n){System.out.println(n);if(n<=0)return+n&3;
else return f(	n/7)*6	+7*f(n-5)+7;
}
public static void g(){
Random k=new Random(45);
String j="YmlULmxZXERFZmNvbg==";
int m;
for(int i=m=0;i<121;i++){
m+=j.charAt(0)+j.	charAt(i&1)+k.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(k.nextInt((int)Math.pow(7201,19))^6^m);
}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRT8IwEMef209x4YG0VOeGwkLGHnzQxER8gJgoRpIyttGxdsvWAWbhs8/ClmiiL23vev/73/3SLNiVUuht0wiZZ4WGhO@5VWmRWnOuNpn0sFA6LCIehDDjQtUYIK/WqQhQqbkWAewzsQGQ5o8sdCFU/PHJi7ikNY6yghg1EgDItz0w9xShiT0AcJxzyBjFi69Sh9KCrNJWbuQ6VURQD0cEjAyQa94xMccJt77Q@SJTC9HZABStuza/uyjqiYioqW/TItRVoZjq33o4TMsQ2oSRI3Xj0sEYMXdgaq9HlLl/rS4rmiFq3EKBna/CA7QBuRuZ6drVIfF77zJ9fZbH5dvD/HEpX/br2Pd7F4xgaHZMQPjSIBFTZ@h4wnCosWR@YgVbXtxrYlOWWKgLRN@hbGep8KiflG5R/LPuT8XZgM643lp5diDu0HaunAmlq/FKXsSnpvkG)

Equivalent to:

```java
09011
70
3767
57
4501210
1
7201196
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155073/68615)

Comment: I did try Whitespace and other Java versions though. :P Eventually realized you make a ton of esolangs and I've been eyeing Locksmith for a while now...

Answer (score 2):

## [Hy](http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/), 63 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155382/11157) by Ruslan

```
(defn !(&optional(> 1))(if(< > 101)(do(print >)(!(inc >)))))(!)
```

Outputs in decimal, newline-separated.

Comment: If I guess Lisp and am right, does that give me credit for a crack?

Comment: @KellyS.French Only if you specify which Lisp interpreter it works in. ;)

Comment: It's [hy](https://github.com/hylang/hy). [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155382/11157)'s corresponding crack.

Answer (score 2):

## Golunar, 30 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155095/76162) by Jo King

```
814918243305927192311963944207
```

> This is [Golunar](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Golunar). The program is a decimal representation of the number of zeroes in the corresponding Unary program. This translates to the Unary program with 814,918,243,305,927,192,311,963,944,207 zeroes, or to the brainfuck program
> `++++++++++[->++++++++++<]>[->+.<]`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155095/76162) (I *knew* someone was going to post a Golunar program)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-93, 97 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155186/16766) by DLosc

Starting off with an easy one.

```
shovv fRom-0to*1E#' <iostream
?>e[10]++;B:12\;g\=`||(
@. >!1:then.do+^\x61@
:^A&>#+:$#<math>eaa$q
```

Comment: [This is Befunge-93.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155186/16766)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 133 bytes, [cracked by totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155227)

```
#import<stdio>
1//1;f=__import__;
2//1;String=str
0//1;i = 1;
while(i<101):#{
    f("sys").stdout.write(String(i)+" ");
    i+=1;
#}
```

Might be a bit obvious but, it can also be very confusing.

**EDIT:** I hoped I could confuse you more with this, but totallyhuman cracked it. By the way: This was my inspiration: https://www.python.org/doc/humor/#python-block-delimited-notation-parsing-explained

Comment: [This is Python 3.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155227/68615)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fantom](http://fantom.org/), 55 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155240) by totallyhuman

unfortunatelly don't have much time to obfuscate this

```
class A{static Void main(){(1..100).each|x|{echo(x)}}}
```

Comment: [This is Fantom.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155240/68615)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 664 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155265/59487) by Mr. Xcoder

```
for(each num in #1/#100)
(
    do #pointOfNum(num)
Push (#pointer@#num)
if(result(pointer@(num/pointOfNum(run2)+#diff)))
while(each num of pointer@num)
do
(ITS GO TIME!)
DO THE MATH
)
def fun add{
while add #(point@100)
})
def {
do@#point()
})
open{ref}add(42))
do
{SAY IT TO THE NAND})
{
push why1998@point
})
if(output!ready
(push@#out
{buy})
onGler<@spoin>
pushet)
<Divmod@point@uf2X3>
discov def n{
<div@23>
point@(4524#f34)
(@#do(@3h)
{point*723
numdif}
)#huCX5DBP^h~0_GG1<h32X542P[18F18h42X%AAP[h!.X%OOS`M a@<euws
[give@point
(for@point13)])
div<pointmod>
divide((42/9
{
over@point27
})
[pointto(27)]
giv@12)}
div<mod>
def run{
pointOfnum
fun@#(23)
why1998
}
```

Took under a minute :|

Comment: This is brain-flak.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem wth

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155265/59487).

Comment: Too many balanced brackets = very suspicious

Comment: @JoKing I also use brain-flak a decent amount

Answer (score 2):

## PARI/GP, 23 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155271/61563) by DevelopingDeveloper

```
#for (o=1,100,print(o))
```

Thought maybe since it was such an uncommon language nobody would know about it :(

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155271/76365)

Answer (score 2):

## Attache, 40 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155286/68615) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
Define[$main,{Print[Range[1,100]]}]
main[]
```

Output, minus a trailing newline:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Note that this doesn't work in Mathematica, as [it uses braces](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lNS0zLzVaJTcxM0@nOqAoM68kOigxLz012tDAIDa2NpYLJBMd@/8/AA).

Comment: This has an extra 0 :)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien fixed.

Comment: [This is *ah-tahsh*.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155286/68615)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 47 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155472/76162) by MD XF

```
{%c++}=t=+~\%c<100;
ADD.+L0|~tt\
\OR;MULTIPLY c
```

Outputs as decimal numbers separated by newlines, with 2 trailing newlines.

---

Cardinal spawns pointers in every direction for each `%`. The main one here is the one going right from the first `%c`, which sets the inactive value to 100 active value to 0. After that it enters a loop, where it increments, prints the number and a newline, until the number modulo 100 is 0, where it exits. The executing code is:

```
%c++ =t=+~\
 D.+L0|~tt/
 R;MU
```

Note that the second `%c` is necessary, as it is used to flip the `\`s into the right position.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155472/61563)

Answer (score 2):

## Golfscript, 55 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155372/12012) by Dennis

```
2.upto(100){|i| p i}; printf RUBY_VERSION, $$ > 0; p $_
```

Outputs `[1 2 3 … 100]`.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155372/12012)

Answer (score 2):

## Gambas, 98 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155443/61563) by NieDzejkob

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim num as short
For num = 1 To 100 Step 1
    print num  
Next
End 
'1-100.print
```

The edit is from when coping over I snipped part of the code off.

Comment: Is the language free?

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/155430#155430) Didn't test, but I am pretty sure I got it right.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder not what i used :P

Comment: If this is VBA, this answer is invalid. You know that? (can't test it, no windows license nor VM handy)

Comment: @NieDzejkob not VBA

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155443/55934)

Comment: @nie nice! That is it

Answer (score 2):

## [Ouroboros](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ouroboros), 27 bytes, safe

```
$0$1@l();
($1+JOYjoy$100=_)
```

Outputs as bytes.

---

[Try it here!](http://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/)

Ouroboros is usually pretty distinctive with constructs like `1(` at the ends of lines, so I tried to get creative with the parentheses to disguise it. Also with `$` before numbers to make it look vaguely Perl-inspired.

#### Snake 1

```
$  Switch to shared stack
0  Push 0
$  Switch back to own stack
1  Push 1
@  Rotate top 3; since there's only one item on the stack, uses two implicit zeros
l  Push length of stack (3)
(  Eat that many characters from the end of the snake
```

This swallows the IP, and the snake halts.

#### Snake 2

```
(   Swallow characters; with an empty stack, swallows 0 characters: no-op
$   Switch to shared stack (on the first iteration, this just had a 0 pushed to it by
    snake 1; on future iterations, it will be the previous number printed)
1   Push 1
+   Add
JO  No-ops
Y   Copy top of shared stack to own stack
j   No-op
o   Output top of current stack (which is the shared stack) as ASCII character
y   Copy top of own stack to shared stack
    We now have a copy of the current number on each stack
$   Switch to own stack
100 Push 100
=   Push 1 if 100 equals current number, 0 otherwise
_   Negate
)   Regurgitate that many characters: if 0, does nothing; if -1, swallows a character
```

Thus, if the current number is 100, the IP is swallowed and the snake halts; otherwise, control loops back to the beginning of the snake, where we switch back to the shared stack, increment the number there, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

## [AsciiDots](https://esolangs.org/wiki/AsciiDots), 58 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155469/66104) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
//$#n=100(v.|)
[+]:<>/99#*%2
#~H6+-e>*</xxxx>
(^)>*{L}<d>;
```

Prints numbers in decimal separated by newlines.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155469/61563)

Answer (score 2):

## [Macaulay2](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/), 27 bytes, safe

```
<<stack\\(1..100)/toString;
```

Prints numbers separated by newlines.

Macaulay2 is a language designed for computations in advanced commutative algebra and algebraic geometry. It has a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaulay2), it's available for free from its [official website](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/), and it [fits](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_numeric_sptypes.html) [PPCG's](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_lists_spand_spsequences.html) [criteria](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_printing_spto_spthe_spscreen.html) [for a](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_getting_spinput_spfrom_spthe_spuser.html) [programming](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/__pl.html) [language](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_is__Prime.html). It's [widely used](http://swmath.org/software/537) in the algebra community, even if no one seems to know about it here…

The `stack` function was meant as a red herring — it concatenates strings vertically (useful for printing matrices and whatnot with just ASCII), and has nothing to do with stack-based memory.

Answer (score 2):

## Piet, 242 bytes, [cracked by Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155499/41024)

The code contains a... few unprintable characters, so here's the reversible `xxd`:

```
00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
00000010: 0000 000a 0000 000a 0803 0000 01cd eb0f  ................
00000020: 1900 0000 5450 4c54 451e 010e 02cd 0500  ....TPLTE.......
00000030: 212a 0134 3e65 be20 f0c7 0000 0000 0000  !*.4>e. ........
00000040: c080 0000 c000 00ff 0000 c000 c0ff 00ff  ................
00000050: 0080 0000 8080 8080 0000 c000 00c0 c0c0  ................
00000060: c000 00ff 00c0 c0ff 00ff ffff c0c0 ffff  ................
00000070: 00c0 ffc0 c0ff ffff ffff 0000 ffc0 8cf4  ................
00000080: 0b00 0000 5949 4441 5408 d735 ca41 12c2  ....YIDAT..5.A..
00000090: 300c 04c1 3d4d 1283 1209 61e4 90ff ff13  0...=M....a.....
000000a0: 4315 7be8 dac3 a877 9969 5329 63d5 ddd5  C.{....w.iS)c...
000000b0: 5eaa 4535 c22f adc9 30c5 6da1 8bb9 e327  ^.E5./..0.m....'
000000c0: 7fcb a7c6 1bdc 69a6 469c c120 51d2 67f2  ......i.F.. Q.g.
000000d0: a4be c163 de13 43bb 991d 49db f900 2114  ...c..C...I...!.
000000e0: 04cf a503 d231 0000 0000 4945 4e44 ae42  .....1....IEND.B
000000f0: 6082                                     `.
```

Output format: decimal numbers separated by spaces.

The Piet program was supposed to be a trap, but I forgot to specify the output format. Oh, well...

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155499/41024)

Comment: @Erik Uh, I forgot to specify the output format. Reposted.

Comment: Oh so you failed to mislead us that way >_>_<_<

Comment: @Erik Yes, well said

Answer (score 2):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 190 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155518/45151) by [quartata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45151/quartata)

```
main :: RunIO
main = print (list (range (1, 101)))

list :: Fn ((Range, Int) -> (List, Int))
list = xs -> List.fromObj (xs)

range :: Fn ((Pair, Int) -> (Range, Int))
range = (x,y) -> {x..y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsIwEEX3@YpZJhCD2RbiUigIlf5BLCoRO5EkhRTx22MeCt0M3Dn3nslOFpeQ0qwNQtfBuGA/kJoUvJzBAPRpfL5O4/0KVHKQe8kYI6T@8@aIQOlYMIceA4PdAegpwxZZKyqIvpACxM3Zebg8gEafRU39N521cRvRRsx@TZV3fK34HYVYPyl9AQ)

Coconut extents Python by syntactical constructs for functional programming.

`main = print (list (range (1, 101)))` is the only line that is actually doing something, though a more idiomatic way would be [`(1,101) |*> range |> list |> print`](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/X8NQx9DAUFOhRstOoSgxLz1VocZOISezuAREFxRl5gHVAAA).

The lines with `::` should be reminiscent of Haskell's type annotations, but Coconut is actually dynamically typed and `::` is its [chain operator](http://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/master/DOCS.html#chain) which works lazily, which is probably the reason why those nonsensical declarations do not throw an error.

I also wanted to create the impression that functions can be used before their definition appears in the code, but actually Coconut is interpreted sequentially and `list` and `range` are build-in functions which work fine in the second line, but are redefined to nonsensical functions afterwards.

Calling `list` after the redefinition produces a `NameError: name 'List' is not defined`, because there is no function `List.fromObj`.

Calling the redefined `range` with two numbers, e.g. `range(1,101)` returns a singleton set which contains a function object, because the `..` operator is used for [function composition](http://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/master/DOCS.html#compose). This does not cause an error yet, but trying to evaluate this composed function of course throws a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155518/45151)

Comment: @quartata That was quick. What gave it away?

Comment: `print(list(range(1,101))`, despite your attempts at spacing it to make it look more Lisp-like, is just too damn Pythonic.

Comment: Couldn't you have just done `{1..101}` instead of using `range`?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit `{1..101}` is not actually a range expression. The `..` operator is used for function composition. The code only works because it is executed sequentially, that is in the `main` part the build-in `range` function is used, before it is redefined to nonsense on the last line.

Comment: @Laikoni So `{1..101}` is just nonsense?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Pretty much. It is a singleton set containing a function which throws a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` when called, that's probably as nonsensical as it gets while being syntactically valid.

Answer (score 2):

## I, 5 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155547/43319) by [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz)

```
1i101
```

Returns (the only output-form this language supports) a list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/z/3zDT0MDw/38A)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155547/71256) this is [I](https://github.com/mlochbaum/ILanguage)

Answer (score 2):

## PBASIC (BS2), 20 bytes, safe

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 1400 6607 3cfd 03fd 6cfd fd66 0621 535a  ..f.<...l..f.!SZ
00000010: fd03 07fd                                ....
```

Outputs as ASCII bytes [to the screen](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7139/45151).

---

This one is a bit of a gray area since the only free "interpreter" I know of is the demo version of [Proteus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteus_Design_Suite), and it's a little difficult to write directly to the EEPROM in it.

Comment: It looks like some form of tokenised BASIC on an 8-bit microcomputer to me.

Comment: This is safe; please reveal the language!

Comment: @NieDzejkob Your instincts were good.

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton 1](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 79 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155634/68942) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
class M{fun main{args:Array<String>}{for(i=0;i<100;){if(i or i==0)print(++i)}}}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEADAr3hUumzX1KAHdOoFEigL5cpqh1h8uzXnKUyN8hjnFWpVu8QnqztglsCpLhtzeN3RGHNau0RijR4suhnAGsGoUREr9B5M@VPT04Sm9z7GBw)

hehe this abuses Proton 1's lenience to undefined variables and placing expressions right next to each other so much. `class`, `M`, `fun`, `main`, 
and `args` are all just seen as (undefined) variables. The `{}` are all just code-blocks except for `{args:Array<String>}`, which I think is a dict from `None` to `Array<String>`, though I'm not even sure how that doesn't error.

Credit goes to @totallyhuman who also guessed the language; however, because my initial program printed 0..99 instead of 1..100, and both totallyhuman (chat) and MD XF (comment) asked me about that, and I saw the later message first in my inbox, MD XF got it first. Good job to both of them though!

Comment: If this is supposed to work in Proton, it doesn't print 100. Red herring or bug?

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155634/61563)

Comment: I took totallyhuman's suggestion and I always try user-created languages. You made Proton so I figured I should try it out.

Comment: For fairness' sake: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=42825026#42825026

Comment: @MDXF Hm ok good idea :P

Comment: @H.PWiz Thanks for linking the chat message!

Comment: ;-; -----------

Comment: @totallyhuman lol sorry I saw the comment before the chat message in my inbox :P i'll add a footnote actually

Answer (score 2):

### [K](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:K), 62 bytes, safe

```
p:{`0:$x} /output
i:1;do[100;p[i];p[:[i<100;","]];i+:1];p@"\n"
```

I wonder that this one is safe since i didn't really obfuscate the code.

Only the /output is a comment i forgot to delete. :D

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNzs9L/P@/wKo6wcBKpaKWK9PK0DolP9rQwMC6IDozFkhYRWfagLhKOkqxsdaZ2laGQFEHpZg8pf//AQ)

I think on tio its not exactly the same language, but it works the same.

Comment: This is now safe!

Answer (score 2):

## [Felix](https://github.com/felix-lang/felix), 33 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155721/55934) by Esolanging Fruit

```
for i in 1..100 do println$i;done
```

Comment: This prints 1 to 100 not 0 to 99, right?

Comment: @RobertFraser it printed 0 to 100 before, now it's correct, my bad.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155721/61384).

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org), 22 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155860/47066) by [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)

```
{(1..'d')*.toString()}
```

---

The crack: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/F9QlJlXkpOnoPG/WsNQT089RV1TS68kP7gEKJ6uoVn7X0NT8z8A)

---

After lengthy discussion, this would not work as a program, a valid submission would have been:

```
print (1..'d')*.toString()
```

Putting this in it's own file, passing it to the groovy interpreter and allowing it to execute will print the numbers 1 to 100 to the user.

Comment: **Hint**: this time it's not 05AB1E... *or isssss it?*

Comment: [This is Groovy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155860/47066).

Comment: @Emigna bahhh... I thought adding the wrapper would stop most people from bruting it. Didn't expect people to just, y'know, know it :P.

Comment: @Dennis so putting it into a file called `a.groovy`, without the braces, and calling it from CMD `groovy a.groovy` is fine, and I can knock off 2 bytes?

Comment: @Dennis [I guess I need to add a print statement too by that logic?](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMFOIVEvvSg/v6ySC0LB@f//FxRl5pUoaBjq6amnqGtq6ZXkB5cAhdI1NAE "Bash – Try It Online") Also I'm deleting above comments after the edit I made, good catch though Dennis. Also, neat trick with the Batch TIO.

Answer (score 2):

## Hexagony (Esoteric IDE), 506 bytes, safe

Base64:

```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```

Exact output content:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

(with a leading space, without any trailing whitespace, numbers separated with spaces)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVLbkqIwEH3nK3y3pgrxNlbNblWIXEJE1CiobwSYELmYkUFkft5ta/ah63TSfbpPd8LjJn8@edxks8ngLR18fAyswB78HfD@O2u0iTIkGTdfXqFmDCuWGHa3l0odpV2RsNxPVO9Azs9EzVYxvsn65udesZR1bEeH0VFqNVkXEPz0AppVxkXW1@sQzhsgGYAuYEtbmnyX0wx8caxOVyjqg7GthQpQMDsxvci9jCZNRlM1BHx1ImEWDmkqZP4iXig0uEU7J4F4XdiIAd5qobQwgAswcQh3HrrStLL7eK9LcrE6H6kuqco2xYLG0UlsJOowQ5TgfJ7pYXBYormGJZKUWRJLs@bj3Z24Zh9HU50i1Z@iaX1m4uEvkcKyoMQdLej2SrfWwjgfPcjblRquzdGpeqhTb0puLJpzZLfECR9pZDdJLxRxG0EwulNpVnxMrqCuC4zi3d@jLuibmxazcp8d1/o50ls@DvVV/V@BU6igR1@rHgniemXqhj2X6LG5oPknQx4U9QgqPA2L6@XglnrsLFrwX91E4nqK11vwBVjieVBkJdGFOJZIGllzmRbe0JlffDrSiLO@T3i15Ak7PtRIh50AyfziRtlSd60nMlf0x1LEOd8TaQKWLSjKeZWWdGl1mo8L9VrMJzON05GIeK/GfOwVAezkHKWK/84uYoZmG4YexIVFA9HHZsF7c6zBM@lnlqsVRjXIhbnNklfbFsv3O7Gblo70Pxp8XU3rksFb8vt/n89/)

---

But... it doesn't look like Hexagony!

Timwi added a secret debugging feature to Esoteric IDE, in [this commit](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE/commit/4cc87139e899f0c3a83deac4bc01c6b6a3546c67). Specifically, if a `❢` appears at the first of the program, the source code is treated as linear, using `if > 0` and `goto` for control flow.

However, I can't find Timwi talking about it anywhere.

- [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E2%9D%A2%22+Hexagony+codegolf) [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E2%9D%A2%22+site%3Acodegolf.stackexchange.com) [attempts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E2%9D%A2%22+site%3Achat.stackexchange.com) failed.
- [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240/2015/9/22) transcript at the time of the commit.
- [Trying](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22%E2%9D%A2%22) to [search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=_linearCode) for related contents on the site itself.

No related search result... so I guess this must be safe. Personally, I was very surprised, and could only know that while reading the Esoteric IDE source code (and I can't understand why the Hexagony interpreter need the character `✓` and `❢`) (after I have written LinearHexagony for the same purpose) (my version is sonewhat better, as it has support for multiple IPs, but unfortunately doesn't support `if`, only conditional `goto`).

---

So, if the source code starts with a `❢`, then

- A line `if > 0` will be treated as conditional command. Use indentation similar to Python to specify code blocks.
- A line starts with `goto` ... well, `goto` a label.
- A line that is equal to the target of some goto is considered a label.

In this code, I used `print(` as the label name.

---

Yes, Esoteric IDE normally only run on Windows, which is not free. However

- The OP allows for programming languages running on a non-free OS to compete. [See this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops#comment379565_155018).
- With some tweaks and/or dirty hacks it's possible to [get Esoteric IDE to run on Mono/Linux](https://github.com/user202729/EsotericIDE).

---

And... some details about why I deleted my previous answer.  It outputs character codes from 1 to 100, and it was supposed to be valid. However, on line 423 of `Mainform.cs`,

```
txtOutput.Text = _env.Output.UnifyLineEndings();
```

On Windows, it modifies the value of `CR` (13) to `LF` (10). That is... wrong.

On an unrelated note, I manually replaced all `CRLF` in the source code to `LF` to prevent people guessing it's on Windows.

---

Esoteric IDE was linked on [Esolangs wiki page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony).

Answer (score 2):

## Rutger, 82 bytes, [Cracked by Dude coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/233394#comment532848_233394)

```
z=While[{a=Unequal[$x];Print[$x];a[100];}];
z=z[{b=Add[$x];x=b[1];}];
x=1;
Do[$z];
```

This language is cursed.

Comment: This is Rutger, I'll post an answer in a bit

Answer (score 2):

## [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/splinter), 206 bytes, Cracked by user :p

```
C{X{A{}X{A{\1}X{A{\2}X{A{\3}X{A{\4}X{A{\5}X{A{\6}X{A{\7}X{A{\8}X{A{\9}V{B{\9}M{}}}}}}}}}}}}}D{Y{B{\0}Y{B{\1}Y{B{\2}Y{B{\3}Y{B{\4}Y{B{\5}Y{B{\6}Y{B{\7}Y{B{\8}Y{B{\9}VY{DYX}}}}}}}}}}}}M{Z}CDXYZ{YAB\ M}Z\1\0\0
```

I love how my tactic for this challenge is just to write valid programs and go for security by obscurity.

Output is space-separated.

Comment: Splinter?aaaaaa

Comment: @user :( :( :( :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 40 bytes, Cracked by UnrelatedString

```
numbers:=Range[1,100]
Map[Print,numbers]
```

You shall see...

I didn't realise this worked in Mathematica :P

Comment: [took me longer to remember what it's called on TIO than to identify it](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@vNDcptajYyjYoMS89NdpQx9DAIJbLN7EgOqAoM69EByof@/8/AA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString It works in Mathematica? Dammit...

Answer (score 2):

## Malbolge, 669 bytes, [cracked by Aaron Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236063/107299)

```
D'`%$p"=IY|jExU5R-?+a/;-]Ilkih&}$BSbba+N)yxwvXnsl2SR/mlkdL)gfH^c\"Z_X|\[=xX:VUTMRQJnNMLE-hHA@dD=B;:9]=<|492Vw5.-Qr*/.'K+*)ihEf|#"y?`_uzyr8vutmUkpi/gOedchg`&^F#a`B}]V[ZSwWP8sMLQPIHlFEJIHGF?>b<;:987[;:381U5.t,10/.-&J*)i'~%${Ay~w={ts9wvoWmrqj0hg-eM*hgfeG]\"`_X]VzZY;QVUNrR4JONGkKJIH*)dD=B;:9]7<;:981U5.-Q10/.nmJk)"!~}C#cyx}vu;s9Zvotm3Tpohmlkd*Kgfedc\"Z_X|V[ZYXQVOsS54JImMLKDIBfFE>=<`@9876Z:32V0/43,1*N.-&%I)i'~D$#cy~w={tyxq7otsrk1ohmled*hgIe^$bDCYX|\UTYRQu8NSRKJnHMLKDhBAF?>b%;:987[;:381U/4-2+O/(-,+$H(!~}C#"!x}|u;yrq7otsl2pihmfe+Lhgf_%cEDZ~^]VUZSRvVOTSLpP2NMLKDhBGFED=a;#?>=<;4X810T.t21*N.-,+$#G!~}|B"yx}|ut:rq7utVUqpong-kjibgf_%]\a`_XW{[Z<RQVOsSR43ImG/EiCHAF?>b<$:?>76ZG
```

Outputs ASCII code points 1-100. I rate this easy.

Comment: [cracked. Nice one!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236063/101522)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 362 bytes, safe

```
# Program name: "1to100"
# Date created: 11-9-2087

1-100p
# Output: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FZA7bhtQDAR7nWIg1wIe/6Tq9MkVlEQIXNgyZPn8ynPFZme5u7fPy@/X6/P5wq/77d/98sb75e165iiPm6x1PLzw4/K48ud@3efvGZHTnHR1HQ5y2oqPrfj59fj4enxDKIYTJEUzyNoEooghjgSSSCGNDLrQzShqqKOBJlpoo4MtTLBtaZhjgSVWWGODL1xwxfdHxwNPvPDGh1iEEEoYsQMFkUQRTQy5SCGVNNLJnTfJIpscalFCKWWUU0HtOkU1NfSihVbaaKeDTnq3bXqYxQijjDHOBJNMMXuM7zXW8fn8Dw)

Most lines are ignored, and on the last line, 05AB1E just prints out the string.

Comment: Does this print the numbers 1-100?

Comment: @emanresuA this was 1-100, not hello world. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes, safe

... the ASCII-based [version 1](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/releases/tag/v1.0-ascii) of Brachylog, that is!

```
101>#>$@@w\
```

Outputs numbers in decimal, with a newline after each number. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlP///f0MDQTtlOxcGhPOb/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
101>#>$@@w\
101          The number 101
   >         Any integer less than that
    #>       which is strictly positive
      $@     String representation
        @w   Write with newline
          \  Fail, causing the program to backtrack and try the next number
```

The equivalent in Brachylog v2 would be

```
101>ℕ₁ṫẉ⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39DA0O5Ry9RHTY0Pd65@uKvzUdfS//8B)

Comment: Attache? Just a random guess.

Comment: @AlanBagel Not the intended language; I haven't tried it, but I doubt that it works.

Comment: I'm trying this in pushy, and it's taking forever.

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/Lyxal/Keg), 35 bytes, cracked by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

```
  /(

*
_


__


____|
_:.
_\  /+
,
```

It'll be interesting to see if y'all get this one.

Comment: [Keg](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fQUFfg4tLiyuei4srHkLEx9dwxVvpccXHACW1uXT@/wcA "Keg – Try It Online")

Comment: @Steffan post as an answer for free +10 lol

Answer (score 2):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/), 28 bytes, cracked by [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)

```
Take(Sequence(-100,100),102)
```

This has a high chance of working in multiple languages but whatever.

Comment: As I said in chat, this is geogebra

Comment: @emanresuA lol yep, a bit too obvious... Will edit my post now

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 12345 bytes, cracked

```
+π5œÅu‰++´k+JO+za%Î+†+Å5DZÓXDv˛5ˆ◊+Á5c[\"Utp9j>ƒ+>l(s0‰Å=jLÏ++>+*+T‰\+y?>‰h+ŒE4+Ó++>++˚NˇgPım6∫+S++>DfT+ßd=ˆ+Q"B+q‰lˆ+H+˛+Y>ÅX+x+ST˛+´m&Nwˆ+ƒ {V#∂+j+\i_xƒÎ+>+a´++@+++hˆE1+UE´ÁD`w+Ω=BˆPˆ>)++f++%3+PS+n+¨+Å∫VıPZf=+ç>+UÂ+;+¨l˝Ï(++!6++†6∑I+∑aY+´!+œN>+B+˚z†++˙œ+\+Cç v+¬`„ß+dS¨O√†ˇ++Á+b∆¸M9DÏ6e>˙+Â++'Ç∫D++˙q≈∫+Vßı˙+ ++ˆÍ˜+`#`:K? 3Y¬++>+O++´Iv+Ç+vF++xƒ√+`++b1++p+4>ÁˇLˆ'Í+J(˚++hÇ+Q6++~++aw˛+!+o++V˝+atÅ+aƒ/>+"++†œ+p|+Â+Kp+++ç+U+++|+Qå©+W¨¬>+Å+xd˜+x+Ó´1¬´\+6d;+B++ˇ+©#+~+9{+D+/A++?Q+®6<<∫1Øq<<E<<x<<<Z<OΩg)<a<<@<6øA<<ˆÁ-]Ø!25>j>´>No{U>>(> CTk+∑.-<~h<<<<<ßÅıç>>;>å>rÇ=å.v=¬π‰3</gÅ9˜2Ωc#π<<<>b>ı/>y>>„!ƒ>++m.xV´k--<<W<<:YkØ¨∑z%√H´;f4˜<|<:m>Ó3$Å5mj9>@?RÎ>a&>Kƒ.8\<<ÍΩÍç<<5>~˝>>\Î>l>';∆6>Um+åXqÂ+x+.--Z5-D<rˆ6X´<<Ò≈\cVÅ<_˛<<>>>%'Ff>.<wÎ<<<Í>>ruF˜"$#Ω„>QVi>;>%f>>--∂Xå-Ï˚-Î®.ˇ#Ï+++e+</<2K<˛<\ << <>K28>GRÁå>>@g.@<8<<∂r<>lç>ÇqZv$>>>>3>„$®-Ïß-Œ4-Y'.œ++˙;ˆ}ns+ <8adB<<q<˜<S<<>n">>>Ô‰.<x≈u∂‰<˝xΩ<Á<´{">>^>R8X&>J>Ω> z>!∫-Wu-¸%"ıSˇ5i.5{ +√c+<<&ˆ<;tf<<<zÎ∑∏<„fT>>>deŒika>G.$<´®X<<<">>>Î>>>)>-7s/˜/„ZL*U´'˜{\@.+‰Y`<<<<<˛P<8<e>H|>vo>Yg>.˛TÅ<<˚˜≈<P*Í˜Mudı<‰1PtQa>ˆß>˝Ô>ow0>ÂC>EÓ>J>Ω.g<≈<<∂<}<2*&<†Ym∏¬<F?¬ Ya¨>>H>˛VE>6}O\Døˆ.çe;6t6Ô<Œ<<I<∫>>H">oWÍ>CD5Î!Q{zg>>6œ>F+r.-<ç≈<NH&Buπ<œ@#%|<N<<<Ó>>QLÍ>(1>.¬<˜<7<<Sı>∏„~>>>ß ∑>>∂}+Ó.å˝;-}Ø7<Q<z¬<Å<∂<<>J>©b≈>>>>.<^¨<∂<Qµw<<Â<>)U>Í>G>ƒ.<*<=<<> &&M>>Âc`N>f>>˝W+.-<<g◊K˜<s<;<<;Ω8|Fß>/ppR(>v`>?>>>+.-E<1<<RM˝dzßkP<Òuå{ ∆=<ıe<>UÏ>#>>∆fj.'<<<<">ˆ˜*>>>^>k7>F+.9-NRπ<Í<8XΩ<¨yı<©^h<$|Ç<>I>>˜uø>{T¨ˇohK>◊Ô>˚KR++.å-H:¨¨∂{*ŒdÔ-L<oG∑%jåe3†<<\yI√<r„œœ√ø*¬<<>>B>l˙>◊.<c¸:˛Ø<√¸_≈<<>„Í>>?C>„Wh>>S+.C-˛<<~<<µ=OT˚<ˆ<=>>w>Y{>D>Çƒ>dK;;++6„t¨+.-kJ-g8-<E`œN<P<Qc!uK<<)I<D>®>˜~ÔŒ>&∆>s.<<<*Ï<|>>†4BDtbT?\˝UE TF‰>v≈^L>>®F^ÔZK|>+q6f.{|r-<p<˜J<de_<<p∆}qL<g)>#>√a>>Ô>T>>---`&◊ˇøΩ~-.´Z+`+JZ¬+Eut7$å+y¬◊3<<<G<<<E5˛<ƒΩQ>ÒJK{´>I>Uç3Z>b.<G<<<Ò?1Ô>#>>a>>´>˜/©+µj.-˚9uÎ<B<†Z<62<</d<A1Ω>>>U6\‰>>b©p>>-∫--.+zL++<<2:<<W<∏<<ß2b>>k>k>.<h<∏<C†<}x$◊O4Ô˚çπåø¨>>>>2i˝>P>/+˜.-˙'Îcs∏˝Ôfx<HzR<Á<<<!∫<Ø>@ ƒ>XY>lb2>B∂>O>>Wkbß4Ó--.„UΩ+;+<å<<Q∑˚r<@9<∆TŒyå<O?/Í˝˜<8k ezcgZ>¨Œ©˜g>>>(.<< p<n~˜Ht<8>ˇˇz#∫}‰q∑Ó>I>>7Ln)_˜>>≈+vZ√.-ZOå&<Â<"<<√lcXWØ<ˇ!LU<>%bt>y&?Y`>ÅπO/å:H6>@~>ˆ>>d-.Ç+3¬◊ø˜<<<Ø<`<aQ√◊¨<ø<2>\>>>.k2<ˇ<g<}B<◊˚>øŒ>s>>>O ZO>+bn6.-iı1<®<P<Óf¬v <<ˇØ0\<˜cœ>Tˆ>@†Ø∏ß>Œ?Ám("3>a%>w>S>Œˆd.ˆç0<1<*<<C<<<^>ƒ´>7˙>◊t>qIu.<˚<\<</>>7~>˚{>>>+.-®<#<¨˝ø}©I<˜<1a<<ø>7>>>i∂∫y>>†>+.ˆ%-g<∂<˚◊Å<\<<<<1¨>>>>.<dKLÏ@qˆ<oL˜ø<o<>'>‰ˆ>IŒ>>1>„∫Ò+6LJW^+X.8!--<j¨<:9;´O<x<ØÏ$<<>v>Or;>N9>m>>.ø\u<◊<†!j=◊(QIgÎˆf<G<@<z{4i<*7>Ç>Rn>_†'gˇoLå_G{>.¨m¸;l<<<<yzÔAkE>2>ø>>d>K>9+Ih+=.5--Xc#<<œ<qm∏!<h<u‰Y<>˛∑>rX>>RR´`Z>>˜+G%o0˜:D˛˜¨.-)<l˙mAßπ/D<√Ø<<Ô<{<v3tÏ\a4>~(∂>ƒc>>.<<`<S<>=U˝^_nJY >ˇ>>_>µP>oÎ!+b)a+.I-Áyw*-<Ïå~w<‰<|<<<˙0´^∑6>>>ıF>µ>>+ßUØÔ+h%\.˜˚--Î<<=qÏÂ<<D<Ô@ˇ"G%<Iux&$lHı>ZH>D(>˛∆w∑>?∏=/q&.3LÓ@d˙$<d¸<©<<Ø)t´(S>∂O!>>eL>:R>>$+l %Ó¸|+E!SA./H--˝˝C¬;ß<<<<G<¨m<>>>>>W>y1J+N˙ŒΩL+d+*.tz8*Hˆ:Ô∫Knj8k˚--"}Â¸-‰˜¨˝?<Po8W<<†<≈Rzv<<Á&Î>≈ßı@>>?ı>Á.<<N<<nG˜Ï>BA>0ÎS9=>^ÔSOπ>>>|gbSÏ+}+./--m<<<<<x'<alf8>9>>b∂>©˝>/c {>~>Ø----.ÓÁΩE+(+Y¸+ +<√K<@Å<<s~<p<{=ı<∏Í>r>>>R.{œ^d◊<:=<)w´q≈<G<∂¨˜>N>9>rÓW>>>++~˝.--<<©v(9ND©W}<7<l<<>¸†gå4|/ˆI=Á>>w>U;>Â^cz>\>c-Ωf--.+∏+qbıΩ+&<R¨<`I<˝2^a#<W¨:<ı˙M</<>/Mj>>>|¸R˚.<<iDn<tÂ<>>H>Îå>o>>Âv;ÅXB‰++gT.--k<kB<$\¬<√7<O<<t>Ç>3!πH>∆∏(E>≈>ÔTg=\lF>¨˜¸>z#-◊gÇΩ4-Ω.=ı˚"Ò~++<<„®'Ó^/P*<´π)≈< <<mxC´˜<´>>>ÂI∆J>.&=X<L<<<>>>>0>_∫F◊>\XÒ+π`œ+Å´LLˆJ.$D--<<<{ß<π¨W@<<#>>n>BQ®>>>?π0>π-.+Zˆ<(<<J6<<Y<?¸0f<>>ÎF>KÏ \MrÁπ|>N∂T√∆.J´¸ç~Ç5`<`<<<>´>:∆Ï%y8´¨J∆>>◊>◊>n+6\+C.-A-<<<<m<<>5>>>>wÇ&>N¨© ‰>ˆÇEt.<<<{<q<<◊<˝ÏœCl>>cå&WAw=)>ˆ4˛>.tÔ∑<¨¨S<<çµåu}Ç<>„>>ÒxB>>`>)+Ô¬πIGÓ&Í+zK.ß-~˙-<Ó|<B<<Hdml<<>>Ï1>Ó2i˜∫)>>X>u>\8gÍ†3+˚.X-F<´Î©<j<Ehß<!<<®gÒ^∆®<?_å|‰>>n7πç>e˝>z.†\d<<4≈<|†8@<>>>>_>>Ï|D+d\+¸q+.--w-¬o‰u<µ<Ò<Á<ç<¨©TÂˆ∏u∂<>>d>>ˆ>>.<˙%/<Eıx}ç</<µ!@0∂<{<Vj>¸>>>.<¨<q^˜z8a6m=˛N<<>˝®UØ˙>>cGÒ~w>;Q>>ˆ´Z ++π+.˝%¨%--uˆ'˜1c-{®xv¬Y<¸Ï<z\<<<<>}´>>sWÔ˝*Á>b>>+{p*C.-C|<A<j˙deM*V2ÏY<Ï<<h\Óvyƒ/<¸~>v>'> ¨1\Œ>`.<YbEt∏WF<Dø∫5<ÁÏ<¸Çk^?>L_&ZqS≈˜B∆p>ˆh˚ˆ>v@#Ky8a¨6sAC%Ω>>≈>+z*T+oß+.---<<˝<Î´3<<6<>&T>ˆÒ>∑1>>g>|\++∑¬.wØy2tv~¨-_-ˇ<@<hH< ø˝¬å9<<s~ˆ¬Ó∫I<ˇ$>y#J>>>Y.<E<%<jq<>>X>3>>sq>¨M++T}J~_A´+p¨p.-Â˚--<<h<ŒˇHÁHß<<<>>√Q>>h>2>†+Sƒ++.q{œ---<˛´u<x˝<<<?<>>;?˝u>>≈π.ŒS<ˆå<mt ? c<Qlıµh<øœ4dø>c>"/>S>>I(Áe>∂©+¨L&m˛2d++®5Ω.$-2lBl∂„-r@†-<rSßA<Âøˆ<y<<<>Ô>a>>%ˆ>®>B"9>^cŒZ-3-g-!-Í.+mRI¨+"++QvT*~<<TX<´<<gEyA^∂<<9>>ˇ>>_B6∫PmB.<dMˆ˚aJ<<I<~%c>L>>>†>*)^øSƒz>1Á+=ƒ+Ï+.2P--ŒÓ-<<´"<`<w<v©<u>6†∏8>>(>>>({rY∆>--l˙-.+RdÂÂT¬+√+å7(bg2<ZO<˚\<G<ˆ%<¨<a<Â>´ee>b>>.<Ò<<=˛„Vz|å<Å>>>>>>~e+˝+% ˆ+.u--pŒ-<<\<3mE_Á<"s4u<Ø∂˜ΩeN<im&w>;å˜†>Å\>>>>Ï>}G¸/5F\V2-Ó-Is.Sa+çh˜+B0\<<\Â<<Ò<1LY<@<h´0>m9>o†#\d>>.<<<„NleE1ƒœøÏ´¬<>>≈ø>XOjn7>Á/√b>Ô>+++7X∑:.@M´IcC-Ø/6--Ïr2<<H'<çU<ˇ∆^2<1Z˙B∑<i>k>4R>ÏVÂ>>vπ>G4>-Ç.√+çX„v∫<<_^®<<˝∫„I<≈œˆ<å'<>Ïq>Ò¨√®z‰>>.< H')I<Iœ)K!<´m<B˜$©F>˚>˛>9>ˆ>_AÍ`>◊|++Ç8+. -¨¸I--<<_J˜πå<<hq<bp<˚/>#„Ø´s>>>>)>1¬>.p<<<t8<wÓµC<`C<#<>ƒ>˜iµ◊ß#>\>.H\å<‰d?<<≈v˝å<G>>r6XK>C&>o'8nf„>Â◊gvyV3¸>+„˜\˙+ıh+ß=.-◊{ÒNe-ƒIÅPJ3M-A<$\<rN9Ø<<<< ;>>ÓYYˆF>O>>$L>>gXfLÒ◊o∫w`51ß+.-<Z<~<Fˆ<Oœ<π<<9˜≈N>Y‰>>6)>.F=∫¨%1Ò√Y<¨nP:<Y<r2ˆu<>>d∑3gp®Wa>M>˜˛~≈>Å{> tP>-©-˙Zœµ∆--©O.ÍV+^|˛`+∏'+E+<<<r<P<<<C∆X>>>Dxj>¨√ˆ>ÅE91>.<¬˚<krl<‰<ßx?hµÏ9{Z<˝<>>†=3>>.<<<<>t˙π@jF>ˇN>©:ç>>s>!R6ƒCQ>-kx(˜-k-@-l./+Ó++µ|∫˛„+;KÍ<FG<<HŒb<qÍ∂´D´¬}Y<<ƒG<A&>>R3>>M>†=e:Ô>®¬+r1.Q˝q&T-;LsÁ<a<`<b}√<˜<<n>yy>~kiÓ>ƒß\∆◊>C.˝Ω<oŒ<<<> S†3å2>`´:¬>Ø"c>:Ô√>;‰>>=-Ç--ŒÎÍD1-Q.C+Hc+4å+ˆ+qz<N<<´Ç<!´:%4ƒ<<¸<Å>π>X√6®>ywS>>†1>π+∑0+7|.~&--=XÁJ<Ó;<<<∑x<vW<∏œÎÇS>>J#*ç>†>.<S}TB<˝*c%m<<>>>=Å>*U@>‰!|2g>>B-"®sB--Å˚-.++s++ın<∏<oTu;<<˚<&<<åZÂqS'ÇD>†ı>>{ƒ*D6L>;:>g:~>++≈+.´˛Î-å-f´fı{YÔåyA∫t6Å®ÇÓc7„-#r<6<1iQzJÍ<ıµbÔ<<Ï<(ƒWf)˜E~>|X3ı>>|>.<ıF<<4Y<>'>ˇl!>>>>>∑¨X†`\-z-†Byd-\-„Ï.+aM+sW?{+8W+∂´3<<ƒ¸gEÂHp1<<r<<<>:>>ÍZœ∑>√>´>0√©å6V>'ƒÍ--m--Œ˙.+QY+~Íwø+~+</<¸<lcçs<{◊Q<D†<<@>|˙H>7>>.Å<<<<>>W>>>ø>Ø>{*k--Å$--.+++A+<<<ı<F?~D<wE<<>å>h>>Ç∆>>x>Wj◊H-J--.kœ4^Å2+t++<¬<<ßu;ap<ÍˆJµ;˝U<<@T<≈p∑˝>˚Xuhå:>Ò˚>œMYdp>ZkY.ywµ_b&ˇi<Q˜IR<Ω<<Óe2>>XI1∆ˆJWa>>>>Ô√sC˜K>---Hbˇ-;G.?++|fƒ+_?˚H+<<<n√gB<<<<∂>>#>Aπ>>c>>--Å.Hfˆ+Îi$A+|Ó<<<<I<&<Ω<mVS>=ß)ÅD|>>>´Le.ˆ}◊Å©Mab\$3"qD\◊K<∆)<I<πC4|ß<>P>>∆ @4>/:çpK>¬>>)ƒpe9-i2lÂ-P-´Å0-ı~c≈Í.Å+0Ωˇ+6ˆ„++Q%<A<)u7Ø@<l<}Å´´<\'<F´u<>Ç„$%ƒR6>N‰π>_>>3>Wc´ıXçÍH>-Ò.$6+<<'gB<<<ˆ|1∆F<<QLçÏƒ;:Á!>¨∆vÏ>˜3>>sx.˝Œ∆<<<<>8>>>V>>I_>x-pG-=--NÂ.'U9Ó++˙$Ó+t„˙&+nÔ<7<<<"¨D03<*Å&Å<<wƒ>Ó>D˚>>˜>>ΩZ>.„sˆ∑øIF<!\Çlœ`<~<(dÎÅ´<<˙©(π<†®e<O#>>>&˛U>3¬øFL¬5.<<<<®Ï˜_>m˜DHn>ŒgA>µ>&!„>_ßG>>|----P◊ˇDƒs.N++El3+≈Ó+Òd<ø†˜W<"(=UQ<˚3*˝<Ón<e}r<<Ï¸>†å>>dç>Ø>gŒ>>3+˙.;_-<<<ÍZA< <;<<Up$>>´H>I>w.Áb<zXB1<<(ı1¨<œf>ÇAu\pÔ(C>K>SΩN=\>˚6>≈j˛>Ò¨4>--8N-s.\++Q+Á<<ÂPo<Çg4d=ØVø<sP*<m<\Ó<†8>_>>84wˆ&ø>π>I>1.˚u˜"^2<Î1!fı5lç<<ƒ<<V˝<haw7>>>R*u 6SÇ>ÇiÅ.ˆ<<<¬e/<srÓ>>>>VF>>ÓRzŒ>-ˆFr¨¸-i`-.\+wU+µ+<<\Œ<˜IL<'m¨D<<<yVw>4>@>Z>>>*+.bi-<%<´?<<g<D2<¨>å†8>Î>VPZ>i.<<D¨◊<h7©<>>g>{ˆ>>SZTBc>%>---◊.ˇb+˝@AY'◊|+/$+<O<Î$<ø/3BWD<<Á<<>En„©>>>∫>pœ(4rΩ/¨}vƒU|q>∆&++Eœ∆V=.--<x<<<<<◊Œ>◊">m>fz>œ†a*Ó˛.m<qwB<<≈<Ø >r@|¬>Ï>RKçZ>>>≈ØπT9∫π>---ŒÂ}øƒ◊f`.‰+ˆhj+P‰F+<Ç<N<I7sÇ˚<<t7˙<ˆB<>>Ïa!J˜>@b>lk9>/ˆ>4?˚I¬+3+`˚+Ò!.˚-∂√*˚-˜†X|-!3<<L<7%&Ω%<u<<HMuJ>>¸>◊>.C~∫<<ç8)z|uRÅ:<©2ıGXq<>D>ƒ>>Ó7Ndi>>>´¨Ó-6--.∏+$#+j+<<<<C´<ŒÏ<vÒ<>K>>f}uPy†>>>>h-@3---%.ŒXO∑r7+!+\+ÁR+<Ï<Îj6Óxj<œ<<hnDc<<>\F>>¸I\>cx7.KÒ<Ç:˛ƒØ<!x<<V>Ω>>ÁxSˆ>>zœOlV>>‰F`-Í0-˛A4-.+_´√x)07Ô+œc+Â;<=G<<<øucW<m∏Ωµ\B˜B?8_¨Á1œ˝E%<<>>ŒÔ>Ø>>>>-eo„--J.++ç+&<<<˜<H<<U˝<\>´>2Í@>>.l<OWE<E∂<∆19{<>_>zT>*µ> ∫#t>>tO:VˆVcb|ß:>-∂ß--1F.ˇŒ++!+<I<70<v<T<Œ0<B<#"Í∆Zk!:>Tå&qj*i>ÅEÓpT>>Ø>Ò{Md>>'ı-\-ÓZ.GQ++<(Î<G<;<<R<˛kA<i>6†v>ˆD(Y>>.=¸j<<HE<Qˆ<f˛>x>IK´>>P>A„>K>¨r--T-‰.&+F++vC∂_‰(√^<0F|5π<<~=˚<t9Ò´W8<n=Pƒ<@BF<>>„>´:∏>2>/h>Árw>u-Á/.+<ı˜<zJ<åΩ<<^:Í<<>a>>ˆn>.Ô<<f<<råyr>ˆÁÍ3>mV>Ω*8>V&ÎUÎÁ\◊>>Nh∆=¸®q>PÂƒX-'-Rx∑!-v)Åµ!.¨Ôß+++Á<VÂ"QÅ∆<<˙øj\©Ku≈8o<<˜<<Â>O∑@>˙=2>Í¬>W'>>„7qøsøx>x.<<<*<ˇ<<\´ørW¨Qe<Ò>>®ˇˆ>`>Â‰.<<&&<¸&;∫U<>3x>>>J>>>--h1-V.+++`9<c<L:\\R<L<<´FÏÅ∑˙4Q<ø<$>>˜>>>Ø>dA>Ï+.-<<ˆ4Â<<b<<oz©<>"~'>"R>√>.<p∏<fe◊Wf<7œLƒLçH2<qy>Î◊>˙>>>>øˇ>¨¨-2\V-."ÁıIq≈N∫4+M`o˜ `¸+`<Ónaø%C<4<f}e:<<=<rBM<>>>8>Pøc(9Z>m>.´r<Ò<"<<Lˇ<<>Ï0>9l>>FØ~.E<<<Í<&µdÅ>|@>ˆ¨`>>>>>®--ˇåˇ˛9yø.+9∆j\+<<1a<<<C®r<&T<>>>u>>9Ω>+.ı}}„-<<<"∑<≈^R<<≈>A>)√&>>µ.nK<∫B<PÒ<G%BgÇ<´˙1cV>MAr2c¬>Ø>b˚WÍÍX>´}>‰ÎÍ˜∂Ø\>>ç!-v;-;.+˝;µ+<0<˛˙<<KbçJ)mAY^<∆<QœÂçl<Ô>µ//>>¨ 8c>7n7ˆc>>(¸+Øcw+\˚A.^X8-dq(-G<√ß∫Î<s<Ø}<†bI<<%>˜∫L>$>Zg>.<‰y\<<<>˛`O>;4>sµ#o}Ô63∑>>Ø'%_>>-∑(-∑{'Î@m.++X":˝<<<<eÔ<‰^1<<1>I‰UW˜3Ò>Î`K>>i¨H9>G√>yˆvp+77++‰ç.-A-ø-<Á<˛g\R¨$<*<)<<f>>>>D¨Z¸.*√<<y´M<<6œUN©våÍ#k>Ô>>>oŒP>>>W√-mµezB-^XåCT5.++˜x´<< <E<<WµÁn<<>>2˚˝>>√>s≈*'Ø>>-s4ZMsı3∏---.+ı+´+;7Á'WÂ/˜F®WCl˛+Mz/"<<Ô<<<<)∆πw˜<≈I~ww>>'$n>>8Y.<<\Çe<<IE>rŒ>(>>>>1´o>~--.ı+ +<r˚!®<<ÂW3<Î!√&<W/∑®V<a<O>$>>Ò~≈>>E>åQ∑†>I|-ıçrÓ˙-bh-.D++˚≈}ˆ˜©+nL∆<)vHLˆf©ø¸∂˝◊%_<< 9<ˆ"<4<∂<>k>¨>>A.¨*<Y<<øE∂fç<>>j>>˜ç6$>>A©å>˝µÒi-Kµdkh!i∏´˚b-Ô.+¨øJM+<¨<o´<<Ô´<<œÂ<>>>>>M√åÎ>>`tØ--9?Z.I+Dk:˚V+Y<¬ı<ø7<<v˙∂~<@uph<"<>> &>X@>˜ÔqiÒOK^.o<a<o<J<>ΩEÎ}>;UœLç*A>>>◊T/>h>N-Á-.˚d+ø†+Y<^<˙YŒ˜<!<oi˙<}L<ix7<√Åu>y>u>=>>L>˙)#¨ >-ƒb. +y~<q X<´xÏ®Î\9@N<j<K<R<d<´>Âµ>¸?√6ˆœ¬˝>\∑>=.n<Œ'∆muU)„)GoÒ<ku<<j?> >y>œˆ>>>>\--bÁ.i*+å+◊f<%<!ßCu<z<_´x_m<<<ƒ>bH†!>!>‰c>&†>˜!y9†>!2S>5.<<6<˙<˝e;<<<‰√Å>>yıx>>.<<<<59ˇ>9†HEÇ>ÒÓn˛9M;>k>>†cø´c∏>Î=açJ>u´G--∑.+Å+uI<^<=<<v<}Ω<<{ç>>>3∑y>>®V>F>aN8!Òß9+d.-<J◊e<´„Œ<ÎπF?\AŒMbÔ®<¨å<<ˇ<>>a#>&>.<<k∂z<Ωr<>>ˇ`>>>†Ac'>>-U˜.+$<◊wØwd:B<<2/n<<G<<%>*>egW>;{>'Q∂>>}&D1N.<<<ƒ1~<(Ø´<:≈Ø≈∫<}>>rc>ˆg®k>.´eV6˛∑<<<AU6<>¸>w>$˜>¨lq>ˆ>´∂>-®.+<πçˇgMß˚"Z<|¨<<ƒ<<QÅjƒ<%>3˛>>K>/=∑> _>+a.-8M BÍA´<k<∆!Ωø<˙'¬<<Ï¨q<m'=>U>T˝3N„ˇ◊∆9ƒÎxje>>'QÓ3^.<K<<Qb~<e>˝µ>4Ç>>@>V>Q>-UåvO.+<y<<e&ø◊<<øum<</CØVHYm`>cjå#Ï/s>Ø)>>>>++.18¬Òπ--<<´T<<x< <>>>ß>.<h:T<US<†4<‰∑>CÂb9>w¨s">>I>$Kr∏=6ƒ>J>ˆ-. Rø'+˛i0nÂ<<<i/å<<zÒ#i˙<ˆ<≈9l~=>˙˙h˜˚D6>ÓKD>Óv>1P>‰>++H+.m-a˙k-d-<◊<=y∏◊<<<<>3>>`˝‰>◊."1ÅbZ<<<Ô)e∫vfpC®¬<Z>~˜>9∂>∫RSÂ5T>>9>8>x-.}ålß+B<o´Í3W7<ÓŒ<k˚ç<<„<d<>>;˙:4>La>>=>F>ˆ-H-Ï(:Å{´ß-ç˜-.+Ó++Q6ÍM+<9q<„<<0<t∏T<<¸>◊NB>>l x>(∏∑`aa._<<<<M>˚>zID6>C>>y>>|-_\.+_<<Fˇ<Ω<<\t<Î<>MRÓ¨#pœz∆vA>>>E>>>-ÒH-Ø-L'{eO/.˛=+g++/{˛„~1#<<ÎZ<<˜SG\M{Ï<®I<Ô@<(@Œa´>>qÒ)´> >Í◊. Q<_vB<=Â/?Òq˜Ó<AJÅ t∆Z2fT<f(>jG©F>>@?6>cÅ>>8>-Á.Î+<0<e^"/mπÏ8C<<<<<2>Z>e¨∑>Ôc˛>>7¬¨>˙¸>ˆw8√gR-`ßh∫-ÅÏ˝7Ï.u++ß∫<<#<Â<<®<<Ó>>´|Bå>>Y.</^<e<®~)`<|e&&b˜π>g>>>>>`C>-ˆøAp.∑+b&l$<©#<P<<<Um{√Paıc<Z<\Ω>O>>>Ó>fÔ>8>-.;π*+<<r7<<</VÍ<´0¨a<>!>ug>>å.<Á<m∑:<<2u>D>1e>Ω>ç∏c>åÒ∂C&b>>~-.+iyp<πWÁ<r<5`T<<w`<<=N >>Q"?>>|˜T˝Ø>cÔ>HΩL†Kµjsa7å>∆ŒBP."©<<ÏH6Yq<<<PH<ƒ◊AluQF<>>o˜}>>5_.Î5<ŒGÁı<<„<>∆ÏÂX®>¨´Ó>S‰X\>>=>>-πå^.Òa=+<<A◊q<<<<©T=<√ıˇÎ>?v>>h¨Xr>7Ï´˛¸G>>>Óla¨+∫.-7<Ó~<$<0∏<5z<<∑<)Ò>cH∂ß>µ>$v>)K.∆<˜<<<j#Ω>>>πB¸>>>>.6d<¨<{T<t‰<Ç<Ç<<>>H>C>˜>>0.<g99<v~ÒELX˜´i<ˆÍ<µ!∂<∏<G˜>Tv>>jµ>#∂.Î<œg<ÔÓ∂ˇP<µ:Á˝WQBI<I>GÅ>>Ç˙>˜>>w>.åπ&˙<x<g$'<<◊N◊<¨<π<∫Ò*>†;lÁ>>ƒ˛ø>çI>>Z+.Gıˆ¸-<<<Òi†◊<√Í"<∆D5m<S>hG;>)$>>t¬.<<wIÍ∆<<Òb¨ˆr5>>>g˝>BW¨‰0˜>¬@>Nuap>nfz.p?\= L<gπ) <<@Ò<ı<å©<I˜<>>>>®>R>+uWΩ¬1Å+\V¸w.◊-(Á$-<H;e<<<<<r_>W>}4\π>MÍ˙∑*∆©/´`ÔÁ5>Oz5œ.˚<Ó?∆ı<;<SLY<˜>©>>>4>>Ç>pj.?<Ò<tΩ<dkµaK%πK<B9<∆x˜∏5}<<>j>>}>ˆD˝Î!7Øç_>>Ô+?)++;r¨.OÔ-´-#n?E-}<8©<<S<rsk3ˆ®<'3I}†#6<˝\>>:©6H>X>{Ou.2\<<¬h<<∏>>>>>>¨Axœq^>.∂v<˜_<ı\Ç<<Lg<<<~>>ZCG˙>f&=\>x>>˙Lq∫˜Âm>g\-pjß-Fx%(_VÏ-{g-m.!&+ı$I`R+g+0+ø<D<Í$œÂÇ=<<G<<k<Ò>>>µM>.<x<<V7<>ø>w˜∂T˝y>e>sŒn>>|LW>.©WI3<<9pUpn<<Jx<w<A◊<åi∂®>>Ó>ƒT¨>S>_>3>r-˜9-*Òy;-cJ.I+≈?¨+O+&F\Å<i<&<<<Â<<>@>>Å>.<<\jbu<1<eM>¨"pt>_>>mCπ˜>R∏>>q*.:<Î<\˛<v<<<g‰å<˝Òw`>P*D">h>ˇ>M¨>>0>m9˚6&ƒ-c-ç1©.e~5S˙©7++ß<<&<|'IDd<Z´<<Ï~<#>>K>≈øÎ>.t◊<ˆ<%ˇ6O3&{<n<∂>√>>%©sI>>>≈˜B≈>"dvp◊.<\h´w#<¨<LÒ<<<µˆ<>>\Y=>\>t>>HπS>-.´+}˛ <{mm<¸ E<<<oIe˜∑<˛z*NC<D©ˆΩN>9=>r>B>.Y˚∂<8<Á©<U7r@=e<ZåB>{Ô'>"}>m'4>>}>¸ˆw>.R≈Ï<A<<<<f<å<Å>>>>>>>.<åbÒ|W<^<*Mƒ<<=w2T<<1Su>åc˛>>0>DÒeE.<<*B<X82<&Â5∆ç>T>Á>>d>?rO8r^>>.<Î|<<ø<<wh<L<>x>˛˚u>jd>†FQ>>>+.-Ø˙S9zmN<<<<©t<PV<{<>>)li3Ï>>.<`BåÓ<ÍDƒ<<>Ω¬W4I˛å2N7¨>C{>ø√>¸>K>2*>+UßÏ.-p_<Ø<4VT<¬<l<<I<p>>>>>∫:>Ïnµ.<´˚;<∆%<<<<R>>7>∫>.&å<µH<<ß<>{>(>> "Di/Øx|>N>Î#åh! ^∑Í>+.-v<<O˙bnç˜<<<®¬vˆ<tFç<>>>ßr>Î>ØØ2a>©|"+œ.-<I<d<<<ß´1<\7>>`kµF{>`>.<Jq≈\<<\˛f<>ˆœj>e>G&>>4S>>+˛bA(?.-ˆGø\;<<3:w<e<(r<<<˝ı†H¸>>>Å>7>Rˆ˜Ô/´z>+dI0/~iE˙®+.ˆı-Z_ßåD-ˆˆeH∏Ó8b<<5iHa˛Í<<√^c<<6>>4p>L≈7®>2.<?≈<N<<FÁU^`>>i>pd>a≈ß1O√dÂd>>g>Cˇøz+.ÍsŒt-<<<<∂3≈ç?Í˛D∫<<{v=&<R/>BßÁÅÔ>>6X>y)*y¬Ç>>+å˜Ó++|aÍ)J)\u.---m∑<<®EX<<s<<Å>>>A>RKE.ˆ<m<#N¬AyF~<◊<>_$PJs>>i>Ó\>>Rˆ1>¸{+V.˜K-|<27w<t6<„Ω<<´Á<c<>˜>˛Ô8>M>umk=>>Âµb>-J-Ò-@TA-.+Ï+++≈◊<<<Áµz<09Ç<~3%∆¨< <◊Œ>>>>˙.Â˜<∑Åå<J<<>l*>>;µµ>>˚>~ç>+6i∫.\U-hÅµ7<<n˛<Ø<f=<<d"SoC6k%x<>;moç>†2†>n>CB>>>∂-GO-∑&-lΩi6.∆+F++µ¨9˙<N<<<<<<>>VÍ∫˜g‰>∆>◊.<<<π<>>Ô>?YQB11>≈9>o0≈ƒl`x>>X∂+'u.-œ<Ω≈åI¸‰<K≈=R7N<<<$u<z<q1K1>F\>>s>Hˇ√/ˆ>>ßC>-∆ß|´-`.FCj+∫Ô;+¨Ò<<<<Q¬<\<c_Ò_å!pB<˝q$>Ø1XI}>>‰>.Bj<∑}<Á'f<6rÍ*<>0>®>K>>R^y~ˆIBœdX¨>Ω>˚+∂√.Ç\I1v≈-OƒX˚<¨k|<u<ˇ@ıjÓ<<G<ˇ?<RΩ>>>>∫M>å∂3%m>2!t"@{>-.A´;˝l„¸:Iu˙hı+)∏6<0Òˆ˜\<$<^<<=L<jS˜Å∫<|>n>#>?>"q.ŒC<Å∆<W<Ø6&DœHj4~M5<Og;>QBÂV>>>ˇ>>>Ò7+.†-<<^<Y'i#2vøåJC<Jl<p<<>¸>>6>:w>∑h?`D>>d5√.cˇ<ˆ<hOuß˜<<jπ∫\<<fåfB?<˛†˝ıˇ>>>/>.<*_d<◊<e_<>">>>>5>J>ø∂ø˝+yç ç.N9∏∫-<∂<</<=<=l#8ø<?<>>øx$>sE>'>>ßS>e?X#+¸.Î¬d∆Ø-Í\<n˛<w<<˝zh<<4^<a@Ig_µ◊>^øF>˛>4Ó/ˆ>.n∆<5<˚"2Á<|@<>>πÁ%´>Ø∆ >p¸sv!>´v∂Ç|πÒ>{¸+^.W-s<<<å<<<>{¨˝>>>0>>.@øƒÓˇ<H<<<◊<∂P¬A<>Î>>d>O>>*k∆.<<<<Å<ƒ<mm.
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/247381#247381)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-98, 13 bytes, [cracked  by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/247425#247425)

```
:+1_#_@#-d',:
```

I rate this easy-medium, with the right perspective. It's a language on TIO that you have probably heard of.

Prints ASCII characters 1-100.

I went to a lot of effort to disguise that this was 2d, avoiding explicit redirects like `<>^v`. I tried to remove the `@`, but code to replace it was too complex. I now realise that the `d'` was a big giveaway as it signified that the program had to reverse.

The basic idea is that `:+1_` at the start effectively redirects left, then the loop begins.

The loop is `1+::,'d-#@_#_`. `1+` increments the ToS (initially a 0) then `::,` duplicates it twice and prints it. `'d-` pushes 100, then subtracts, leaving 0 only if the ToS is 100.

`#@` and `#_` are skipped during normal iteration of the loop, because `#` skips the next character. The instruction pointer passes through the `#@` to the `_`, and if there is a `0` (i.e. the current number is 100) the IP redirects right to the `@` and halts the program.

Otherwise, it continues through the `#_` and the next iteration begins.

Comment: Quadrefunge-97/Quintefunge-97

Comment: or befunge98 whichever you like lol

Comment: or befunge96/97

Answer (score 2):

## Vyxal 2.4.1, 27 bytes, [cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255884/100664)

```
For 100 Do _ (
  Put n++,
)
```

`For` does nothing. `100 Do _` eventually pushes 100. `(...)` loops 100 times, with the context variable n going from 0 to 99. `Put` pushes 1, and `n++` adds 1, then 0. `,` prints.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255884/78850

Answer (score 2):

## Pyret, 23 bytes, [cracked by Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256750/100664)

```py
map(print,range(1,101))
```

This doesn't work in Python because the map is never evaluated. My intended solution was Proton, but apparently it also works in Pyret.

Comment: Would this happen to be [pyret](https://www.pyret.org/)?

Comment: @lyxal Unlikely.

Comment: No, I'm telling you that it works in pyret. You've been cracked, nerd. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/256750#256750

Answer (score 2):

## [Alphabetti spaghetti](https://github.com/stasoid/Alphabetti-spaghetti), 69 bytes (safe)

```
>%:/j
 uv - =
k*i\"d" \
_:  3 = 1
j)o  y1|h     /
   4    &
>    @l;t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8wpyEhMSi0pydQtLkhMzwCx/v@3U7XSz@JSKC1T0FWw5crWyoxRSlFSiOGKt1JQMFawVTDkytLMV1CoNKzJUAABfS4gYQJiqXHZgSiHHOuS//8B)

Output is integers separated by a constant delimeter (the program's source code).

The actual program:

```
juvkidjoyhlt # program
j            # Increment cell to 1
 uv          # Multiply by 10 twice, to 100
   k         # Decrement, to 99
    i        # Increment, to 100
     d       # Move down in the memory 
      jo     # Increment this value and output it
        y    # Output the program's source code (delimiter) 
         h   # Move up
    i     lt # Decrement this value, jump back to the i if nonzero
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vyxal 2, 33 bytes, cracked by emanresu A

```
n=0
print from 1 to 100(n, n=n+1)
```

Comment: [This is vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCJuPTBcbnByaW50IGZyb20gMSB0byAxMDAobiwgbj1uKzEpIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Comment: @emanresuA Yeah, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

### dc, 17 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155028/68615) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
0[1+pd100>a]salax
```

Have fun. It won't be too hard to solve, I have a more intresting one coming soon.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155028/68615)

Comment: Heh, knew it would be a quick crack.

Answer (score 1):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 14 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155157/61563) by totallyhuman

```
(].[]%<100@9)&
```

Outputs decimals separated by tabs.

Comment: [This is Implicit.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155157/68615)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically), 47 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155144/61563) by user202729

```
[
out:6 ~ x * 1 + 1 / 1 % 6;
string x @ 8;
]100
```

Prints decimals separated by ASCII 0x00.

Cubically strips out all spaces, and alot of the commands are no-ops. The code it interprets is:

```
[:6~*1+1/1%6@8]100
```

The code that actually does useful things is:

```
[*1+1/1%@8]100
[.........]100   repeat everything in brackets 100 times
 *1+1/1          fail-safe add 1 to notepad
       %         print notepad as integer
        @8       print !issolved(cube)
```

Comment: This is Cubically. (new square bracket? nice)

Answer (score 1):

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 9 bytes, cracked by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155070/48922)

```
(100+1$c)
```

Another easy one.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155070/61563)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 600 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155062) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0063\u006c\u0061\u0073\u0073\u0020\u0058\u0020\u007b\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0076\u006f\u0069\u0064\u0020\u006d\u0061\u0069\u006e\u0028\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u005b\u005d\u0061\u0029\u007b\u0066\u006f\u0072\u0028\u0069\u006e\u0074\u0020\u0069\u003d\u0031\u003b\u0069\u003c\u003d\u0031\u0030\u0030\u003b\u0069\u002b\u002b\u0029\u007b\u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006d\u002e\u006f\u0075\u0074\u002e\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0074\u006c\u006e\u0028\u0069\u0029\u003b\u007d\u007d\u007d
```

Outputs decimals.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155062/68615)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gopher](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gopher), 217 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155211) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
'&^<'?×++<%@-<!÷-<'&^<.!<'?^×-<%!÷--<?^×++<++<%!÷<?×<+<&?^++<%!@-<&××-<.@÷+<'&^<.@÷÷+<×<÷-<'×-<?^×+<.!<++<<<'?××-<!÷--<%!÷<?+<&?^+<#÷-<'^×++<×+<÷--<×+<.@÷÷+<÷--<--<++<××-<<-<^+<-<<÷÷+<=
```

Output is a series of space-separated numbers.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155211/61563)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_(programming_language)), 72 bytes, [cracked by moonheart08](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155084)

```
export Executable
run(args) = do
for i<-seq(1#100) do
println(i)
end
end
```

Links: [Specification](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/samth/fortress-spec.pdf), [Direct download of version 0.1 alpha](http://web.archive.org/web/20070715233437/http://fortress.sunsource.net/files/documents/81/140/fortress_168.zip).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155083/77964)

Comment: @moonheart08 That's a link to this answer :)

Comment: Wrong link, @moonheart08

Comment: [whoops! Real link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155084/77964)

Answer (score 1):

## 0815, 21 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155213/41024) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
}:S:<:1:+$~<:64:-^:S:
```

Output is raw bytes.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155213/61563)

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](//git.io/triangular), 31 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155205/61563) by MD XF

Should be quite easy

```
,i#%)`A;A^A@&NN*L!o|_\Om;;-?!>/
```

Newline separated integers

Stripped of all the unnecessary characters and formatted it looks like the following:

```
        , 
       i # 
      % . ` 
     A . A . 
    A . & . . 
   * . ! . . .
  \ . m . . . .
 . > / . . . . .
```

It goes around this loop of characters in an anti clockwise direction.
Redirect SW, increment the stack, output the number, push 10 twice and multiple for 100, redirect around (3 steps), mod, skip the next command (exit) if not 0, push 10 (newline), output the character and start loop again.

Of course this could be golfed down quite a bit.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155205/61563) Were all the no-ops intentional?

Comment: @MDXF Thanks for the edit and yes the no-ops where intentional.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 24 bytes, cracked in like 30 seconds by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155175/42963)

```
("v"|% le*)`
..(""+,1e2)
```

Output is newline-separated.

Comment: [This is Powershell.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155175/68615)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 139 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155190) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
$,=$
";*a&*z;*aa&*az;*ba&*bz;*ca&*cv;s;;
$.++;e##cv]
      ;;;   print++$
      _..          $
=*
5/3   ;;;
6/4   ;;;
7/5   ;;;
8/6   ==*cv
```

Outputs decimal integers, space separated.

Comment: [This is Perl 5.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155190/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman, well, it was fun while it lasted. I almost managed to take a whole breath. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/), 37 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155304/76162) by Nitrodon

```
v<[-=0lfn_v#:-d<]
<[/_>]/@-0>_?!:^"d.
```

Outputs the ASCII code points 1 through 100.

---

The executing code is:

```
<[--d<]/_>]/@-0>_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85NSvv/3yZaVzfFJlY/3i5W30HXwC4eixAA)

The first section `<[--<]` decrements every character from the end by 2, until it reaches the last character of the loop, turning it into a `[`. The code then looks like:

```
<[--d<[-]<[->+.<]
```

The `[-]` resets the `<` and the second part uses the `d` as a loop counter to print out the first 100 ASCII code points.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155304/69059).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://tio.run/##HcqxDoIwEADQ3a8gTHA9YlFxsDl3EkZGlrbUpMsFTXvx74syv6cH6/pQyswTvtGiQ48rjpgo8pZT0xohbzI58PA7p/ANvo6vSp501Y/DFK0LCwnI@TKoO4jqb7rLavyThcaBdLk12ydyqmThGlIpOw), 106 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155247/68615) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
TnL,q,a,b,c,d,I,t=input();v=c;u=b*c*TnL
exec"if v>=30:v=c;u+=d\nv=v*v/25+6*v+140-u+I;u+=a*(b*v-u);print v\n"*t
```

Outputs as an array of integers from 1 to 100.

---

`TnL,q` prints `[1, ..., 100]` then immediately exits due to `q`, all other junk is ignored.

Comment: [This is 05AB1E.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155247/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman incorrect! It's OBVIOUSLY python, or whatever answer I stole the filler from.

Answer (score 1):

## [FALSE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FALSE), 26 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155326/76162) by Rlyeh

```
1a:[a;101-][a;.a;1+a:" "]#
```

Comment: Is this some dialect of REBOL or something?

Comment: Is it False? chr

Comment: [Link to Ryleh’s cracked post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155326/76162)

Answer (score 1):

## [Quartic](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Conor_O%27Brien/Compilers/Quartic), 78 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155325/31957) by [Esolanging Fruit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/esolanging-fruit)

*Gotta love google*

```
decl	a,z,e
set	a,1
set	z,1
loop	z
print	a
cmp	e,a,'d'
if	e
dec	z
end
inc	a
end
```

Now for something a bit longer. Output is character codes.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155325/61384)?

Answer (score 1):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 353 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155451) by MD XF

```
$ 123
@(%
#ZZ
&^0
*i*j F=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101
$ 123
@(%
#ZZ
&^0
*i*j
```

Output is separated by new lines.

Came across this by accident trying to crack someone else's answer. Hopefully it is disguised enough... Good luck!

Comment: Haha I thought that looked familiar at first

Comment: @dylnan I coudln't crack yours (Yet!!), but I saw some cool looking output on a language I thought yours was and played with it a little more until it gave me the output I wanted!

Comment: Which language? (jk)

Comment: Are all the leading spaces intentional?

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the catch @MDXF

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155451/61563)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 31 bytes, [cracked by jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155356/25180)

```
0>1+:aa*1+=?;:\
 ^       o"|"n/
```

Output looks like:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|100|
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155356/25180).

Comment: This was an obvious one...

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](//git.io/triangular), 40 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155397/61563) by totallyhuman

```
1%P
*>\
A+.A
@~~.@A)][(An!!?_
`*/-S+1%U<
```

Comment: [This is Triangular.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155397/68615)

Comment: @totallyhuman come onnnnnnnnn

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 24 bytes, [cracked by MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155420)

```
Ł1ɊHǙ:Ȱ#Ĭhȅȡ;œœ
```

Have fun!

Comment: Which encoding is this in?

Comment: Can you post a reversible `xxd`?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, can you explain?

Comment: windows bro, and utf-8

Comment: This is 24 bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155420/61563)

Comment: @MDXF Good job!

Comment: Was surprised to see someone using my language... :)

Comment: yeah I like languages like this @FlipTack

Answer (score 1):

## Add++, 83 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155412/68615) by totallyhuman

```
DECLARE -> (A, B) => g [1, 2] , 100 () - () 100 V From 1 (#) RAN pop => GRAVREL & G
```

Outputs as a list with `,` separating the numbers.

Comment: [This is Add++.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155412/68615)

Answer (score 1):

## [Crayon](https://github.com/ETHproductions/crayon), 10 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155468) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
100O)q"q"q
```

Outputs numbers separated by `q` and ends with `q`, i.e.:

```
1q2q3q4q5q6q7q8q9q10q11q12q13q14q15q16q17q18q19q20q21q22q23q24q25q26q27q28q29q30q31q32q33q34q35q36q37q38q39q40q41q42q43q44q45q46q47q48q49q50q51q52q53q54q55q56q57q58q59q60q61q62q63q64q65q66q67q68q69q70q71q72q73q74q75q76q77q78q79q80q81q82q83q84q85q86q87q88q89q90q91q92q93q94q95q96q97q98q99q100q
```

`100` puts `100` on the stack, and `O` iterates over the numbers `0..(100-1)`. Then for each number, `)` increments the number, `q` prints it, `"q"` puts the string literal `q` on the stack, and `q` prints that.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155468/61563)

Comment: @MDXF How did you come about Crayon (which was the intended language)?

Comment: I've messed around with ETH's languages before (never solved challenges in this one though)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyke, 9 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155500/41024) by [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)

```
~th5@.oLh
```

The expected output is this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155500/41024)

Answer (score 1):

## Aceto, 17 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155516/21173) by MickyT

```
O
nX`m
pd2F
d9
II
```

Output format: integers, newline-seperated.

Comment: [cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155516/31347)

Comment: @MickyT sadly yes :(

Answer (score 1):

## [SIL](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/SIL-S.I.L.O.S), 38 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155524/46918) by [Conor O' Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)

Output as integers separated by newline

```
a=100
lbla
i+1
printInt i
b=a-i
if b a
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155524/31957)

Comment: I knew it wouldn't last. I thought I'd last more than a minute though @ConorO'Brien

Comment: I think the way you formatted your answer broke the snippet

Comment: @ConorO'Brien did I add some strange whitespace or something when formatting it? I meant to just paste from my TIO I had whipped it up in.

Comment: I think it might be the header format? `[cracked](link) by [user](link)` is how most answers do it. I guess the snippet is a bit finicky

Comment: @ConorO'Brien did that fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73014/discussion-between-rohan-jhunjhunwala-and-conor-obrien).

Answer (score 1):

## Fission 2, 21 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155536/75553) by totallyhuman

```
I[!$Z;R'd@
)Md`S,.=+-
```

Output is ASCII 1-100.

Equivalent without unnecessary code:

```
R'd@I[!$Z;
  +  M  S
```

Comment: [This is Fission 2.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155536/68615) That `R`...

Comment: @totallyhuman haha too fast

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 118 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155580/78124) by [jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25180/jimmy23013)

Probably way too easy, but it's funny. :D

```
HAI 1.3
IM IN YR loop UPPIN YR var TIL BOTH SAEM var AN 101
    VISIBLE SMOOSH var AN "," MKAY! 
IM OUTTA YR loop
KTHXBYE
```

Comment: [Yes, way too easy.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155580/25180)

Comment: Damnit, a minute too late

Comment: Lasted longer than my last submission :)

Comment: Tip: You should try obfuscating your code, rather than golfing it

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 53 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155645/61563) by totallyhuman

```
${-}=${-}-band0;while("${-}".length-le2){${-}++;${-}}
```

Outputs numbers in decimal starting at 1, ending at 100 - one per line

Comment: [This is PowerShell.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155645/68615)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 2009 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155649) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
'.
Puck, a day.
Page,.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Puck and Page]
Puck:
You are the sum of a bold cute fair fine good rich warm joy and the sum of a bad fat bad fat bad hog and the sum of a fine warm day and joy.                                                                        '; $_ = str_split('
Page:                                                                                              '                                                                                                                );                                                                                                                                                                    array_walk/*
Open thy heart! You are the sum of thyself and a day!
Puck:                                                                                                                                                                                                               */($_,function($_/*
Are you nicer than me?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    */, $_i/*
Page:                                                                                                                                                                                                               */) {print 1+                                                                                                                                                         $_i;/*
If so, let us proceed to Act I.
[Exeunt]                                                                                                                                                                                                            */print' ';});
```

Outputs numbers as integers from 1 to 100, separated by spaces.

Comment: I think this is intended to be PHP, but it is missing a starting `<?php` tag.

Comment: The opening tag is not required for code golf, as it can also be run using php -r, in which case an opening tagbis not required. But yes, you are correct :)

Comment: In that case, [this is PHP.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155649/68615)

Comment: @chocochaos From the rules: `Flags may be used, but you must reveal what flags are used in your answer.` If you used `-r`, you needed to specify that.

Answer (score 1):

### Julia, 53 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155697) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)

Not even my Ruby polyglot could disguise my language of choice.

```
i=[1,2][1]
while i<=100
print(i)
print("\n")
i+=1
end
```

Comment: I've only ever seen you submit answers in Julia, and it [looks like it works](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8/z/TNtpQxyg22jCWqzwjMydVIdPG1tDAgKugKDOvRCNTE8pQislT0uTK1LY15ErNS/n/HwA)

Comment: [cracked here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155697/67312)

Comment: I figured that would be the case, faster than i I expected though.

Answer (score 1):

## C + [ecpp](https://github.com/aaronryank/ecpp), 196 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155826/61563) by Dennis

```c
#rule control_flow foreach
#rule control_flow in
#def `foreach a in b..c:` for (int a = b; a <= c; a++)

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1, b = 100;
    foreach i in a..b:
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Comment: [This is ecpp + C.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155826/12012)

Answer (score 1):

## Stuck, 55 bytes, safe

```
HEX:
22 78 c3 9a c3 8b 48 c3 8c 48 c3 b4 c3 8b 2f 48 05 20 0e 0e 03 25 22 44 67 79 0a
22 65 4e 71 4c 63 72 53 31 42 51 41 43 35 67 45 57 22 42 44 42 63 5d 52 22 20 22 6a

CODE:
"xÚËHÌHôË/H %"Dgy
"eNqLcrS1BQAC5gEW"BDBc]R" "j
```

I think this will be pretty easy for you guys. Cheers! :)

Comment: You did it. Reveal the language to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki), 170 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156033/76162) by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

```
3112211411100*11v
_*ŕ2vthesĨngulařity [[]((<>))] 
   4  /...psh...cřackle...fĨžz....pop24
is.../
    /coming to eaŕth
the ŕobots aŕe going to get you...
  /ĉ52*²
řun fas⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDoIwGIX3nuIfgaHwV9yMFyHEVFIKESlJCwneQHcGdgdmD@Bg6EW8SC2Jy8vLe@/L60bj3A6RMcQUEZMkQhzIKbITG0wl9Lq0sm@4nWszQpblQXA4hmEOBABSgJhS2unKa2FnXlwa4W25LvZ9o1ulOpaSWnsbbwTEhbrWrQSjQHA7mYr4E7CTOiujwScCpPoPpDAwqt6zHo3X@55Fnxexc99CyfX38XTuBw)

Comment: [This is Pyt.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156033/12012)

Answer (score 1):

## MIX self-loading executable, 136 bytes, safe

```
 O O6 A O4 D B= X BC K B1=C B= S 6C O -1 U -1 A QI*=Z4   AB=AC+AE XAE3 XAZ1  AAG
 K B2 J I9 XAE3  AXG AAJG J XI XAR7  AMG K B4 S D9 W R4 VKBE
```

Outputs numbers left-padded to three digits, two spaces preceding each number, and a line break after every 14 numbers.

The biggest clue here, I think, is that if you look at every character in a column divisible by five, all but three of them are spaces (and the other three do not affect the operation of the program). It doesn't hurt that the format described uses five bytes for each number, with the exception of line breaks; and the arbitrary positioning of the line breaks might have hinted at a record-oriented language.
This was obfuscated only by (a) keeping all used bytes in the range 0-48 and avoiding 10, 20, and 21 (which are `Θ`, `Φ`, and `Π`, respectively, though they are usually mapped to other ASCII characters by implementations), so it could be read by a MIX-standard card reader, and (b) selecting bytes whose values were arbitrary to look interesting.
The code decodes to:

```
| Loc | Chars   |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 | Instruction      |
|-----|---------|----|----|----|----|----|------------------|
|   0 | " O O6" |  0 | 16 |  0 | 16 | 36 | IN   16(16)      |
|   1 | " A O4" |  0 |  1 |  0 | 16 | 34 | JBUS 1(16)       |
|   2 | " D B=" |  0 |  4 |  0 |  2 | 48 | ENTA 4           |
|   3 | " X BC" |  0 | 27 |  0 |  2 |  3 | MUL  27(0:2)     |
|   4 | " K B1" |  0 | 12 |  0 |  2 | 31 | STX  12(0:2)     |
|   5 | "=C B=" | 48 |  3 |  0 |  2 | 48 | ENTA 3075        |
|   6 | " S 6C" |  0 | 22 |  0 | 36 |  3 | MUL  22(4:4)     |
|   7 | " O -1" |  0 | 16 |  0 | 45 | 31 | STX  16(5:5)     |
|   8 | " U -1" |  0 | 24 |  0 | 45 | 31 | STX  24(5:5)     |
|   9 | " A QI" |  0 |  1 |  0 | 18 |  9 | LD1  1(2:2)      |
|  10 | "*=Z4 " | 46 | 48 | 29 | 34 |  0 | NOP  2992,29(34) |
|  11 | "  AB=" |  0 |  0 |  1 |  2 | 48 | ENTA 0,1         |
|  12 | "AC+AE" |  1 |  3 | 44 |  1 |  5 | CHAR 67,44       |
|  13 | " XAE3" |  0 | 27 |  1 |  5 | 33 | STZ  27,1(0:5)   |
|  14 | " XAZ1" |  0 | 27 |  1 | 29 | 31 | STX  27,1(3:5)   |
|  15 | "  AAG" |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  7 | MOVE 0,1(1)      |
|  16 | " K B2" |  0 | 12 |  0 |  2 | 32 | STJ  12(0:2)     |
|  17 | " J I9" |  0 | 11 |  0 |  9 | 39 | JLE  11          |
|  18 | " XAE3" |  0 | 27 |  1 |  5 | 33 | STZ  27,1(0:5)   |
|  19 | "  AXG" |  0 |  0 |  1 | 27 |  7 | MOVE 0,1(27)     |
|  20 | " AAJG" |  0 |  1 |  1 | 11 |  7 | MOVE 1,1(11)     |
|  21 | " J XI" |  0 | 11 |  0 | 27 |  9 | LD1  11(3:3)     |
|  22 | " XAR7" |  0 | 27 |  1 | 19 | 37 | OUT  27,1(19)    |
|  23 | "  AMG" |  0 |  0 |  1 | 14 |  7 | MOVE 0,1(14)     |
|  24 | " K B4" |  0 | 12 |  0 |  3 | 34 | JBUS 12(2)       |
|  25 | " S D9" |  0 | 22 |  0 |  4 | 39 | JL   22          |
|  26 | " W R4" |  0 | 26 |  0 | 19 | 34 | JBUS 26(19)      |
|  27 | " VKBE" |  0 | 25 | 12 |  2 |  5 | HLT  25,12       |
```

The computer automatically reads in instructions 0-15, then starts at 0.
Our instructions say:
Read in instructions 16-27 (`IN   16(16)`)
Wait until they are read in (`JBUS 1(16)`)
Set A to 4 (`ENTA 4`)
Set AX to A times 25 (`MUL  27(0:2)`) (multiply by the A-field of word 27)
Store X (which is now 100) to the A-field of location 12 (`STX  12(0:2)`)
Set A to 3075 (`ENTA 3075`)
(More accurately, set A to 48m+3,
where m is the number of distinct values of a byte.)
Set AX to A times 19 (`MUL 22(4:4)`) (multiply by the F-field of word 22)
Store X mod 64 (or max_byte+1, rather) (which is now 57)
to the C-field of location 16 (`STX  16(5:5)`),
thus transforming the instruction there into `CMP1 12(0:2)`
Store 57 to the C-field of location 24 (`STX  24(5:5)`),
transforming that instruction as well into `CMP1 12(0:2)`.

We are now finished with the self-modifying code
and can actually do the real work.
Remaining instructions look like this:

```
| Loc |    A |  I |  F |  C | Instruction      |
|-----|------|----|----|----|------------------|
|   9 |    1 |  0 | 18 |  9 | LD1  1(2:2)      |
|  10 | 2992 | 29 | 34 |  0 | NOP  2992,29(34) |
|  11 |    0 |  1 |  2 | 48 | ENTA 0,1         |
|  12 |  100 | 44 |  1 |  5 | CHAR 100,44      |
|  13 |   27 |  1 |  5 | 33 | STZ  27,1(0:5)   |
|  14 |   27 |  1 | 29 | 31 | STX  27,1(3:5)   |
|  15 |    0 |  1 |  1 |  7 | MOVE 0,1(1)      |
|  16 |   12 |  0 |  2 | 57 | CMP1 12(0:2)     |
|  17 |   11 |  0 |  9 | 39 | JLE  11          |
|  18 |   27 |  1 |  5 | 33 | STZ  27,1(0:5)   |
|  19 |    0 |  1 | 27 |  7 | MOVE 0,1(27)     |
|  20 |    1 |  1 | 11 |  7 | MOVE 1,1(11)     |
|  21 |   11 |  0 | 27 |  9 | LD1  11(3:3)     |
|  22 |   27 |  1 | 19 | 37 | OUT  27,1(19)    |
|  23 |    0 |  1 | 14 |  7 | MOVE 0,1(14)     |
|  24 |   12 |  0 |  2 | 57 | CMP1 12(0:2)     |
|  25 |   22 |  0 |  4 | 39 | JL   22          |
|  26 |   26 |  0 | 19 | 34 | JBUS 26(19)      |
|  27 |   25 | 12 |  2 |  5 | HLT  25,12       |
```

We now load register I1 with 1 (`LD1  1(2:2)`),
do a no-op (`NOP  2992,29(34)`)
(this no-op exists because character 10 isn't
printable normally, so we have to adjust things a bit),
and repeatedly:
Copy register I1 into register A (`ENTA 0,1`)
Turn A into characters in AX (`CHAR 100,44`)
Clear out location 27+I1 (`STZ  27,1(0:5)`)
Put the last three digits from X into that spot (`STX  27,1(3:5)`)
Increment register I1 (`MOVE 0,1(1)`)
Compare I1 against 100 (`CMP1 12(0:2)`)
Jump back to the copying unless the answer is ‘greater’ (`JLE 11`)

I1 is now 101.
Now we clear out location 128 (`STZ  27,1(0:5)`),
increase I1 by 27 (`MOVE 0,1(27)`),
copy location 128 to location 129, 129 to 130, and so on (in that order!)
up to 11 copies (`MOVE 1,1(11)`)

Now we reset I1 to 1 (`LD1  11(3:3)`),
type out 14 words starting from location 27+I1 (`OUT  27,1(19)`),
increase I1 by 14 (`MOVE 0,1(14)`),
compare it to 100 (`CMP1 12(0:2)`),
jump back to the typing if it's smaller (`JL   22`),
wait until we are finished typing (`JBUS 26(19)`),
and stop (`HLT  25,12`).

`CHAR` and `HLT` ignore their arguments in A and I,
which is why we can ignore the nonexistence of I12 and I29.
(This might cause a segfault on some implementations
and a premature stop on others, though.)
`NOP` ignores all its arguments.
(These statements are true for [my implementation](https://github.com/NoLongerBreathedIn/MIX).)

Comment: Is there a reason that this is third time that you have posted this?

Comment: Logic errors. Several bugs I spotted while writing up an explanation.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise that it had even changed

Comment: To clarify, I edited it a few times, then deleted and reposted, then repeat. If you look at the original post, there are a few changes from the most recent version of that. (For example, the second line starts " N C2" in that version, but " K B2" here.)

Answer (score 1):

## [TorqueScript](https://github.com/GarageGames/Torque3D/tree/development), 90 bytes, safe

```
function base(%a){if(%a<50){echo(%a*2+1@" "@%a*2+2);schedule(0,0,base,%a++);}}$editors1();
```

Outputs two numbers per line separated by a space.

Un-golfed:

```
function base(%a) {
   if (%a < 50) {
      echo(%a * 2 + 1 @ " " @ %a * 2 + 2);
      schedule(0, 0, base, %a ++);
   }
}
$editors1();
```

So what does this do? It defines a function named `base`, then it calls `$editors1();`. `$editors1` happens to be conveniently set to the value `"base"` by the Full Template's default scripts so the call `$editors1();` is resolved to `base();` with `%a = ""` because undefined arguments are initialized to empty string.

`base` itself is a simple recursive function with 2 parts:

```
echo(%a * 2 + 1 @ " " @ %a * 2 + 2);
```

Prints the concatenation of `(%a * 2 + 1)`, `" "`, and `%a * 2 + 2`.

```
schedule(0, 0, base, %a ++);
```

Schedules an event to run the base function in 0ms with an input value of `%a ++`, which happens to be `%a + 1` due to TorqueScript's postfix `++` being applied before the value of `%a` is copied. So this will recursively (through events so it won't overflow the stack) call `base` with increasing values of `%a`.

```
if (%a < 50) {
```

Will stop the recursion once `%a` reaches 50.

---

I haven't seen anyone mention TorqueScript on here yet. It has a bunch of weird quirks that might make interesting code challenges.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 10 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/233393#233393) by Dude and exedrag

```
{1+x}'!"d"
```

Have fun again!

Outputs space-separated.

It has to be oK - other implementations throw a typeerror because characters and integers aren't considered the same.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233393/66833)

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing That was quick.

Comment: Dang it caird you ninjad me

Comment: who is exedrag?

Answer (score 1):

## [MineFriff](https://github.com/lyxal/minefriff), 36 bytes, [Cracked by exedraj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233396/100664)

```
0,        v
>I:a,:*=?#v;
^o,Cao:+,1<
```

It's obviously 2d - right?

Outputs integers separated by newlines.

### Explanation

The basic code that is run is:

```
0, 1,+:oaC,oI:a,:*=?#
```

```
0,                    { Push 0 }
                      { Enter the loop }
   1,+                { Add 1 to ToS }
      :o              { Output ToS as a number without popping }
        aC,o          { Output a newline as a character }
            :         { Duplicate }
             Ia,      { Push 10 as a number }
                :*    { Square it }
                  =?# { If it's equal, don't skip the next instruction, which is a trampoline skipping the `v` to continue the loop, so the `;` gets executed, halting the program.}
```

Comment: [obviously it is indeed 2d](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233396/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Factor), 53 bytes, safe

```
39410751325974217594763149909395167718097095908551781
```

Output as characters.

This huge number factorises to \$37*73*89*113*113*167*191*191*191*191*191*239*331*367*367*491*499*617*619*643*673*701\$.
Modulo 11, these  are \$4*7*1*3*3*2*4*4*4*4*4*8*1*4*4*7*4*1*3*5*2*8\$, which map to the following BF:

```
-[>++<-----]>--[->+.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pOW9tGFwRi7XR1o3XttPVsYv//BwA)

[Convert it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/NboJAEL7PU4yahhpt3QHWZWLpQ/RqPGDY6iZC6QAxPj0dPBA6l/ny/cyP9OfHMACs8EsRNvJzkaIC8b99EI9RI6HyEUDpv7GTom5vRedf675aA2qJbzHH5fKAQXt8wLYTBZH5/Ni8vW@Pp@hpu1/DzaOmcJEjPan/9IvmVTKTNFbAzdzt63LCY2aXY5iI8RB16/pj0GlEJ5hnVIYRAzR9184@STgl4ywlsWWXxuQsp26fUMpsOGFLe@coM@wMWzaZteQyWg/DHw)

#### Explanation (of the BF)

```
-[>++<-----]>--        # Put 100 into a cell (stolen from esolangs)
               [-    ] # While decrementing that gives a nonzero value
                 >+.<  # Increment the cell next to it and print it.
```

This prints the characters with ordinals 0-100.

Comment: only numbers?001001101101011000110000100011010101010101000011010110100

Comment: What's the output format?

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing Edited.

Answer (score 1):

## 51AC8 5 bytes (yes again) cracked by emanresu A

```
100rJ
```

Outputs numbers separated by newlines.

This took some time.

Comment: 51ac8 again - WHY???

Answer (score 1):

## evil, 200 bytes, [Cracked by emanresu A](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59119806#59119806)

```
awawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawaw
```

Prints ASCII chars from 0x01 to 0x65 without any whitespace separating the characters.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 349 bytes, cracked by Lynn

```
aeaaeeaeaaeeaeaaeaeaeeaeaae
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100"
aeaeaeaeaeaeeahaaeaeaeaeaae
```

I posted this months ago and forgot about it, so I'm accepting Lynn's crack.
This does work in GolfScript but intended ROOP.

### Why?

This looks like evil, but it's not. If you look closely at the last line, you can see a `h`. ROOP sees it like this:

```
"1 2 3 ..."  # Save 1-100 separated by spaces
h  # Print that string out
```

Comment: @SjoerdPennings Nope, not Foo or evil.

Comment: If you haven't specified the output format, anything is valid, so this has been cracked in Foo.

Comment: @emanresuA When I try it in Foo on TIO it up to 87 and then prints a 8.

Comment: I guess I'm late, but this prints `1 2 3 … 100` in GolfScript.

Comment: @Lynn Not intended, but whatever

Comment: This solution *does* work in Foo, at least according to the spec, but the interpreter on TIO has a bug that makes it so that no string longer than 255 characters can be printed.

Answer (score 1):

## 446 bytes, cracked by pxeger

```
some junk

print "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100"

++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
more junk
// Filename is $$
```

This was intended to by Mouse-2002. Explanation coming soon.

Comment: [This works in Zsh](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZFBThxBDEWVbZ_iCbFD3ZRdZZctjXqZSyAWWRBlkjBEDGxylWyQENfIQTgNNdB8yVXfJX2X7f_v-e_xx9PTy-PD9zlev_w_3t3e8PPx8Gua_tzvDw-cCUqlYTidIJGCCKJIRRpiiCMdCSTRgg6NohVtqKGOdjTQpBaqUEfJSm1Uozq1U4OatEITmtLGj41mNKd1WtASK5hgilVsNGSYYx0LLPGCC654xRs--nW844EnvdCFrvRKb3Sjj3E6PehJFEIIJSrRCCOcGNMGkWQhhVSyko000slOjmWctlHOpuliw9X6eZ7IR-wG5ut1sHVe14ur3fUpXZd1nudl0y0nsozH3bzs3vn8ju0aZCiXUW-Zbu_uN4suL_m6_31z-DY82x85P_-wcXPz09U3)

Comment: @pxeger Welp, not intended, but ok

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 14 bytes, cracked by Mayube

```
#K1KHZRAS
1ò#d
```

Outputs 1-100 separated by commas.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237887/44998)

Answer (score 1):

## brainfuck, cracked by [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)

```
START
TAKE x AS -1
INC x REM Haha
WHILE [x > 0 AND x++ < 100 AND x---- AND -1 IS TRUE] {  REM (Post/pre)fix operator hacks 
 IF x > 0 {
  PRINT x--
 }
 WHILE [x - 1 > 4 AND x + 4 .< 5] {
  NOTHING
 }
}
BYE
```

This theoretically should be hard.
Outputs 0x00-0x68 in characters.

Comment: Not Vyxal, not Dinoux, almost certainly nothing 2d... yet I feel like this is an esolang

Comment: [Cracked](https://tio.run/##PY1NC4JAFEX38yvushBLoXYSWE05VJPoRES4mERRhBQ1GBB/u/kRvdV5cO@5r1Km7/gTZl3nC9sTRNgnCgXbh24Sxnc9e/QCRyaS3B12pngqbGDA5nsoTYMF0/h9en8j6SaYD@HdaIAGo2Dm5lW9LMpoHqcKeRGVss5LJDLMKhCwAyZtQwDXY1wMOoKW4L@qw@wjq2kLWk8LC@tgrPCrcBg/DoWWbB@0674), maybe don't ask for [golfing tips](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59824719#59824719) if you don't want people to guess easily

Answer (score 1):

## BrainFuck+, I don't care how many bytes, cracked

```
d#a#m#n#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#+-+#[l#o#l#:-)#cmd+v-]#a[0a]#a[0a]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Deadfish, X bytes, cracked

```
ibbfibbfsdbfsibfbffsfbfbi
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
DONE... THIS IS ALL I HAVE TO SAY... 
Oh do!
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/247376#247376)

Answer (score 1):

## MarioLANG, 2022 bytes, Cracked

```
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
# 2022 bytes for 2022!
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/247432#247432)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 143 bytes, [cracked by emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247467/92689)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e001 2200 875d 0018 8802 a848 1ea2 618e  .."..].....H..a.
00000010: ba58 e8d8 b9db 6604 e1a3 f1a8 dbcc 8053  .X....f........S
00000020: 0835 e444 539b a0f4 0369 0d1d a219 f0b5  .5.DS....i......
00000030: 2178 ae46 89df b43b 9f4a 6e6d dcde 8ec4  !x.F...;.Jnm....
00000040: e2fe 95dc e75e dbfb f737 1dc2 aa77 8c3c  .....^...7...w.<
00000050: 04d4 fae0 1991 c8ba 7a0a ed70 4a78 76ab  ........z..pJxv.
00000060: 7cd9 839d 35f6 2730 8893 ecd3 89b1 350b  |...5.'0......5.
00000070: 7425 b77c 630d 0b2e 73f3 4fb3 93d8 ba29  t%.|c...s.O....)
00000080: 8e07 d6f4 7549 fadc 41a5 3d36 8a00 00    ....uI..A.=6...
```

[Decompress the hexdump online!](https://tio.run/##TZJLa1VBEIT3/opSEHFhMzM9jx69LgQNmk0W2WSj0PNCF4qYqJeQ/37twz0BizOL4VAf3VVzf/v1dOp6h8Phw9UFHnA8Drz69cTteo3pnEcIzkFKGrCbQMQFqESBnxqQvUyA6BnRZ9r0kUhpZ3hjNE2CKUPQ6mjI2UVMr4zlVTBa7xCX2Bg3m33RruudEYzhhBNmjBGJa4O6FeE4V7jhBzT4iuVaMkai99eb@9sZsjPYGMEXgc6YIXUstMgNdUVFnnlg9DEhs0fg6ZEuzPqGLn98/48RtzzCmqhpdMySpg2/GlbhAj@6haKlQDr3LQ/TFzvFzl867Iy07RJHxNLp4Gv16NIURZ1ijuIQ1aYsWdvOMN0T/bw8/nmcIxuj9FEhXAc4rYxQ2BqSyph9sO3XvP1wxngwf6IX7kxKj4yyMWJIaKV0ZHbWbQsThRcjrsaovBWmoQJ3z@mhm/uWrjbIy50hxpDpCka2NkqK1oFaMtFrAg@2nNUejn047/L7E9E7epu3SO29nU7/AA)

Language is on TIO.

Comment: Took one look at this and... [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155019/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-robbers/247467#247467)

Comment: @emanresuA lmao I honestly didn't think it would be that easy

Comment: The hexdump was a dead giveaway

Answer (score 1):

## [Banana Golf](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Banana_Golf), 34 Bytes, safe

```
X [print(_) for _ in range(1,101)]
```

Comment: Is this Python?

Comment: @noodleman no, this is using the “execute python” instruction of the language.

Comment: Is this programming language listed on Try It Online, esolangs.org, Rosetta Code, or have an English Wikipedia article? (these are the requirements for a programming language to be used in this challenge)

Comment: @noodleman yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 70 bytes, safe

```
>1+v< /  >    \
(!_++)t(!_++^!#
@!d_+)        /
v""<> /
> ^>^
~~<^\=~~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/fzlC7zEZBX0HBTgEIYrg0FOO1tTVLwFScojKXg2JKvLamAhToc5UpKdnYAWk7hTi7OK66Opu4GNu6uv//AQ)

How is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way), 11 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155045) by [ovs](/u/64121)

```
print-ZL¡;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83Mya7ULU@s/P@/oCgzr0Q3yufQQuv//wE)

Have fun!

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155045/64121)

Answer (score 0):

## [Huginn](https://codestation.org/?h-action=menu-project&menu=submenu-project&page=&project=huginn), 54 + 9 (`--no-argv`) = 63 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155067/12012) by Dennis

```
main(){i=1;while(i<101){print("{} ".format(i));i+=1;}}
```

Outputs each number in decimal. These are separated by a space.

Comment: If anyone cracks it, feel free to edit in, I'll most likely be sleeping :P

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155067/12012) The `--no-argv` is a dead giveaway.

Comment: @Dennis Actually it didn't even need to be mentioned at all in the post, per the new consensus. ;-)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer *Flags may be used, but you must reveal what flags are used in your answer.*

Answer (score 0):

## Symbolic Python, 242 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155212/61563) by user202729

```
_=+([]==[]),
__('_+=-~_[~([]>[])],;'*-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~([]==[]))
```

Comment: Is the count of `-~` correct?

Comment: @tsh yep ------

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155212/69850)

Answer (score 0):

## [Prelude](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), 38 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155339/41024) by [jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25180/jimmy23013)

```
91+ v+   vv++ (1-v!)
   ^  ^^+    0 1+
```

Output is in raw chars 0x01-0x64.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155339/25180). It's Prelude.

Comment: @jimmy23013 yeah this wasn't hard at all

Answer (score 0):

## Pain-Flak, 241 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155299/31957) by [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155299/31957)

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gB35DCUt)

```
‮>‭<)‮‭‮))‮‭)‮)‮‭)‮)‭‮(‮)‭(‮‮)‭(‮‮(‭}{‭(‮}‮‭{(‭}‮{‭‮)(‭(‮}‮‭{(‮‭}‮{‭(‮}‭‮))‭}‮‮{‮‭(]‭)‮‮(‭‮[‮(‮‮‮‭{)‭(}‭{‮}‭‮><‭{‮‮
```

Everyone knows what I program in??

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155299/71256). It looks like your Pastebin has a lot of unprintables, was this intened?

Comment: @H.PWiz AFAICT Christopher didn't want people to know he used the RLM in his answer, nor did he want to fix it using an LRM, so he outsourced it to pastebin. (Just a guess tho)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien no if it has unprintables you have to pastebin

Comment: @Christopher right but that doesn't stop you from posting code :P

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 37 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155377/77483) by [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61405/steadybox)

```
n=1;while(n<101){console.log(n);n++;}
```

Pretty easy... but... ehhh...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155377/61405)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 301 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155394/9486) by Silvio Mayolo

```
Print["1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 "]
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155394/9486).

Comment: This also works in Foo. I was just about to post a crack.

Comment: @totallyhuman actually intended to be [Mathics](https://tio.run/##FZC7UUNRFANb2XEF5//pgpwhYEhwgAPj/h@XAiTt6ufz9X3/@r2ut@f98Xq/KYYTJEUzLCqoooY6GmiihTY66GKCnYxhjgWWWGGNDba44IqfSscDT7zwxgdfQggljDiLQSRRRBNDLCmkkkY6eYCSLLLJIZcSSimjnArq8BbV1FBLC6200U4HnfTRaXroZYRRxhhngkmmmGM7zLLCKmuss8EmW2yz54z/N4Tbx3X9AQ), didn't realize mathematia had a print[] function

Comment: I had to verify it myself; never personally had cause to do a straight print in Mathematica, but alas it does.

Comment: @tfbninja Mathics is just a FOSS version of Mathematica.

Comment: @totallyhuman good to know!

Comment: @MDXF And we thought there wouldn't be any Foo polyglots this time around!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript/[JSFuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/JSFuck), 38541 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155406/75797) by [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61405/steadybox)

If this remains uncracked for seven days, I am seriously going to cry.

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]])+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+[+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]))+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]))+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZTTDZBDM)'s a pastebin link, for easier copy-and-pasting.
(And no, I did not write all of the code manually.)

The program outputs normally by printing to the language's equivalent of STDOUT

This program, when un-JSFuck-ified, turns into `(function(){for(var i = 0; i < 101; i++){console.log(i)}})()`. Not too crazy looking now, is it?

I could have made it worse/longer by making it un-runnable from the console (yes, that is possible, but it could make it extremely clear what the language is), and adding some extra awesomeness to it.

Comment: Not exactly aiming to win, just want to see if anyone can crack it :)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155406/61405)

Answer (score 0):

## Super Stack, 47 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155418/68615) by totallyhuman

```
1 1 if pop dup output 1 add dup 101 swap sub fi
```

Let's see if anyone knows *this* one!

Comment: [This is Super Stack!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155418/68615)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 33 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155481) by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```
print(Vecrev(((x^101-1)/(x-1))'))
```

A very easy one. I don't expect it to last long.

Comment: [This is Pari/GP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155481/59487).

Comment: OK. 27 minutes.

Comment: It lasted 27 minutes because I only saw this 25 minutes ago :P

Answer (score 0):

## [Unfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unfuck), 78 bytes, safe

```
++++(^~)~(~?!)((>+++++<-))(^)>(^~)~(~?!)((>+++++<-))(^)>(^~)~(~?!)((>+.<-))(^)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cubically 6×6×6, 14 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156039/61563) by H.PWiz

```
[+1[+7]35@]100
```

Per [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13660/61563) meta post, Cubically with the `-6` flag counts as a completely different language (Cubically 6x6x6) than with the `-5` flag (Cubically 5x5x5), which is again different from the default language (Cubically 3x3x3).

Cubically 6x6x6 does not have its own wrapper on TIO (i.e. there is no [tio.run/#cubically-6x6x6](https://tio.run/#cubically-6x6x6)), but the language itself is on TIO; it simply requires the `-6` flag. I believe this is valid due to the linked meta post and the fact that the language is on TIO, but simply needs more to run than just one of the `/srv/wrappers` scripts.

Dennis' [8cc answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155533/61563) acts similarly; the language is on TIO, but it requires multiple commands and command-line flags, none of which were specified in the answer.

Comment: I'm watching :)

Comment: It takes less than 6 seconds to crack once you find the right language.

Comment: What's the output format?

Comment: @JoKing Raw bytes.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156039/71256). This is Cubically -6

Comment: This is invalid because you didn't specify the command line flags. (not that it matters now)

Comment: @quartata edited why I think it's valid in.

Comment: @MDXF The difference is that ELVM doesn't actually need any additional commands outside of TIO, whereas this does. This requires additional command line options everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

## zsh, 288 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155522/56721) by [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)

```
`#echo#`:`#a:G.Array.Integer#`
;: PVar$i: G.Integer :;
;: `#FOR#:i=0:!i>a.Length:i+=1` :;
;: :: IO.Out.PrintInt: a.$i :: :;
;: `#ENDFOR#` :;
`#endecho#`
`#main#`:`#a:G.Array.Array.Char#`
;: PVar$i: G.Integer :;
;: PVar$j: G.Integer :;
:; i=1 ;:
:; j=100 ;:
:; echo {$i..$j} ;:
`#endmain#`
```

Probably won't last long, but eh.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155522/31957)

Answer (score 0):

## QML, 215 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155544/68615) by totallyhuman

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 100
        delegate: Text { text: index + 1 }
    }
}
```

Outputs 1-100 in text with every number on it's own line. The whole UI is a vertical flickable application.

Well done to @totallyhuman who cracked this.

This is, indeed, QML. The model property usually is connected to a data source providing data for a list (as per doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#model-prop). However, it can also point to a Javascript array, or, hold a single number. When it's the later, it functions like a "Repeater" and the delegate element is repeated n times.

Comment: [This is QML.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155544/68615)

Answer (score 0):

## Windows Batch file, 320 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155549/61563) by MD XF

```
set S=1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90;91;92;93;94;95;96;97;98;99;100
echo %S:;= & echo %
```

Output: the numbers 1-100 with each number (in plain text) on it's own line

Well done @md-xf who cracked this. It is a Windows Batch file. The trick was an echo expansion causing the following to be generated:

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
...
```

Comment: [This is Batch.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155549/61563)

Answer (score 0):

## [ExtraC](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/extrac), 68 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155770) by [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob)

```octave
for(int i be 1 AND not(i greater 100)AND increment i)do
print(i)
end
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155770/55934)

Answer (score 0):

## [rk-lang](https://github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang), 44 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156040/12012) by Dennis

```
int $1
while $1 < 100 do
  print: ++ $1
done
```

Requires the `-e` flag. Outputs decimals separated by spaces with a trailing space.

Comment: [This is rk.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156040/12012)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 133 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155996/12012) by Dennis

Easy one : (numbers are separated by pipe symbol)

```
for 
(
 putenv("num=".(int)(bool)NO); 
 getenv ("num") <= 100; 
 putenv("num=". (getenv("num") + 1))
)
 printf("%d|", getenv("num"));
```

Catch :

> 1. No PHP variables in FOR loop
> 2. Code is made to be C-like syntax
> 3. Objective-C has macro named [NO](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/no) which is 0.
> 4. PHP has strange syntax construct "*define without define*" :
>     if
>      interpreter finds unqualified token in code - it assumes that this token is an undefined constant and because it's value is unknown -
>      value is taken from token name converted to a string constant. That's
>      why NO get's interpreted as `'NO'` and because all non-empty strings
>      in PHP means `true` when converted to boolean - integer 1 is saved
>      into environment variable in FOR loop initialization part. Fortunately
>      this PHP behavior is now [a deprecated feature](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php)
> 5. The only thing which truly reaveals that it is PHP code snippet - string concatenation operator `.` If PHP would have function
>      `strcat()` like C does - hiding dot from the reader would make code
>      more inseparable from a C syntax.

Comment: [This is PHP.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155996/12012)

Answer (score 0):

## Attache, 15 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156097/61563) by totallyhuman

```
Print!V[1..100]
```

I like this language.

Comment: [This is Attache.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156097/68615)

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[1,...,100]
+.+.+.+.+.+.+./*
r=1
t(x)=(x,x)
n=1
*/for(i=0;i<100;i++){console.log(i+1)}
print(l)
i=1
p=1
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
```

What a mess. Just like me.

Specifying the output format would give it away. That's a hint.

Comment: You realise if you don't specify the format, anything's valid...

Comment: [This is Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/enaxakzncf). Please specify your output formats next time if this was unintended.

Answer (score 0):

## 51AC8, 7 bytes,  [Cracked by emanresu A](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58896290#58896290)

```
100r[t]
```

This was fun.

Outputs numbers as decimals separated by newlines.

Comment: This is [51ac8](https://pygamer0.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&header=&code=100r%5Bt%5D&footer=&stdin=)

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly, 3 bytes, [cracked by exedraj](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58896332#58896332)

```
³RY
```

Outputs numbers separated by newlines.

Comment: this is jelly: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5qDI//8B "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## ><>, 25 bytes, [Cracked by emanresu A](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59119739#59119739)

```
0>1+:aa*1+=v
 ^ oan:;?  <
```

Outputs numbers separated by newlines. I learnt a new language :).

Should be fairly easy to crack.

Answer (score 0):

## Desmos, 9 bytes, cracked obviously

```
[1...100]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 147 bytes, safe

```lisp
(print "")"e"(print ")ʁ(")(print ")1(")(print ")ɑ(")(print ")e(")(print ")o(")(print ")e(")(print ")1(")(print ")s(")(print ")ø(")(print ")ɒ(")
```

Outputs newline-separated decimal numbers to STDOUT.

#### Explanation

This abuses how matching parentheses `()` are comments in IPEL to make mostly incomprehensible Lisp code.

```
"e"ʁ1ɑeoe1søɒ (prints 1-100 inclusive in decimal separated by newlines)
"e"           (literal string "e")
   ʁ          (ord)
    1         (literal int 1)
     ɑ        (begin loop: from 1 to ord["e"])
      e       (loop counter)
       o      (pop and println)
        e1sø  (increment loop counter)
            ɒ (if loop counter <= ord["e"], jump back to ɑ. else exit)
```

Comment: What's the output format?

Comment: @emanresuA newline-separated decimal numbers

Answer (score 0):

## Vyxal, 6 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/262316?noredirect=1#comment575475_262316) by [noodle man](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108687/noodle-man)

```
100�
```

Uses SBCS encoding.
Two unprintables at the start with hex codes `1C 1E`.

Comment: Please give a hexdump of the program (just list the encoded hex codes)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is [Vyxal `Þ∞100Ẏ`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInjEwMOG6jiIsIiIsIiJd) but I can't be sure until you post the dump

Comment: @noodleman well done, you cracked it

Answer (score 0):

## GolfScript, 37 bytes (safe)

```
print foreach n in range(100), n * 1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v6AoM69EIS2/KDUxOUMhTyEzT6EoMS89VcPQwEBTByigpWBo/f8/AA)

Output separated by newlines, preceded by a line containing `100`.

I thought this would be pretty obvious but I guess not that many people on this site still know GolfScript.