# Add a hidden language to a polyglot

Tags: code-challenge, cops-and-robbers, polyglot, answer-chaining, obfuscation

[Inspired/mostly copied but I don't think it's a dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171884/overlapping-polyglots). [Also Inspired](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot).

In this challenge, you will create polyglots that include all languages from previous answers, *and* another language which you won't share and others must guess.

The first language prints 1, the second prints 2, etcetera.

For example, if the first answer was this:

```py
print(1)
```

You could crack it as Python 3 (or numerous other languages), then you could write another answer that prints 2 in, say, Befunge-93:

```py
2<3 and print(1)#@.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38jGWCExL0WhoCgzr0TDUFPZQc/o/38A)

Then, the next person to answer would first have to figure out that this was written in Befunge-93 before posting an answer that printed 1 in Python 3, 2 in Befunge-93 and 3 in a language of their choice. Feel free to share a crack if you don't want to post an answer.

To keep this challenge fluid, you must reveal your language if it has been uncracked for a week, at which point anyone can post another answer.

Please, be nice and try to post answers in languages which can be easily polyglotted.

## Rules

- The criteria for a valid programming language are the same as those of [The Programming Language Quiz, Mark II - Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-):

  > - It has [an English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_programming_languages), [an esolangs article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) or [a Rosetta Code article](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Languages) at the time this challenge was posted, or is on [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#) (or [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com)). Having an interpreter linked in any of these pages makes that interpreter completely legal.
  > - It must satisfy our rules on [what constitutes a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/8478).
  > - It must have a free interpreter (as in beer). Free here means that anyone can use the program without having to pay to do so.
- Each answer must run in less than a minute on a reasonable PC.
- Different versions of a language / languages with different flags / whatever are valid as long as you can get them to behave differently. However, flags must be revealed to avoid obscure combinations.
- Cracking a submission consists of finding *any* programming language that prints the correct result, not just the intended one. If a submission is run in any language that was not declared or found to work, there are no requirements to do anything, and future answers must be valid in that language.

### I/O clarifications

The program must output a decimal integer, optionally as a float with a `.0` afterwards. Any reasonable amount of leading/trailing whitespace is acceptable, as is stuff unavoidably printed by the interpreter, or formatting for the integer. Anything else is not.

Ending with an error is allowed as long as that error is printed to stderr, and not standard output - it can't be printed with the number.

### Scoring

The person with the most answers wins.

[A chatroom's been created for this challenge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136684/add-a-hidden-language-to-a-polyglot).

Answer (score 9):

## 9. Deadfish~, 116 bytes, cracked by pxeger

The previous answer was in [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

```
4+0#  @ iiiiiiiiio
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10)#+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#  ^
5_3
```

Try it online in:

- [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/30TbQFlBwUEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDTSVtUEgQAFCkwT0uAzAFsVxmcYb//8PAA)
- [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99E20BZQcFBIRMG8rkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA00lbVBIEABQpME9LgMwBbFcZnGG///DwA)
- [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbjVfMyIsIiIsIiJd)
- [Radvylf Should Not Be Allowed To Write Programming Languages](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbjVfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)
- [Headass](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbjVfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)
- [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30TbQFlBwUEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDTSVtUEgQAFCkwT0uAzAFsVxmcYDbQUA)
- [brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fRNtAWUHBQSETBvK5Cooy80o0LHQ1jLRMdY01tTUM9Y00tQwNNJW1QSBAAUKTBPS4DMAWxXGZxhv//w8A)
- [Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99E20BZQcFBIRMG8rkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA00lbVBIEABQpME9LgMwBbFcZnGG///DwA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer! I've edited in a byte count, and links to run your program online in all the languages revealed so far.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Runic Enchantments was indeed the intended answer, so well done! :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice! I accidently found that just scrolling through TIO! I was shocked! Thought it was ><> or something at first.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248001)

Comment: @pxeger Well done, Deadfish~ was indeed my intended language. I would have obfuscated it more (should've used the 'i' in 'print'!) but I mostly just wanted to crack the Runic Enchantments one.

Answer (score 7):

## 10. FISHQ9+, 137 bytes, cracked by accident

```
4+0#  @ iiiiiiiiio
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+8-4*(2147483647*2%3))#+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#  ^
5_3
```

The previous answer works in [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f/fRNtAWUHBQSETBvK5Cooy80o0LHQ1jLRMdY01tTUM9Y00tQwNNJW1QSBAAUKTBPS4DMAWxXGZxhv//w8A).

Try it online in:

- [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/30TbQFlBwUEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDbQtdE20NIwMTcxNLIzNTMy1jFSNNTWVtUEgQAFCkwT0uAzAtsdxmcYb//8PAA)
- [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99E20BZQcFBIRMG8rkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA20LXRNtDSMDE3MTSyMzUzMtYxUjTU1lbVBIEABQpME9LgMwLbHcZnGG///DwA)
- [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCs4LTQqKDIxNDc0ODM2NDcqMiUzKSkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbjVfMyIsIiIsIiJd)
- [Radvylf Should Not Be Allowed To Write Programming Languages](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCs4LTQqKDIxNDc0ODM2NDcqMiUzKSkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbjVfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)
- [Headass](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCs4LTQqKDIxNDc0ODM2NDcqMiUzKSkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbjVfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)
- [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30TbQFlBwUEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDbQtdE20NIwMTcxNLIzNTMy1jFSNNTWVtUEgQAFCkwT0uAzAtsdxmcYDnQIA)
- [Brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fRNtAWUHBQSETBvK5Cooy80o0LHQ1jLRMdY01tTUM9Y00tQwNtC10TbQ0jAxNzE0sjM1MzLWMVI01NZW1QSBAAUKTBPS4DMC2x3GZxhv//w8A)
- [Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99E20BZQcFBIRMG8rkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA20LXRNtDSMDE3MTSyMzUzMtYxUjTU1lbVBIEABQpME9LgMwLbHcZnGG///DwA)
- [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f/fRNtAWUHBQSETBvK5Cooy80o0LHQ1jLRMdY01tTUM9Y00tQwNtC10TbQ0jAxNzE0sjM1MzLWMVI01NZW1QSBAAUKTBPS4DMC2x3GZxhv//w8A)

---

My intended crack was Crystal before [version 0.31.0](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/releases/tag/0.31.0), which is when Crystal got integer overflow checking by default.

This also works with the version of Crystal on TIO, with `-D disable_overflow`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy6qLC5JzPn/30TbQFlBwUEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDbQtdE20NIwMTcxNLIzNTMy1jFSNNTWVtUEgQAFCkwT0uAzAtsdxmcYb////LzktJzG9@L@uy/@UzOLEpJzU@Pyy1KK0nPxyAA), but I didn't want to reveal that flag (which the rules would have required), so I chose to use an old version of Crystal instead.

(this flag appears to have been removed entirely in the latest versions of Crystal: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708uaiyuCQxZ1e0kq6Lko6CUkpmcWJSTmp8fllqUVpOfrlS7IKlpSVpuhY3O020DZQVFBwUMmEgn6ugKDOvRMNCV8NIy1TXWFNbw1DfSFPL0EDbQtdES8PI0MTcxMLYzMRcy0jVWFNTWRsEAhQgNElAj8sAbHscl2m8McRBUHctgNIA))

Comment: Wow that's some clever/cursed operator precedence. I suspect we're looking for a lang with 32-bit ints and `print`, and numbers with underscores obviously. Of course, it could just be a red herring...

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248046/100664)

Comment: Yes, my username is accident lol

Answer (score 7):

## 11. Neutrino, 144 bytes

```
4+0#  @ iiiiiiiiio
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+8-4*(2147483647*2%3))#+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#  ^
-1*-10+4_3
```

Try it online in [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/30TbQFlBwUEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDbQtdE20NIwMTcxNLIzNTMy1jFSNNTWVtUEgQAFCkwT0uAzAtsdx6Rpq6QItMIk3/v8fAA), [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99E20BZQcFBIRMG8rkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA20LXRNtDSMDE3MTSyMzUzMtYxUjTU1lbVBIEABQpME9LgMwLbHcekaaukCLTCJN/7/HwA), [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCs4LTQqKDIxNDc0ODM2NDcqMiUzKSkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbi0xKi0xMCs0XzMiLCIiLCIiXQ==), [rSNBATWPL](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCs4LTQqKDIxNDc0ODM2NDcqMiUzKSkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbi0xKi0xMCs0XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==), [Headass](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCs4LTQqKDIxNDc0ODM2NDcqMiUzKSkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbi0xKi0xMCs0XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==), [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30TbQFlBwUEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDbQtdE20NIwMTcxNLIzNTMy1jFSNNTWVtUEgQAFCkwT0uAzAtsdx6Rpq6QItMIkHuggA), [brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fRNtAWUHBQSETBvK5Cooy80o0LHQ1jLRMdY01tTUM9Y00tQwNtC10TbQ0jAxNzE0sjM1MzLWMVI01NZW1QSBAAUKTBPS4DMC2x3HpGmrpAi0wiTf@/x8A), [Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99E20BZQcFBIRMG8rkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA20LXRNtDSMDE3MTSyMzUzMtYxUjTU1lbVBIEABQpME9LgMwLbHcekaaukCLTCJN/7/HwA), [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f/fRNtAWUHBQSETBvK5Cooy80o0LHQ1jLRMdY01tTUM9Y00tQwNtC10TbQ0jAxNzE0sjM1MzLWMVI01NZW1QSBAAUKTBPS4DMC2x3HpGmrpAi0wiTf@/x8A). [FISHQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJmaXNocTkrIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAIGlpaWlpaWlpaW9cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCs4LTQqKDIxNDc0ODM2NDcqMiUzKSkjKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCMgIF5cbi0xKi0xMCs0XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==). I created this interpreter to make testing easier for others, but it also works with the Kotlin implementation that pxeger's answer works with.

Pxeger's post was (not intentionally) in [FISHQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FISHQ9%2B), using the kotlin interpreter `.jar` file supplied on the esolangs page, run with `java -jar`. When running the REPL and entering the code:

```
######@######## downloads % java -jar FISHQ9P.jar
>> 4+0#  @ iiiiiiiiio
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+8-4*(2147483647*2%3))#+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#  ^
5_310
```

It prints 10 (without a leading newline) after the code. To avoid making testing hell for everyone in future, I will shortly be adding a FISHQ9+ interpreter to DSO.

This works because the `iiiiiiiiio` from answer #9 prints 9, but FISHQ9+ merges HQ9+'s `+` command in which increments it one more time to 10 before printing. Nothing else is printed.

Comment: And they said hq9+ derivatives couldn't be useful..........

Comment: [Cracked](https://tio.run/##y0stLSnKzMv//99E20BZQcFBIRMG8rkKgDIlGha6GkZaprrGmtoahvpGmlqGBtoWuiZaGkaGJuYmFsZmJuZaRqrGmprK2iAQoAChSQJ6XAZg2@O4dA21dIEWmMQb//8PAA), but I'm not gonna post the next answer.

Comment: Ok never mind I posted the next answer.

Answer (score 6):

## 7. brainfuck, Exactly 100 Bytes, [cracked by aiden chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247975/add-a-hidden-language-to-a-polyglot/247999#comment554554_247988) and [continued by Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247999/52210)

The last answer was Python 3.

```
print(8 - (2 * 5 - 3) + (1/2) * 10)#+++++P #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
5_3
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to run in [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7@gKDOvRMNCQVdBw0hBS8EUyDDWVNBW0DDUN9IEChgaaCprg0AAF4QmDehxmcYb//8PAA)

Comment: @Samathingamajig That's been fixed

Comment: [Cracked](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v@/oCgzr0TDQkFXQcNIQUvBFMgw1lTQVtAw1DfSBAoYGmgqa4NAgAKEJg3ocZnGG///DwA), but I'm not going to post the next answer.

Answer (score 5):

## 1. Ruby, 9 bytes, [cracked by caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247977/100664)

```
$><<$$/$$
```

The answer to start things off. Should be fairly easy.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247977/66833)

Answer (score 5):

## 4. rSNBATWPL, 26 bytes

```
print(8 - (2 * 5 - 3))
5_3
```

[The previous answer was in Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIkPjw8JCQvJCRcbjIrM18zIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Comment: Ayy this is rSN isn't it

Answer (score 5):

## 5. [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 34 bytes, cracked by emanresu A

```
print(8 - (2 * 5 - 3))#++++++P
5_3
```

Previous answer was in [Radvylf Should Not Be Allowed To Write Programming Languages](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCJwcmludCg4IC0gKDIgKiA1IC0gMykpXG41XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Thanks emanresu A for adding my language to your web-site :D

Comment: [This is Headass](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCJwcmludCg4IC0gKDIgKiA1IC0gMykpIysrKysrK1BcbjVfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

Answer (score 5):

## 12. [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 170 bytes, cracked by Dingus

```
4+0#a /z@ iiiiiiiiio
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)#!+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#a ^
-1*-10+4_3
```

Try It Online in [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/30TbQDlRQb/KQSETBvK5Cooy80o0LHQ1jLRMdY01tTUM9Y00tQwNtA2xQV2sUFNZURsEAhSUtUkGelwGYHfFcekaaukCLTaJN/7/HwA), [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99E20A5UUG/ykEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDbQNsUFdrFBTWVEbBAIUlLVJBnpcBmB3xXHpGmrpAi02iTf@/x8A), [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI0KzAjYSAvekAgaWlpaWlpaWlpb1xucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpIyErKysrK1AgIysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLlxuMCswI2EgXlxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiJd), [rSNBATWPL](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCI0KzAjYSAvekAgaWlpaWlpaWlpb1xucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpIyErKysrK1AgIysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLlxuMCswI2EgXlxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd), [Headass](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCI0KzAjYSAvekAgaWlpaWlpaWlpb1xucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpIyErKysrK1AgIysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLlxuMCswI2EgXlxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd), [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30TbQDlRQb/KQSETBvK5Cooy80o0LHQ1jLRMdY01tTUM9Y00tQwNtA2xQV2sUFNZURsEAhSUtUkGelwGYHfFcekaaukCLTaJB7oVAA), [Brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fRNtAOVFBv8pBIRMG8rkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA20DbFBXaxQU1lRGwQCFJS1SQZ6XAZgd8Vx6Rpq6QItNok3/v8fAA), [Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99E20A5UUG/ykEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDbQNsUFdrFBTWVEbBAIUlLVJBnpcBmB3xXHpGmrpAi02iTf@/x8A), [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f/fRNtAOVFBv8pBIRMG8rkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA20DbFBXaxQU1lRGwQCFJS1SQZ6XAZgd8Vx6Rpq6QItNok3/v8fAA), [FishHQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJmaXNocTkrIixudWxsLCI0KzAjYSAvekAgaWlpaWlpaWlpb1xucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpIyErKysrK1AgIysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLlxuMCswI2EgXlxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd), [Neutrino](https://tio.run/##y0stLSnKzMv//99E20A5UUG/ykEhEwbyuQqAciUaFroaRlqmusaa2hqG@kaaWoYG2obYoC5WqKmsqA0CAQrK2iQDPS4DsLviuHQNtXSBFpvEG///DwA)

The code is ran under the `-u` flag. Very easy, definitely gonna get cracked within a few minutes.

Comment: I was just about to post #12 lol

Comment: [BitCycle](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/99E20A5UUG/ykEhEwbyuQqKMvNKNCx0NYy0THWNNbU1DPWNNLUMDbQNsUFdrFBTWVEbBAIUlLVJBnpcBmB3xXHpGmrpAi02iTf@//9ffkFJZn5e8X/dUgA "BitCycle – Try It Online")

Comment: @Dingus Yep, that's the intended solution!

Comment: @Seth Good luck, this has been cracked so now you can extend it fairly easily. Join us in [the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136684/add-a-hidden-language-to-a-polyglot) if you need help

Answer (score 4):

## 2. Jelly, 11 bytes, [cracked by Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247978/66833)

```ruby
$><<$$/$$
2
```

The previous answer was written in Ruby:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkZFRV9Fhcvo/38A)

Comment: This is Jelly, I'll post a new one in a min

Comment: @Steffan Missed oppurtunity to use Vyxal, smh my head

Comment: [posted crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247978/92689)

Answer (score 4):

## 8. [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments), 105 bytes, [cracked by 00Her0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248000/52210)

```
4+0#  @
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10)#+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#  ^
5_3
```

Since *@AidenChow* cracks answers without posting a new one, I took the liberty to post the next in line.

1. [Try it online in Ruby.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/30TbQFlBwYGroCgzr0TDQlfDSMtU11hTW8NQ30hTy9BAU1kbBAIUIDRJQI/LAGx6HJdpvPH//wA)
2. [Try it online in Jelly.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99E20BZQcGBq6AoM69Ew0JXw0jLVNdYU1vDUN9IU8vQQFNZGwQCFCA0SUCPywBsehyXabzx//8A)
3. [Try it online in Vyxal.](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI0KzAjICBAXG5wcmludCg4LSgyKjUtMykrKDEvMikqMTApIysrKysrUCAjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuXG4wKzAjICBeXG41XzMiLCIiLCIiXQ==)
4. [Try it online in Radvylf Should Not Be Allowed To Write Programming Languages.](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAXG5wcmludCg4LSgyKjUtMykrKDEvMikqMTApIysrKysrUCAjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuXG4wKzAjICBeXG41XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)
5. [Try it online in Headass.](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCI0KzAjICBAXG5wcmludCg4LSgyKjUtMykrKDEvMikqMTApIysrKysrUCAjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuXG4wKzAjICBeXG41XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)
6. [Try it online in Python 3.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30TbQFlBwYGroCgzr0TDQlfDSMtU11hTW8NQ30hTy9BAU1kbBAIUIDRJQI/LAGx6HJdpPNAqAA)
7. [Try it online in brainfuck.](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fRNtAWUHBgaugKDOvRMNCV8NIy1TXWFNbw1DfSFPL0EBTWRsEAhQgNElAj8sAbHocl2m88f//AA)

Answer (score 4):

## 14. Vanilla TeX (initex), 256 bytes, mostly cracked by emanresu A

```
1#+iiiiiiiiiokh-\catcode`\#=6\font\m=cmr10\m
14#\end;
4+0#a /z@ MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoO
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)#!+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#a ^MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM
-1*-10+4_3
```

This is now available on ATO!

> You can run this on ATO [here](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724JLViRbSSbmZeplLsgqWlJWm6FrcYGQyVtTNhID87QzcmObEkOT8lNSFG2dYsJi0_ryQm1zY5t8jQICaXy9BEOSY1L8Way0TbQDlRQb_KQcE33x8TcRUUZeaVaFjoahhpmeoaa2prGOobaWoZGmgbYoO6WKGmsqI2CAQoKGuTDPS4DMBOjMN0nL-_L5euoZYu0DUm8cZLipOSi6HBsQBKAwA).

Try it online in:

1. [Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31BZOxMG8rMzdGOSE0uS81NSE2KUbc1i0vLzSmJybZNziwwNYnK5DE2UY1LzUqy5TLQNlBMV9KscFHzz/TERV0FRZl6JhoWuhpGWqa6xpraGob6RppahgbYhNqiLFWoqK2qDQICCsjbJQI/LAOzEOEzH@fv7cukaaukCXWMSb/z/PwA)
2. [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99QWTsTBvKzM3RjkhNLkvNTUhNilG3NYtLy80picm2Tc4sMDWJyuQxNlGNS81KsuUy0DZQTFfSrHBR88/0xEVdBUWZeiYaFroaRlqmusaa2hqG@kaaWoYG2ITaoixVqKitqg0CAgrI2yUCPywDsxDhMx/n7@3LpGmrpAl1jEm/8/z8A)
3. [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2gtXFxjYXRjb2RlYFxcIz02XFxmb250XFxtPWNtcjEwXFxtXG4xNCNcXGVuZDtcbjQrMCNhIC96QCBNb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xKSMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCNhIF5Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09PT01cbi0xKi0xMCs0XzMiLCIiLCIiXQ==)
4. [rSNBATWPL](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2gtXFxjYXRjb2RlYFxcIz02XFxmb250XFxtPWNtcjEwXFxtXG4xNCNcXGVuZDtcbjQrMCNhIC96QCBNb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xKSMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCNhIF5Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09PT01cbi0xKi0xMCs0XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)
5. [Heada**](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2gtXFxjYXRjb2RlYFxcIz02XFxmb250XFxtPWNtcjEwXFxtXG4xNCNcXGVuZDtcbjQrMCNhIC96QCBNb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xKSMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCNhIF5Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09PT01cbi0xKi0xMCs0XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)
6. [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/31BZOxMG8rMzdGOSE0uS81NSE2KUbc1i0vLzSmJybZNziwwNYnK5DE2UY1LzUqy5TLQNlBMV9KscFHzz/TERV0FRZl6JhoWuhpGWqa6xpraGob6RppahgbYhNqiLFWoqK2qDQICCsjbJQI/LAOzEOEzH@fv7cukaaukCXWMSDwwBAA)
7. [Brainf***](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fUFk7EwbyszN0Y5ITS5LzU1ITYpRtzWLS8vNKYnJtk3OLDA1icrkMTZRjUvNSrLlMtA2UExX0qxwUfPP9MRFXQVFmXomGha6GkZaprrGmtoahvpGmlqGBtiE2qIsVaioraoNAgIKyNslAj8sA7MQ4TMf5@/ty6Rpq6QJdYxJv/P8/AA)
8. [Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99QWTsTBvKzM3RjkhNLkvNTUhNilG3NYtLy80picm2Tc4sMDWJyuQxNlGNS81KsuUy0DZQTFfSrHBR88/0xEVdBUWZeiYaFroaRlqmusaa2hqG@kaaWoYG2ITaoixVqKitqg0CAgrI2yUCPywDsxDhMx/n7@3LpGmrpAl1jEm/8/z8A)
9. [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##lY5LCsIwFAD3OUUkmzbh2bx@RJCCFyj1AEENSUqLNJHalZePH3DVbpyZA4x12nbDo4cYkYnhR7j1oIyeTbDuqli9U13wsxprM04o1UiwZMp5eyClkEzT7HmkTWiXkfs0@DnZQ5LzCopUJJjlKUcpcE1YNWUb8eFEmfibLZHfxfNyrm0bAsjhfVNeihhf)
10. [FISHQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJmaXNocTkrIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2gtXFxjYXRjb2RlYFxcIz02XFxmb250XFxtPWNtcjEwXFxtXG4xNCNcXGVuZDtcbjQrMCNhIC96QCBNb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09cbnByaW50KDgtKDIqNS0zKSsoMS8yKSoxMCsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xKSMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy5cbjArMCNhIF5Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09Nb09PT01cbi0xKi0xMCs0XzMiLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)
11. [Neutrino](https://tio.run/##y0stLSnKzMv//99QWTsTBvKzM3RjkhNLkvNTUhNilG3NYtLy80picm2Tc4sMDWJyuQxNlGNS81KsuUy0DZQTFfSrHBR88/0xEVcB0PASDQtdDSMtU11jTW0NQ30jTS1DA21DbFAXK9RUVtQGgQAFZW2SgR6XAdiJcZiO8/f35dI11NIFusYk3vj/fwA)
12. [BitCycle](https://tio.run/##lY5LDoIwFAD3PQWmG6B50gfVmBgSL0DwAI2KBWKjtATrQg9v/SSuYOPMHGCO2qm7ujTeI2X6hz2fQKrKKVs3B0nzpWytcbLLVTcglx1BQWVj6jURjNMqSB6boLDlONIP2rhwBWEaLyCLWIhJGsXIGU4Jk0Z0xj5sA8r@Zk74d3E3nivLggDG8L4R@8z7p@2dtubq4fYC)
13. [COW](https://tio.run/##S84v///fUFk7EwbyszN0Y5ITS5LzU1ITYpRtzWLS8vNKYnJtk3OLDA1icrkMTZRjUvNSrLlMtA2UExX0qxwUfPP9MRFXQVFmXomGha6GkZaprrGmtoahvpGmlqGBtiE2qIsVaioraoNAgIKyNslAj8sA7MQ4TMf5@/ty6Rpq6QJdYxJv/P8/AA)

Comment: I feel like this is some form of TeX, but I can't figure out how to run it

Comment: And generally lack of input is assumed, so I'd say the flag has to be revealed.

Comment: Agree with a username.

Comment: THIS CAN ALSO BE KEG!!! [LINK](https://tio.run/##y05N///f0ERZOxMG8rMzdGOSE0uS81NSE2KUbc1i0vLzSmJybZNziwwNYnK5gKpjUvNSrLlMtA2UExX0qxwUfPP9MRFXQVFmXomGha6GkZaprrGmtoahvpGmlqGBtiE2qIsVaioraoNAgIKyNslAj8sA7MQ4TMf5@/ty6Rpq6QJdYxJv/P8/AA)

Comment: @Nobody Keg outputs `1` instead of `14`, though. In your link you've modified the first line.

Comment: This is a snippet in rSNBATWPL, not a full program

Comment: It works on DSO as a full program

Answer (score 4):

## 21. PingPong, 294 bytes, cracked by Aiden Chow

```
1# 2:0+:@ iiiiiiiiiokh \#+++++++++++++++O \font\m=cmr10\m14\end ;n+3e
4+0# MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM h$1 o$ h$8 o$
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) #!+++++P #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-#19$#&
0+0#;print{4} >8z@ S5^7^MOAOF
-1*-10+4_3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5NC4JAFEX3/ooXI6EOU/P8IFMK27STCdoOtihTCWdEXBX9dhOhReWicy/c5T1NpYpGq6LvkYAbcRolUL3RtxIkoZ8IkFetOllvznWLXNboy1xdIFbUyw2fcgKpFv9UiBRKE0Gbw4TDGE1bqc4KmeU6AfNsauHStR3kFKfCJmMDmY2iB/hW/2XBCK5NMjf44B2P9w//CdvwnsAxyFZZKnZibzB02GDhn7y@fwE)

That's right, the code didn't change at all. Lol

Try it online in [Ruby](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkaorn9wYoouriVCK6hglppkSZS6qAvH6vgoHbwfB@c9TTX/c05pLx6Y88laMo/UaBP1rS6nh/qBqWuMdaFOcLM8KggMZcUMqv@uVIZuTSVaf1U@GGQiIhxH8chC1By7JvoHQM6eKVt4Dv2l5GgOPXokMhn6SK9L2Gb5JM8Uyu1htJDsF6ntBMRGIguJd5Fzj0A) [Jelly](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkborn9wYoouriVCF1DHbTSaptI6aIvH6vgoHbwfB@c9ZyLur5Zi5RVb8ylBEXZJxLUyehONctD06JQDUaq0EdYaBYWJGKCQmrkP5cyJde20p2bcDfwYx56zMVp4PkoGA6ND84DOnql7eA79pcJpzh36JiIZ@kqua8hi/NZnsqN3ELpIBinV9KLcPR5nxLtQ2sf) [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2ggXFwjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrTyBcXGZvbnRcXG09Y21yMTBcXG0xNFxcZW5kIDtuKzNlXG40KzAjIE1vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT09PTVxucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpICMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLSMxOSQjJlxuMCswIyA+OHpAIFM1XjdeTU9BT0YgaCQxIG8kIGgkOCBvJFxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiJd) [rSN](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2ggXFwjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrTyBcXGZvbnRcXG09Y21yMTBcXG0xNFxcZW5kIDtuKzNlXG40KzAjIE1vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT09PTVxucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpICMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLSMxOSQjJlxuMCswIyA+OHpAIFM1XjdeTU9BT0YgaCQxIG8kIGgkOCBvJFxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd) [Heada**](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2ggXFwjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrTyBcXGZvbnRcXG09Y21yMTBcXG0xNFxcZW5kIDtuKzNlXG40KzAjIE1vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT09PTVxucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpICMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLSMxOSQjJlxuMCswIyA+OHpAIFM1XjdeTU9BT0YgaCQxIG8kIGgkOCBvJFxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd) [Python 3](https://tio.run/##jZA9C8IwFEX3/IonKdI0RPP6gRVRdHErEbqGOmilRZqU0kX/fI2Cg9rBcy/c9XDbW19ZEw0DUl6/sdcKNOWfKNAXa3rdrE9Nh1I3GOvSnGFleFSSmEsKmVX/VKmMtF1tej8VfhgkImLcx3nIApQcxyJGw4BOXmoH@Jb9ZSYoLj06JfJpuknvW8iTYlFkaqf2UHkI1nOTuiECA@FU4qP75QE) [Brainf***](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwGEX3PMUnKdI2RPP1Byui6OJWIriGitaWltJESl18@VgFB38Gz71w1nPqjrUur3ljLVJWvzBNBYqydySo0uhetcu87VCoFiNV6DMsNAsLEjFBITXyn0uZkktX695NuBv4MQ895uI08HwUDH@N/5wHdPRM28Fn7DcTTnHu0DERj9JVclvDPs5mWSo3cguVg2CcQckgwtHnQ0p0CK29Aw) [Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkaorn9wYoouriVCF1DHWqlRZpIqYsvH6vgoHbwfB@c9XQ305TOIeXNG3upQVP@iQJ9tqbX7bpsO5S6xVhX5gQrw6OKxFxSyKz650pl5No1pvdT4YdBIiLGfZyHLEDJcWxidAzo5JV2gO/YX2aC4tKjUyKfpZv0voU8KRZFpnZqD7WHYL1B6SAiMBBDSnyMnHsA) [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##jY7NCoJAFEb38xQ3RkIdpub6Q0YUtWknE7gdjEhFCWfCXPXykwUtKhed74OzPUV5KqrmVnNrkbLmjbnUoCj7RIKqjO5Vuz63HQrVYqRKXcBKs7AkERMUUiP/uZQpuXaN7t2Eu4Ef89BjLs4Dz0fBcGx8dB7QySvtAN@xv8w4xaVDp0Q8SzfJfQtZnC/yVO7kHmoHwTiDkkGEo8@HlOgYWvsA) [FISHQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJmaXNocTkrIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2ggXFwjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrTyBcXGZvbnRcXG09Y21yMTBcXG0xNFxcZW5kIDtuKzNlXG40KzAjIE1vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT09PTVxucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpICMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLSMxOSQjJlxuMCswIyA+OHpAIFM1XjdeTU9BT0YgaCQxIG8kIGgkOCBvJFxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd) [Neutrino](https://tio.run/##jY6xCsIwFEX3fMWTFGkbonlNixVRdHErEVxDHbTSIk2k1MWfj1FwUDt47oU73mOqW981xjqHlDVv7KUGTdknCvTZml63y2PbodAtproyJ1gYJiuSMkGhsOqfKlWQq3/tw5yHSZxxGbEQp0kUo2A4FD6YCOjopbaDb9lfJpziPKBjIp6mq/y@hn1WzspCbdQW6gDBBn5yP4RjzL1KepDOPQA) [BitCycle](https://tio.run/##jY7NCoJAGEX38xRfjIQ6TPn5Q0YUtWknE7QdDDJDKWfEbFEP32RBi34WnXvhbM@2bLNLdsyNQcrKF/pQgKTsHQFyr1Urq2lWNejJCkOZqx1MFAtyEjKPQqLFPxciIXVTqtaOue27EQ8cZuPQd1z0GP4a/zkHaO@ZtoLP2G8GnOLYon3iPUpn8XUO6ygdpYlYiCUUFoK2OsWdCEeXdynhJjDmpuu21Opk@PkO) [COW](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkaorn9wYoouriVCF1DHWqlRZpIKQi@fKyCg9rB831w1lPam3NIefPGXmrQlH@iQJ@t6XW7LtsOpW4x1pU5wcrwqCIxlxQyq/65Uhm5do3p/VT4YZCIiHEf5yELUHIcmxgdAzp5pR3gO/aXmaC49OiUyGfpJr1vIU@KRZGpndpD7SFYb1A6iAgMxJASHyPnHg) [TeX](https://TeX,%20278%20bytes:%20%5B%601#+iiiiiiiiiokh%20%5C#+++++++++++++++O%20%5Cfont%5Cm=cmr10%5Cm14%5Cend%20;n+3e%204+0#%20MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM%20print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)%20#!+++++P%20#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-#19$#&%200+0#%20%3E8z@%20S5%5E7%5EMOAOF%20h$1%20o$%20h$8%20o$%20-1*-10+4_3%60%5D(https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724JLViRbSSbmZeplLsgqWlJWm6FrcYxQyVtTNhID87QyFGWRsV-CvEpOXnlcTk2ibnFhkaxOQamsSk5qUoWOdpG6dymWgbKCv45vsTg_z9fbkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA20DbFBXaxQU0FZEey0AAV0x2ICPV1lQ0sVZTUuA5BL7SyqHBSCTePM43z9Hf3dFDJUDBXyVYCUBZDi0jXU0gU6xSTeGBI80FBaAKUB)) [Brainf***+](https://tio.run/##7Vzrk5vIEf@uv2JudRXAelha2xVHt2zl4thVrsS3js/JF8RRLIwkbAQYBu/Kiv52p3uGhxAPgWSf7yqHbQlBd09Pz697el6@NaPV58/Bhq187xEZXV1dfT8lV7JlMuXz52l/4KSX/35F5v1B8boh84XvsflatdbhdDJfTx/PqWeTH7zBI9p7PJj0ySv/ps3fm5tXvSB0PCY/HcmXD56MHikDefrwUnkwnQymVX9GlX8U0v@Oq/aaHCpbvsaj/vQv3/f/1JugptdPP/2V/Pzklz//8urmx5sXZAWW8L@Hr6fw1RtNH4xAlcfGo899smIsiGYPHy4dtopvx5a/fvj2o@9/emUuPWfhWNRjD/8Wmo73Irbev3bj6KXHaBiEFD57fbL2baQymeN70QwejEgUUMtZbEgQ@svQXJOF41LPXFNiRnAfRoyY4TJeg2BO7vnE8l0fDLbswYOX68APWc/hXyTaRPDsmW/TnrMgb8OYznoELnzmRcz0WMR/F17iZdAw9ENVkvInd2boFR74MQtiVnjkeIdPQLGlU@SDuscoau7lDznjh9hnVF1I24RktxUCdy/xk3iU2tQG0tQ0M5JRXl9fk70iVE16/uaNpD940uslFX4Rexa3Mv9t0wWYLdjIrpJXWsgirhMxWeNvDYUs/JAYWKirK2gntgkocKkqkhHqRpS4SSEoNPY@OYHMaMQMJChL1yRp/M53PFlzuGxnSN6h@IxFV4YZT3pp72po9b2iASgAKmrLwuamO3xPaVDWQKjIaylYZNdc39omuZ@Re22iYwnIORSWQOJMYmh6SypPhgDJ7KEirszSz1wzEla28I7DL1cCNTWgXR1mGHJE3cUQGsKme2rihS/G@Jyo/HWB3XKp6Rn4mAs4YO2L4JFJGEeB6zBZ6kuKNptd6kqBOrFJ2igtuFCDJWW15ScShaRc07IAn61oaKxMdyHs4Hg2vT8QZq3M0LSgjcAOXGJWsqJxer1A7k6h0S6BVpK17dVw/FAaSoq@u/5hNp9LBUpAci4b0X05K6EuomZordTDcmeiYDDLaKrXMBkIVxX00dzLMaeXs@KUIhO6UOuyuajZTNem8HGk7EvNnR4p26N3XLKwPY0M4MvcSEgbahnzMJd/gCLqOmtwBRG9MvrdNmfYFc1/t4KonrNhC6S6lG3hgFbp26RCGadSok4p1fQGGkwfZD8cbjz@r1xQYgU1veGs2Y86VtOL7jhCM8oDbXMzHNi/DQoTf@KSoL@TRWmDaaUfpy@F0iWXc30/MCAtqXe4atyd45MGXhjGUrZjHktqXDYDK2lAKwgcuJeDHPDVOI2AFdxDg@YFP3F00b1gE4gIj/HdnSoHzWV41hBCt63yzjHVRxnyn6lSyiELFAWf2gw5E0AIy@tkwN@UXgwOEcYLxY8qKQP@ovSclKQIpxPtATWFosto29fXsxKBnCVX9@A5PK5yJlQIRQmtq2RxtY8L403j8cQntXFFjFhwGs9nvGpwP0jAWKbdB9NeaEkCO4jP7cgVzWNH@f2gqur7sWQ/LNQVkEeYFgWIVjS9jaxVxk9ur8KbHPW6UrZGA3m16cDULQP3aQG8uYmKDdIQzJsbomj2GjH7obcirAvEDi71QpwFUitmNM3tqOtGKmSVcBuHEYwpxL0fONRWf/I9CGc4VDGBarsbkkWapvNfkWlRFUcmcGtZ/O4w2@M0hMzIzyv/jvxosdh0IeVcr03PjshzoYx9yGNZJON5FochjKbIM1S1QBhASggxVJ0U479ok6YuAiACRZQB0S89EckqjnlwfLXLBjSpUtx@MNDh3zvoHChGQkGkVPhFovIVBvCKvJo3EqTtTOX4Saj1qnCCdq2GdL/yaV1NRBPA8BRqwYuGWtRWgneJvhgPQy7Fa729uBDJuawtLrSts9Mv8u5KgEpXlIMEK6lEWltV@pc066L2g8vd69C3aISDbs@JVjDyvN0AuB0mADCXPswlqdp7E78xSi/B6xeZRh9qNOqT5x9i56MJTchm5Dak5vumUriNUu9KPStzqj2PatYGKtO9taU5E41ZZYmC@IuTpHstpd/USAcjxlSl8CWnqFLqYroTOXxKxKIyZ4P0kCn1MT3HjZgH2W05165e4/rBTlkmn36pgPRB15VPlRwn/WdiAIglHCo7sjIjcpyPV4sktRu2YMAZErLl8yScSWnFBeGaWKaHCcwthYYNqcXcDRHGHZMOFX3@5g2fuQBWqb53beejfhOwMIk@DVsR5vBN6BLAFbS1RCzczBqtUcaotQrTRmkGKrfEvUUDRv6D9M8RkG1La4fejgg@B8UnIVkwJRl1MvF1P51O4FLaciOq2SqOANpxBF0It8yMdKz0XgsQbEEFp4BJtWYdRaOzgEjAB5fTgIZGpzke23jKeJBJHabhooGgTgL4zXA7iv4WHkCOucAJbnCqK5zgDue6RNktopZ@ITj9BWad1iqZnNnyr10HAajoCV55vmd@Oe/8yh56ipce9dR2Hlvw3IE6be4pB@emYI3@jINK9KdUxA70qUuxhLu@hfzjiLf@P6dbeapl2riqxgfi7bK0czxmIeXtgukelAtJnuV7YCzKJ1T4spqMul1A61wohPn82QkJ4ODs9G/UBOp22V83WI/@gPUXgnUU3zI@Bf5tsB17URzgGBzLD2jIhWNlIrGkPFJnZC4hSucSwZdzCVptLp0A89HZMJ/Uz0SY0abXCrnq5Ngg3ZRq51MFlrTRVFfVye8M2QtcA08iwuQcjI5b8DpjIEsELCEw0gXrOjQO/GhyEmT43GfWUKOKhOCLzt4VsGPXYCfXZ/C19TkezI93BkkQf4kZ1ZEofoLeGi7I1ytf6bZjMwhwQXSiHHPf6Py@sGqW7chESDnOaBO9Br3CCnmNmutzVwcpNbWm3lCKumfyurqikwqyGcbShFHV9G8e4NrGNp6dQWgiSVt1CW4hxQpT@4SwFgcnBDWxHSkOzu4Nndre8GdnHbi0ZX@41fzQ5jtPRI@Pd2INN4iZnG94U/TdMdd7WddzerhV40Bc98CFmANRTSHrG/XJYuNfpwwTKtIxU8QlsCUNnU/dsRoxP6TENpnZBbDnJ5r70w2OBzV3bEgFGaSZbrJdgMkKuXPYityaESXTCWab3DadU8xb03a8U/OFCrdAJY4B3qp1wbcrP16uGKF1iWmyssx7I2hl3JmSl360k/t4esHOIin7O76szUP@65B@xFXcCVGvyQvTjWiHjm4rxO1@e0tJP/ls5XhLcgeOKZT8VYZXP5nrFPR8Q/RcEoXDCMqJeG9rU8jGqd0R4Z6PMDm73wjqVpjFIntdgopVObIaL6Tw9VwNyXWxAUskFEcQ/fqratXYr6SZEupaUL8xOf4H3XzLCY4U25bpuoDSLSq840hPwPWrQD0zQqJAxkraQhq0RZufGrjTMIRbDH87A6fn/AvVgvb4VtHvNYdyohLo0qlht3tteZz67/Q2XgLwmOnwXUDtORE1JfC0yIoK2426MCbjnHTypANrEhqAN7nbdU7@QyZqenYMXzRHSzJQyVnx0irQ1IwwDUO1tOks3RgKSinVhNnWnqRXMIzmUL8vsdkOL86xQ3Jm44yeY6EeVO2PDuPX6DDQ6CfPDIptaPOGOZPat8mWtXlT4lP3OgMKoA5PGskLZZxuQRU6tVxl3dOzC4fQvQNHWp8OLFkda6fVxDZblZ96m50TA7Ezz44iVEuyHa6MGW7A5PhDzs6TZZzKUKuf2UxPm92r6mTYguy7VmTk/rod2VWrQq/b6XbVioxvYa4kg5Spafowt7XGm0eXi8lSw8zp8d1hye7mbCPz3oG05N3va2/Yv73AdEKKa2m3oWm9p7i2NpeSXcdw31HeF9uzFcW3EcMTurxNF34M4f6EfVqej/VLN1GfuFOr0M273Rf@GmGVpgd7u@PLoBpMldG0dyaovmqX/uWAdDKIviCAuoGnHXD@25wf5jElO3FXG1EKco22cg8Oz1aXVYWzhnmPulMb3CM6nXmoO71Re@6h817@5Kz1KxP66/Roe3YSfA1P5b2uASqG50GiTTQ2w@VHhaiQvhfrKWpykf7nA@l/OnBxcH7w3mF7R134uUY/2BOtTXXcVAnpP4BVvYjZYvT0QhmH1LT3@HieZhh5ooaHe/j06JCf@OG36YFyB8@Loy4wLAKAGFg5Yx8nora9/wE) [RunR](https://tio.run/##jVhbd9pIEn5Gv6KMvUEYJMCOJxlsPJPNxOf4IcuecbL7YJxEoAZpLCRWLdmwDvvXs191t0Bc4sTOcUvVdfm6bl3K0JPBt29x4gtyLi4ujjp0YY@8rP7tW@ewERY/yX1Ag8PG5k@fBuMkzgbT3miadtqDaeflQMQ@nceNU2G9bLQP6X3S/5l//f57a5aGcWa/duyT4zPntN6wO62T@nGn3ejs@3X2/tbp8EBB@ydtg939cZ3Dzq9Hhy@sNiO9fP3f3@nm7NOrT@/7b/pXFMATyRGW11gsp3PsAMrLz6ffWi36EISS8M8j9ttfeI4zkc5Sgb80TlIKsmwmu62WkEnkxRPpJumk9Rjeh60/8/hPCyq8PAuStEsy82QS@ueUikh4UviUJTTLh1E4Ij@ZemFsWQ8etErqgec/eZgKuzaWtfq5ZYVjsmdpMhJSul46eXAjEU@ygC56dFKnJ6sySmIgEG6UTOzqR@lNRFdBpjSPUxfAL8ZhJC6rUFYpFIl5mNlw5bm1VJZHzN8DADcVnn8F/ptFPNqwe3ty16Rano2d1wrXLM9GAUR7NAqod0kFr8z8JM/cxzTMhD0KwNpqbfOCASRq8Ps5wVMPIpVhEiu/DtPkUYrUYg8WPoYHR/cJuMZR8uiOkmnLa/3y8uT07LTTsYpgxUL4kt5xmJqUx1F4LyhJw0kYe5GJnsvM/U0aQiBkXMtI5rNZkmZwXuyoLW@UhQ8CbADbJJGmSSoZOz0GItZuXRkf5zG4cYShCLwHgbyR9OG6X5M4DwI8zkf3TcQ2y9NYUpvA@K5/peD8I8kQMU0gdj@7fsVaHbSrrrXSPhHKk3adLIQ@EhkN8/FYsGv/rh5cL4qSkc2hrZhwqlC2m4azSXhU29qEIbtZcpOhOif2OsZLq3X8r93IdJ@Dg4BalXBsK6dRr0fVal1FXZ0EeyKSgtO2ooiK7bZ9h42KEdE0V6I6hD7HcoWVtS@PWyo3MnY7ss7PkXfkh3wKESOMSY7@lAVevB19ayjEDAYAdzNhEVqTsLXBK5XdfBR/OEFNcf7qJ07fda2pvIUfkumUraKiRewNI0HYg9GJZWXpgg/K3cDmAmuSqYNm4TfEBIiaxpLyONryKLBVrm1Ut6JoeqOmg2Ot4/DzNiylU1U7L66cRWgFtUHMOis4UiqmKDQapHAajdCtKBnjbRBrOReJ8M4DRDsKY9EMlSv50QQMTaXXqw3SGv2mDNyGdzBVYmg3uYV3qc322M2PoZ8FBZxUcDhtOxUyj7ImyykL770scKfevLxhOmG9ybo4GloT4EZJPBEyU2YtbWWWcHMdh7H/Gc0kzZS36vT1Kz3Nu1wSC/xdGkh@yAX15GOnA8@Vt1QnwubtnSFMSxQGMfVQRnPNpznifIrtttod5alKUtCG6HEVlceCc3GSelO6Of3QJ3VJShqcNtFoQpSJzCd8HMlJnVG10PHgRbmo8h0VJ5lSI72p4MZT3TRT1TjAzy7wUIAbWJQeq4J@UaTTtpusChcstwCbFS2KaJmryKHOOYiX6pALxwG/ElBW54b5dnHnRp7MrmNfzPtju3ajMg5ljwtuTgc94rwwdf40by7Y41z6SPRKueHYCKVBhD5zwK@uNk4vXpB@uyjjq6/UxnkUnZfl5htyc8ipHNqVKPoPH0SZuFPL/A7Ae2gDvoDPcLH/to@lSzWqnW@dZJbMbJUk5izrTFFUl/frBqyil@3UEW40Y/pyo5KP6epqJOTH0VPhpCXZR08Kw7KpHxbL@pfScaBXt9cSrlEUztjg2sVs/QI1VvikXUJ1SSdnZ6sdPO/RXlLu@Q9ejPpeh1D7HZMAas715@eGtFiRFts60MU4N9GsS1lgupsBwlo0xf7yA3cwyt7RE/4u4fj73u3Rk/L/8o4rW71PCwIKBaz4u/xSN6hQoBHfUiaGa2jnJqTqlisQMFE@htzhMRkVVaKaLMqhu36h8sv/al0u12v4w@c5BdWORkpevCBfRN6CGzVX/9Zt18RNSGGm@0MyowDXo8taK0NMBfe45FYWrmCh5DpN5dTvFlQGkPKNihlMGRP@RN0MkzT0S5quoUlnscqj1Xzg8vIWpfEms9t1tGuDYSXYh6C5umw9iLjjNJm@NWIqI9dia7lPtW5RMLkMFNuu8ocVqnXV7XK92cTOj42SwB6Jj7sSzvMS73cljp@X@EOnAt8UfyCyMktXA@tjkt4/F/xHQTyL8mwyyTHq8NwK3pQJuRSKdYJXP3wI1ZCHBo/kcgt7VwiAvldmYtSl6r957OX3zeuFJsCDKYP7T5t1eEOeINAMmpx/MpzOogWClMwk9ydWEISTQN87brWwpsbozatO64dUugIrV@j03KzceB2jK4bZos4DJ@wqlpKb1fSA/ogJiqmtssf1JbRdE7V2ravWjllPzHpq1pdmPTPrL2Z9ZdbXZv3VhE@jaajxeF8J/g2JoS/oA@6bpTTAUT8P8wkHWscBDlTBk/g8wCdKjol/oXMhUU23qeYBPLM@Wwq4W@CjgFkiv742ebRRFdPvlcULsE2/V2JrtoP1AbDsqvmw2s/SXDx7wCv13R3xt8uCE9VXXx8cYhlogXXb2hhqdkDZ4NgZ5jDLGU7uas4laSe99TKXP5lLHqpviDv7xC8cy5zBnzcBF@rUgyGyybaywXOvITolIhVE9cxEtbsmOopIBVEDa22ey9E3pR5V9ct8ueXiH8KjffCcHXi0D56zCW8w2MRXhreNbi31tVbsQs6cYjePnIJrseJa7FHW4Cut@Nlx1bzsqsVy18ohxHmuQHrVf158Lf@7llfi5aFng3UnKkRqcIrEOHsuf3bd/sOk2sqfi@/H56fSxwDFnRNkz6XS3qR2nj3TFtLLZzL9@6l0DCn@7LU3HY7p2cPXY7eYnq9jBCj09bWamxH15yZoDM2VjcCaOVprrn2MYRXDDP@HAH8R1PiD/f8) [><>](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkborn9wYoouriVCF1DHbSlRZpI7eTLxyg4qB083wdnPXV7a6xFyto35tKAouwTCao2elDd@tT1KFSHiar0GVaaxRVJmKCQG/nPpczJtW/14Gfcj8KUxwHzcR4FIQqGY@OjC4BOXmkH@I79ZcYpLj06JeJZusnuWyjSclHmcif30HgIxnPKnAjHkLuU5Bhb@wA) [xEec](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkborn9wYoouriVCF1DHWqkRZpI6SC@fKyCg9rB831w1nPTunIOKWve2EsNirJPJKizNb1q11XboVAtJkqbE6wMizVJmKCQW/nPpczJtWtM72fcj8KUxwHzcR4FIQqGY@OjC4BOXmkH@I79ZcYpLj06JeJZusnuWyjSclHmcif3UHsI1huUDSIcQz6kJMfYuQc) [Versert](https://tio.run/##jY5NC4JAFEX3/ooXI6EOU/N0JFMK27STCdoOtihDCTVMWhT99mkQWvSx6NwLd3nPteguRddrjQT8mNM4hepFeypBEfqOBHVsm17Vi33dIVc1ClU0B0gaGhSWoJxA1sp/KmUGpY3Q2mYiM9a5q5reiZjjeyELXOrg1Hc95BR/hf2MC2Q0iG7gU/2bCSM4t8nY4sY7Ge7v4gHL6JbCNsxneSZXcm0x9JixELtA6yc)

Comment: … what … how … nice :p

Comment: It's been uncracked for more than a week by this point. I'm curious to see what the lang is :P

Comment: Oh wait... [I just found the lang](https://tio.run/##jY5NC4JAFEX3/ooXI6EOU/P8IFMK27STCdoOtihTCWdEXBX9dhOhReWicy/c5T1NpYpGq6LvkYAbcRolUL3RtxIkoZ8IkFetOllvznWLXNboy1xdIFbUyw2fcgKpFv9UiBRKE0Gbw4TDGE1bqc4KmeU6AfNsauHStR3kFKfCJmMDmY2iB/hW/2XBCK5NMjf44B2P9w//CdvwnsAxyFZZKnZibzB02GDhn7y@fwE), holy shit. I literally came across this answer like 5 minutes ago, no joke.

Comment: Figured out how it works. Relevant code is: `1# 2:0+:@`. `1` pushes 1 to the stack. `#` skips the next instruction, which is the space (space is actually a no-op, so the `#` didn't actually do anything). `2` pushes 2 to the stack. `:` prints the number at the top of the stack without newlines (in this case, the `2`). `0` pushes 0 to the stack. `+` adds the top two numbers on the stack, so 1+0 = `1` is left on the stack. `:` prints the `1`. `@` terminates the code.

Answer (score 3):

## 3. Vyxal, 15 bytes, cracked in literally 30 seconds by emanresu A

```
$><<$$/$$
2+3_3
```

The previous answer was written in Jelly.

[Try it online in Jelly.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/FzsZGRUVfRYXLSNs43vj/fwA)

[Try it online in Ruby.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkZFRV9FhctI2zje@P9/AA)

Comment: [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIkPjw8JCQvJCRcbjIrM18zIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Comment: Don't mark as cracked until another answer's posted

Answer (score 3):

## 6. Python 3, 46 bytes, [cracked by aiden chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247975/add-a-hidden-language-to-a-polyglot/247983#comment554545_247983) and [continued by Nobody](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247988/100664)

```
print(8 - (2 * 5 - 3) + (1/2) * 10)#+++++P
5_3
```

The previous answer was in [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass).

For the sake of everyone else doing this:

[Try it online in Ruby!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6AoM69Ew0JBV0HDSEFLwRTIMNZU0FbQMNQ30gQKGBpoKmuDQACXabzx//8A)
[Try it online in Jelly!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7@gKDOvRMNCQVdBw0hBS8EUyDDWVNBW0DDUN9IEChgaaCprg0AAl2m88f//AA)
[Try it Online in Vyxal!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJwcmludCg4IC0gKDIgKiA1IC0gMykgKyAoMS8yKSAqIDEwKSMrKysrK1BcbjVfMyIsIiIsIiJd)
[Try It Online in rSNBATWPL!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCJwcmludCg4IC0gKDIgKiA1IC0gMykgKyAoMS8yKSAqIDEwKSMrKysrK1BcbjVfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)
[Try It Online in Headass!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCJwcmludCg4IC0gKDIgKiA1IC0gMykgKyAoMS8yKSAqIDEwKSMrKysrK1BcbjVfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

Comment: [Cracked](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew0JBV0HDSEFLwRTIMNZU0FbQMNQ30gQKGBpoKmuDQACXaTxQPQA), but I'm not going to post a new answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your Headass code works according that link

Comment: @Samathingamajig Give it a couple of seconds to load and check for errors in the console.

Comment: @emanresuA I'm getting `ReferenceError: code is not defined` when I run the code, with no errors in my browser console. Does the code work only on certain browsers?

Comment: @AidenChow Frick. That's probably an interpreter bug :P will see what I can do

Comment: @AidenChow Fixed, idk why it *was* working on other browsers – it shouldn't've lol

Answer (score 3):

## 16. [RunR](https://esolangs.org/wiki/RunR), 286 bytes

```
1#+iiiiiiiiiokh\#+++++++++++++++O\>#\catcode`\#=6\font\m=cmr10\m
14#\end;
4+0#a /z@ MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoO
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)#!+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#a ^MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOMS5^7^MOAOF
-1*-10+4_3
```

Answer (score 3):

## 17. [><>](https://tio.run/#%23jY9LC4JAFEb38ysmhkgdJmd8VCBGbdrJBG0vlvhACccwV/35KYwWplDnu8u7OKeo7qXWgtDqQ3MtgdAhErYE0qRLmyy/AAlXUDSqgzpM61ZwqOfg5kh4BHKVBfg3iwB5lJME248djho5vsG3Qre2Up2xYYZj@cw1qSFsx7QEp2JqbHImmfUxR/yd9wdLxHvheKwqZXTy43Ucyb08vI1hKhoQExZ7OXtnV@sn), 329 bytes, cracked by stasoid

```
1#+iiiiiiiiiokh\#+++++++++++++++O\>#\catcode`\#=6\font\m=cmr10\m%\3e
14#\end;                                   ';
4+0#a /z@ MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoO            'n
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)#!+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#a ^MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOMS5^7^MOAOF      \                    \
-1*-10+4_3
```

Try it online in [Ruby](https://tio.run/##jY/NCoJAFEb38xQTQ6QOk44/FYhRm3YyQduLZWok4UyILerlpzBamEKd7y7v4pz6drxrzQktP6jLGQjtImBJIEubTOXFAUg0g5OSDVRRVtXcgWoMXoG4T6CQeYh/MwmRTx2SYvuxwrES/et8S3StS9kYC2a4VsA8kxrcdk2LO5QPjQ3OJKM2Zou/8/5gipxWOOmrChHvgmSexGItNm9jGIoGxLjFXs7@3tP6CQ) [Jelly](https://tio.run/##jY/NCoJAFEb38xQTQ6QOk44/FYhRm3YyQduLJWpk6UyIm3r5KYwWllDnu8u7OOdcVNVNa05o@UZdTkBoHwFLAlnaZiovDkCiGRyVbKGOsrrhDtRj8ArEfQKFzEP8m0mIfOqQFNv3FY6V@L7et0TXppStsWCGawXMM6nBbde0uEP50NjgTDLqYrb4M@8PpsjphJNvVSHiXZDMk1isxeZlDEPRgBi32NPZ33taPwA) [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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) [rSN](https://dso.surge.sh/#@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) [Heada**](https://dso.surge.sh/#@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) [Python 3](https://tio.run/##jZDBCoJAFEX38xUTQ6QOk05qBWLUpp1M0PZhiRpKOCMym/p5E6OFKdS5b3kX5776oQsl3bblhJYf1L0AQocI2BFIE52qLL8CCddwU1JDFaZVwx2o5uDmiHsEcpkF@DeLAHnUIQm2n3scKTG@QVuiuimlNrbMWFk@c01qcHtlWtyhfCpsMiaZ9WNO@HveHyyR0wvHY1UhorMfb@JIHMTxbQxTowExbrHO2bt0L38B) [Brainf***](https://tio.run/##jY/NCoJAFEb38xTGEKnDpONPBWLUpp1M0PZi2agk4kyIbXr5KYwWllDnu8u7OOfcZpUsb6LWmmFSvVH1BTAZwmGNQWSdUHlxAhwvoFSygyYWTctcaKbgF4gFGAqZR8ZvZhEKiIszw7lvjETx7xt8S3RtK9mZK2p6dkh9i5jM8SybuYSNjY7OwpM@Zm985v3BHLm9cPqtynlyCNNlmvAt372MYSwaEGU2fToHR1/rBw) [Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##jY9PC4IwGIfv@xTGiNSx3PxTgRh16SYLur5YMo0k3ELs0pdfYXQwhXp@7/E9PE9zV5U0hmNSfdDXC2DSR8Aag8xbqYvyBDhZwFmrFupE1g1nUE8hKBEPMZSqiK3fzGIUEoZzy3tsrFSL4fW@Fbo1lWrtFbV9N6KBQ2zu@Y7LGeFjo6Nz8KSL2VvfeX8wR6wTzoaqQqSHKFtmqdiK3dsYxqIBUe7Sl3N4DIx5Ag) [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##jY/NCoJAFEb38xQTQ6QOkzP@VCBGbdrJBG0vluiIEjphrnp5C6OFKdT57vIuzslUkuXlvWBdJwgtP@hrAYQOkbAlkCZtqjN1ARKuINd1C1WYVo3gUM3BVUh4BFSdBfg3iwB5lJME248djrQc3@C7RremrFtjwwzH8plrUkPYjmkJTsXU2ORMMutjjvg77w@WiPfC8VhVyujkx@s4knt5eBvDVDQgJiz2cvbObtc9AQ) [FISHQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@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) [Neutrino](https://tio.run/##jY9BC4IwGIbv@xWLEalj6VIrEKMu3WRB1w9LdJGEW4hd@vNLjA6mUM/7Hb/D8yj5aOpSaWM4oeUHfbsCoX0EbAjkWZPrQp6BxEu4aNVAFedVzT2opuBLxAMCUhUR/s0sQgH1SIbd5xYnWgyv963QvfVsrDWzFk7IfJta3F3YDvcoHxsbnU0mXcwBf@f9wRx5nXA6VBUiOYbpKk3ETuzfxjAWDYhxh7XOwck35gU) [BitCycle](https://tio.run/##jY9BC4IwGIbv@xXGiNSxdKkVRFGXbrKg64dl00jKLWod6se3ouhgCvW83/E7PM@m0OIqDrkxDJPig9rvAJMqHCYYRKqFyvI14HEftkpqKMeiPDEfyjYEOWIhhlxmI@s3nREKiY9Ty7tNrVjx@lW@JTqeCqntIbV7bkQDh9jM6zku8wlrGm2cg1uvmIX1nfcHXeS/hJO6KufxMkoGScxnfP42hqZoQJS59OkcrgJj7uqoCyXPhl4e) [COW](https://tio.run/##jY9PC4IwGIfv@xSLEaljufmnAjHq0k0WdH2xZBpJ6EKEoC@/wuhgCvX83uN7eB6l78YIQssP@noBQvtIWBNQWat0XpyAxAs467qFKlZVIzhUU/ALJAICRZ1H@DezCAWUkwy7jw1OtBxe77tGt6asW2vFLM8JmW9TS7ie7QhOxdjY6Gwy6WL2@DvvD@aId8LpUFXK5BCmyzSRW7l7G8NYNCAmHPZyDo6@MU8) [TeX](https://TeX,%20369%20bytes:%20%5B%601#+iiiiiiiiiokh%5C#+++++++++++++++O%5C%3E#%5Ccatcode%60%5C#=6%5Cfont%5Cm=cmr10%5Cm%25%5C3e%2014#%5Cend;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27;%204+0#a%20/z@%20MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoO%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27n%20print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)#!+++++P%20#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.%200+0#a%20%5EMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOMS5%5E7%5EMOAOF%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%20-1*-10+4_3%60%5D(https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724JLViRbSSbmZeplLsgqWlJWm6FrcYCw2VtTNhID87I0ZZGxX4x9gpxyQnliTnp6QmxCjbmsWk5eeVxOTaJucWGRrE5KrGGKdyGZoox6TmpVgrEAbq1lwm2gbKiQr6VQ4Kvvn-mAhFdR5XQVFmXomGha6GkZaprrGmtoahvpGmlqGBtiE2qIsVaiorgj0ToIDuPSKAHpcB2MFxmE719_cNNo0zj_P1d_R3g7g4BpunY7h0DbV0gW42iTeGhDw0AhZAaQA)) [Brainf***+](https://tio.run/##7Vxtk9u2Ef6uX4Gc2iFpvZx0ttuMcrxp6tozntY513H7hWJYHgVJjCmSJkHfyap@u7sL8EUU3yU7TqaR7TuK3F3sLp5dLEDAd2a4/vTJ37K15z4mo@vr6z9MybVsmUz59GnaH9jJx3u3nvcH@c/t/KY/B1LLW9D/zPvqn@ZLz2XzjWptgulkvvnj/DHtTZ/059RdfEeaP9J3vSeDSd8klx//Ql55t8W/OWq35we2y@RvR/LVo6ejx8pAnl5eKY@mk8G07M@o9I/S/4Yb85ocm9fiM@5NuMI/FVW9vX3149Of/vzTq9vvb18IjedlRs97o@mjEej8xHj8qU/WjPnh7PJyZbN1dDe2vM3l2w@e9/GVuXLtpW1Rl13@NTBt90VkvXvtROFLl9HADyj87PXJxlsglclszw1ncGNEQp9a9nJL/MBbBeaGLG2HuuaGEjOE6yBkxAxW0QYEc3LXI5bneODZVQ9uvNz4XsB6Nv9Fwm0I955Bf/fsJXkbRHTWQyPwnhsy02Uh/557iB@DBoEXqJKU3bk3Azd3w4uYH7HcLds9vgOKrew8H9geoai5m93kjO8jj1F1Ke1ikv1OCNy/xJ/EpXRBF0CauGZGUsqbmxty0ISqSc/fvJH0R097vdjgF5FrcS/z7wu6BLf5W9lRMqOFLOLYIZM1/tRQyNILiIGNOrqCfmJbnwKXqiIZoU5IiRM3gkIj96Pty4yGzECConRNksY/e7YrazaXbQ/Jzyg@ZdGVYe8YdNrPFbT6QdMAFAAVXcjC56YzfEepX9RAqMitFCyyY27uFiZ5mJEHbaJjC8g5FJ5A4lRiYLorKk@GAMn0piI@qaefOWYovGzhFYdfpgRqakC/2sww5JA6yyHBfHSgJn7wwRjvE5U/zrFbDjVdA29zAUesfZFlUgnj0HdsJkt9SdFmsytdyVHHPkk6pQUXarCirLL9WKKQlGlaFOCxNQ2MtekshR9sd0EfjoRZazMwLegj8AOXmLasaJxez5E7U@i0K6CVZG13PRxfSkNJ0fc3383mcylHCUjOZCO6r2YF1IXUDKy1etzuTDQMbhlN9QomA@Gqgj6aczXm9HLanJJnwhBq3TYXNZvp2hR@NLR9pTnThrZdes8lC9/T0AC@NIyEtKGWMg8z@Ucooo69gVAQ2Sul3@8yhn3e/fdryOoZG/ZAokvRFzZolTyNDUo5lQJ1QqkmF9Bh@iD9YnPn8X/FhmIvqMkFZ02/VLGabnjPEZpSHmmbueHI/21QGMcTlwTjnSxaG0xL4zh5KJQuhJzjeb4B1U11wJXj7pyYNPCDaSxha4pYUhGyKVhJDVpB4MC5GmSAL8dpCKwQHhp0L8SJrYvhBbtAZHjM785UOeouw7WGkLoXKh8cE32UIf@aKKUcs0BT8FObIWcMCOF5nQz4k8KDwTHCeKP4o0zKgD8o3CcFKSLoRH@ApdB0EW2H@rpWLJCzZOoe3YfbZcGECqEooXWZLK52szDeNS4vfBIfl@SIJadxPcZNg@tBDMYi7SGYDlJLnNhBfOZHrmiWO4rPB2WmH@aSw7RQ1UCWYVo0IHrRdLeyVpo/ub9yTzLU60rRGzXk5a4DV7dM3Kcl8PouyndITTKv74i82yvEHKbekrQuEDu40nN5FkitiNGktqOOE6pQVcJlFIQwpxDXnm/ThfqD50I6w6mKCVS7/ZAskzKdfwtNi6o4M4FLy@JXx9UepyFkRn5ce/fke4tFpgMl52ZjuouQPBfKLI55LIukPM@iIIDZFHmGquYIfSgJIYeqk3z@F31SN0QARKCJIiD6hTuiWMU5D86v9umEJlGK@w8mOvz3HgYHiplQECklcRGrfI0JvKSu5p0EZTtTOX5iar0snaBfyyHdL71bZYnoApieghW8abCi0gg@JHpiPgy1FLd6d3EhinNZW15oO3uvX2TDlQCVrihHBVZsRGKtKv1TmnVR@9HV/nXgWTTESbdrh2uYed5tAdw2EwCYS@/nklQevXHcGIWHEPXLVKP3FRr1yfP3kf3BhC5kM3IXUPNdXSvcR0l0JZGVBtVBRNVrA8Z0721pzkRnlnkiJ/7iJOluS@m3FdLBiRFVKfySE1QpVTndDm2@JGJRmbNBeciU6pye4Uasg@x3nGtfrXH1ZKcoky@/lED6aOjKlkqaSf8ROwByCYfKnqzNkDTzcbNIbN2wBQOukJAdXyfhTEorLkjXxDJdLGDuKHRsQC3mbIlw7ph0MPT5mzd85QJYperRtV2MenXAwiL6NGyFWMPXoUsAV9BWErFgO6v1RhGj1jpIOqUeqNwTDxb1Gfk30j9HQLZtrR16OyL4HBSfhGTBFFfU8cLXw3Q6gY/SlhtRzdZRCNCOQhhCuGdmpKPRBz1AsAcVXAIm5Zp1FI3BAiIBH1xODRpqg6Y5t/GS8aiSOi7DRQeBTQL49XBrRH@LCCBNIXBCGJwaCieEw7khUQyLsGVcCE5viVWntY4XZ3b8176DAFT0hKg8PzI/X3R@4Qg9JUobI7VdxOYid6BO60fKwbklWG0846QS4ykRsQd9qkosEa5vof5oiNb/53IrK7XMBb5V4xPxdlXaORGzlLJ@wXIP2oUiz/JccBblCyr8tZqMul1A71wohHn83gkF4ODs8m9UB@p21V83WI9@h/VngnUY3TG@BP51sB25YeTjHBzb92nAhaMxoXilPFJnZC4hSucSwYdzCXptLp0A89HZMJ9Ur0SY4bbXCrnqpGmSbkqV66kCS9poqqvq5DeG7CW@A48zwuQcjI5b8NpjIIsFrCAx0iXrOjX2vXByEmT42mfaUaOSguCzrt7lsLOowE6mz@BL69OczJsHgziJv8SKqiGLn6C3hi/kq5UvDdux6fv4QnSiNIVveP5YWLbK1rAQUswz2kSvQK/wQmZRvT33VZBSE2/qNa2oBy6vshWDVJDNMJfGjKqmf/UE1za38eoMUhOJ@6pLcgsoGkwXJ6S1yD8hqYntSJF/9mhoV46GP9ob36Etx8Od5gULvvNEjPh4Jd7h@hGTsw1vir5vCr2XVSOni1s1jsR1T1yIORBVl7K@0pgsNv51qjDBkI6VIr4CW9HA/tgdqyHzAkoWJjO7APb8QvNwucF2wXJ7AaUggzLTibcLMFkh9zZbkzszpGQ6wWqT@6ZziXlnLmz31HqhJCxQiSbAW5Uh@HbtRas1I7SqMI3fLPPRCHoZd6ZkrTcOch9Ob9hexm1/w19r85T/OqAf8C3uhKg35IXphLTDQLcT4va/vldJP3hsbbsrcg@BKZT8RaZXP5ibBPR8Q/RcEo3DDMoO@Wi7oFCN00VHhLsewuTsccOvesMsXrJXFahoSsPbeCGFv8/VkFwXG7BEQdGA6NdfVKvacSWplFDXnPq1xfHf6fZrLnAk2LZMxwGU7lDhPUd6DK5fBOqpE2IFUlbSFtKgLfr81MSdpCHcYvjrmTg9579QLeiPr5X9XnMoxyqBLp06dnfQl83Uf6N30QqAx0yb7wJqz4moKYCnRVWU227UhTGe5ySLJx1Y49QAvPHVvnPxHzBh6dk5fFmfLclAJWflSytHUzHDNAzV0qazZGMoKKWUE6Zbe@JRwTDqU/2hxHo/vDjHD/GZjTNGjqV6ZNrvA8YvMWCg009eGRTb0OY1ayaVT@Mta/O6wqfqcQoUQB2eNJKXyjjZgip0avmW9UDPLhxC9w4ciT0dWFIbK5fVxDZblZ96m52TA3EwT48ilEta2FwZM9iCy/GLnJ4nSzmVoVa9spmcNntQ1cmwBdk3rcjIw007sutWjd600@26FRnfwlxKBiVT3fJh5muNd48u54ulmpXT5t1h8e7mdCPzwYG0@Nlva2/Yv1zftAOK79LuAtN6R/Hd2lyKdx3DdUd5n23PVhjdhQxP6PI@XXoRpPsT9mm5HtqXbKI@cadWbph3ur/4q4VVUh4c7I4vgmowVUbT3pmg@qJD@ucD0skg@owA6gaedsD5b319mOWU9MRdZUbJyTXayj06PFveVhnOatY9qk5t8IjodOah6vRG5bmHznv547PWr0wYr5Oj7elJ8A3clQ@GBjAMz4OE23BsBqsPClGhfM/bKSy5SP7zgeQ/Hbg4Oj/4YLODoy78XKPnH4jWpjpuqoTyH8CqXkRsOfr2QhkH1Fwc8PE6zTCyQg0P9/Dl0SE/8cMvkwPlNp4XR11gWgQAMdA44xAnwtre/wA) [RunR](https://tio.run/##jVhbd9pIEn5Gv6KDPUHYSIAvSRYbz2Qz8Tl@yLJnnOw@GCcRqJE0FhKrbtkwDvPXvV91t0AC4gR8kFRdl6/r1iWPPBE@PSWpz5lzfn6@32Xn9tiTzaen7t5hVHzSu3C4d1j9DIYXe0OwjiH7dbjXfzWcpIkcTvvjadbtDKe/DI@51T3ZG/LEP2M//jTOrJPDzp7H2n/9xj6kg@2/CndizbIokfYbxz46OHWOm4d2t33UPOh2Dru7vs7Ob3PvhdrMv9nm9n7i41odBfjzNtTB4MP16efXnz8M3g4uNeLhrk0PLad74ADzyZfjp3abfQwjwfDnMQrJn7hPJM9mGccvm6QZC6WciV67zUUae0kg3DQL2g/RXdT@I0/@sKDCy2WYZj0mpCfSCK7PeMw9wX0mUzbLR3E0Zn469aLEsu49aBWsD57/5VHG7cZENJpnlhVNmD3L0jEXwvWy4N6NeRLIkJ332VGTPVq1cZoAAXfjNLDrn4QX8J6CzLI8yVwAP59EMb@oQ1mtUMTnkbTh8zNrqSxT5sD2RLgZ9/xL8F8vknHF7s3RbYs1cjlx3ihcs1yOQ4j22Thk/QtW8Arpp7l0H7JIcnscgrXd3uQFA0jskJ7PGDx1zzMRpYny6yhLHwTPLPJg4WN4cHyXgmsSpw/uOJ22vfark6Pj0@Nu1yqClXDuC/aewtRieRJHd5ylWRREiReb6LnEPKjSEAIukoZkIp/N0kzCeYmjlryxjO452AC2xXiWpZkg7Owh5Il268r4JE/AjS2MeOjdc@SNYB@vBg2B/SDAk3x810JsZZ4lgnUYGN8PLhWcf6USEdMERu4n169Y68NO3bVW2gOuPGk3mYXQx1yyUT6ZcHLtP9WN68VxOrYptDUTThXKTstwthhu1bI2YciuTK8lyjiw1zFeWu2D/2xHpvccHATUqkUTWzmN9fusXm@qqKudYI3HglPa1hRRsd10brFQMyKa5gpUB9f7WK6wkvblQVvlhiS3I@v8HHnH/Ih2wROEMc0TVFjoJZvRt0acz2AAcKsJi9CahG0MX6vspq34owA1Rfmr7yh917Wm8hZ@SKdTsoqK5ok3ijnDGowGliWzBW2UuoFNBdZipg5ahd8QEyBqGUvK49TGQ1vlWqW6FUXTDxs6ONY6Dj9vw1I6VbXTxRWzGK2gMUxIZw1byvgUhcaGGZzGxuhWLJ3gaZhoOReJ8N4DRDuOEt6KlCvp1gQMTaXfbwyzBvtVGbiJbmGqxNBpgYX1WIfskZsfIl@GBZyMUzhtO@Mij2WL5JSFD54M3ak3Ly@YTthskS6KhtYEuHGaBFxIZdbSVmYpNddJlPhf0EwyqbzVZN@@scd5j0pigd@lgeRHVFCPPla68Fx5SXUiLN7cGsK0RCEQUw9lNNd8miPJp1juqNVxnqkkBW2EHldTecwpF4PMm7Lr448Dpk5TwYbHLTSaCGUi8oC2IyipJasXOu69OOd1OqOSVCo1wptyajz1qpm6xgF@coGHAqxgUXqsGvpFkU6bbrJqVLDUAmxStCiiZY4ih3XPQLxQm1w4DviVgLI6N8w3i1s39oS8Snw@H0zsxrXKOJQ9Drg5e9FnlBemzh/nrQV5nEofiV4rNxwboTSI0Gde0KOrjbOXL5l@Oi/ja67UJnkcn5Xl5hW5OeRUDm1LFP2HNqJM3KrL/BbA@2gDPofPcLD/uoulxxo0U1V3MktntkoSs5d1piiqS@tNA1bRy3aaCDeaMft6rZKP6OpoZMiP/cfCSUtm7z8qDMuWvlksm19L24Fe3V5LuMZxNCODaxeT9XPUWOGTTgnVBTs6PV2t4H6H9pJyz7/3EtT3OoTa75gEUHOuPz8zpMWKtNjUgS5GuYlmXcoC090MENKiKfbXH7iDUPb3H/G7hOPv@jf7j8r/y1uqbPU8LQgoFLDid/m1aVChQGM6pUwM19DOTEjVKVcgIKJ4iKjDYzIqqkQ1WZRDb/3Ayg9/N3pUrlfwh09zCqodjZR5yYL5PPYW1Kip@jdOuxZOQhZJ3R/SGQtxPLqktTbCVHCHQ25l4RIWSq7TVEr9XkElABmdqJjBlDHuB@pkCLLIL2m6giadxSqPVvOBS5d3KI230u400a4NhpXgAILm6LL1IOJOsnT6zoipjFyLreU@N3pFweQiVGzbyu9XqNZVt831toqdbg9LAjskPm1LOM9LfNiWOHhe4nedCnRS/I7ICpmtBtaHNLt7LvgPnNEsSrNJkGPUobkVvBkRcsEVa4BHP7qP1JCHBo/kcgt7lwiAPldmfNxj9f/S2EvP1eOFBcCDKYP6T4d0eCOaINAMWpR/IprO4gWClM4E9SdSEEZBqM8dt15YU2N09ajT@iGVrcCKFTo9Nys3XiXoipFcNGnghF3FUnKzmh7QHzFBEbVd9rg@hDZrotFp9NS1a65H5npsrifmemqur8z1tbm@Mdd/mPBpNIdqPN5Vgr8gMfQB/YL6ZikNsNUvozygQOs4wIEqeAKvB3hFyTHxL3QupKrpttQ8gHvSZwsOd3O8FBBL7DfXJvcrVTH9Xlm8BNv0eyW2Znux3gAu22o@rtZllvNnN3ip3rtjendZUKL66u2DQixCLbBuW5WhZguUDY6tYQ6znOGkruZcMO2kd5506ZW55KFmRdzZJX7uWGYP/rwFuFCnbgyRTHaUDZp7DdEpEVlBVPdEVKtroqOIrCBqYO3qvhx9UupRVT/Mlxsu/iE8tgueswWP7YLnVOENh1V8ZXib6NZS3xrFKuTMLrbzyCm4FiuuxQ5lh3SkFZ8tV83Lrlost63sQZzmCqRX8@fF1/K/aXklXh56KqxbUWFMDU4xn8jn8mfb7T9Mqo38Of9@fH4qfQxQnDmhfC6Vdia18@yeNpBePJPp30@lA0jRa69ddTimZw9vj71ier5KEKDI18dqbkbUn5ugMTTXKoE1c7TW3PiUwCqGGfqHAL0RNOiF/f8)

Comment: This is broken for BF+, one minute please

Comment: Fixed it, works now!

Answer (score 3):

## 18. [xEec](https://esolangs.org/wiki/xEec), 271 bytes, cracked by 00Her0

```
1#+iiiiiiiiiokh \#+++++++++++++++O \font\m=cmr10\m14\end ;n+3e
4+0# MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) #!+++++P #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0# >8z@ S5^7^MOAOF h$1 o$ h$8 o$
-1*-10+4_3
```

Previous answer works in [><>](https://tio.run/##jY9LC4JAFEb38ysmhkgdJmd8VCBGbdrJBG0vlvhACccwV/35KYwWplDnu8u7OKeo7qXWgtDqQ3MtgdAhErYE0qRLmyy/AAlXUDSqgzpM61ZwqOfg5kh4BHKVBfg3iwB5lJME248djho5vsG3Qre2Up2xYYZj@cw1qSFsx7QEp2JqbHImmfUxR/yd9wdLxHvheKwqZXTy43Ucyb08vI1hKhoQExZ7OXtnV@sn).

Comment: This works in xEec https://tio.run/##q0hNTf7/31BZOxMG8rMzFGKUtVGBv0JMWn5eSUyubXJukaFBTK6hSUxqXoqCdZ62cSqXibaBsoJvvj8xyN/fl6ugKDOvRMNCV8NIy1TXWFNbw1DfSFPL0EDbEBvUxQo1FZQVwU4LUEB3LCbQ4zIAOdHOospBIdg0zjzO19/R300hQ8VQIV8FSFkAKS5dQy1doBtM4o3//wcA. I need some time to post next answer please.

Answer (score 3):

## 20. [Versert](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Versert), 294 bytes

```
1# 2:0+:@ iiiiiiiiiokh \#+++++++++++++++O \font\m=cmr10\m14\end ;n+3e
4+0# MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM h$1 o$ h$8 o$
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) #!+++++P #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-#19$#&
0+0#;print{4} >8z@ S5^7^MOAOF
-1*-10+4_3
```

#19 is [AsciiDots](https://tio.run/##jY7NCoJAGEX38xRfjIQ6TM3nD5lR2KadTNB2MEINh9AJddXLmwUt@ll07oWzPacu17owfTcMSMGLBYsT0C/MpQJF2TsS1Nk0varXed2iUDUGqmwKWDXML0nABIXUyH8uZUqurW56O@K254bcd5iNc89xUTD8Nf5zDtDJM20Pn7HfzDjFpUWnRDxKN9EtgUOYLbJUbuUOKgvBWKOiUYSjy8eU4OgPwx0).

Fixed rSNBATWPL code according to [this](https://github.com/chunkybanana/do-stuff-online/pull/17).

Comment: Got around to pushing it

Answer (score 2):

## 13. COW 214 bytes, cracked by Dingus

```
4+0#a /z@ iiiiiiiiiokhMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoO
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)#!+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#a ^MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM
-1*-10+4_3
```

Pretty easy, should get cracked fast. I don't know enough languages :/.
Try it online in:
[Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/30TbQDlRQb/KQSETBvKzM3zz/TERV0FRZl6JhoWuhpGWqa6xpraGob6RppahgbYhNqiLFWoqK2qDQICCsjbJQI/LAOzcOEzH@fv7cukaaukCXWMSb/z/PwA)
[Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99E20A5UUG/ykEhEwbyszN88/0xEVdBUWZeiYaFroaRlqmusaa2hqG@kaaWoYG2ITaoixVqKitqg0CAgrI2yUCPywDs3DhMx/n7@3LpGmrpAl1jEm/8/z8A)
[Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI0KzAjYSAvekAgaWlpaWlpaWlpb2toTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PXG5wcmludCg4LSgyKjUtMykrKDEvMikqMTArMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMSkjISsrKysrUCAjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuXG4wKzAjYSBeTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PT09NXG4tMSotMTArNF8zIiwiIiwiIl0=)
[rSNBATWPL](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCI0KzAjYSAvekAgaWlpaWlpaWlpb2toTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PXG5wcmludCg4LSgyKjUtMykrKDEvMikqMTArMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMSkjISsrKysrUCAjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuXG4wKzAjYSBeTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PT09NXG4tMSotMTArNF8zIiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=)
[Heada**](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCI0KzAjYSAvekAgaWlpaWlpaWlpb2toTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PXG5wcmludCg4LSgyKjUtMykrKDEvMikqMTArMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMSkjISsrKysrUCAjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuXG4wKzAjYSBeTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PT09NXG4tMSotMTArNF8zIiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=)
[Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30TbQDlRQb/KQSETBvKzM3zz/TERV0FRZl6JhoWuhpGWqa6xpraGob6RppahgbYhNqiLFWoqK2qDQICCsjbJQI/LAOzcOEzH@fv7cukaaukCXWMSD/QXAA)
[Brainf***](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fRNtAOVFBv8pBIRMG8rMzfPP9MRFXQVFmXomGha6GkZaprrGmtoahvpGmlqGBtiE2qIsVaioraoNAgIKyNslAj8sA7Nw4TMf5@/ty6Rpq6QJdYxJv/P8/AA)
[Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99E20A5UUG/ykEhEwbyszN88/0xEVdBUWZeiYaFroaRlqmusaa2hqG@kaaWoYG2ITaoixVqKitqg0CAgrI2yUCPywDs3DhMx/n7@3LpGmrpAl1jEm/8/z8A)
[Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f/fRNtAOVFBv8pBIRMG8rMzfPP9MRFXQVFmXomGha6GkZaprrGmtoahvpGmlqGBtiE2qIsVaioraoNAgIKyNslAj8sA7Nw4TMf5@/ty6Rpq6QJdYxJv/P8/AA)
[FISHQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJmaXNocTkrIixudWxsLCI0KzAjYSAvekAgaWlpaWlpaWlpb2toTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PXG5wcmludCg4LSgyKjUtMykrKDEvMikqMTArMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMSkjISsrKysrUCAjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuXG4wKzAjYSBeTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PTW9PT09NXG4tMSotMTArNF8zIiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=)
[Neutrino](https://tio.run/##y0stLSnKzMv//99E20A5UUG/ykEhEwbyszN88/0xEVcBUEuJhoWuhpGWqa6xpraGob6RppahgbYhNqiLFWoqK2qDQICCsjbJQI/LAOzcOEzH@fv7cukaaukCXWMSb/z/PwA)
[BitCycle](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/99E20A5UUG/ykEhEwbyszN88/0xEVdBUWZeiYaFroaRlqmusaa2hqG@kaaWoYG2ITaoixVqKitqg0CAgrI2yUCPywDs3DhMx/n7@3LpGmrpAl1jEm/8//@//IKSzPy84v@6pQA)

Comment: [COW](https://tio.run/##S84v///fRNtAOVFBv8pBIRMG8rMzfPP9MRFXQVFmXomGha6GkZaprrGmtoahvpGmlqGBtiE2qIsVaioraoNAgIKyNslAj8sA7Nw4TMf5@/ty6Rpq6QJdYxJv/P8/AA "COW – Try It Online")

Comment: 20 mins. Nice one! It was pretty obvious though... Mostly just wanted to get a funny language in here.

Answer (score 2):

## 15. BrainF*ck+, 430 bytes, Should Be Very Easily Cracked By whqwert

```
1#+iiiiiiiiiokh-\ #+++++++++++++++O\ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>14#+iiiiiiiiiokh-\catcode`\#=6\font\m=cmr10\m
14#\end;
4+0#a /z@ MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoO
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)#!+++++P #++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
0+0#a ^MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM
-1*-10+4_3
```

For this language it ends in an error, but that is supposed to be allowed.

Comment: If you don't mind answering this, is it significant that there are two "iiiiiiiiiokh"s?

Comment: Actually it is a typo, so no, it isn't significant. @00Her0

Answer (score 2):

## 19. [AsciiDots](https://tio.run/#%23jY7NCoJAGEX38xRfjIQ6TM3nD5lR2KadTNB2MEINh9AJddXLmwUt@ll07oWzPacu17owfTcMSMGLBYsT0C/MpQJF2TsS1Nk0varXed2iUDUGqmwKWDXML0nABIXUyH8uZUqurW56O@K254bcd5iNc89xUTD8Nf5zDtDJM20Pn7HfzDjFpUWnRDxKN9EtgUOYLbJUbuUOKgvBWKOiUYSjy8eU4OgPwx0), 278 Bytes, Cracked by stasoid

```
1#+iiiiiiiiiokh \#+++++++++++++++O \font\m=cmr10\m14\end ;n+3e
4+0# MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM
print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) #!+++++P #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-#19$#&
0+0# >8z@ S5^7^MOAOF h$1 o$ h$8 o$
-1*-10+4_3
```

Try it online in [Ruby](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkaorn9wYoouriVCK6hglppkSZS6qAvH6vgoHbwfB@c9TTX/c05pLx6Y88laMo/UaBP1rS6nh/qBqWuMdaFOcLM8KggMZcUMqv@uVIZuTSVaf1U@GGQiIhxH8chC1By7JvoHQM6eKVt4Dv2l5GgOPXokMhn6SK9L2Gb5JM8Uyu1htJDsF6ntBMRGIguJd5Fzj0A) [Jelly](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkborn9wYoouriVCF1DHbTSaptI6aIvH6vgoHbwfB@c9ZyLur5Zi5RVb8ylBEXZJxLUyehONctD06JQDUaq0EdYaBYWJGKCQmrkP5cyJde20p2bcDfwYx56zMVp4PkoGA6ND84DOnql7eA79pcJpzh36JiIZ@kqua8hi/NZnsqN3ELpIBinV9KLcPR5nxLtQ2sf) [Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2ggXFwjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrTyBcXGZvbnRcXG09Y21yMTBcXG0xNFxcZW5kIDtuKzNlXG40KzAjIE1vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT09PTVxucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpICMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLSMxOSQjJlxuMCswIyA+OHpAIFM1XjdeTU9BT0YgaCQxIG8kIGgkOCBvJFxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiJd) [rSN](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2ggXFwjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrTyBcXGZvbnRcXG09Y21yMTBcXG0xNFxcZW5kIDtuKzNlXG40KzAjIE1vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT09PTVxucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpICMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLSMxOSQjJlxuMCswIyA+OHpAIFM1XjdeTU9BT0YgaCQxIG8kIGgkOCBvJFxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd) [Heada**](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2ggXFwjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrTyBcXGZvbnRcXG09Y21yMTBcXG0xNFxcZW5kIDtuKzNlXG40KzAjIE1vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT09PTVxucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpICMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLSMxOSQjJlxuMCswIyA+OHpAIFM1XjdeTU9BT0YgaCQxIG8kIGgkOCBvJFxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd) [Python 3](https://tio.run/##jZA9C8IwFEX3/IonKdI0RPP6gRVRdHErEbqGOmilRZqU0kX/fI2Cg9rBcy/c9XDbW19ZEw0DUl6/sdcKNOWfKNAXa3rdrE9Nh1I3GOvSnGFleFSSmEsKmVX/VKmMtF1tej8VfhgkImLcx3nIApQcxyJGw4BOXmoH@Jb9ZSYoLj06JfJpuknvW8iTYlFkaqf2UHkI1nOTuiECA@FU4qP75QE) [Brainf***](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwGEX3PMUnKdI2RPP1Byui6OJWIriGitaWltJESl18@VgFB38Gz71w1nPqjrUur3ljLVJWvzBNBYqydySo0uhetcu87VCoFiNV6DMsNAsLEjFBITXyn0uZkktX695NuBv4MQ895uI08HwUDH@N/5wHdPRM28Fn7DcTTnHu0DERj9JVclvDPs5mWSo3cguVg2CcQckgwtHnQ0p0CK29Aw) [Runic Enchantments](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkaorn9wYoouriVCF1DHWqlRZpIqYsvH6vgoHbwfB@c9XQ305TOIeXNG3upQVP@iQJ9tqbX7bpsO5S6xVhX5gQrw6OKxFxSyKz650pl5No1pvdT4YdBIiLGfZyHLEDJcWxidAzo5JV2gO/YX2aC4tKjUyKfpZv0voU8KRZFpnZqD7WHYL1B6SAiMBBDSnyMnHsA) [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##jY7NCoJAFEb38xQ3RkIdpub6Q0YUtWknE7gdjEhFCWfCXPXykwUtKhed74OzPUV5KqrmVnNrkbLmjbnUoCj7RIKqjO5Vuz63HQrVYqRKXcBKs7AkERMUUiP/uZQpuXaN7t2Eu4Ef89BjLs4Dz0fBcGx8dB7QySvtAN@xv8w4xaVDp0Q8SzfJfQtZnC/yVO7kHmoHwTiDkkGEo8@HlOgYWvsA) [FISHQ9+](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJmaXNocTkrIixudWxsLCIxIytpaWlpaWlpaWlva2ggXFwjKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrTyBcXGZvbnRcXG09Y21yMTBcXG0xNFxcZW5kIDtuKzNlXG40KzAjIE1vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT01vT09PTVxucHJpbnQoOC0oMio1LTMpKygxLzIpKjEwKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMSsxKzErMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEpICMhKysrKytQICMrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLSMxOSQjJlxuMCswIyA+OHpAIFM1XjdeTU9BT0YgaCQxIG8kIGgkOCBvJFxuLTEqLTEwKzRfMyIsIiIsIiIsIiJd) [Neutrino](https://tio.run/##jY6xCsIwFEX3fMWTFGkbonlNixVRdHErEVxDHbTSIk2k1MWfj1FwUDt47oU73mOqW981xjqHlDVv7KUGTdknCvTZml63y2PbodAtproyJ1gYJiuSMkGhsOqfKlWQq3/tw5yHSZxxGbEQp0kUo2A4FD6YCOjopbaDb9lfJpziPKBjIp6mq/y@hn1WzspCbdQW6gDBBn5yP4RjzL1KepDOPQA) [BitCycle](https://tio.run/##jY7NCoJAGEX38xRfjIQ6TPn5Q0YUtWknE7QdDDJDKWfEbFEP32RBi34WnXvhbM@2bLNLdsyNQcrKF/pQgKTsHQFyr1Urq2lWNejJCkOZqx1MFAtyEjKPQqLFPxciIXVTqtaOue27EQ8cZuPQd1z0GP4a/zkHaO@ZtoLP2G8GnOLYon3iPUpn8XUO6ygdpYlYiCUUFoK2OsWdCEeXdynhJjDmpuu21Opk@PkO) [COW](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkaorn9wYoouriVCF1DHWqlRZpIKQi@fKyCg9rB831w1lPam3NIefPGXmrQlH@iQJ@t6XW7LtsOpW4x1pU5wcrwqCIxlxQyq/65Uhm5do3p/VT4YZCIiHEf5yELUHIcmxgdAzp5pR3gO/aXmaC49OiUyGfpJr1vIU@KRZGpndpD7SFYb1A6iAgMxJASHyPnHg) [TeX](https://TeX,%20278%20bytes:%20%5B%601#+iiiiiiiiiokh%20%5C#+++++++++++++++O%20%5Cfont%5Cm=cmr10%5Cm14%5Cend%20;n+3e%204+0#%20MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOOOM%20print(8-(2*5-3)+(1/2)*10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1)%20#!+++++P%20#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-#19$#&%200+0#%20%3E8z@%20S5%5E7%5EMOAOF%20h$1%20o$%20h$8%20o$%20-1*-10+4_3%60%5D(https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724JLViRbSSbmZeplLsgqWlJWm6FrcYxQyVtTNhID87QyFGWRsV-CvEpOXnlcTk2ibnFhkaxOQamsSk5qUoWOdpG6dymWgbKCv45vsTg_z9fbkKijLzSjQsdDWMtEx1jTW1NQz1jTS1DA20DbFBXaxQU0FZEey0AAV0x2ICPV1lQ0sVZTUuA5BL7SyqHBSCTePM43z9Hf3dFDJUDBXyVYCUBZDi0jXU0gU6xSTeGBI80FBaAKUB)) [Brainf***+](https://tio.run/##7Vzrk5vIEf@uv2JudRXAelha2xVHt2zl4thVrsS3js/JF8RRLIwkbAQYBu/Kiv52p3uGhxAPgWSf7yqHbQlBd09Pz697el6@NaPV58/Bhq187xEZXV1dfT8lV7JlMuXz52l/4KSX/35F5v1B8boh84XvsflatdbhdDJfTx/PqWeTH7zBI9p7PJj0ySv/ps3fm5tXvSB0PCY/HcmXD56MHikDefrwUnkwnQymVX9GlX8U0v@Oq/aaHCpbvsaj/vQv3/f/1JugptdPP/2V/Pzklz//8urmx5sXZAWW8L@Hr6fw1RtNH4xAlcfGo899smIsiGYPHy4dtopvx5a/fvj2o@9/emUuPWfhWNRjD/8Wmo73Irbev3bj6KXHaBiEFD57fbL2baQymeN70QwejEgUUMtZbEgQ@svQXJOF41LPXFNiRnAfRoyY4TJeg2BO7vnE8l0fDLbswYOX68APWc/hXyTaRPDsmW/TnrMgb8OYznoELnzmRcz0WMR/F17iZdAw9ENVkvInd2boFR74MQtiVnjkeIdPQLGlU@SDuscoau7lDznjh9hnVF1I24RktxUCdy/xk3iU2tQG0tQ0M5JRXl9fk70iVE16/uaNpD940uslFX4Rexa3Mv9t0wWYLdjIrpJXWsgirhMxWeNvDYUs/JAYWKirK2gntgkocKkqkhHqRpS4SSEoNPY@OYHMaMQMJChL1yRp/M53PFlzuGxnSN6h@IxFV4YZT3pp72po9b2iASgAKmrLwuamO3xPaVDWQKjIaylYZNdc39omuZ@Re22iYwnIORSWQOJMYmh6SypPhgDJ7KEirszSz1wzEla28I7DL1cCNTWgXR1mGHJE3cUQGsKme2rihS/G@Jyo/HWB3XKp6Rn4mAs4YO2L4JFJGEeB6zBZ6kuKNptd6kqBOrFJ2igtuFCDJWW15ScShaRc07IAn61oaKxMdyHs4Hg2vT8QZq3M0LSgjcAOXGJWsqJxer1A7k6h0S6BVpK17dVw/FAaSoq@u/5hNp9LBUpAci4b0X05K6EuomZordTDcmeiYDDLaKrXMBkIVxX00dzLMaeXs@KUIhO6UOuyuajZTNem8HGk7EvNnR4p26N3XLKwPY0M4MvcSEgbahnzMJd/gCLqOmtwBRG9MvrdNmfYFc1/t4KonrNhC6S6lG3hgFbp26RCGadSok4p1fQGGkwfZD8cbjz@r1xQYgU1veGs2Y86VtOL7jhCM8oDbXMzHNi/DQoTf@KSoL@TRWmDaaUfpy@F0iWXc30/MCAtqXe4atyd45MGXhjGUrZjHktqXDYDK2lAKwgcuJeDHPDVOI2AFdxDg@YFP3F00b1gE4gIj/HdnSoHzWV41hBCt63yzjHVRxnyn6lSyiELFAWf2gw5E0AIy@tkwN@UXgwOEcYLxY8qKQP@ovSclKQIpxPtATWFosto29fXsxKBnCVX9@A5PK5yJlQIRQmtq2RxtY8L403j8cQntXFFjFhwGs9nvGpwP0jAWKbdB9NeaEkCO4jP7cgVzWNH@f2gqur7sWQ/LNQVkEeYFgWIVjS9jaxVxk9ur8KbHPW6UrZGA3m16cDULQP3aQG8uYmKDdIQzJsbomj2GjH7obcirAvEDi71QpwFUitmNM3tqOtGKmSVcBuHEYwpxL0fONRWf/I9CGc4VDGBarsbkkWapvNfkWlRFUcmcGtZ/O4w2@M0hMzIzyv/jvxosdh0IeVcr03PjshzoYx9yGNZJON5FochjKbIM1S1QBhASggxVJ0U479ok6YuAiACRZQB0S89EckqjnlwfLXLBjSpUtx@MNDh3zvoHChGQkGkVPhFovIVBvCKvJo3EqTtTOX4Saj1qnCCdq2GdL/yaV1NRBPA8BRqwYuGWtRWgneJvhgPQy7Fa729uBDJuawtLrSts9Mv8u5KgEpXlIMEK6lEWltV@pc066L2g8vd69C3aISDbs@JVjDyvN0AuB0mADCXPswlqdp7E78xSi/B6xeZRh9qNOqT5x9i56MJTchm5Dak5vumUriNUu9KPStzqj2PatYGKtO9taU5E41ZZYmC@IuTpHstpd/USAcjxlSl8CWnqFLqYroTOXxKxKIyZ4P0kCn1MT3HjZgH2W05165e4/rBTlkmn36pgPRB15VPlRwn/WdiAIglHCo7sjIjcpyPV4sktRu2YMAZErLl8yScSWnFBeGaWKaHCcwthYYNqcXcDRHGHZMOFX3@5g2fuQBWqb53beejfhOwMIk@DVsR5vBN6BLAFbS1RCzczBqtUcaotQrTRmkGKrfEvUUDRv6D9M8RkG1La4fejgg@B8UnIVkwJRl1MvF1P51O4FLaciOq2SqOANpxBF0It8yMdKz0XgsQbEEFp4BJtWYdRaOzgEjAB5fTgIZGpzke23jKeJBJHabhooGgTgL4zXA7iv4WHkCOucAJbnCqK5zgDue6RNktopZ@ITj9BWad1iqZnNnyr10HAajoCV55vmd@Oe/8yh56ipce9dR2Hlvw3IE6be4pB@emYI3@jINK9KdUxA70qUuxhLu@hfzjiLf@P6dbeapl2riqxgfi7bK0czxmIeXtgukelAtJnuV7YCzKJ1T4spqMul1A61wohPn82QkJ4ODs9G/UBOp22V83WI/@gPUXgnUU3zI@Bf5tsB17URzgGBzLD2jIhWNlIrGkPFJnZC4hSucSwZdzCVptLp0A89HZMJ/Uz0SY0abXCrnq5Ngg3ZRq51MFlrTRVFfVye8M2QtcA08iwuQcjI5b8DpjIEsELCEw0gXrOjQO/GhyEmT43GfWUKOKhOCLzt4VsGPXYCfXZ/C19TkezI93BkkQf4kZ1ZEofoLeGi7I1ytf6bZjMwhwQXSiHHPf6Py@sGqW7chESDnOaBO9Br3CCnmNmutzVwcpNbWm3lCKumfyurqikwqyGcbShFHV9G8e4NrGNp6dQWgiSVt1CW4hxQpT@4SwFgcnBDWxHSkOzu4Nndre8GdnHbi0ZX@41fzQ5jtPRI@Pd2INN4iZnG94U/TdMdd7WddzerhV40Bc98CFmANRTSHrG/XJYuNfpwwTKtIxU8QlsCUNnU/dsRoxP6TENpnZBbDnJ5r70w2OBzV3bEgFGaSZbrJdgMkKuXPYityaESXTCWab3DadU8xb03a8U/OFCrdAJY4B3qp1wbcrP16uGKF1iWmyssx7I2hl3JmSl360k/t4esHOIin7O76szUP@65B@xFXcCVGvyQvTjWiHjm4rxO1@e0tJP/ls5XhLcgeOKZT8VYZXP5nrFPR8Q/RcEoXDCMqJeG9rU8jGqd0R4Z6PMDm73wjqVpjFIntdgopVObIaL6Tw9VwNyXWxAUskFEcQ/fqratXYr6SZEupaUL8xOf4H3XzLCY4U25bpuoDSLSq840hPwPWrQD0zQqJAxkraQhq0RZufGrjTMIRbDH87A6fn/AvVgvb4VtHvNYdyohLo0qlht3tteZz67/Q2XgLwmOnwXUDtORE1JfC0yIoK2426MCbjnHTypANrEhqAN7nbdU7@QyZqenYMXzRHSzJQyVnx0irQ1IwwDUO1tOks3RgKSinVhNnWnqRXMIzmUL8vsdkOL86xQ3Jm44yeY6EeVO2PDuPX6DDQ6CfPDIptaPOGOZPat8mWtXlT4lP3OgMKoA5PGskLZZxuQRU6tVxl3dOzC4fQvQNHWp8OLFkda6fVxDZblZ96m50TA7Ezz44iVEuyHa6MGW7A5PhDzs6TZZzKUKuf2UxPm92r6mTYguy7VmTk/rod2VWrQq/b6XbVioxvYa4kg5Spafowt7XGm0eXi8lSw8zp8d1hye7mbCPz3oG05N3va2/Yv73AdEKKa2m3oWm9p7i2NpeSXcdw31HeF9uzFcW3EcMTurxNF34M4f6EfVqej/VLN1GfuFOr0M273Rf@GmGVpgd7u@PLoBpMldG0dyaovmqX/uWAdDKIviCAuoGnHXD@25wf5jElO3FXG1EKco22cg8Oz1aXVYWzhnmPulMb3CM6nXmoO71Re@6h817@5Kz1KxP66/Roe3YSfA1P5b2uASqG50GiTTQ2w@VHhaiQvhfrKWpykf7nA@l/OnBxcH7w3mF7R134uUY/2BOtTXXcVAnpP4BVvYjZYvT0QhmH1LT3@HieZhh5ooaHe/j06JCf@OG36YFyB8@Loy4wLAKAGFg5Yx8nora9/wE) [RunR](https://tio.run/##jVhbd9pIEn5Gv6KMvUEYJMCOJxlsPJPNxOf4IcuecbL7YJxEoAZpLCRWLdmwDvvXs191t0Bc4sTOcUvVdfm6bl3K0JPBt29x4gtyLi4ujjp0YY@8rP7tW@ewERY/yX1Ag8PG5k@fBuMkzgbT3miadtqDaeflQMQ@nceNU2G9bLQP6X3S/5l//f57a5aGcWa/duyT4zPntN6wO62T@nGn3ejs@3X2/tbp8EBB@ydtg939cZ3Dzq9Hhy@sNiO9fP3f3@nm7NOrT@/7b/pXFMATyRGW11gsp3PsAMrLz6ffWi36EISS8M8j9ttfeI4zkc5Sgb80TlIKsmwmu62WkEnkxRPpJumk9Rjeh60/8/hPCyq8PAuStEsy82QS@ueUikh4UviUJTTLh1E4Ij@ZemFsWQ8etErqgec/eZgKuzaWtfq5ZYVjsmdpMhJSul46eXAjEU@ygC56dFKnJ6sySmIgEG6UTOzqR@lNRFdBpjSPUxfAL8ZhJC6rUFYpFIl5mNlw5bm1VJZHzN8DADcVnn8F/ptFPNqwe3ty16Rano2d1wrXLM9GAUR7NAqod0kFr8z8JM/cxzTMhD0KwNpqbfOCASRq8Ps5wVMPIpVhEiu/DtPkUYrUYg8WPoYHR/cJuMZR8uiOkmnLa/3y8uT07LTTsYpgxUL4kt5xmJqUx1F4LyhJw0kYe5GJnsvM/U0aQiBkXMtI5rNZkmZwXuyoLW@UhQ8CbADbJJGmSSoZOz0GItZuXRkf5zG4cYShCLwHgbyR9OG6X5M4DwI8zkf3TcQ2y9NYUpvA@K5/peD8I8kQMU0gdj@7fsVaHbSrrrXSPhHKk3adLIQ@EhkN8/FYsGv/rh5cL4qSkc2hrZhwqlC2m4azSXhU29qEIbtZcpOhOif2OsZLq3X8r93IdJ@Dg4BalXBsK6dRr0fVal1FXZ0EeyKSgtO2ooiK7bZ9h42KEdE0V6I6hD7HcoWVtS@PWyo3MnY7ss7PkXfkh3wKESOMSY7@lAVevB19ayjEDAYAdzNhEVqTsLXBK5XdfBR/OEFNcf7qJ07fda2pvIUfkumUraKiRewNI0HYg9GJZWXpgg/K3cDmAmuSqYNm4TfEBIiaxpLyONryKLBVrm1Ut6JoeqOmg2Ot4/DzNiylU1U7L66cRWgFtUHMOis4UiqmKDQapHAajdCtKBnjbRBrOReJ8M4DRDsKY9EMlSv50QQMTaXXqw3SGv2mDNyGdzBVYmg3uYV3qc322M2PoZ8FBZxUcDhtOxUyj7ImyykL770scKfevLxhOmG9ybo4GloT4EZJPBEyU2YtbWWWcHMdh7H/Gc0kzZS36vT1Kz3Nu1wSC/xdGkh@yAX15GOnA8@Vt1QnwubtnSFMSxQGMfVQRnPNpznifIrtttod5alKUtCG6HEVlceCc3GSelO6Of3QJ3VJShqcNtFoQpSJzCd8HMlJnVG10PHgRbmo8h0VJ5lSI72p4MZT3TRT1TjAzy7wUIAbWJQeq4J@UaTTtpusChcstwCbFS2KaJmryKHOOYiX6pALxwG/ElBW54b5dnHnRp7MrmNfzPtju3ajMg5ljwtuTgc94rwwdf40by7Y41z6SPRKueHYCKVBhD5zwK@uNk4vXpB@uyjjq6/UxnkUnZfl5htyc8ipHNqVKPoPH0SZuFPL/A7Ae2gDvoDPcLH/to@lSzWqnW@dZJbMbJUk5izrTFFUl/frBqyil@3UEW40Y/pyo5KP6epqJOTH0VPhpCXZR08Kw7KpHxbL@pfScaBXt9cSrlEUztjg2sVs/QI1VvikXUJ1SSdnZ6sdPO/RXlLu@Q9ejPpeh1D7HZMAas715@eGtFiRFts60MU4N9GsS1lgupsBwlo0xf7yA3cwyt7RE/4u4fj73u3Rk/L/8o4rW71PCwIKBaz4u/xSN6hQoBHfUiaGa2jnJqTqlisQMFE@htzhMRkVVaKaLMqhu36h8sv/al0u12v4w@c5BdWORkpevCBfRN6CGzVX/9Zt18RNSGGm@0MyowDXo8taK0NMBfe45FYWrmCh5DpN5dTvFlQGkPKNihlMGRP@RN0MkzT0S5quoUlnscqj1Xzg8vIWpfEms9t1tGuDYSXYh6C5umw9iLjjNJm@NWIqI9dia7lPtW5RMLkMFNuu8ocVqnXV7XK92cTOj42SwB6Jj7sSzvMS73cljp@X@EOnAt8UfyCyMktXA@tjkt4/F/xHQTyL8mwyyTHq8NwK3pQJuRSKdYJXP3wI1ZCHBo/kcgt7VwiAvldmYtSl6r957OX3zeuFJsCDKYP7T5t1eEOeINAMmpx/MpzOogWClMwk9ydWEISTQN87brWwpsbozatO64dUugIrV@j03KzceB2jK4bZos4DJ@wqlpKb1fSA/ogJiqmtssf1JbRdE7V2ravWjllPzHpq1pdmPTPrL2Z9ZdbXZv3VhE@jaajxeF8J/g2JoS/oA@6bpTTAUT8P8wkHWscBDlTBk/g8wCdKjol/oXMhUU23qeYBPLM@Wwq4W@CjgFkiv742ebRRFdPvlcULsE2/V2JrtoP1AbDsqvmw2s/SXDx7wCv13R3xt8uCE9VXXx8cYhlogXXb2hhqdkDZ4NgZ5jDLGU7uas4laSe99TKXP5lLHqpviDv7xC8cy5zBnzcBF@rUgyGyybaywXOvITolIhVE9cxEtbsmOopIBVEDa22ey9E3pR5V9ct8ueXiH8KjffCcHXi0D56zCW8w2MRXhreNbi31tVbsQs6cYjePnIJrseJa7FHW4Cut@Nlx1bzsqsVy18ohxHmuQHrVf158Lf@7llfi5aFng3UnKkRqcIrEOHsuf3bd/sOk2sqfi@/H56fSxwDFnRNkz6XS3qR2nj3TFtLLZzL9@6l0DCn@7LU3HY7p2cPXY7eYnq9jBCj09bWamxH15yZoDM2VjcCaOVprrn2MYRXDDP@HAH8R1PiD/f8) [><>](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkborn9wYoouriVCF1DHbSlRZpI7eTLxyg4qB083wdnPXV7a6xFyto35tKAouwTCao2elDd@tT1KFSHiar0GVaaxRVJmKCQG/nPpczJtW/14Gfcj8KUxwHzcR4FIQqGY@OjC4BOXmkH@I79ZcYpLj06JeJZusnuWyjSclHmcif30HgIxnPKnAjHkLuU5Bhb@wA) [xEec](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFEb3PMWVFGkborn9wYoouriVCF1DHWqkRZpI6SC@fKyCg9rB831w1nPTunIOKWve2EsNirJPJKizNb1q11XboVAtJkqbE6wMizVJmKCQW/nPpczJtWtM72fcj8KUxwHzcR4FIQqGY@OjC4BOXmkH@I79ZcYpLj06JeJZusnuWyjSclHmcif3UHsI1huUDSIcQz6kJMfYuQc)