# Peel away the layers - Cops

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity, cops-and-robbers, code-generation, obfuscation

In this [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge, robbers must crack cop answers by finding out which languages the cops used.

This is the **Cops** thread. For the Robbers' challenge, see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/212069/66833)

Cops, you are to write a program, which, when executed in a specific language, does one of the following:

1. Outputs one of the 5 phrases below
2. Outputs a piece of code, which when executed in a specific language (not necessarily the same language as the first program), does either point 1. or point 2. This may be either a function or a full program, and should [output in a reasonable method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

That is, the first program should output the code for the second, which outputs for the third, and so on, until the final program outputs one of the below phrases. If any of the codes uses non-ASCII characters, you should output the *bytes* that represent the program, not the characters.

None of the programs may be longer than \$65535\$ bytes long, to keep it somewhat sane.

**You may repeat languages**, but the languages you choose should all meet all of the following criteria:

- It has [an English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_programming_languages), [an esolangs.org article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) or [a Rosetta Code article](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Languages) at the time this challenge was posted, or is on [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#). Having an interpreter linked in any of these pages makes that interpreter completely legal.

  - Given that the influx of languages to TIO has been paused, languages that [have been requested to be added](https://gist.github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/46f79623ea7b5cfe67286d0a5e96d307), but haven't yet been added, are also legal languages
- It must satisfy our rules on [what constitutes a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/8478)
- It must have a free interpreter (as in beer), per [site standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7822/66833) for [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) posts

The phrases you may choose from are:

- `Game Over!`
- `Greetings!`
- `Code Golf.`
- `It's Done.`
- `The Last 1`

Despite being a possible interpretation of the initial task, you may *not* write a program which simply outputs one of these phrases, to avoid the challenge being to similar to [an existing challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz). Your submission must use a **minimum of 2 languages**

In your answer, you should reveal the following information:

- The number of layers your submission has (note "layers", not "languages")
- The initial code that will output all following layers (but *not* the language this code was written in)
- The final outputted phrase

The robbers will be attempting to guess the languages you've used for each layer. Each robber must crack your entire submission for it to be a valid crack.

Note that a crack is valid *even if the languages are different*. So long as the robber's languages, in the order they state them, produce the specified final phrase, the crack is valid, even if the languages are not the same as yours.

If your answer has not been cracked within 14 days, you can claim it as safe. You should reveal the languages used and the codes in said languages. Note that your answer is not safe until you've revealed the languages and code and robbers can still crack your answer until then. The submission which is safe and uses the **least amount of distinct languages** wins!

### Formatting

Cops, please format your original answer as so:

```
# <N> layers

    <code>

<Final output>

---
```

And, when cracked, please edit in the following format (underneath the `---`):

```
Languages used (in order):

- [<language 1>](<link to interpreter>), outputted <output>
- [<language 2>](<link to interpreter>), outputted <output>
...
- [<language N>](<link to interpreter>), outputted <final phrase>

---

<anything else>
```

and you should edit your header to read

```
# <N> layers, cracked by [<robber>](<link to robber's post>)
```

If your answer is safe, edit this into the title, along with the complete list of intended languages. **Your answer can still be cracked until you do**.

Good luck!

Comment: [Sandbox 1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14824/66833). [Sandbox 2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19370/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops)

Comment: Do different major versions of a langauge count as distinct languages?

Comment: @Sisyphus I'll say that different versions count as different languages if that *specific* version meets the language requirements above. As Python 2 and 3 are both on TIO as different languages, yes they count as different languages

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing no fair! I was preparing an answer where you would have to find the specific commit of the language to get it to work

Comment: A tower of [TrivialBrainfuckSubstitutions](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Trivial_brainfuck_substitution) anyone?

Comment: Good idea adding the TIO restriction. Else I would have won in two layers using a language that is beyond obscure.

Comment: @user I'm not going to make a case by case ruling, if it falls under our [standard definition for "program"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/66833), its fair game

Comment: Those phrases - do we need those exact Unicode (or ASCII) characters? For example, can we use Unicode's left single quote for "It's done"? It would save me an escape

Comment: @user No, you should output one of those exact phrases, using the same *characters* as shown

Comment: @user It's also not code golf, so you don't need to worry too much about saving characters in this case.

Comment: This seems to have a lot less traffic than I expected

Comment: @user Well, you can never predict what people will enjoy and what they‘ll skip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 2 layers, safe!

```
"D0Up0IZUnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnUU5nnnnnn3SUUnUUUwCiudIbEAt33wwWt0GD3wwpDDGDDDGpDDwGGtpDt33333sw03333sDDfBDKgGQskWwQ" "1 gfnY ruG" '" +\
```

Output: `The Last 1`

This one will hopefully stand for a bit longer.

Hint: Both languages are available on TIO. That's only \$681^2\$ possibilities to try!

---

Solution:

> [Foo](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fycUgtMDAMyo0DxOEhppCGMbBoaFAXmi5c2ZpimeSq2OJsXF5eXiJgbsLkC5wcXF3AWIgXe7uXlLgApQFguJyAzDl4pLm5OKd7h5YnB1eHqikoGSokJ6WF6lQVOqupKCupKAd8/8/AA) followed by [Bubblegum](https://tio.run/##bZBRSwMxDMff/RR5FyTXJA3zTa0cw6chZSi@rPM2RB3D3dGPf6a3uqEYaJq2//yaJA0pfXTb4XMcsdo1MBOCiCIQ8gxkJQK@891fBwHjHufPcVft4khojPGfvjqjiVBFwu5sMcqJ4X4xiIQsaapjSjenygR@pnJk0GOMRoj57m2oDCoMtg68YwFulA1EZJmqIFqOyFraJYDXebq/6YlyXvbYBqoMNsakV2Q26aT/ieqdvbLaEXLeh9AGW7bntq0MKQy2cZq0llCdlmJs2Oc76PehLxEdMpatMnxh0PSd98CuRMmXj6WxB59KQ9ZVQw3AIYTNbXjYtovD@zIvmspQYzi0JO9tpjJzCOpsfqwWuSRrwBWcbLvZPcHX0MLly9U4fgM).
>
>  The idea here is that the Bubblegum string is printable ASCII but also a valid DEFLATE stream. The solution was zipped with [ascii-zip](https://github.com/molnarg/ascii-zip), which was originally designed to exploit the [Rosetta Flash](https://molnarg.github.io/ascii-flash/#/) vulnerability but has also found esoteric use in CTFs, such as [PlaidCTF 2019 Potent Quotables](https://blog.pspaul.de/posts/plaidctf-2019-potent-quotables/). The first layer is also valid CJam, but this is a red herring. The `1 gfnY ruG` is also designed to mislead; in fact everything after the last `1` can be discarded.
>
>  Note that Bubblegum meets Code Golf's definition of 'programming language', but only on a [technicality](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum#Examples).

Comment: `"1 gfnY ruG"` is rot13 of reverse of the output.

Comment: The first layer is also valid Stax, as I discovered thanks to some futile `grep -iRl rot.*13` operations on TIO's `/opt` directory. Nice trap!

Answer (score 29):

## 840,527,321,220,386 layers, safe

```
D'`Aq9\n[;|FyDUv4tc+OMLKJJHZG4~ffT@RQ>v{)LxZponm3qSongled*bJ`_^$bD`_XW{[Z<RWVUNr54JONMFKDhH*)E>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDZ_^]VUyYRWPOsS5KPIm0/EDhH*)?>b%A@9]=6;492V6543210/('K+$)"Fg%${z@xwv{t:xZputm3TSohmlkd*bJ`_^$baZ~XW\UTx;QVONMqQ3IHGLEihBG@?cC%;@?>7[;:9870v.3,P*p.-&J$j"!E}eBz!x}vu;yxwpun4rqji/gfedcb(`H^]\"!_X]V[ZYXQuONMLKPOHlLEJCBf@(>b%;:^>=}|Y9876/SR,1*/.'K%*#"!Efe#z@~}v{zyr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`H^]\"!_X]V[ZYXQuONMLKPOHlFKDhHAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/('K+$#Gh~%${z!x>|utsxq7uWmrk10nmledihg`&Gcb[`_^W{[ZYXW9OTSLKPImlFKDCgGFE>=B;_?>=6;:981U54321q)M-,%$#G'&}eB"!x}v{zyr8pun4Ukj0hmlkdcba'Hdcb[`_^W{[Z<;QPUNMLKo21GLEi,+GFE>=aA#9>7[;:9870v.3,P*)(-&J$j"!E}eBz!x}vu;yxZpo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzyS;WPOsSLKPOHGk.JCHGF?>b%A@9]=6;492V6543210/('K+$)"F&}|{Abaw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9876/.R,10/('K%*#G'&}eB"y~w=^zyrwp6tVUkpoh.ledchg`_^$baC_^WVzZYRWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBfF?DCB;_?>=6;4X2765.R21qp.-&J$j"!E}eB"!x}v{zyr87unmlqj0QPfkjchg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsS54JOHlFKJIBA@E>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNr54JONMFKDhH*)E>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`Y^WVUySXQPUNMq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9]7<543870T4321*/.'K%*#"!E}$#"!x>|{ts9qpon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$baC_^WVzZYRWVUNrLQJINGkK-CHGF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,PO)o'&%I)i'~%|B"yx>v{t:xqYun4rqpohg-ejihg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsrq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9>=6Z:98705.RQ1*/.'K%*#"!E}$#"!x>=u;yrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvPOsSRKJIHl/KDCHAFE>C<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*b(fHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQ3IHGLEiCBA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9876/.R21*p.-&J$j"!E}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9>=<5Y98765.-Q1*/.'K%*#"!E%|#"y?}vu;yxZputm3TSohmlkd*Ka`edc\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhH*)?>b<;:?8\6;492V05.3,10/('K+$)"Fg%${z@a}|uzs9wvuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9870T4-21*/(L&+$)"!E}eB"y~w=uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9876/.R,+Op(-&J*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,Pqp.-&J*j('&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"`_X]V[TxRQVONMLp3INMFjD,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;4XW765432+*N.',%I#('~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun4rqpohg-ejihg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsrq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9>=6Z:98705.RQ1*/.'K%*#"!E}$#"!x>=u;yrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8TSRQJONMLEiCBA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9270/.R21*N('&%I)i'~%|B"yx>|u]s9qYun4lkpi/gfedcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9876/.R,10/('K%*#G'&}eB"!x}v{zyr8pun4Ukjong-eMiha`&dcbaZY}@V[TxXWVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzZSXQVOsS5KPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<`#">76;4X8xw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9876/.R,+Op(-&J*#i!&}C#"y~w=uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(fHdc\"Z_^]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<`#">76;4X8xw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U/4321*N.'K%*#"!Efe#z@x}|uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|{zyr8vo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDZ_^]VUyYRWPOsS5KPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,+$H"'~}$#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nPfkjc)Jf_%]b[!_XW\UyYRQVONMLp3INGFEiIHG@(>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.R2+0)('K+*j(!E%|B"yx>v{t:9wvonsl2SRhmlkd*bg`&^Fb[`Y^]VzZSRQVOsSRQ3IHGLEiIHGFED=aA#9>7[;:981w/4-,PON(L,%*#"!E}$#"!x>|{ts98vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,%$H('&}|B"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9870T4-21*/(L&+$)"!E}eB"y~w=uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`H^]\"Z_XWVzZ<XWPOsSLKPOHGkKJIH*)E>bB;:?>=6Z:98765432+*N.',%I#('~D|#"!~}v<tsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qmf,dc)gfedcbaZ~^]VUTSwWPUTSLpJOHlFKDCgGFE>=B;_9876;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;:981UT4321*N('&J*j(!Efe{"y?}_uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9876/.RQ1*N('&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1ongf,diba'eGcba`_X|V[ZSXQuONMLKPOHlLEDIHG@dDCB;@9]7<5492V05.3,10/('K+*)('~D$#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(`edcb[Z~XW\UTx;QVONMqQ3IHGLEihBG@?cC%;@?>7[;:981w543,P0)o-,+$Hi'~%${z!x>|utsxq7uWmrk1Rnmle+cha`&dcbaZY}@VzZSRQVONr5KPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<A:?>7[5:3876/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C{"!x>|{ts9wvunVrk1onmfe+cKa`_^$baC_^WVzyYXQ9UNSRKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;4X2765.R,1*/('&J$j"!E}eB"!x}v{zyr876tslk1Rhmf,jihg`e^$\aZ_^]V[TxwQPUTSRKJnN0/EDhH*)?>b%$:?>7[;:32V0v43210/.'&J*)('~D$#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9876/.R,+Op(-&J*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvotsrk1inmlejib(I_dcbaZYX|\[Z<;QVUNMRKoO10FKDhBG@?cC%;@?>7[;:981w543,P0)o-,+$Hi'~%${z!x>|utsxq7utVlkjoh.fNdc)a`edcb[!_XW\UySwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#"y~w=^zyrwp6tVUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#zb~w|{t:xwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`e^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*b(fHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQ3IHGLEiI+AF?cCBA@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J$)"!Ef|{z!x>|utsxq7utVlkjoh.fNdc)a`edcb[!_XW\UyYXWPUTSLpJImGLKDCgGFE>=B;_9876;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzZSXQVOsS5KPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<`#">76;4X8xw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9876/.R,+Op(-&J*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDCYX]VzyS;WPOsSLKPOHGk.DCHAFE>b<;:?8\6;492V05.3,10/('K+*)('~D$#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eBz!x}vu;yxwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|{zyr8vo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzyS;WPOsSLKPOHGk.DCHAFE>b<;:?8\6;492V05.3,10/('K+*)('~D$#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8NSLQPOHGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_9876;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~Dedz@~}v<]yxwpo5mrk1ongf,dcbaf_%]ba`_XW{[Z<RWVUNrLQJINGkjJIH*)ED=a;@9]=}|Y9270/.RQ+0)('K+*#G'&}eB"!x}v{zyr8vunsl2johmled*Kg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsr54JOHlLEJIHGF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,PO)o'&%I)i'~%|B"yx>|u]s9qYun4lkpi/gfedcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDZ_^]VUyYRWPOsS5KPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nPfkjc)Jf_%]b[!_XW\UyYRWVUTMLKoONMLEDhHGFE>=a;@?8\<549870T.-,+*N.nm%$)"Fg%|{z!x>|utsxq7unVrk1ih.fejib(IH^cbaZ~^@VUTSw:PUNMLpoINMFKDhBAF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,P*p.-&J*)"'~D$#"y~}|u;yxZponm3qSihg-,+cha`&dcbaZY}WVUyS;QVUNrqKPONGkK-IBGF?cC<$:?>7<;4981Uvu-2+Op(-&J*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#c!~wv<zyr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\[!Y^]\Uy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#"y~w=^zyrwp6tVUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#zb~w|{t:xwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`e^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nPfkjc)Jf_%]b[!_XW\UyYRWVUTMLKoONMLEDhHGFE>=a;@?8\<549870T.-,+*N.nm%$)"Fg%|{z!x>|utsxq7unVrk1ih.fejib(IH^cbaZ~^@VUTSw:PUNMLpoINMFKDhBAF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,P*p.-&J*)"'~D$#"y~}|u;yxZponm3qSihg-,+cha`&dcbaZY}WVUyS;QVUNrqKPONGkK-IBGF?cC<$:?>7<;4981Uvu-2+Op(-&J*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#c!~wv<zyr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\[!Y^]\Uy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9>=<5YX210T43,10/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1ongf,diba'eGcba`_X|V[ZSXQuONMLKPOHlLEJCBfFE>C<;_98765Y9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBA@E>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBf)EDC<;_98765Y9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('gf|B"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(`edcb[Z~XW\UTx;QVONMq4JINGLKDhHG)(D=a;@9]=}|Y9876/S321q)M-,%$#G'&}eB"!x}v{zyr8vunsl2ponmleMib(IH^cbaZ~^@VUTSw:PUNMLp3INGFEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1qp.-&JI#"!~}Cd"!x}|{t:xZponm3qSihg-kdchgf_%]\aZ_^]VzZSXWVOsSRQPON0/EDhHAF?cba;:?8=6Z:9yx0543,Pqp.-&J*j('&}CB"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qmf,diha'_d]\[!_XW\UySwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}|u]s98vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`H^]\"Z_^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;:9]=<;492V0/.-Q10/('K+$H('gf|B"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*Kgfedc\"Z_XW\UyYXQuONMLKPOHlFKDhH*)ED=a;@9]=}|Y9876/.R21q)M-,%$#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs98vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`H^]\"`_XW\UZSwQVOTSRKoON0/EDhH*)?>b%A@9]=6;492V6543210/('K+$)"F&}|{A!aw|{t:xZputm3TSohmlkd*Kgfed]#aZ_XWVzZYXQuONMLKPOHlLEJCBf@(>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-,+O/.'K%*#"!Efe#z@?wv{zsr8Yutmrqj0nPfkjc)a`ed]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*#i'&}C#"!x}|u;yxZponm3qSihg-kdchgf_%c\aZ~^]VUZSRv9ONMLKJIHl/KDCHAFE>bBA#"8\<5:3810T43,10/.'&J*j(!~Dedz@x`|uzyxwp6nmlkjong-kjibJ`_^$#aZB^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjiIBfF?DCB;_?87<;:3W765.-Q1q).'K%*#"!Efe#z@x}|uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|{zyr8vo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~Dedz@~}v<]yxwpo5mrk1ingfe+iha'_d]#D`_X]VzZSRQPtTS54JImGLKDhHGF?DCB;_9876;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9]7<543870T4321*/.'K%*#"!Efe#z@x}|uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"`_X]V[TxXQPtTS5KPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<A:?>7[549870T43,+O).'&%*)(!E}$#"!x>={tyrqp6tsrqji/gfedcb(`e^c\"`_X]V[TxXW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?c&BA:?>=<5YXWxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A@x`|uzyxwp6nmlkjong-kjiKg`_dc\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|{zyr8vo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#zb~w|{t:xwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`e^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*b(fHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQ3IHGLEiCBA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9270/.R21*N('&%I)i'~%|B"yx>|u]s9wvonsrk1i/mlkdcb(`e^c\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhH*)?>b%$:?>7[;:32V0v43210/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1ongf,diba'eGcba`_X|V[ZSXQuONMLKPOHlLEJCBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,Pqp.-&J*#(!~Dedzy?}_{zyxwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=<;4X8765.R21*/.'K%*#"!E%${A!xwv<]yxwpo5mrk1ingfe+cba'_d]baZ~^]VUTSw:PUNMLpJOHlLKDhBAF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w543,P0)o-,+$Hi'~%${z!x>|utsxq7utVlkjoh.fejiha'_d]#D`_X]VzZYRQu8NMq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBf)EDC<;_98765Y9yx0543,P0)o-,%$HG'~%|B"yx>|u]srq7onslkjongf,jiha`&dcbaZY}WVUyxXQPUTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCB;@?>7[5{3276/.-Q1q).'K%*#"!E%|#"y?}_uzs9wvuWsl2ponmlkdcb(fHdc\"`_^]\[TxXWVOTSRKoON0/EDhH*)?>b%A@?876Z43810T43,10/.'&J*j(!~Dedzy?}_{zyxwpo5mrk1onPle+ihgfeG]#aZB^WVzZSXQPOs6LKon10FKDhBG@?cC%;@?>7[;:981w543,P0/(L&%$)(!E}eB"!x}v{zyr8pun4rqSonmf,dcba'Hdcb[`_^W{[ZYXW9OTSLKPImGFKJIHG@dDC<;:^>=}|Y9810/.R2+*N.',%I#('~D${"!~}v<zyxwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlFKDhHG)(D=a;@9]=}|Y9270/.R2+0)('K+*)i!&}${Abaw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*Kgfedc\"Z_X|VUZYXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@dc=<A@9876Z43810T43,10/.'&J*j(!E}${A!~}|u]s9qp6Wsrqpohg-kdiba`&%$bD`_XW{[Z<RWVUNrLQJINGkK-,BGF?cb%;:^>=}|Y9876/.R21*p.-&J$j"!E}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#c!~wv<zyr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\[!Y^]\Uy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eBz!x}vu;yxwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`e^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*b(fHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981Uvu32+0)Mnm%$#(!E}eB"!~}|u]s9wvonsrk1i/mlkdcb(`e^c\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhH*)?>b%$:?>7[;:32V0v43210/.'&J*)('~D$#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBA@E>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBf)EDC<;_98765Y9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('gf|B"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(`edcb[Z~XW\UTx;QVONMqQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/('K+*)i!Ef|{z!x>|utsxq7uWmrk1Rnmle+cha`&dcbaZY}WVUyS;QVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBfF?DCB;_?>=6;4X2765.R21qp.-&J$j"!E}eB"!x}v{zyr87unmlqj0QPfkjchg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsS54JOHlFKJIBA@E>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|{zyr8vo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#zb~w|{t:xwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`e^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8NSLQPOHGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDCYX]VzZSXQVOsS5KPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<`#">76;4X8xw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=<;4X8765.R21*/.'K%*#"!E%${A!xwv<]yxwpo5mrk1ongf,diba'eGcba`_X|V[ZSXQuONMLKPOHlLEJCBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8NSLQPOHGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_9876;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~D$#z!~}v<tyxwvo5m3Tpohmlkd*bg`&^F\[ZY}W{[ZYXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>v{t:xqYun4Ukpoh.lkjiha`&dcbaZY}WVUyS;QVUNrLQJINGkK-CHGF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,PO)o'&%I)i'~%|B"yx>v{t:xqYun4rqpohg-ejihg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsrq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9>=6Z:98705.RQ1*/.'K%*#"!E}$#"!x>=u;yrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8TSRQJONMLEiCBA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9270/.R21*N('&%I)i'~%|B"yx>|u]s9qYun4lkpi/gfedcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;:981U5.-Q1*/.'K%*#"!E}$#"!x>|u;sxwvonm3Tpohmlkd*bg`&^F\[Z_^]Vz=SXQPUNMq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvotsrk1inmlejib(I_dcbaZYX|\[Z<;QVUNMRKoO10FKDhBG@?cC%;@?>7[;:981w543,P0)o-,+$Hi'~%${z!x>|utsxq7utVlkjoh.fkdiha'edc\[!_XW\UySwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDCYX]VzZSXQVOsS5KPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<`#">76;4X8xw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;:981U/4-Q1*/.'K%*#"!E%${A!xwv<]yxwpo5mrk1Rnmfkjiba'e^$bD`_XW{[Z<RWVUNrLQJINGk.JIHAF?c=<A@?>=6Z43810T43,10/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_9876;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~D|#"!x>|{tyxqpo5mrqpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|{zyr8vo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDZ_^]VUyYRWPOsS5KPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,+$H"'~}$#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nPfkjc)Jf_%]b[!_XW\UyYRQVONMLp3INGFEiIHG@(>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.R2+0)('K+*j(!E%|B"yx>v{t:9wvonsl2SRhmlkd*bg`&^Fb[`Y^]VzZSRQVOsSRQ3IHGLEiIHGFED=aA#9>7[;:981w/4-,PON(L,%*#"!E}$#"!x>|{ts98vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,%$H('&}|B"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=<;4X8765.R21*/.'K%*#"!E%${A!xwv<]yxwpo5mrk1ingfe+cba'_d]baZ~^]VUTSw:PUNMLpJOHlLKDhBAF?cC%;@?>7[5{3276/.R21q/('K+*#G'&}eB"!x}v{zyr8pun4Ukjong-eMiha`&dcbaZY}]Vz=SXQPUNMq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X870/.R21*/.'K%*#"!E%edz@a}|{tyxqp6tVUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/.R21*N('&J*)('~D$#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFj-,HGF?>b%;:^>=}|Y9876/.R,+Op(-&J*#i!&}C#c!~wv<tsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_9876;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~D|#"!~}v<;yxZputm3TSohmlkd*Ka`edc\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H(!~%|{A!x}|u;yxZponm3qSongled*bJ`_^$bD`_XW{[Z<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-,+0/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~D|#"!~}v<;yxZputm3TSohmlkd*Kgfed]#D`_X|V[ZSXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;:9]=6|:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*)('~D$#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8NSLQPOHGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;:981UT4321*N('&J*j('~Dedzy?}_{zyxwpo5mrk1Rnmfkjiba'_^cbaZ~^]VUZSRv9ONMLKJIHl/EDIHA@?cC<;@98\<5:3810T43,10/.'&J*)"!E%|#"!~w=uzyrwpo5mrk1ongf,dcbaf_%]baZ~^]\[ZYXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?8=6;4X810T43,10/.'&J*j(!EDedzy?}_{zyxwpo5mrk1ongf,dcbaf_%c\[!_X]V[ZYXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@dcb%;:^>=}|Y9270/.R2+0)('KJ$j"!E}eB"!~}|u]s9qYun4lkpi/gfedcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}|u]s9wvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSw:PUNMLp3INMFjD,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;4X2765.R2+0)Mnm%$#(!E}eB"!x}v{zyr8vunsl2jonmf,dihg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsr54JONMFKDhBAF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,P*p.-&J*)"'~D$#"y~}|u;yxZponm3qSihg-,+cha`&dcbaZY}WVUyS;QVUNrqKPONGkK-IBGF?c&BA:?>=<5YX870v.3,P0)('K%*)"'~Dedz@~}v{zyr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`H^]\"Z_XWVzZ<XWPOsSLKPOHGkKJIH*)E>bB;:?>=6Z:98765432+*N.',%I#('~Dedz@a}|{tyxqp6tVUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSw:PUNMLp3INMFjD,HGF?DCB;_9876;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=<;4X8765.R21*/.'K%*#"!E%${A!xwv<]yxwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_9876;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~Dedz@~}v<]yxwpo5mrk1ohgf,jibgf_%]b[!_XW\UyYRWVUTMLKoONMLEDhHGFE>=a;@?8\<549870T.-,+*N.nm%$)"Fg%|{z!x>|utsxq7unVrk1ih.fejib(IH^cbaZ~^@VUTSw:PUNMLpoINMFKDhBAF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,P*p.-&J*)"'~D$#"y~}|u;yxZponm3qSihg-,+cha`&dcbaZY}WVUyS;QVUNrqKPONGkK-IBGF?cC<$:?>7<;4981Uvu-2+Op(-&J*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#c!~wv<zyr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\[!Y^]\Uy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?87<;:3Wx05.-,+O/.'K%*#"!Efe#z@x}|uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"`_X]V[TxXQPtTS5KPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<A:?>7[549870T43,+O).'&%*)(!E}$#"!x>={tyrqp6tsrqji/gfedcb(`e^c\"`_X]V[TxXW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?c&BA:?>=<5YXWxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A@x`|uzyxwp6nmlkjong-kjiKg`_dc\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|u]srq7unmlqj0QPfkjchg`&Gcb[`_^W{[ZYXQ9UNSRKo21GLEi,+GFE>=aA#9>7[5{3276/.R2+*N.',%I#('~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun4Ukpoh.lkjiha`&dcbaZY}WVUyS;QVUNrLQJINGkK-CHGF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,PO)o'&%I)i'~%|B"yx>v{t:xqYun4rqpohg-ejihg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsrq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9>=6Z:98705.RQ1*/.'K%*#"!E}$#"!x>=u;yrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8TSRQJONMLEiCBA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9270/.R21*N('&%I)i'~%|B"yx>|u]s9qYun4lkpi/gfedcb(`H^]\"Z_XWVzZ<XWPOsSLKPOHGkKJIH*)E>bB;:?>=6Z:98765432+*N.',%I#('~D|#"!~}v<tsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhH*)?>b<;:?8\6;492V05.3,10/('K+$)"Fg%${z@a}|uzs9wvuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;:981U5.-Q1*/.'K%*#"!E%|#"y?}vu;yxZputm3TSohmlkd*Ka`edc\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhH*)?>b<;:?8\6;492V05.3,10/('K+$)"Fg%${z@a}|uzs9wvuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`H^]\"Z_XWVzZ<XWPOsSLKPOHGkKJIH*)E>bB;:?>=6Z:98765432+*N.',%I#('~D|#"!~}v<tsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H(!~%|{A!x}|u;yxZponm3qSongled*bJ`_^$bD`_XW{[Z<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-,+0/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~D|#"!~}v<zyr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_%cb[Z~XW\UTx;QVONMqQ3IHGLEihBG@?cC%;@?>7[54381U54t2+*N.',%I#('~D|#"!~}v<t:xZputm3TSohmlkd*hgIe^]#[Z~XW\UTx;QVONMq4JINGLKDhHG)(D=a;@9]=}|Y9876/S321q)M-,%$#G'&}eB"!x}v{zyr8vunsl2ponmleMib(IH^cbaZ~^@VUTSw:PUNMLp3INGFEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1qp.-&JI#"!~}Cd"!x}|{t:xZponm3qSihg-kdchgf_%]\aZ_^]VzZSXWVOsSRQPON0/EDhHAF?cba;:?8=6Z:9yx0543,Pqp.-&J*j('&}CB"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qmf,diha'_d]\[!_XW\UySwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"y~w=^zyrwp6tVUkpoh.ledchg`_^$baZ_XW\[ZSwQ9UNSRKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;:981U54321q)M-,%$#G'&}eBz!x}vu;yxwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`e^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P0)o-,%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*b(fHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQ3IHGLEiCBA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y9270/.R21*N('&%I)i'~%|B"yx>|u]s9wvonsrk1i/mlkdcb(`e^c\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhH*)?>b%$:?>7[;:32V0v43210/.'&J*j(!~D|#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1ongf,diba'eGcba`_X|V[ZSXQuONMLKPOHlLEJCBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,Pqp.-&J*#(!~Dedzy?}_{zyxwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJIBGFE>b%;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cCBA@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=<;4X8765.R21*/.'K%*#"!E%${A!xwv<]yxwpo5mrk1ingfe+cba'_d]baZ~^]VUTSw:PUNMLpJOHlLKDhBAF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w543,P0)o-,+$Hi'~%${z!x>|utsxq7utVlkjoh.fejiha'_d]#D`_X]VzZYRQu8NMq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBf)EDC<;_98765Y9yx0543,P0)o-,%$HG'~%|B"yx>|u]srq7onslkjongf,jiha`&dcbaZY}WVUyxXQPUTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?cC<$:?>7<;4981UT4321*N('&J*)('~D|#z!x>v{tyxwpo5mrk1ingfe+*b(I_dcbaZYX|\[Z<;QVUNMRKo21GLEi,+GFE>=aA#9>7[;:981w/4-,P*p.-&JI#G'&}eB"!~}|u]s9qvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$baZ_XW\[ZSwQ9UNSRKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_?>=6;:981UT4321*N('&J*)('~D$#"!~}v<]yxwpo5mrk1ongf,diba'_^]b[Z~XW\UTx;QVONMq4JImMLEDhHA@E>=a;@?8\}54381U54321q)M-,%$#G'&}eBz!x}vu;yxwpon4lkpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|{zyr8vo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9]7<543870T4321*/.'K%*#"!Efe#z@x}|uzsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"`_X]V[TxXQPtTS5KPIm0/EDhHAF?c=<A:?>7[549870T43,+O).'&%*)(!E}$#"!x>={tyrqp6tsrqji/gfedcb(`e^c\"`_X]V[TxXW9OTSLKPImGkK-IBGF?c&BA:?>=<5YXWxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A@x`|uzyxwp6nmlkjong-eMibgfe^c\"!_^]\[TxRWVUNrRQPON0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,Pqp.-&J*#(!~Dedzy?}_{zyxwpo5mrk1ingfe+cba'_d]baZ~^]VUTSwWPUTSLp3INGFEiIHAF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w543,P0)o-,+$Hi'~%${z!x>|utsxq7utVlkjoh.fejiha'_d]#D`_X]VzZYRQu8NMq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDZ_^]VUyYXWPtTS5KPIm0/EDhHG@d>C<;_98765Y9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8NSLQPOHGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBf)EDC<;_98765Y9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('gf|B"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*b(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNr54JINGLKDhHG)(D=a;@9]=}|Y9876/S321q)M-,%$#G'&}eB"!x}v{zyr8vunsl2ponmleMib(IH^cbaZ~^@VUTSw:PUNMLp3INGFEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1qp.-&JI#"!~}Cd"!x}|{t:xZponm3qSihg-kdchgf_%]\aZ_^]VzZSXWVOsSRQPON0/EDhHAF?cba;:?8=6Z:9yx0543,Pqp.-&J*j('&}CB"baw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qmf,diha'_d]\[!_XW\UySwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]VzTYXWVOsS5KPIm0/EDhBfF?DC<`@?>=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}|u]s98vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_dcb[Z~^]V[ZYRvPUTSRKoON0/EDhHAF?cb<;_?8=65Y9yx0543,P0p.'&%$H('&%|{"y?wv{zsr8Yutmrqj0Qmf,jiba`e^$bD`_XW{[Z<RWVUNr54JIm0/EDCHAe?DC<;:^>=}|Y9270/.R2+0)('K+*)i!&}${Abaw|{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(`edcb[Z~XW\UTx;QVONMq4JONGFjJIBA@E>bB;:?>=<5Y3810T43,10/.'&J*j('~Dedz@x`|uzyxwp6nmlkjong-kjihgIed]#D`_X|V[ZSXQuONMLKPOHlFEDCBf@(>b%;:^>=}|Y9876/.R2+0)('K+$j"!E}eB"!~wv<tsr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`_dcb[Z~^@?UZYRvPUNMLpPON0/EDhHA@?cC<;@98\<5:3810T43,10/.'&J*)"!E%|#"!~w=uzyrwpo5mrk1ongf,dcbaf_%]baZ~^]\[ZYXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?8=6;4X810T43,10/.'&J*j(!EDedzy?}_{zyxwpo5mrk1ongf,dcbaf_%c\[!_X]V[ZYXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@dcb%;:^>=}|Y9270/.R2+0)('KJ$j"!E}eB"!~}|u]s9qYun4lkpi/gfedcb(`_%]\"C_^WVzZSXQPOsSRQP2HGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}|u]s9wvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSw:PUNMLp3INMFjD,HGF?DCB;_9876;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bDCYX]Vz=SXWPONMq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9>=6Z:98705.R2+0)Mnm%$#(!E}eB"!x}v{zyr8vunsl2jonmf,dihg`&Gcb[`_^W{[=<XWPOsr54JONMFKDhBAF?cC%;@?>7[;:981w/4-,P*p.-&J*)"'~D$#"y~}|u;yxZponm3qSihg-,+cha`&dcbaZY}WVUyS;QVUNrqKPONGkK-IBGF?c&BA:?>=<5YX870v.3,P0)('K%*)"'~Dedz@~}v{zyr8vuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"ZY}@?UZSRvVO7SLQPIm0/EDhH*)?>b<;:?8\6;492V05.3,10/('K+*)('~D$#"!x>|uzyrwpo5mrk1onmfejib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8NSLQPOHGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bDZ_^]VUyYXWPtTS5KPIm0/EDhHG@d>C<;_98765Y9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fe^c\"Z_X|?UZYRvP8NSLQPOHGFjJCHA@?cC<;:^>=}|Y981U5.-210/(L,+*#G'&}eB"!~}_uzs9wvunVl2pinmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9wvon4lTjohmf,Mibg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwWV87SLKoO1GLEi,HGF?DCB;_9876;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~D|#"!x>|{tyxqpo5mrqpi/gfedcb(fHdcb[!Y^WV[TxXQuONMLKPOHlLEJIBG@d>C<;_?>7<;:3Wxw/.R21q/.'&J*j(!E}${A!x}|u;sr8Yutmrqj0Qglkd*)gfHdc\"C_^WVzZSXQPOs6LKoIHMFEiIH*)?>b%;:^>=}|Y9270/.RQP0).-&J*)"'~D$#z!~}v<zyxqYun43kpoh.lkdcb(`H^]\"`_X]V[TxXWVO7SLQPIm0/EDhBf)(>=<`@"8=6Z:9yx0543,P*p.',%$H('&fe#z@x}v{zsr8Yutmrqj0nmleMib(fHdcb[!Y^]VUy<RWVUNrRQ3IHGLEi,HAF?cC%$@9>7[54927654-Q1q/.-&J*j(!E%|B"yx>|{zyr8vo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X816/St,10/(L,+*#i!&}C#cy~}|{zs9qvo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$bD`YXW\UZSwQVOTSLpJONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@">76;4X87w/43,Pqp.',%I#('~D|#"!~}v<zyxZpo5VUkpoh.ledchg`_^$baZ_XW\[ZSw:VOTMq4JONMFjDIHGF?>C<`@9>=<5Y38765.-Q1q).'K%*#"!E}|{A!~}_uzs9wvuWsl2ponmlkdcb(`e^c\"ZY}@VzZ<XWPOsSLKPOHGk.JCHGF?>b<A:98\<;492VC
```

Final output: `Game Over!`

That escalated quickly.

---

**Solution**

> Safe despite some valiant efforts (particular credit to @Sisyphus and @DomHastings). It's now clear I could have got away with using only two languages instead of four!
>
>
> You probably don't have time to run every layer so here are the [first seven](https://tio.run/##7V1nVyJNE/3@/goEUZBgQAWMGBEDiIqIiSTJRJAo6F/ft6p6BmaGHkBBfXadL3t23XOKsrrq1q3QTSL@kv3zJ5XM5nX6w3gjVdLN6kzHe8dmXb5SLlTKS/r/FbIFnT33DP@wl3N53ZoumS9Ey9l42f6UWNYl42XpD/6Hojp/iELndKaj@GMi/5hJSSRP5wvl6Sfh5@2/SMVJPy2RKyezig@kn6l8pkNnov@WfOB9vBrX2ZIFHX0y/a@O/WlLKoRKP7mk/D1Lar/nvM50Ukk0JB9Zgn/qbKVCKfeUkgoY5jdb@IHfbPFbfjPnUL/Znz/bk7GNovv6@Wq5tdvYDlXny0lL4OjwYH9/79I7/55On3lOgmvVpvmwflnIPz85iqf558xj6m4qsR@L3o4ntmPRi3Dz6nLlJHwe8pcW5vcD/qPdg@3s3pR5Zy1hXF66XVt9a0XcrtnQgt02NzszbTq0WqYM3smJt9Smfuz9LVp5fXEXq/mF89BDIZ@1g/RkNsOkX0Zvb85DjchJ@DjwcrpwcOx7mpneIenrIH3D475ZXVyed8@dLy7MO0j65IFl3KzfzRjHm6@eeq3aLC@B7pXyk@PsNJ99enxo6x6/fL8IX4fO6svBc9C6GHT49ryHO7nsptezntwyLnvW15xXy0tul3OmandYj6cKdtvE/vi9fmwHdH8dq79VK8uNeq1QeZ4vFe9z05k06J4wxfZub671Y9GLm/Ory8hFsALSDw@OA3uPhzv7W5tpj0lmGefi9OmJdXZq2j55YJwygPR0yvDqeX@rNl8bJVe1En55nEPrg@49pZPdN3ZR93GPG3RfAMs4wTK24GyRWcbgzb6jZcbqa61K@aVedFbCT6WH2RmQnrrLgd0nvMnEFdgHTzVyEXYHzk4P0e4ofSvj3d1ZW91cjq6vgd2X6FTR7kXzkc1qHG@fal3QHS0TerifyTLd45N7dx3pK8vB4xDqnp@bRbtbLSQ9vmFwK@xuNvHsDh7J85mtCFjmtXG6TD5DlvE@2Pe39ry7fXxm4q3V3EjEa63m60vJFQGfgVMlyxzlEqY06T4WIY8U/P0keDwHcu9B@gb6zIrsVO1wqiTd2Pb3xntt9RYsUysslrt1j2@BZc5fLyMK6b7N9O769pZo9/kLPFX7Cdhd5pEduzsroDXoHjxOP9wn5ae6unLBogliFX0GpG94ZLE655wB3YPHM2aUPmXWT75vjxteIVarK6@NejECp@pguks8MkYeeVa/CJ8HnKeHQTFWN9Nm09rqSsyjd60uXi65G/UZsDtF0yT4zJ5pcoL8nXQf0O6jxplYBOweapxekEcWmfT7bR/5zBbo7r5xroDW4JFn6DOSWH0bhz8hmpplkA5ROv94dg84k7aC7txTPQzu@/zehwMbeaQMZ2Zr0/M263HAnJ@cMPrMucl3Ywt8pr5GKEZ2L8FnZDO21H2Oe6olnu5rZHfQHXwmyNF9FaIJPDK/gEgAOJMG6WD31G3yWn8ZvWith0D3KvrMCXjL3uM0IAHgzA5JV5zqjDlv63WqwQwhMJ3qtV6wDNodpYsIvLXJjSawu8Lf@50q4vvlaQ3wHVCswLPMygJJB5@RWcbYMugb6yLOyLLHQTyWQt0vI28esMzpSVXu7yw3ge7rrmuGM2B3h7UrN8XfWqh7rQvfo8abbsuo4wx4pA090nQ4gdKZZRBnKmj3YaUTilkCBUTgKUNubOJty5BsvL8hRoLuPH8XEPgsgkggzdoMxcDu62syn2EoNnUPPiOXrtSdPFLEmRPK2ocFh49O1YqnKsXIsJPw3TLlR5zxGUwcFPvBaHKdgd1ROs/fGQLDqfpNCiRoVW7A31H3x4dCh3F85lSVuUmZtYHp2QCBs/HYBOZu9HcR37nRpF9zot1ds8BnytY2Ait8RiVWmc@g7nKfIT4D2cMgSq/XyDJFsDv5zNj7doshcOWVZ/fPZG2Fv6tHE0MxYqmczPfNus@Gpik3@eU8sk44w9edpIdJdzlL9QEHvoNTxWhywmc4wl26g783N8ZQ@nIXvpszHHxfBKbn2zva3cn5BP7@FzGOdm6yqjNsAcUwe7BYZfz9c7lpqGhSq5vULENZ2zK@B3YHFONYhnikeT8NOAOWiaLuIL2DwF46Va@8shFQzDJjxswntQzyGcoe4JGnJ0JVBgh8uwsIjHYHnzkhJGjbHS2zsy2tDkS25AfLdHMxFz97jIFlrjF7iNEU8PfMTRI@8wa6j6w6@GDWJn@H7IHRJPB3obJBRkYceBMYh5ibujMf4gxGU5knneUmFT7z2WgKAie4S5pZhoJaGy1zdloLH4eYv@/JK0rU@tP@3o6m8LkLdD/IB1hFKecEVK8y/o55lcVqOtVEphcdGVsKSqSr4HsGLJODajgFjCMOKNaCSv5UjsCIBJ471F2oPRQ8Empiwkj17IEsNXE1cI9jtiZDAmQcnD7BCfq7JSnjBEKsQlWmzNobSyh9YclBPQ7lqTbbsQpM7/lc1N2SBIYtqZsakYugO@SH2oN/qmI1jB0UtDunGl4svzyC7shSiemlbsev42LWrgXRI6GyefZLe0vjS8wyDrB7lfUJKPP1tfsoGIeUYUPEPszm0O4o3Rdldr9oXVMHBaQfkWVmsBr@@KmWzx@B6WXtaT/Eapz5jIDvn8xNfXocQ2a@18Q7IDBUwzWqtSUc@K/mM8Pmps/X2j4L8RmoQLh8hnJTujWoz8DZCvjue/Iejgzf/8vVwWDVsLIfKXRQVPsEI8cZbl9M0sP@l6JJqw4GiKYv8MiuHocf7R74iEe2e3oq0dSX6Yk444TqgPWW2hw4dUdTlZUb8ncJF4OMSpVNXD7NEjq194xhQ@2BXEzqkWJl09VBAT4DPBJ1x1nZAbe3xPrvGE2D94FVuj8/4O8fw5nPzvk@rTu/XgXdz3DeRF03yB5s3gR2d10jw8aqzA48Ceqm5ycj69TKMx@x1BxkPsbF9m5ZZeOhymaJplmFvI9NJjY3@KfKetgiiukxVoVpFs1XgZ@CClKGTZMJYnqlIsQqzQ4AgVH6CrHUFYhVsHu1YptTy03FL8GZsfcaIrBK3UQ@c/1lPjOc7hpL/S6WqsWqFqsDTuIuQO7ZPDEO@9AdFNy0oBkl4wQLkdFmvq6p@ecsoz4rA8bRU/dMulc/ktv9mUc@c4hTc6/ZJOUz1J/pscfB@Az5DEnnR5PQB1bnwBRNPupEbt2h9BbbzulE0wNaBpFA6M8gioVZH1jEGZKeiCNLVZ8icixD/chcNj4ZvUN/H6rHMRjDHnwC@t1cjHikape5d25aAp9ZYdXBNE7Nhbm2qkey3HRA@Y/1sKlPoNxbUjBsceKv9EghmlR0j0WlOIN9Mf@A@2K0@zMWr7U4@2Kk@40hLvTf@290kd2tloBio2u9xs182EG5Uc3a/SpKQ46m5nrGCRrcaEpeC/137O67SXfZHkdic8Ogx7y65HBxEBjrpnoMERj4zCJanGbDD5BXaZMOLLPJ65DnJHtLLsZnhE2LolmbUf72LsTA0ger5HPACVIWAd8N22R3mkwcl89w1431I7NdfYKv1f1rpKtvo/WMJvn@zAWzjMrMhjFssLslALE6YZwymzobLs1yo1SEuulFtvUql97ZHO1w4IlNlE5MTyVWVXDmACxzl9Si6as8UqtXv3qDsc9GF@1CIIpNDzST7zOjHLpu4keTwLANAifAqXnzVdpLHWQygUgwko1dsQ/MwRm0/miiqcc@wQrlJraHLd0cJX@vcXIT7r9DbpLsQgh1E/WB@V2IQae3uMEoz3yRk2DFxd1lHswyNJOH7JF75vffh0OxD2@O8qthMVa9smgqFZ24WUTZgyb@8v4MZr4Qx2eY3ReajjmsPeQsVdgHjnI3dhkSxAScYfuRnNoDOPDi5bwaw@6OpuNH5DPgOd4bBcNGjHzuM/HHzSLjOGVt5W5nCW/xPLG5h@xGhvS@hxdvBrAdFGlFyTa6ZDu1Tb2IwB/IHrucLoRiX8yMPjPOuZHRVVG2oLKJ8HIT8hmPW83uLDcJ1TDwmfCLsA/8gBgZA/Mp7ze1d/et5DOKWzxfsKH@gz29f3Q2/AOcoIfdqxUH@vsR9rANprbPfAEnGG6f4G/sdg7A30WcUW64qOy6Sbr72t0srW7S6qZP@cxot0R@jKV@8zbab6ybhqxXf49HDrMVJSJBGewOp/rkOCvkpTcyrq8w8zWv@Axb678Pl/k6N3uFaHroqlcFxvHX3hv@vpuO/wxGim8rKG4li/ebIJowVp95sUpT81X1m@wD48w33Tt4oJk8VvKjmslrWfvrPHJ6XnFPnpO1oW5K42wYTvVWrYNi3/eJ8ybGI/l9sV9u9x5ZuyXedITMR5Yparv72s1e7WbvN9/s1aZZg02zxKkK4Qz/zoTqqxOD8RmRR0p0xy2R@JuAkUNvebdZ6pC9VJtVeImq370y6u6XP3or@VdkPsweH3@Zp2/2GIPaQ8x8jcFevOs3VbFavuhWw8cswzYYt1U6KLLdzsVWFyf47ptf/8UOitoLApPc6W2HA0dv268fKLYv8Y6/YBmPm7t9aRYmz2P0LoRyj6N9aw2lX/fsz7hWmWW6JqD8yXNHOqvKeO8YsvmqGieQTUBH8mZR713mWp9o6myoc9@KEmY2XZM45X2@Z7ZDrnqf79tuk0g26cRXEsnuRiZd2I/s8X7kMG@JfCCvqtl9RK99/BU9bK1eVbl7m6XtnERGu/ml3dL8qqwt3DsApse7kaFtSv9YB4Xt6fXYhbjsvPvDex@4U1H2fOFRm6oM/oLAz7wv9qXvpf7rE6GffKf2v/wm3T9Syatk7UHfdcM7QvhCe1nF7l03HbMZX@r2xqDdG9buDXdjZJ@36@lm7xX6e6/X@tS@M0DbNtZuIGk3kLQbSL/5BpKsTyDtMptZ1ka7V7HrJj/VKdXtHLXvVZH1OHzKXmqRa5mP4HuX7uMC4@DudgI68l4qeWLdH9x/F7o/byKf@S3Z49/fhfhdN9nR7pn0pzhBn8ynhu/Ca6ztPY5fj@/i/gzUq3KfEZHgs29F/SO3GkZ3N0vKUjnf36RVlFpFqf4SVZTd57ulyTNEU0h2o5rsLsy1pVysgPhOuhtb@Kp/rfsbCXAmH0txv7mQWQZ0T61vd9dNfW8l93l5LeCX3KNkfTHIHt1br5O93lvC/ozaHscu6M77bsGO7pKZvOpmkWB3j4BiFE0df9e2FX50W2EEb6ivnmKnlv8dd9LJxC/ZhRhiMvEbtqI0tvQVN@603X3trvnnJ0Iq33vb6c8sgXQVfCfG0f0GI719@a7yuk0HI7vmfO1v1YVaGzkBYeTW/wE) and [last seven](https://tio.run/##zVNdb5swFH3Pr7BSsuDGOOYjkGZJ@gf2tFfqWUCJYFMKImRrFZW/ntowwmfSVJq0Egnb93LOuedex3V2wfHoe0EEhioCGgK7X2EMHLDx/wCM8XAgcoPig2/Oi5@AuUHQTLOQrqlI0wjS5wTI3/fuCwTRPo336WI4SPgRKEmchFsf4PCJR3EaRmANvChmaeCk2A1TL/gKPCdtxSrFd2RVIOeAmu5P57cDFC8G0yhOp3kWFG/Fa8nUa0ncViGJe3UV2mXzNcp/617/FO6N/@R@9incm1e7Px7ZirEVedaRdodUS0e6YSHybBgzZGhEM3XTJKZK1Pl8wNjtauunQfQoMyZgi0Vx3NmZkik8eMuXjLHlkjFIoV1mlUzkMuXvCy6XYqElXLBBm@WcFaUseAo@KL5GfIPEiSLWRTbLKQRLOQ4QTxfE43yl/BnwxjylsszaXOcU@thy1R9CkPZ4402dbQziqWRDVNcyfGfjqJZ316NEKbxnZ2pu2hQ/OW@SnUtT0bJyz42PkpF6j/FoRw@y9KXNVmdidr18eFm4VBD9PQlXe0pfG/D6WLrI2hY2WN67HzXLNdMVHp2CqMpTJK0XZ6qrGCsnveNpBqU1rjkshnIyVxwbQ5FInzWJfGyw6AE9PE4kRA@XBiv@lh1XUAyoe0H5ZcGjLT2Mb8aTLieuKK/t02Q8Hb/CNw). Note that version-dependent Ruby code is used so both links will likely break if/when TIO's Ruby is updated.
>
>
> **Layer 1: PHP**
>
>
> Just a (cheating) quine. The purpose of this 'invisible' layer is to mask the simple alternating pattern of Layers 3–840,527,321,220,386 by giving the false impression that after Layer 2, an *odd* number of layers remain.
>
>
> **Layer 2: Malbolge**
>
>
> This layer, created using [this generator](http://zb3.me/malbolge-tools/#generator), was a last-minute addition. It serves two purposes:
>
>  1. *Obfuscation.* Layer 3 is easy to crack even without knowing the language (as noted in @Dion's comment). I wanted some protection against this first-glance weakness.
>
>  2. *Red herring.* A cracker stuck at Layer 4 (missing the `-rprime` flag) might wrongly guess that there is code in another language hidden in Layer 2.
>
>
> **Layers 3, 5, 7, ..., 840,527,321,220,385: bitch `-c`**
>
>
> The bitch layers don't do any real work; they simply spit out the next Ruby layer. The (implementation-specific) `-c` flag activates character I/O. I chose bitch for its simple ASCII-code-based character I/O and because it is relatively unknown/unpopular on CGCC (only used in four previous answers).
>
>
> **Layers 4, 6, 8, ..., 840,527,321,220,386: Ruby 2.5.5 `-rprime`**
>
>
> The Ruby layers rely on obfuscation, the nasty version-dependent practice of calling methods *by index*, and the even nastier 'feature' that the default method indexing is disrupted by loading certain libraries via the `-r` flag. Specifically, the `-rprime` flag (which loads the `Prime` library) alters the `methods` array for objects of `Integer` type, inserting `:prime_division` and `:prime?` at indices 20 and 21, respectively. Thus, by including calls by index to `Integer` methods with index greater than 19, the code is made to break if executed without `-rprime`.
>
>
> The code works as follows. The hex integer `0x5f40c10f01b74eafa17c9` is \$7197109101327911810111433\$ in decimal, which is the ASCII codes of `Game Over!` concatenated. The prime factorisation of this integer is \$3^2\times29\times173\times347\times1093\times420263660610191\$. Each of these prime factors, except the last, appears in the first line of Layer 4 (\$3\$ and \$1093\$ are expressed in hex; this is a red herring). Call the last integer in the first line \$n\$, so \$n=0\$ in Layer 4. The code tests whether \$3^2\times29\times173\times347\times1093\times{}n=7197109101327911810111433\$. If so (as occurs only when \$n=420263660610191\$), the integer is broken into an array of ASCII codes (basically via `7197109101327911810111433.to_s.scan(/1?../)` in de-obfuscated form), converted to characters, and printed. If not (as occurs for all \$n<420263660610191\$), the code prints itself, with \$n\$ incremented by 1, as a bitch program. This program is simply a string of ASCII codes sandwiched between `#` and `/` characters.
>
>
> *Why `-rprime`?*
>
>
> No methods provided by the `Prime` library are actually used (the prime factorisation was done separately), so why `-rprime`? The original plan was not to increment \$n\$ by 1 at each iteration, but rather to replace it by the next higher prime. This would have added another level of frustration to any cracker who stumbled on the `-rprime` flag because the required execution time would have gone through the roof. I gave up on this approach because I was unable to calculate the required number of iterations (i.e. the number of primes \$\le420263660610191\$) in reasonable time!

Comment: The first layer is Malbolge. Only 840,527,321,220,385 layers to go!

Comment: I don't know what the next layer is, but I still cracked it :D https://justpaste.it/8qj7d

Comment: So the first 3 layers are Malbolge, bitch (yes that's the name), and Fueue. The next layer is some Ruby but it seems to only work for some ultra-specific ruby version which I don't have. It relies on the ordering of `methods` which changes even in minor versions ... I guess it's time to use `rvm` and install every ruby version ever made

Comment: wheteher this is solved in time or not, I'd really like to know how you did build up so many layers, I hope there are at least repeated language sequences!

Comment: ... it seems like the ordering of `::methods` is OS-dependent as well, which means it's probably it for me since it doesn't seem like the script runs under `rvm` on Ubuntu on any version. If anyone else wants to try with their Ruby: [Try it online!](https://tinyurl.com/yxguu3fa)

Comment: @Sisyphus I'm getting errors with TIO, too many arguments into `?nil`. This intended?

Comment: I don't want to give the game away but... *every* layer is runnable on TIO. (I admire your tenacity with `rvm`, @Sisyphus.)

Comment: @Dingus Yikes! This goes deeper than I thought, then. Back to square one =)

Comment: Also loading different modules via `-r<something from gem list>` changes `methods`. So far `json`, `mini_portile2`, `openssl` and `psych` look promising, but I don't know if there's another flag that also does something. I've managed to get it to fail on `to_a`, `ual?`, `object_id`, display`, `send` and in different places too it seems. Hopefully that helps someone else!

Comment: So I tried to brute force the modules to load and the order of the modules also changes things... I checked for method changes on numbers, strings, methods, symbols, `Object`, `nil`, `Array`, `Hash` and I think the list of modules is: csv json mini_portile2 openssl psych rake scanf. I tried to iterate and permute all variations of ordering (including missing some out) without any luck. I look forward to seeing if I was close at all...

Comment: 14 days have passed, so you can claim this answer as safe by editing in the languages!

Comment: @DomHastings Close but no cigar! I was convinced it would be cracked once you revealed `-r`.

Comment: To be honest, I was pretty confident it'd be that, but I couldn't find the right module! Thanks for sharing the details. A good combination of problems! For my future reference, are the available modules listed somewhere?

Comment: @DomHastings [stdgems.org](https://stdgems.org/) is great.

Comment: This is genius.

Comment: `perl -MMath::Prime::Util=prime_count -E 'say prime_count("420263660610191")'` prints `12876059828856`, and runs in less than 4 seconds on my computer; this might come in handy if you have similar problems in the future. (You'll need to install Math::Prime::Util from CPAN, but I find it to be a very handy library for solving this sort of number-theoretical problem.)

Answer (score 13):

## 33 layers, cracked by [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212088/68942)

```python
i=496;a=     0
print('gREETINGS!'.swapcase()if a==447775else'i=%3s;a=%6s%s'%(i-16,a+(int(1/2*2)*int('syd0s6ncczl7ka1ioletm9t1atoqjq2awpshwfxcorai94tcmzim91j2zzq2c08wxjmfmzr0x9euhjojhltjpay0g8t1o78y83a',36)>>i&0xFFFF),open(__file__).read().strip()[14:]))
```

Final output: `Greetings!`

Hint: Python.

---

Solution:

> This uses Python 2 and Python 3 to encode a [Subset Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem. `int(1/2*2)` is `1` in Python 3 and `0` in Python 2, which allows you to pick whether you want to include or exclude a number per layer from a packed list. With strong parameters, subset sum is NP-complete. However, the subset sum has weak parameters (~16 bits per number for 32 numbers) so it can be solved by many methods.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212088/68942). This was quite a fun one, thanks for the challenge!

Answer (score 8):

## 3 layers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213940/95792) by [Aiden4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97691/aiden4)

```scala
class Main:
  print(
"""class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {String a="ɗefine";char c=10;String z="pɼint";char d=23;String y="⁸fẇ×ịṛs⁷";String e="";char x=90;String b="⁺°`¬²ịĿ°£Oḋ®ẋṄ¢¦";String w="⁸Ḷ⁸Ŀ~ʋ^ḋ*Ẓ>{S";String i="return";String n=" ";String f="Game";String s="main";String t="def";String k="#";String u="ƈlass";String m="Іt'ѕ Dоnе.";String o="¨";String g="ƊƝƤƬƲȤɓ";
    if (""")
  print(((1 ^ (29 * -54) + 23 & 103) / 3))
  print(">")
  print(302 - 67 + (2 % 590) | 930 - 123 * (-169))
  print(""") {
      System.out.printf("73----T---|---111-T   T46%c      |     /     |   1%c 39-  1      %c    |   0%c/   %c 1       |   1   1%c|    -6      /    1   |%cL115----    |     0  /%c        %c   8     L76%c         3  6%c          2-J",10,10,92,10,92,10,10,10,92,10,10,10);
    } else if (""")
  print((65 % (59 - 20 * 24)) / -193 * 134) 
  print(">")
  print((624 & 13 + 3012) / 23 * 9)
  print(""") {
      System.out.printf("%cm=%cIt's Done%c;print %c$m%c;", 36, 34, 34, 34, 34);
    } else if (""")
  print(12345 * 4 / 910 - 2 * 401)
  print(">")
  print((1 + 3 / 3) % (24 - 36 * 90))
  print(""") {
      System.out.printf("Flexibility speaks for yard%cairport announces all lies%cring a ring a rosie%ccaesars sat bad%csay %cIt's Done.%c%cAmerica is great",10,10,10,10,34,34,10,10);
    } else if (""")
  print((393 / 91 * 56) - 12 * 78 + 192)
  print(">")
  print(67 | -123 + 21 * 34 - 193)
  print(""") {
        System.out.printf("You are done%cSay %cIt's Done.%c(It really is that simple!!)",10,34,34);
    } else if (""")
  print(154 % 91 * 10 + 345 - 2)
  print(">")
  print(89 + -920 | 65 * 2 ^ 12)
  print(""") {
      System.out.printf("4@abƤḞ⁹%dỴ !Ṙȯ/ṣƥA^?rCs>Y|°ỵ4$m(0a+4r  /ZÐæ⁽e)D1ṖÐ,Ḅ Ḃ &ẉ1ɗḌ¢ġʋḞṬŒ$c “¢¤ƲgṖḳ®[⁾»",29,10,90,3,102,11,1234,95,666);
    } else if (""")
  print(10203 / 192 + 182)
  print(">")
  print(12 - 45 * 69 | 3)
  print(""") {
      System.out.println("YoucAnTryTofIguReoUtwHatThislaNgUagEiSButyOUwoNtBeaBleTobEcaUseiamToOpoWeRFulmWahAHaHaAnDhEreIssOmefilLeRteXtCOmmeNTcOmmeNtCommenTpRInTLpAreNcAPeitSiNGLeQsCaPeDonEdoTrpArencoMmEntCoMMentCoMMeNTfOOBaRyAbBaDabbadAbBAdOOcAnyOuFIndoUtTHEsEcREtBUrIEdINtHIsMEaNInGLeSStEXtNOYoUcaNTbEcaUseIhaVetHepOweRofNopUncTUatIoNandilItERaCYoNmySiDEbyeByePPl");
    } else {
      System.out.printf("%s"+e+"ẊD.%1$s",o);
    }
  }
}""")

def main(Main:Main):
  Main=Main

@main
def mian():
  Main=main(Main())
```

Outputted phrase: "It's Done."

This is a pretty easy one to crack, but here's a hint anyway - at least 2 of the languages can run on the JVM. And choose your version carefully.

> Okay, it's cracked now, so here are the possible branches:
>
> - Python 3 + Java + Perl 5 - prints "It's Done" (no period)
> - Python 3 + Groovy + Perl 5 - prints "Іt'ѕ Dоnе." (wrong Unicode chars)
> - Hypothetical Cython 2 version (or other Python 2 version that allows type hints with `:`) - imaginary 2-D language
> - Third branch in layer 2 - TrumpScript program that outputs "it's done." because TS is case-insensitive.
> - Fourth branch in layer 2 - Rockstar program with correct output but never reached
> - Dotty + Java - nonsensical Jelly-ish program
> - Sixth branch - oOo Code, never reached
> - Last branch - Husk, never reached

Comment: [Cracked- for real this time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213940/97691)

Comment: By the way, your code is not valid python 2 because you didn't declare an encoding for the non- ascii characters.

Comment: @Aiden4 I know it isn't - it was just a red herring to make people hunt for an implementation of Python that worked that way

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your use of hypothetical. I do know that is a red herring (after trying every python 2 implementation on tio).

Answer (score 5):

## 4 layers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212069/peel-away-the-layers-robbers/212138#212138) by Sisyphus

```
"/-G^A_:;aT$e}qz\"7\"y^&'7T|-q3ZO@,]GN6==3g4U^Y)S_L7:fVp6_4'!s,a8IUK1[ Sp.)Ae)/P%ZY&D*K>j6feVfN1Fky,Vl2Z'?ie%\"<f,nv\\VS&T^e]5ZP}j!6/AivE` 0>9x<DdQL# kdzrz~sSO\"7[&U"{32-}%95base
3base{'
    '1/=}%
```

This isn't a serious answer by any means, but it was fun to make.

Final output: `Code Golf.`

Hint: Love is a great mystery, [but I couldn't really explain it](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/).

This was cracked quickly.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212138/48931). NB: I had to modify your Golfscript layer slightly, I think stackexchange swallowed the tab.

Comment: @Sisyphus Hm, strange. It worked in TIO (though obviously I couldn't link to it for this question). Anyways, wonderful! I didn't think this would stay uncracked for very long at all, hehe.

Comment: @Sisyphus SE indeed makes all tabs 4 spaces instead. If you would edit _Josiah_'s answer you would still see a tab, but copy-pasting it from a question/answer would change tabs into 4 spaces each.

Comment: In the long debate of tabs vs spaces, SE has chosen its side (and it's the wrong one, obviously.. no i'm not partisan ;)

Answer (score 4):

## 2 layers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212104/52210) by *@Sisyphus*

```
,322,241,245,241,245,313,245,241,241,315,245,241,245,241,315,245,245,245,245,245,245,315,315,245,245,241,241,315,313,245,313,245,245,315,241,241,241,241,241,315,245,245,315,245,241,245,315,322,241,245,245,245,245,245,241,315
```

Output: `Greetings!`

---

EDIT: Solution after being cracked:

> I thought it was fun to try some languages I've never used before, since printing text to STDOUT is pretty straight-forward in most languages.
>
>  The first language used is [μ6 `-a`](https://github.com/bforte/mu6), for which the leading `,` will take some integers and encode them as a nested tuple. The integers are in base-6, so `322,241,245,241,245,313,245,241,241,315,245,241,245,241,315,245,245,245,245,245,245,315,315,245,245,241,241,315,313,245,313,245,245,315,241,241,241,241,241,315,245,245,315,245,241,245,315,322,241,245,245,245,245,245,241,315` is actually the list `122,97,101,97,101,117,101,97,97,119,101,97,101,97,119,101,101,101,101,101,101,119,119,101,101,97,97,119,117,101,117,101,101,119,97,97,97,97,97,119,101,101,119,101,97,101,119,122,97,101,101,101,101,101,97,119`. These are the codepoints for the characters `zaeaeueaaweaeaweeeeeewweeaawueueewaaaaaweeweaewzaeeeeeaw`, which we can output with the argument flag `-a`.
>
>  The second language used is [evil](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil), which is generated by [this Python program (second method)](https://tio.run/##jZPBcpswEIbP@ClUHTpS4SAx0x5cyLWnPgFlOorZxEyxYDBqnEzf3d2VXIRxkwk@ePh39X@/WGl4nva9zc@tHdzESsa/jQBTax@PH/jXs0GlM4f7xjC7FcKmWn5U9/ryyA2s6lhUSmn6yaLI5Z@geQEL8u5u1rxAWlHoWfOPpj40d2v4gnyVgm0OMBk4DeMRl1RVXX/KP39B@aEfGZVa28ApCw2tZWDdAUYzgZjXye0mmQ04DwZBqWaHmr7PE2ftQ3Rl0B2B8ReOuKQD@zjtsUvT29O@7YDZfmKm68SMSShVTHQdKHYlSEE/r0hWliyY@1KyM7ZpG1zwkyZkhLeTqxINB/5fok/rliWECUoadrywryXDuCLAU82KOdSqLYROktsSxUAx5Ya/yYL3seB1FkQWvM1y72O511kushyxLrNPL8OfT9b18fES1oextZPg3wFvX8P0lkt/WHd74w@Ev40I9m0seqm66sdGUJusUzyLWfTi8sY3/@c7jPA727nRm7@0g@A/TkpxlgZSFv5oq/MGNaaNYKKSibwEQKsQYLUivlR6W9NNWSiqLku6P/7KRH1hkV9B1S0sfJBjP07QiDgNnUWLOvsFzyWOQ6JBdj7/BQ). Here, `z` resets \$A\$ to 0; `a` increments \$A\$; `u` decrements \$A\$; `e` [weaves](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil#Weaving) the 8 bits of the binary representation of \$A\$; and `w` outputs \$A\$ as character with this codepoint.
>
>  [Try it online in μ6.](https://tio.run/##yy01@/9fx9jISMfIxBCITeG0saExEt8QyDdFkUcVw8QgOVR5hDkwsxF2wNQaYmBkM9DdADYLxe3oGKz/////uokA)
>  [Try it online in evil.](https://tio.run/##HYqxCgAgFAK/1cEhaH0J/bxpNyic8qxtXxAcAkonPkrHTAYKJaIH5V4g@wE)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212104/48931)

Comment: @Sisyphus Well done, that's indeed what I had. Out of curiosity, how do you go about solving challenges like this? You have a script, or just try random TIO languages until something reasonable comes out? Or you know about all languages by memory?

Comment: I recognised that it was in base 6, and so searched on esolangs.org for mentions of base 6 - there aren't many of them. I know evil already because I have seen it before.

Answer (score 4):

## 4 Layers, [сracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212102/48931) by Sisyphus

```
1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+=A1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;A;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+;
```

Output: `The Final 1`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212102/48931), although I only counted 4 layers.

Comment: @Sisyphus nice. fixed

Answer (score 4):

## 2 layers. [cracked by Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212069/peel-away-the-layers-robbers/212168#212168)

```
//"/pr/in/t('C/o/de /G/o/lf./')"#ec/ho/'C/o/d/e/ G/o/l/f/.'#con/sole/.l/og/('C/o/d/e/ G/o/l/f/.')#g))#:jd@#$%6a
```

Options, options...

Output: `Code Golf.`

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212168/48931)

Answer (score 4):

## 2 layers, [cracked after 18 minutes by Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212179/48931)

```
printf("Code %s." % "Golf") # Python doesn't use printf?? (Of course I know what Python uses. (print))
# ^ The letter i. Superb letter. Seriously, it's one of the only two letters that can be a word by itself.
```

It outputs `Code Golf.`

This will probably be cracked very quickly.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212179/48931)

Answer (score 4):

## 5 layers, Safe

```
#include <iostream> \/\/ "sgnitreeG"<._@
/x/zzzz//z/mmmm//m/nnnnn//k/p
//h/
o//j/
/
xznjkxmmmnnnnjkxznnnnjkxzmmnjkzmmnnjkxzmmmnnjkzzmmmnnnjkzznnnnjkxzzhjzmmmjkzzmnjkxzmjkxzmmjkxzmmmnnnjkzmmnnjkxxxxxxmmnnnhjxxxxxxxxzmmmhjzmmnnjkmmnnnnhjxmmmnhjzzmmhjmhjzmmnnjkxxmnnnhjzmnhjznhjzmmnnjkmmmnhjzzmmhjxxzmmnhjzmmnnjkxzzznnhjNever gonna give you up.... Never gonna let you down... Never gonna run around and desert you....hjzzzmmmnnnhjzmmnnjkxzzzmmnnnnhjzzznhjzznnnnhjt
```

Just a first attempt, so probably won't be too hard.

Final output: `Greetings!`

### Solution:

Layer 1: [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)

```
#include <iostream> // "!sgnitreeG"<._@

nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
Never gonna give you up.... Never gonna let you down... Never gonna run around and desert you....
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
p
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
o
t
```

Layer 2: [Grocery List](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Grocery_List)

```
echo u:,120#.inv 493675 1496505 1682621 1650191 1429778 1546144
```

Layer 3: [J](https://www.jsoftware.com/indexno.html)

```
"!sgniteerGGc"bk,@
```

Layer 4: [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98)

```
cGGreetings!
```

Layer 5: [V](https://esolangs.org/wiki/V_(DJMcMayhem))

```
Greetings!
```

Comment: It was easy to guess the first layer is ///, but I can't seem to find the next one yet.

Comment: I'm guessing the next one increments every `n` and prints and resets on `p`. First two letters are either `ec` or `gc`.

Comment: It probably starts with `echo`, unless it's a red herring.

Comment: I'm probably interpreting `o` wrong. This is what the output looks like so far. `echo u:,x#.inv ǭʣ \`2 ¨ 2¿`

Comment: @PkmnQ Could that be J?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think that `ǭʣ` means anything.

Comment: Your answer is safe now.

Comment: Aaand posted. I figured that was the obscure bit. Had anyone gotten past the second layer, it was probably easy pickings.

Comment: *Grocery List* nice

Answer (score 3):

## 3 layers, cracked by [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212094/78410)

```
101;1111011;0000;11011111;{110000;11100010;11011110;00110;10111011;000110;10001;0100000;11011;000;11010101;0000010000;10100000;101101;0100000;1101111;0101111;}1001010;0000;100000;10110001;011001;011"00001101110100100010011001000;{111;011111;}1000\1101100;010110;110011;0\;110001;0111010;110010\10110;110001;0110000;\11011;0010;11001;011\11;0100000;11010100\;10110001;101110;1\001;001010;110111\0000;10110001;10\1011;0000;10100\000;0100110111\101101111111"@
```

The phrase to print: `Code Golf.`

Can you get through the binary hell?

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212094/48931)

Answer (score 3):

## 3 layers, [Cracked by PKmnQ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214035/97691)

```
"D'`;#]8JIY4jEhw5uRQ+rpLo98*Z('D2CAdbx>+<)yxZpunsl2SRngfe+Lhg`_^$EaZ_^]V[TxXQ9UNrLQJOHMLEiCBAF?>=a;@?8=<54X876/4-Q10/o-&Jkj"75*1-"F&%edAbaw|{tyr8vuWVlkj0Qgfejib(`H^]#a`YA]\[TxXWP8TSLQJnHlkE-CHAeED&B;_?>=}|4Xy1U543s+O/o-&Jk)"75*1-"!&}C{c!x>|{zyxqY6Wsrqpi/mleMiha'HG]#a`_^W?[ZYRvPUTMqQJ2NMLKDhBG@?>b%;:?876;:3W10543,P0/on&J*)('&%${z@~w|uts9Zvutmlk1oQPfkd*bg`_%cbaCYX|\U=YXWPtT6RKoOHMFEi,HGF?DC<A:^>~6;4381Uv4-2+*Non&+*#Gh~}|{"75*1-"y?wvuzyr8vXWsl2ponmfN+Lbgfe^c\"75*1-"`Y^WVUySRWVOTMqQPONM/EiCHG@EDCB;_?>=}|49870/.R,1*N.n&%$Hi!EDC#zb~}|uts9Zpo5Vlkj0Qgfejib(`edc\"75*1-"`B^]VUTxXWP8Nr54PImML.DhHA@EDCB;_?>~<5Y9270Tu-,+Op.-&+$)"75*1-"Fg%|B"75*1-"!~wv<)"rooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo;
```

This probably won't be too hard, but good luck fighting through my unidomatic code. Outputs `The Last 1`

> Okay, it was cracked pretty quickly, but it did take two people to do it (see comments). The first layer is pretty straightforward, just a string pushed to the stack then outputted in <><. The second layer is Malborge that came from a generator posted by another user in this thread. The third and final layer is an abuse of rust's macro system so egregious that it won't even run on the rust playground. The macro I defined creates a function that invokes a macro based on user input. I then invoked the macro so it created the main function with an invocation of the print macro.

Comment: Can't recognize the third layer. `macro_rules!f{($t:tt$i:ident$m:ident)=>{fn$i$t{$m!["The Last 1"]}}}f!{()main print}` (First layer is ><>, second is Malbolge)

Comment: Rust? Macro rules should be rust

Comment: @user [Looks like it](https://tio.run/##JcWxCoAgEADQX1G5QcdWob6gsS0ipJQOOgs9J/HbbegtL5XMvZM70rOncvssQ9XAlhnQ4ukjA/2bcaohAgJXILmq5fJidpnFoLbWWpBVG3IYxZswcuv9Aw "Rust – Try It Online")

Comment: @PkmnQ You should post an answer

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214035/91569)

Answer (score 3):

## 2 layers, safe

```
print "%s" % "Code Golf."
# Ss4iSBr_Z*YWTR>:wTC`^ 5
# x red herring `-~DqD|`<
# Xt1,i>-%qrFhK-`@eEw, ye
# uI' | g[Wt7BU3A)N<[LsHG
# >s}R"Ia:HF!s {k=)qxlo9h
# $ia;,t"-,]xO3?VDC]<,\:#
# G.-oHn9>.E%B,dx7db_Xs,Z
# H RU"%+70+<G^$n|GT,qR2L
# iB\7.n}-?w\&bF -r[6&G8>
# _}*c%<qWW~E$/M0UiW/A8'Q
# 5AJ"ineTc>g+c&PBS`dtU##
# 7`w-H3|kj3Oz4t<;4zyI72q
# 0jt}>,+=%;'{q837yZo)+ma
# 'a7Upv&<(VG.m}`l}2!]4YX
# ,M`jL>Xd%Igji\'cvim+fL]
# !;S4u&Gv+oT%|G,rHVt?%N<
# JkB*~M'&>er%W@TK7W% FxC
# Wikiq#k*MrX!c<&QkZ?36R.
# "GZu2E6p>qR&r'OF.f3,t0W
# R1`UHS%- B+<PkmnQ8ExK;t
# Le71:N>"(%05vtiPML$\_H.
# 003:W%<P<(3j4vhr-s3,L.W
# SJp`S ('![j,z>x#.cN6&(/
# |m(Bl[^(]<j,w={U$.6:-nm
# @}h[>]c+HbV 7:11mn&)xWi
# [%|&(<Y7V]Qq"a(1BlDs2dJ
# >(~ET7A4+g#b^jhP|G3i^:4
# %<fO}(fRpC_G6f?G0jm@w((
# (?pV{WF9'X-n76IcXE>!hWW
# VjNEAf.|97dvm4<Ph%MOS=X
# >o%y'k44eGzFJE5r^skEy]v
# Yg(mQf9Q.|&mTKHA<1kqBnJ
# WK%v_zXXANpS>~Od3Fl\hKl
# "g(;RkLx=,BT)JT[VXs<]'V
# %g>v[h(z]%)4e`&`P=6^Q__
# Z`^sV3/m'(<=T?{Z})TccNW
# {Cb>k]F?E>(\$IyZ+tS#i,#
```

Outputs `Greetings!`

It works in  Python 2, but it doesn't output the correct string. There's a bunch of gibberish in the comments, but how could that be executed?

Also, just in case it's useful to anyone, [here's the code I used to create the original gibberish](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5crLb9IIVMhMw/ET0/VMDLWtOLiLCjKzCvRSM4o0oCo0gNRICFjIx1DIzNNTZ3UvBRbJSXN//8B).

### Explanation

The first layer is axo. In axo, string mode is different from other 2d languages, in that it can change direction, and do math with ASCII values. Also, `%` is down, probably because you'd be using `v` in your strings. I took advantage of those by hiding instructions in random gibberish.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FdLZcqpAEIDh@/MUiA5gWKKBSFTEiEHcVxSjohhXRFSWuOur5wzXX03XX90zPe///g6uufMRFHgoAhA0v58vEGW/XTLovzDS8TizI7mTwcu3prbF1EnNG2PkHcoZcRdzZL1w4esVYtDPL@frbghQ@n6cMkUaOG5hXaGNz4V8opDLAspvCUfuyGqo@bzUZXPRujCsekUFiug92mhpmioWQh5yszJR57zdJ9dQIuY0TfkoTennBpvtfeV1gRqlwlAUht4Xd0mRkYFEzc/8/GfS96gBlCLS7qKA5GOkoIwju7uiUk77rQrFlEY8s3vQ2dMI@ykgtDtMYMqHCGXyeJkBwdG0pxx5rcW6pvaa@8BbUN5zZdTcLdSZuCJnWFPqGHO/Gw4KeONEF9m7tWEbV84X0tz1UuLfHCixjf8QKTID0vjN@WD5y2AfJe0pFHzKdw9HTCB6CmM/jO3jLaRz330oVM3YVMX@HJRWG3OEz46mTS6rOpRQusP9YsqR3KvgrlBusednQT3YddmSXp41HBMXLtA@1QqvAaRwzkPRTMt0wtZLze2HZgLWsgZZNtFmoKDK4PdNThxEp425eKPALFnKj2lQ2nGjW@wAGpFIoWnZu9aHfK6kfSjVBR9P1UWUALH3o282a9XIaFIMpsVibEoDQlMg2A13XLu0x1JVJpjWKR@MDkLgoeGGuornMDOrJzDiFcrdJqTtcEzowoY6ZW7dCJNI0TsbyudjPRT1GVn86SF8Kh63d1j0rJlQhuCOEcI339NbDjol4tL2y3ubl4O/Qzxllc9x5Cr8M96sm3eFNccpDgoQlo0HsWwf8hMlscwqsY39eSIIKET20LtphSTep3d8ojTry2JorQXVvU1dzi2Ze5KfH21OaK5BrdHJBPcR9@CCWxy3UK6Fsvzujj1LvuhHKN8rwm4tky3mjtlqpZgT4pYj7YI2rQKOk2u/n6sfOuKzMWcL29G6sg2usCLSbat6zlCSGi2rw17fE3S8F1SvxONwTVx1EOUWBmY0M4lxazKBMjDGXo99tXFCyKjZ2@ARVWezelB9y/@Ill7IyiIxipQuA9LvhE0q/Pf3Hw)

Output: `"Greetings!"`

The second is Foo. You can tell I only put my effort into the first layer.

Answer (score 3):

## 7 layers, was invalid

[Code too long to fit in post](https://gist.github.com/chunkybanana/7d0c638e40a0dad41ffbe56081f13f98)

(65365 bytes)

What it would've been:

### Layer 1: Javascript (v8)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#javascript-v8) You'll have to paste the code in 'cos I haven't found a link shortener that supports TIO  links.

This layer is just something that  doesn't prettyprint arrays, so Intcode's fine with it.

### Layer 2: [Intcode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/intcode)

[Code still too long](https://gist.github.com/chunkybanana/cf8629cc7de3e389cee2bc4746f82c6d), paste it in [Here](https://tio.run/##5Vjbbts4EH3XV8zaL1KsBI6dXiLE@7IXoG8FdoF9MASBsWhbG90g0Y3dot@enSElmaRs10mLdhebAIGlOTM8c2Y4pFPuxLrIp0@sSkTCa5jBJwfw5zqAGx@Gf7IHDlsfdj58hEfE4NNoB6KAsqjho4ROFHQAA9heWLZpABO0/SU9k7zciNa@lfYbZX9fJbkAxGTAhGZ@FcAUze@W6h3MZjAO4O9NVrZhdhL32sL9dAT3RlFVdLZwBxbdt6Ydl7MAt4rvL2uWrzhUPGUi@cAJgPIVucLcBmMY/pbHUCyBb/liI02fYfgrX7JNKoDE3kFSw7XjLDf5guyG9CnL7mMGtWCLBx/Sde1DRX/SYsEI7ENWxLwOFOKq5iIi8dzOLgMp4wqNMRPMlWGk31VZlK7nwciGVDbE8522xt@J08XZnKY9TucywU4UruxGLdzNF8OV1KWunYGR3gt/7PQ@O44Tc@oeUbGFiBZFlrE8Rs6Cr3jlBXKx5i02Ti2qziZNyRJSnrsNwoO7GZawY1hxsalyaF18@INywrUlgqc132OLEuM3ceaXkyB0DNKaMbichIeWcIvSa5eY0/NizSoPlkUF9AmLoUKFtD7@LlJW1wqvaJASUZTkiYgit@bp0qdRUbH7lM/mobfnilm3hsAoBzldycIh3xbSIcyEe/h56DiGAbd9dM9qjraxaUlK@U5jjVVoSHs9/alC@5U83Q17llp2n28ecxzDH1i64WbCYldyV5o9mld1miysZJJ4S1kTBFfCeo5w7hzPXYMbSBIXTT/btE1vqmpEJa1oQrrkcWl7WC6m4FesLDm2@thz@sa5pBUiP6mErtjqkGI/WKrZ99eqaa2eZLpUMU8NqR7XTGjroFn3J6vm3g0@5Ysnn5qPptT0pjmth@@bw1G@NNPR2eolxKieprsWEA/H4bss43HCBD8UC10Pe07Mpaly5m4eGb6n6G21vVqUC1wgum30sHeotUSvcWnmW9Ohmd1H26ZXYnVwnOjTxkMbTN2ZqFjvj7qD/PV5ZEPVQZWxJHfLqlhVLGu86Qk11ua@eMjV2McP1PYN/qousR/dgT/wwub00sbo4zpJOb25k6qQj6efTqS@351F9oFJ8HlShnt11N1rBs2Fd64iaCM@aWtKFOfXPkxCU839sdvd3booOg7vNohpGNB8MM2VZZ5Y3o3OBmZqYsxhpNpGKiHn2xSIpXyej8MDW8BYZqTW6XrVOZSz1PPE5c8zGZUUVQrumHuyEZhIvkxbM9kz8jQT0ItC@15P/GAq/T3VD3rRRB1dQyBzV6mHX9TmiDQ3L5PmG5E6xuqVzSqPE61P9xdjXWPzAm9XsovRV5i@wkXtt6sTS0xOLdGNFCPaGfU9R4/X316PvBD/bU3eBEcG4bPVqE66nszw2AC11dYCfN2MpJmEdO@IdD@I5NBGohvs9Rli95zGzrM37Nv/czEwxr@rGrdmWHmHemk9pFN3/2yuY88mZDG6rzh7UOjm2jj4PclZqqgGMFCnp7p5Ok5CXyhylvEoomiDKKKrYBQNVFR5L2z/0/L09PQP) in the input box.

This simply prints the number for layer 3 by building it from base 1000.

### Layer 3: [Golunar](https://esolangs.org/wiki/golunar)

[Code still chonky](https://gist.github.com/chunkybanana/700a26a4207e3733cd6b44f64eb57db0)

[Corresponding BF](https://gist.github.com/chunkybanana/78d2d792c5de16696103613d05a8b9fa)

[Run the BF](https://tio.run/##3Vpbit0wDF1QiFYQspGhH9OBQinMR2HWn97rhyw7lm1ZSubSyzB5WI6lo2NZcvLz7/vvz19fH3@OY1vw97Y//@94vdPD9vitP57ngL99efwtsG3P890fY1N@eb5xEsju5K3kKp3i2flJ3Aj91n1f1@zG9sDHGekN9a1PEFx/fxXOXVveBAt5bBDxEhG2OGTe34@Fj@YeEq6cT1YoO6K0a49tqbdr73f0Q5edXdcomjAgz4qyhRk6KxhNEEMxCGXvrDttZ1VGZ1JQKrqUyjCYomPC9Ro4dAkper6NoNRGb478zY4I1HZqUGPn8CATBV6TIHVyNKJO1KGHBgtGFY6bmGHiBWs3QFW1exAxpSRxvx6aQLjCfXqEKI1lvURdpg22t1gVP@@MCfc4dyiWNzQN83V4VS2IrF5FxDDFnoNQkZWwry6nLE/ewZxW46C5KQCNXHAUZBHEEnM5e@dVvQKhK5J0mpBVx9QxuEVgyWhgPp7cIyDn37TW7dppyjMMc4Xxs80gE9J3bNDjPQf3pUs0ze/qQDTCy2QRdlESiarDWXmDSo2Jyx3Nx6LAYNWdW6PkrIKxUMkrm8FyfPrAzPqjKuLLytUA0RmKnPYmeFL/B26WxrkRK@YnXyc1n/MmDJebGoBaWZhRrWq1JvEZrMluC1xMUm3eNrMNY7eLLdz2MNsongygoImh5vFRVpR2Z4g65c2ZzmRqN6zK3UW5sXMoKBGNCtuXSfLb5BbWOopi8J7ZeEfSarPpNR7QzKYVmOzpvkR@2NPEqN4S79gPv/au8NW9f4f0Hn4NL/c9X7L33DgZiN5eCOWh8n0At@e3xA8PCIrE3PzzgCQbP1VAIXfMdEjaIZfi/SRFm@JIiACBAJszO87BFjOaJJt1L@drqUTh/sIWApfsmRTRIqAl6eS4hQLN8CDAv6I2iAzRonBD8tpx/AM)

### Layer 4: [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter)

This is where I stuffed up. It was basically the output of the above program with some backslashes thrown in, but when running it through a converter, I forgot to escape them, so the program for this layer wouldn't work.

Anyway, next layer:

### Layer 5: Brainfuck

```
++++++++++[>+++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++>+>+++++++++++++++++>+++++<<<<<<<-]>++++.>+.>++.>++.>+.>+.>----.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6i7eBMBAsF2NmB5TBlISI2EKAbC@bq2YEQDIORLhDo/f8PAA)

This outputs the raw bytes `5e dd 02 20 0b ab 2e`

### Layer 6: Vyxal

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgwqzqmI0gwrvigoYuIiwiIiwiIl0=)

When the above bytes are interpreted as Vyxal in the Vyxal codepage, they produce `` `¬꘍ »₆. ``, which decompresses to `Code Golf.`

### Layer 7: PHP

```
Code Golf.
```

A cheating quine. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fOT8lVcE9PydN7/9/AA)

Anyway yeah, this was invalid.