# Peel away the layers - Robbers

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity, cops-and-robbers, code-generation, obfuscation

This is the **Robbers** thread. For the Cops challenge, see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/212068/66833)

As the robbers, your job is to crack the cops' answers. Choose an uncracked, unsafe cop answer and attempt to figure out which languages, in which order, the cop used.

Note that a crack is valid *even if the languages are different*. So long as the the languages you find, in the order you state them, produce the specified final phrase, the crack is valid, even if the languages are not the same as the intended or original cop answer.

If you are unable to fully crack a cop's answer and decide to abandon your attempt, you can (but are by no means expected to) comment underneath the cop's answer with the languages you've already figured out, in order to help other users.

Having fully cracked a cop's answer, post an answer to this thread listing all the languages, along with their outputs in the following format:

```
# [<cop>'s answer](<link to answer>), <N> layers

Languages used:
- Layer 1: [<language 1>](<link to interpreter>), outputted <output>
- Layer 2: [<language 2>](<link to interpreter>), outputted <output>
...
- Layer <N>: [<language N>](<link to interpreter>), outputted <final phrase>

---

<anything else>
```

After posting an answer, leave a comment below the cop's post to let them know it's been cracked. If you have \$<50\$ reputation at the time of posting, and therefore cannot comment, I (or another able user) will be happy to do so for you, simply make a note of this in your answer and someone will take care of it.

This challenge can result in some very difficult answers to crack - more so than the standard [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) - due to the fact that the number of languages a cop could've used increases exponentially per layer they have. Therefore, be sure to check out the [Robbers' chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113749/peel-away-the-layers-robbers-room) to get help cracking an answer, or to help others.

Your score is calculated the following way:

- If you crack \$n\$ answers, with \$x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\$ languages being used (i.e. the first has \$x_1\$ languages, the second \$x_2\$ etc.), your score is

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}x_i$$

i.e. the total number of languages you cracked, divided by the total number of answers you cracked. The lower your score, the better. Don't bother editing your score into your answers, a winner will be declared when all cop answers are either cracked or safe.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Bubbler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212093/48931), 3 layers

```
101;1111011;0000;11011111;{110000;11100010;11011110;00110;10111011;000110;10001;0100000;11011;000;11010101;0000010000;10100000;101101;0100000;1101111;0101111;}1001010;0000;100000;10110001;011001;011"00001101110100100010011001000;{111;011111;}1000\1101100;010110;110011;0\;110001;0111010;110010\10110;110001;0110000;\11011;0010;11001;011\11;0100000;11010100\;10110001;101110;1\001;001010;110111\0000;10110001;10\1011;0000;10100\000;0100110111\101101111111"@
```

Layer 1: [Hexagony](https://tio.run/##XVE5EsIwDPwLL9it1fAQNRQMqUILk@HtRqdNcGYiKdpDcrb76/Z47u8xCArtgBTYkUjtyGFZfvDI2YHh/B1V0bK2KAhSgaUzf0IepTlhTv1jMeqIHyLINdoPJ71Y4YIcIiZKEyLbzjhSc0pCmSJpFL4xrsqSJrph8IlqW@Nq79g47yjP23iua@QcUagBB9e96nm3MpV1XQ6QWsvxRP8q2/86xhc), outputted

```
echo'@',~;0j1":&.>10#.#:91 7 4 5 160 127 7 172 30 198
```

Layer 2: [J](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/dQV2nztogy1DJSk3PztBAWU/ZytJQwVzBRMFUwdDMQMHQyBzIMzQ3UjAGciwt/v8HAA), outputted

```
1011011.0111.0100.0101.010100000.01111111.0111.010101100.011110.011000110.0@
```

Layer 3: [Labyrinth](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f0MAQhPSAGEQYGIAIMAvINgBzIQCuAqwDKg6mgKrALIf//wE), outputted

```
Code Golf.
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Sisyphus's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212086/68942), 33 layers

```
i=496;a=     0
print('gREETINGS!'.swapcase()if a==447775else'i=%3s;a=%6s%s'%(i-16,a+(int(1/2*2)*int('syd0s6ncczl7ka1ioletm9t1atoqjq2awpshwfxcorai94tcmzim91j2zzq2c08wxjmfmzr0x9euhjojhltjpay0g8t1o78y83a',36)>>i&0xFFFF),open(__file__).read().strip()[14:]))
```

All layers are Python, in this order: 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2/3 (the last layer does not matter).

Special thanks to @Riolku for helping me find the right algorithm for subset sum (because I'm bad at computer science and Google)

Since there are so many layers, writing them all as a list would be rather difficult and take me a lot of time (and anyone who wants to verify it a ton of time), so instead you can verify it by running all 33 layers with [this Bash program](https://tio.run/##7VNNT4NAEL3zK7AJwtaKLCAfNvRWGy8e1JsxZNwuZRHYLbsNH38eWz8Sj55MavpOM2/evMxMMq8g83GkJOf6hCV@HMwh0Q9wNNGwWlnm5mG5fLq7Xz2embZsQRCQ1EIs0yFJfD8Mw2taSmqyxPDkvtkIpCFNw2KXOJjBhXXwwFfu1EXTDzvZrx0Z1IQMZfgGmPGSqipWGBTfFlsXWiHzNusIb4DFviLVwKoYF@4wbF3iRG1XVFk1NE4X011e8CIvVSGgdzaRwjyM@sgDc@YFaLFg5053uweacUFrK00zVtI0RXZDYW0hW6qGCQs9Y//mBaGJvtAVlcoWvaaJXuW89r6JfQlsvlNznYD6DH@oj1fsHuEY7hEu@O9PdxKfxH//g7901g7kVzKO7w) that compiles all of the layers together.

Let me know if this posting format is invalid.

Comment: Don't worry about the format, it's mainly to ensure that all the relevant information is included, which it looks like this is

Comment: I wonder if there's a message in the sequence of 2's and 3's.

Comment: @xnor I tried mapping to binary and converting to ASCII and i tried both x-2 and 3-x and rotating and reversing and couldn't find anything, but now I'm curious if there's a more obscure hidden message :P

Comment: Nope, sorry, no message. Just a random instance of the subset sum problem with weak parameters =)

Answer (score 5):

## [User's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212239/97691), 3 layers

```
class Main:
  print(
"""class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {String a="ɗefine";char c=10;String z="pɼint";char d=23;String y="⁸fẇ×ịṛs⁷";String e="";char x=90;String b="⁺°`¬²ịĿ°£Oḋ®ẋṄ¢¦";String w="⁸Ḷ⁸Ŀ~ʋ^ḋ*Ẓ>{S";String i="return";String n=" ";String f="Game";String s="main";String t="def";String k="#";String u="ƈlass";String m="Іt'ѕ Dоnе.";String o="¨";String g="ƊƝƤƬƲȤɓ";
    if (""")
  print(((1 ^ (29 * -54) + 23 & 103) / 3))
  print(">")
  print(302 - 67 + (2 % 590) | 930 - 123 * (-169))
  print(""") {
      System.out.printf("73----T---|---111-T   T46%c      |     /     |   1%c 39-  1      %c    |   0%c/   %c 1       |   1   1%c|    -6      /    1   |%cL115----    |     0  /%c        %c   8     L76%c         3  6%c          2-J",10,10,92,10,92,10,10,10,92,10,10,10);
    } else if (""")
  print((65 % (59 - 20 * 24)) / -193 * 134) 
  print(">")
  print((624 & 13 + 3012) / 23 * 9)
  print(""") {
      System.out.printf("%cm=%cIt's Done%c;print %c$m%c;", 36, 34, 34, 34, 34);
    } else if (""")
  print(12345 * 4 / 910 - 2 * 401)
  print(">")
  print((1 + 3 / 3) % (24 - 36 * 90))
  print(""") {
      System.out.printf("Flexibility speaks for yard%cairport announces all lies%cring a ring a rosie%ccaesars sat bad%csay %cIt's Done.%c%cAmerica is great",10,10,10,10,34,34,10,10);
    } else if (""")
  print((393 / 91 * 56) - 12 * 78 + 192)
  print(">")
  print(67 | -123 + 21 * 34 - 193)
  print(""") {
        System.out.printf("You are done%cSay %cIt's Done.%c(It really is that simple!!)",10,34,34);
    } else if (""")
  print(154 % 91 * 10 + 345 - 2)
  print(">")
  print(89 + -920 | 65 * 2 ^ 12)
  print(""") {
      System.out.printf("4@abƤḞ⁹%dỴ !Ṙȯ/ṣƥA^?rCs>Y|°ỵ4$m(0a+4r  /ZÐæ⁽e)D1ṖÐ,Ḅ Ḃ &ẉ1ɗḌ¢ġʋḞṬŒ$c “¢¤ƲgṖḳ®[⁾»",29,10,90,3,102,11,1234,95,666);
    } else if (""")
  print(10203 / 192 + 182)
  print(">")
  print(12 - 45 * 69 | 3)
  print(""") {
      System.out.println("YoucAnTryTofIguReoUtwHatThislaNgUagEiSButyOUwoNtBeaBleTobEcaUseiamToOpoWeRFulmWahAHaHaAnDhEreIssOmefilLeRteXtCOmmeNTcOmmeNtCommenTpRInTLpAreNcAPeitSiNGLeQsCaPeDonEdoTrpArencoMmEntCoMMentCoMMeNTfOOBaRyAbBaDabbadAbBAdOOcAnyOuFIndoUtTHEsEcREtBUrIEdINtHIsMEaNInGLeSStEXtNOYoUcaNTbEcaUseIhaVetHepOweRofNopUncTUatIoNandilItERaCYoNmySiDEbyeByePPl");
    } else {
      System.out.printf("%s"+e+"ẊD.%1$s",o);
    }
  }
}""")

def main(Main:Main):
  Main=Main

@main
def mian():
  Main=main(Main())
```

layer 1, [Scala (with Dotty)](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5t041CQnQPqHb502g75zkw), Outputted

```
class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {String a="ɗefine";char c=10;String z="pɼint";char d=23;String y="⁸fẇ×ịṛs⁷";String e="";char x=90;String b="⁺°`¬²ịĿ°£Oḋ®ẋṄ¢¦";String w="⁸Ḷ⁸Ŀ~ʋ^ḋ*Ẓ>{S";String i="return";String n=" ";String f="Game";String s="main";String t="def";String k="#";String u="ƈlass";String m="Іt'ѕ Dоnе.";String o="¨";String g="ƊƝƤƬƲȤɓ";
    if (32>21757) {
      System.out.printf("73----T---|---111-T   T46%c      |     /     |   1%c 39-  1      %c    |   0%c/   %c 1       |   1   1%c|    -6      /    1   |%cL115----    |     0  /%c        %c   8     L76%c         3  6%c          2-J",10,10,92,10,92,10,10,10,92,10,10,10);
    } else if (0>225) {
      System.out.printf("%cm=%cIt's Done%c;print %c$m%c;", 36, 34, 34, 34, 34);
    } else if (-748>2) {
      System.out.printf("Flexibility speaks for yard%cairport announces all lies%cring a ring a rosie%ccaesars sat bad%csay %cIt's Done.%c%cAmerica is great",10,10,10,10,34,34,10,10);
    } else if (-520>463) {
        System.out.printf("You are done%cSay %cIt's Done.%c(It really is that simple!!)",10,34,34);
    } else if (973>-817) {
      System.out.printf("4@abƤḞ⁹%dỴ !Ṙȯ/ṣƥA^?rCs>Y|°ỵ4$m(0a+4r  /ZÐæ⁽e)D1ṖÐ,Ḅ Ḃ &ẉ1ɗḌ¢ġʋḞṬŒ$c “¢¤ƲgṖḳ®[⁾»",29,10,90,3,102,11,1234,95,666);
    } else if (235>-3093) {
      System.out.println("YoucAnTryTofIguReoUtwHatThislaNgUagEiSButyOUwoNtBeaBleTobEcaUseiamToOpoWeRFulmWahAHaHaAnDhEreIssOmefilLeRteXtCOmmeNTcOmmeNtCommenTpRInTLpAreNcAPeitSiNGLeQsCaPeDonEdoTrpArencoMmEntCoMMentCoMMeNTfOOBaRyAbBaDabbadAbBAdOOcAnyOuFIndoUtTHEsEcREtBUrIEdINtHIsMEaNInGLeSStEXtNOYoUcaNTbEcaUseIhaVetHepOweRofNopUncTUatIoNandilItERaCYoNmySiDEbyeByePPl");
    } else {
      System.out.printf("%s"+e+"ẊD.%1$s",o);
    }
  }
}
```

Layer 2, [Groovy](https://tio.run/##fVTtT9tGGP/ev@J6IyuMBOIkBCLkbAkxxRM4LHHWsmrVLpdLsGr7It@l1INOY6r2Uvah6rQxaS/SWlbtA@oQW9cAWysZFpV@Yn@C@UfY5QXDxIp1d889z@95v/PVHEpvukdH2ESMgRlk2GCx3iibBgaMIy7ITWpUgCWA/iJ3DLt27X2AnBobAItdHiAZ7q@SqmETOI7nkQOwLEXHe@CHMqzv/2nYvIdV5Fj8GHNleLjcrPrbn@2u@jsr/tZ37HD5KTyGiQx7RrfkVOCw3Dba9jY@8Na9TWG199zb8B7m/eaK99jfFk7ueA@8R4GThU4Mv/mHWPeef/Ry5brQfMPfvp9eLAZKhgwdwhuOHUhsGYKAqcrwMrJIwDMZtvsR8FyGFVIN2BsyfC1gGjJsfd7ubSCxZHjwKb/0z9cgd/DMPngyFCBUht4vAVcTlndbP7TWWuutzRdr@1/B8QtAfEYV9Mdj6Zg0OjIqDqEjA6DoMk6sIdrgQ3Vhzqv9cDQeEZ8u5pKYkiRFdKGoJ5Ih3LVZ6qzDwV4SQDwVEZsu3tVrI9EQHu4KelBXv2vTcRNJghNvbWAphKclaaSdwkmsqFA4jt7zP9bZTo8mT@QgDsBpFsQib8OwFG2PVOxkPS3pjIFuh24DYjLSaVQ0HYuNnNulELbkEFb5JQZy1CYhPN5BRHJ9lmBgGMSTYiZOz7NxIqOJsXTs3ECTJrlllA3T4C5gdYJuMFClDnCRUwlhZDh16nCAbJs2bEwYQKYJTIOwEO7@ZOCYUGaILDEiDDkMMMRBGQkPDLngVB1DIRzCGYs4BkbAYKDmEMThSdfEELWI8YrGRUZi0XQiGT8p6X@LmqMN8RoQUOm0rngmh36VAxHZNN12EnxeZMsMq26SixcHYJDE2fCp0Xg6Miadf8ETb6Fya81v/ni4vBWq@Du/g4v@1rcvfh32tx62fs5cf9OZYOm5JW/D33mS6LP6o2gw4Ygb@N7uvd1Hh8t/kYGc5G99s3sv7DfvAL/5CXjd3/5C2l/1m196D/Z@erkifPtb63/f78Pg8OPvxcOy1tqsCRO/@Zv3@Nrh8jNvB4Zjqc41FLUIKi6jFJZioqzUSDiZTJ4tLRYfSUfi0VT81bWZdqezOGPrjqvTqlprFAgt8YUpxPV5g5lIq5VQTTGK2QZ386UFqvEsQVmT6LSsYFRixECWTvN1eoUUJhumdQXNZ6bQFMrYuXnFISpjeUs82eY0KXBylU/kLYtoOu4QPkEFsfV6QbX16XrGIRrOzBKDFw3t8jR5h02gWSLOV6lQ3WnDNqYzlmILu5kZ0iOaXs3ns6jgZspZlENlcUfFLlPJ50VVbr4xqdoVUZE@pTAFFxSeLTmqUlE1PqWyGQVpqi1CFYtcucq1/BwtYaTpvdLUefQu4VOknl8gBVrVaL1kY72EuEo1ZFcMU@VKAU3MUc1yi0ZOKbsk65LZWRP@9zDOexQYHCSD0N@@mxsKSX0Mhumx7YX2vH109C8), Outputted

```
4@abƤḞ⁹29Ỵ !Ṙȯ/ṣƥA^?rCs>Y|°ỵ4Іt'ѕ Dоnе.(0a+4r  /ZÐæ⁽e)D1ṖÐ,Ḅ Ḃ &ẉ1ɗḌ¢ġʋḞṬŒ
 “¢¤ƲgṖḳ®[⁾»
```

Layer 3, [Jelly](https://tio.run/##AZkAZv9qZWxsef//NEBhYsak4bie4oG5Mjnhu7QgIeG5mMivL@G5o8alQV4/ckNzPll8wrDhu7U00IZ0J9GVIETQvm7QtS4oMGErNHIgIC9aw5DDpuKBvWUpRDHhuZbDkCzhuIQg4biCICbhuokxyZfhuIzCosShyovhuJ7huazFkgog4oCcwqLCpMayZ@G5luG4s8KuW@KBvsK7//8), Outputted (for real this time)

```
Іt'ѕ Dоnе.
```

Comment: @user  dang it, I felt so clever when I dodged the java red herring

Comment: Awesome! May I ask how you knew it was Dotty?

Comment: Don't Groovy and Scala both run on the JVM?

Comment: @user I saw the `@main` annotation. I googled it and it was only a thing in swift and dotty, and that code is not swift.

Comment: @pxeger user is right, I fixed it now.

Comment: @Aiden4 Gah, it's one of the first search results. I really should've chosen something else :(

Answer (score 4):

## [Kevin Cruijssen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212098/48931), 2 layers

```
,322,241,245,241,245,313,245,241,241,315,245,241,245,241,315,245,245,245,245,245,245,315,315,245,245,241,241,315,313,245,313,245,245,315,241,241,241,241,241,315,245,245,315,245,241,245,315,322,241,245,245,245,245,245,241,315
```

Layer 1: [μ6](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mu6), outputted

```
zaeaeueaaweaeaweeeeeewweeaawueueewaaaaaweeweaewzaeeeeeaw
```

Layer 2: [evil](https://tio.run/#evil), outputted

```
Greetings!
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Dion's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212100/48931), 4 layers

Layer 1: [MAWP 2.0](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v2.0/), outputted

```
print('112;114;105;110;116;39;84;104;101;32;76;97;115;116;32;49;39;')
```

Layer 2: [Python 3](https://tio.run/#python3), outputted

```
112;114;105;110;116;39;84;104;101;32;76;97;115;116;32;49;39;
```

Layer 3: [MAWP 2.0](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v2.0/), outputted

```
print'The Last 1'
```

Layer 4: [Python 2](https://tio.run/#python2), outputted

```
The Last 1
```

---

You need to set the 'Max executions' to a high number on the online interpreter for the first one.

Comment: Layer 1 should be python 3 instead

Comment: @Dion oops, fixed!

Answer (score 3):

## [Aiden4's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213964/91569), 3 layers

```
"D'`;#]8JIY4jEhw5uRQ+rpLo98*Z('D2CAdbx>+<)yxZpunsl2SRngfe+Lhg`_^$EaZ_^]V[TxXQ9UNrLQJOHMLEiCBAF?>=a;@?8=<54X876/4-Q10/o-&Jkj"75*1-"F&%edAbaw|{tyr8vuWVlkj0Qgfejib(`H^]#a`YA]\[TxXWP8TSLQJnHlkE-CHAeED&B;_?>=}|4Xy1U543s+O/o-&Jk)"75*1-"!&}C{c!x>|{zyxqY6Wsrqpi/mleMiha'HG]#a`_^W?[ZYRvPUTMqQJ2NMLKDhBG@?>b%;:?876;:3W10543,P0/on&J*)('&%${z@~w|uts9Zvutmlk1oQPfkd*bg`_%cbaCYX|\U=YXWPtT6RKoOHMFEi,HGF?DC<A:^>~6;4381Uv4-2+*Non&+*#Gh~}|{"75*1-"y?wvuzyr8vXWsl2ponmfN+Lbgfe^c\"75*1-"`Y^WVUySRWVOTMqQPONM/EiCHG@EDCB;_?>=}|49870/.R,1*N.n&%$Hi!EDC#zb~}|uts9Zpo5Vlkj0Qgfejib(`edc\"75*1-"`B^]VUTxXWP8Nr54PImML.DhHA@EDCB;_?>~<5Y9270Tu-,+Op.-&+$)"75*1-"Fg%|B"75*1-"!~wv<)"rooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo;
```

Layer 1: [><>](https://tio.run/##7ZHrmqlgHEevxSmjhCgiJBWNSWQkGUIOU04Z5Ni4dfPac9jPvoD9bf5f63nXs35ram3N283LBQeUr0dWHjV8xpsHwmnIyGYt2mkS7jwEuTjLjI1jHsmGTsfO2lltF/Hnxup1OkFE83XQ1/38sNPXe62X5rEtpxVpI8qVmlAVeYstMiU6nxtSBZrMZQm8TaaSURyVsVjURqHKfOZNETCGektQYDJmjOHBvexOG3LvqK3FfBaTAWNmGQ8DQe/5hgON6XXvDLVONp8BYyUs5jzKCsyE56Ai1QekdxdvnzCFwBNbpPbJCH0xPNA7exl5jnn3cj4d37Skut28ra3ocjGpWuYwKJTvjL6u0i8drbGvK83qm1yJS1XxiTOL5QKdNwJUhgYGVCahYjHACNeBxwqqwKGHIBTwX86F68F1dtt0Z@/slos5Zsv16XwMG2ClwMgYslrb7So5DRjsmsnGkw1WKvFWWCiXaI7NMhk9f01SeILElD2OxhFYAq8jsK9sXt/dy5fHiT7snfN9pbYKSqzt1XIqIaIBttJH3a@fBpqutpTTc0Nt1e4e9ZpUjYIeQrnAc@zPVmkyFYtGGmEMliIrYCBYHvDZdzYA74/H2ib@LTEZ/2UUQXPls4e0IfD647IqRjhTYH4Y1yyhpeOpWNNBw0htHUEhxP/do/QacIvfba6HfTbk3di/93v/66jb7QM)

```
D'`;#]8JIY4jEhw5uRQ+rpLo98*Z('D2CAdbx>+<)yxZpunsl2SRngfe+Lhg`_^$EaZ_^]V[TxXQ9UNrLQJOHMLEiCBAF?>=a;@?8=<54X876/4-Q10/o-&Jkj"F&%edAbaw|{tyr8vuWVlkj0Qgfejib(`H^]#a`YA]\[TxXWP8TSLQJnHlkE-CHAeED&B;_?>=}|4Xy1U543s+O/o-&Jk)"!&}C{c!x>|{zyxqY6Wsrqpi/mleMiha'HG]#a`_^W?[ZYRvPUTMqQJ2NMLKDhBG@?>b%;:?876;:3W10543,P0/on&J*)('&%${z@~w|uts9Zvutmlk1oQPfkd*bg`_%cbaCYX|\U=YXWPtT6RKoOHMFEi,HGF?DC<A:^>~6;4381Uv4-2+*Non&+*#Gh~}|{"y?wvuzyr8vXWsl2ponmfN+Lbgfe^c\"`Y^WVUySRWVOTMqQPONM/EiCHG@EDCB;_?>=}|49870/.R,1*N.n&%$Hi!EDC#zb~}|uts9Zpo5Vlkj0Qgfejib(`edc\"`B^]VUTxXWP8Nr54PImML.DhHA@EDCB;_?>~<5Y9270Tu-,+Op.-&+$)"Fg%|B"!~wv<)
```

Layer 2: [Malbolge](https://tio.run/##VZHXcqpgFEafxYYFu6BYEQElBhBURExEQbGi2MCGvrr5PZnJzLneM@tbs/ZGM3XLnBuvFxUcF31DrPmhICt6cUbttggfdqyVxyKDUJBKk8RUv1TgUvh6Gezs7dFMd9rb@cyA2cV8PFL9tDYYqcPeV/fSF/MSf2DFZovhWHpJ1og6XilrxSqOlUso0sdy2QQSE1PJhBWDmuuVtw4FjCmha2f3froeMMeWe@Z6lRQBfbXUQ2NGHfq0sUIMv990WcC6HUDfMuaajpEMYdAUVCuOwMbDRfrXlIQimSPc@qWHvR7oQd4nnkvFvd@ul72SlY@H/W6Z2JgGt1xoQabxpo9UGf8aKG1HkLrcXmymeY79pBa1RhWv6IFiAQfWxUJGTiUBPSoA9y3UjIRDQSjgv9@qz7Nrn475gWOfNuY6ZYnCbD2N6KBMYKJrpNJ3v6WyAtxP3Wz70wJl6vQyyjTqOEWWiIJaeWaLSAZLSQ4SS8MRHtDhiK@xeD7cu/eKnx379i7Tl0H3nbXdzHiY1UEfdfLtHSuq3JOunbbca73dhRbPJUB3plGlKfKvTB7LJRPxdjQV4eNbYM0sPeDsu@lg45/7zkL/725M3/Qa@Kr0250/oIjwseHYOLVgiD/6s4Qq@XQu2bVjUbi1i8cg2B/21ucBt@b1PM9OKfx6/QA)

```
macro_rules!f{($t:tt$i:ident$m:ident)=>{fn$i$t{$m!["The Last 1"]}}}f!{()main print}
```

Layer 3: [Rust](https://tio.run/##JcWxCoAgEADQX1G5QcdWob6gsS0ipJQOOgs9J/HbbegtL5XMvZM70rOncvssQ9XAlhnQ4ukjA/2bcaohAgJXILmq5fJidpnFoLbWWpBVG3IYxZswcuv9Aw)

```
The Last 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JosiahRyanW's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212129/48931), 4 layers

```
"/-G^A_:;aT$e}qz\"7\"y^&'7T|-q3ZO@,]GN6==3g4U^Y)S_L7:fVp6_4'!s,a8IUK1[ Sp.)Ae)/P%ZY&D*K>j6feVfN1Fky,Vl2Z'?ie%\"<f,nv\\VS&T^e]5ZP}j!6/AivE` 0>9x<DdQL# kdzrz~sSO\"7[&U"{32-}%95base
3base{'
    '1/=}%
```

Layer 1: [Golfscript](https://tio.run/#golfscript), outputs:

Layer 2, [Whitespace](https://tio.run/#whitespace), outputs:

```
print" ".join("o"*int(c)for c in str(int("hevvbe0ammyi19tg9ubck4j315jnmd5y0ppsvgebn",36)))
```

Layer 3, [Python 2](https://tio.run/#python2), outputs:

```
ooo o o o oooooo o ooo o ooooo ooo ooo o oooooo oo oooo ooo oo ooo oo ooooo o oooo o oo oooooo oooooooo oooo oo ooooooo oooooo ooooo ooo o ooooooo ooooo o ooo ooo ooooooo ooo o ooooooo oooooo oo ooooooo oooooo o ooooooo ooooo oo ooooooo oooo ooo ooooooo ooooo o ooo o ooooooo ooooo ooo ooo oooo ooooooo
```

Layer 4, [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/), outputs:

```
Code Golf.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Quintec's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212166/48931), 2 Layers

```
//"/pr/in/t('C/o/de /G/o/lf./')"#ec/ho/'C/o/d/e/ G/o/l/f/.'#con/sole/.l/og/('C/o/d/e/ G/o/l/f/.')#g))#:jd@#$%6a
```

Layer 1, [Laser](https://github.com/Quintec/LaserLang), outputs:

```
print('Code Golf.')
```

Layer 2, [Python 3](https://tio.run/#python3), outputs:

```
Code Golf.
```

Comment: Heh, gratz, I figured using my own language might be a bit of a giveaway xD But I tried to use it in the most inconspicuous way possible

Answer (score 2):

## [PkmnQ's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212178/48931), 2 layers

```
printf("Code %s." % "Golf") # Python doesn't use printf?? (Of course I know what Python uses. (print))
# ^ The letter i. Superb letter. Seriously, it's one of the only two letters that can be a word by itself.
```

Layer 1: [Underload](https://tio.run/#underload), outputs:

```
print("Code %s." % "Golf")
```

Layer 2: [Python 3](https://tio.run/#python3), outputs:

```
Code Golf.
```