# Two In One: Guess That Language - Robbers

Tags: source-layout, cops-and-robbers, polyglot

[Cops' challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248188/66833)

This [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge challenges the Cop to write a non-empty program that, when run, produces some non-empty output in language A, and, when reversed, produces some non-empty output in language B. The program may produce any output to STDERR when run in either language, but may not take input in any way.

The cop should provide the following information:

- The forwards program
- The output when run in language A
- The output when run backwards in language B

Robbers should attempt to find the two languages used

#### Rules

- The criteria for a valid programming language are the same as those of [The Programming Language Quiz, Mark II - Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-):

  > - It has [an English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_programming_languages), [an esolangs article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) or [a Rosetta Code article](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Languages) at the time this challenge was posted, or is on [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#) (or [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com)). Having an interpreter linked in any of these pages makes that interpreter completely legal.
  > - It must satisfy our rules on [what constitutes a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/8478).
  > - It must have a free interpreter (as in beer). Free here means that anyone can use the program without having to pay to do so.
- Each answer must run in less than a minute on a reasonable PC.
- Different versions of a language count as the same language.
- Flags must be revealed to avoid obscure combinations.
- Cracking a submission consists of finding *any* pair of programming languages that work, not just the intended ones.

An answer is safe if it is not cracked until two months after the question is posted.

An answer can not compete one month after this challenge has been posted.

Most answers cracked wins

### Example robber post:

````
# Python 3 and brainfuck, 128 bytes, cracks [<user>'s answer](<link to cops post>)

```
print(1)#.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Python's expected output: `1`  
brainfuck's expected output: `v`

<explanation of crack>
````

Answer (score 5):

## Cracks [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248190/92689)

Forwards is in Befunge-96, backwards is Befunge-97.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNfNLUnL/P/fTtlBxyjDKP7/fwA)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNPNLUnL/P8/3ijDSMdB2e7/fwA)

Comment: Doesn't this violate "Different versions of a language count as the same language."?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing This was my intended crack, and idk honestly - they're not "versions" in any normal sense though.

Answer (score 3):

## Cracks [math junkie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248196/110013)

Language A: [Pyth](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0M7I8TZ/f9/AA)

Language B: [Pip](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/f3TkkQzvj/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## Cracks [whqwert's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248194/65425)

```
ioaddrsirmix
```

Language A: [StupidStackLanguage](https://lebster.xyz/projects/stustala#629bd9e5449a1f3821fde58c)

Language B: [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f@/IjO3KLO4KCUlMT/z/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## Cracks [Oliver F](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248239/25180)

Probably not intended.

Language A: [BRASCA](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/)

Language B: [Foo](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fKeH/fwA)

Comment: I guess there are a few languages that this works for, the actual ones were Vyxal and 05AB1E, but I'll accept this answer too

Answer (score 3):

## Cracks [whqwert](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248227/53748)'s `PLACO`

Forwards `PLACO`: [O5AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/wMfR2f//fwA)

- This is the lowercase alphabet converted from binary when treated as base 62 digits (i.e. \$36 \times 2^{25} + 37 \times 2^{24} + \cdots + 61 \times 2^{0} = 2483027905\$).

Backwards `OCALO`: [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether) - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/39/Z0Sfg/38A)

- This is the length of the lowercase alphabet, \$26\$.

---

Note: Both languages will produce the given outputs with just `PLAC`.

Answer (score 3):

## Cracks [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248243/65425)

```
STINK
```

Language A: [Japt](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/PzjE08/7/38A)

Language B: [Seriously](https://tio.run/##K04tyswvLc6p/P/f288zJPj/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Cracks [Nobody](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248234/110013)

Language A: [TrumpScript](https://tio.run/##KykqzS0oTi7KLCj5/1/bistKm8vA//9/AA) (found by searching [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=%22What+are+you+doing+on+line%22&type=code))

Language B: [A Pear Tree](https://tio.run/##S9QtSE0s0i0pSk39/9/fgEvbistK@/9/AA)

Comment: NICE!!! IHATE!%CHAR

Answer (score 1):

## Cracks [Nobody](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248238/25180)

Language A: [MarioLANG](https://tio.run/##nZBLCsMwDET3vsowOkAQukjJIqtQ6Ad6f3Al2XUSSmnpwoMYj6RnX5fH@X5ZbmutIjKhmJiwUMihKqE0QQFAFFX12g1LdYfsSWRGEb3ttjndZ4EbriZZR1dEMhldPjq0T44tgqi/UbXeAxWTCj9Q5ZaN4TOVO/YXlUPZa7KfsdEjydzzg6rvkrhF@@F8kc3c8WgSbl220zHNjpPfHdpp1BOBWp8) (It outputs `<nul>-25<space>` on TIO.)

Language B: [brainfuck](https://tio.run/##lZDNCsIwEITveZUw8wBl2RcRDyoIIvQg@Pxxf9IQilLsYVgms5Ovub4uj/X@vj1bqxVLqf6ZnhRjDtVp/uropOFEg4ippOKsBaD7ppah0POU3V1Uz1DSYewCtgufVX2L2dnzceo9melKjXw00Eq3uzoP8x@pW/NwRnOnCl8x@dGDpMpTJvPfVLH7k6oWiL8VzPH5mApBVXdUYs4Rlb3PQrK1Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## Cracks [lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248192/65425)

```
push 72;ll-l
```

**Language A**: [Gol><>](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/v6C0OEPB3Mg6J0c35/9/AA)

Produces the required output (**16**) with just `sh`. According to the [docs](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/), `s` adds 16 to the stack. `h` seems to be necessary to end the program.

**Language B**: [;#+](https://tio.run/##K84o@P8/Rzcnx9rIXCGjuBTIAwA)

Produces the required output (**-1**) with just `-;p`.

Answer (score 1):

## Cracks [asdf3.14159](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250826/107262)

Forwards is [Javascript](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWtxiZ0mw1FKNjtaP1HzXMObTw4Y55D3f3Ojxq3PNwd_eh3fqxmtGK2tF6enoa0bGasdpAdmystoYiBODSA1SkGQ1XGw3hK-KwQks_Fl2pNtDo2Fh9fWWFTAV9dfVDu4EKgcodgNqAmg8tBBpTra-QoVCtVKukXwtkJivo6cXGRkdrx0brxlvXWpuqKCkZqygo5BurqKsbqqQqVGtqIKngSs7PK87PSdXLyU_XSNOEBAU0RGAhAwA), backwards is [Bash](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GCpaUlaboWNz_G60bHakdHx8bq6WloViukqhiqq6sY5ysoqBgrKamYWtdaI6lQSFbQr67VV6pVqlbIADIfNcw5tPDhjnkPd_c6PGrc83B396Hd6ur6CpkKyvr6sbHRiora0Zqx0dpAloY2kK-tqB2rr3VoN1AhULkDUBtQ86GFQGP0gXLoSiF8fezKFSEAbixQrYaenh7EGBx6wIZDPA71PywcAA)
There were a lot of red herrings in this that threw me off at first but simplifying parts of it gave it away. Fun!
<s>Am I too late to post an answer? :P</s>

Comment: Solved impressively quickly

Comment: I like Javascript :)