# 12 with no 1234567890, but polyglot

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, restricted-source, polyglot, rosetta-stone

This is my 12th question, so I thought of this idea.

Goal:

- Output 12, with **any preceding or trailing whitespace permitted**
- **In as many languages as possible** (where different versions or flags **count as the same language**)
- **Without using any numbers**
- The criteria for a valid programming language are the same as those of [The Programming Language Quiz, Mark II - Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-):

  > - It has [an English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_programming_languages), [an esolangs article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) or [a Rosetta Code article](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Languages) at the time this challenge was posted, or is on [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#) (or [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com)). Having an interpreter linked in any of these pages makes that interpreter completely legal.
  > - It must satisfy our rules on [what constitutes a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/8478).
  > - It must have a free interpreter (as in beer). Free here means that anyone can use the program without having to pay to do so.
- Each answer must run in less than a minute on a reasonable PC.

Your score is \$\Large{\frac{\text{Bytes}}{\text{Languages}^2}}\$. Obviously the lowest score wins. This means that you can't submit something that runs in no languages (wink).

Comment: Come on, give me a reason for these downvotes...

Comment: The downvotes may be related to: "Note that the restricted-source tag should be used with caution -- adding restricted-source to an otherwise trivial challenge does not necessarily make it interesting. Generally, a restricted-source challenge should be a task of moderate complexity along with a clear, simple and relevant restriction." (From: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/restricted-source/info)

Comment: I don't think this isn't interesting; for example the output 2014? 2016? without numbers one is quite interesting...

Comment: In addition to the restricted source issue, having "most languages wins" makes it tedious to compete. It's all about whoever is willing to put in lots of time to dig up lots of languages and do this (easy) task in all of them.

Comment: Maybe I can change the scoring rubric.

Comment: if you revisit [that 2014 question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code), there is a note edited to the top of the question saying not to repeat the challenge

Comment: I'm not exactly replicating it but I understand that I should use the sandbox.

Answer (score 3):

## 5 Languages - [Keg](https://github.com/Lyxal/Keg), [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) and [Curlyfrick](https://github.com/Lyxal/CFEsolang), 114 bytes

```
"""
!+._\PC\DC-\CC\CC- [|,]#`"""
''' TT__D++,q'''
print(ord("P")-ord("D"))
'''
...{}   ({}+{}+{}+{})*({}+{}+{})
'''
```

100% ascii too

[Try Keg online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fSUmJS1FbLz4mwDnGxVk3xtkZiHQVomt0YpUTQJLq6uoKISHx8S7a2jqFQA5XQVFmXolGflGKhlKAkqYumOGipKkJUsmlp6dXXcupUV2rDUOaWnAeWInC//8A)

[Try Python 3 online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X0lJiUtRWy8@JsA5xsVZN8bZGYh0FaJrdGKVE0CS6urqCiEh8fEu2to6hUAOV0FRZl6JRn5RioZSgJKmLpjhoqSpCVLJpaenV13LqVFdqw1DmlpwHliJwv//AA)

[Try 05AB1E online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fSUmJS1FbLz4mwDnGxVk3xtkZiHQVomt0YpUTQJLq6uoKISHx8S7a2jqFQA5XQVFmXolGflGKhlKAkqYumOGipKkJUsmlp6dXXcupUV2rDUOaWnAeWInC//8A)

[Try Curlyfrick online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tyqlMK8pMzv7/X0lJiUtRWy8@JsA5xsVZN8bZGYh0FaJrdGKVE0CS6urqCiEh8fEu2to6hUAOV0FRZl6JRn5RioZSgJKmLpjhoqSpCVLJpaenV13LqVFdqw1DmlpwHliJwv//AA)

[Try Vyxal Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJcIlwiXCJcbiErLl9cXFBDXFxEQy1cXENDXFxDQy0gW3wsXSNgXCJcIlwiXG4nJycgVFRfX0QrKyxxJycnXG5wcmludChvcmQoXCJQXCIpLW9yZChcIkRcIikpXG4nJydcbi4uLnt9XHQoe30re30re30re30pKih7fSt7fSt7fSlcbicnJyAiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Explanation coming soon. Soon here means a time that *isn't* 21 minutes past midnight.

Answer (score 3):

## 7+ languages, 24 bytes, score < 0.49

### Haskell, OCaml, Coq, Common Lisp, Erlang, Octave/Matlab, PARI/GP, and many other functional languages

`(length("twelvetwelve"))`

Comment: Exactly how many languages, though?

Comment: @Nobody Needs Names I don't know *exactly* how many. If you want to calculate the score, use the current number of languages

Comment: You can add PARI/GP to the list.

Answer (score 2):

## brainfuck, [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), Javascript; 3 languages, 52 bytes

```
print("+++++++^[>D+++++P++<-]>:".length/"+?".length)
```

Three cussword titled languages

Javascript: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69EQ0kbAuKi7VzAjABtbRvdWDsrJb2c1Lz0kgx9JW17GFvz/38A)

brainfuck: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v@/oCgzr0RDSRsC4qLtXMCMAG1tG91YOyslvZzUvPSSDH0lbXsYW/P/fwA)

Headass: [Do stuff online](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCJwcmludChcIisrKysrKyteWz5EKysrKytQKys8LV0+OlwiLmxlbmd0aC9cIis/XCIubGVuZ3RoKSIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

Javascript:

```
                  /             Divide
           .length     .length  The lengths
      "..."        "+?"         Of these strings (24/2)
print(                        ) Output the result
```

brainfuck (ignored characters removed)

```
+++++++[>+++++++<-]>    7*7 (canonical)
                    .+. print charcodes 49 and 50
```

Headass (ignored characters removed)

```
(        [>       ++<-]>:      nothing important
 +++++++^  D+++++P             print 12
                         .     halt
                          +?.) inaccessible code
```

Not sure what else I can add without drastically changing my approach. Just wanted to get a score up to start with for now.

Comment: `print("++++++++++++"/*P[>++++<-]>+*/.length)+"."` is 48 bytes.

Comment: @tsh i did not know you could insert comments like that mid thingy. i probably wouldnt have thought to shoot for 48 afterward anyway :D great golfing!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (jsshell), Python 3, bash (core utils)?, brainfuck, 109 bytes

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S grep -c ^
e=">+++++++[->+"
print(True//True*len(e));"""++++++<]>
=e.length)//+."""
```

I'm not quite sure if this should be count as bash as it actually runs `grep` from its shebang. It does not work on TIO version of jsshell, as support shebang as comment requires a newer version.

- [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X1lRv7S4SD8pM08/Na9MQTdYIb0otUBBN1khjivVVslOGwKide20lbgKijLzSjRCikpT9fVBpFZOap5GqqamtZKSEkSdTawdl22qHlA8vSRDU19fWw8oxQUD//8DAA)
- [brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fWVG/tLhIPykzTz81r0xBN1ghvSi1QEE3WSGOK9VWyU4bAqJ17bSVuAqKMvNKNEKKSlP19UGkVk5qnkaqpqa1kpISRJ1NrB2XbaoeUDy9JENTX19bDyjFBQP//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## Example Submission, \$1\$ Language(s), \$26\$ Byte(s), Score \$\frac{26}{1^2}=26\$.

Language(s):

- Python

```py
print(len('aaaaaaaaaaaa'))
```

## Explanation

Need I say more...?