# Shoot the ASCII Moon

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

(Previously on "Print the __ without using __" ... [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36639/the-symbols-vs-the-letters) and [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35310/write-the-whole-of-the-holed-using-the-unholed))

The game of [Hearts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts) has a popular scoring variant called "Shooting the Moon," whereby instead of trying to not acquire penalty cards (and thus penalty points), as is the usual gameplay strategy, if you acquire *all* of the penalty cards you actually score the best that round. We're going to apply that same logic to some code golf.

The ASCII printable characters (plus space) are, in order

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Let's divide these into three groups:

Alphanumeric:

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Symbolic (or non-alphanumeric)

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

and the space character.

Your task is to use the alphanumeric characters to print the symbolic characters (in any order), with the following restrictions:

- The program/function should take no input and output to STDOUT (or equivalent).
- You can use a symbolic character in your source code for a penalty of +5 per unique character.
- Using the same character more than once does not increase your penalty (e.g., you can use `[` 25 times and only get one +5 penalty)
- Whitespace (including tabs and newlines) in the output or the source code is completely optional. Leading, trailing, inline - no penalties or bonuses. They still count for bytes in source code as usual.
- If you manage to use all 32 symbolic characters in your code, you get a bonus of -100 points for **Shooting the Moon** instead of any penalties.
- If you manage to use all 32 symbolic *and* all 62 alphanumeric characters in your code, you instead get a bonus of -250 points for **Shooting the Sun** instead of any penalties.
- Characters inside literal strings, literal characters, or comments do not count for the bonus or the penalty. (E.g., a Foo program of something like `"!#$%..."` would be allowed, but would not get the bonus or penalty points for the characters inside the literal).
- Literal string or comment *delimiters* do count, however, so something like `// !#$*...` would count the initial `/` for penalty/bonus calculations.
- Yes, this rules out languages like Whitespace or the like, where everything not whitespace is treated as a comment. Bummer.
- Scoring is `bytes of code` + `penalty(ies)` + `bonus(es)`, lowest score wins. Negative scores are possible.

#### Example scores:

50 bytes code + (5 unique symbolic characters)*5 penalty each = 75 points

200 bytes code + (32 unique symbolic characters)*0 penalty each + (-250 bonus for shooting the sun) = -50 points

Comment: According to my calculations, there are *62* alphanumeric characters `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and *33* non-alphanumeric ```!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``` (note the space at the end). Is this correct?

Comment: What about no-ops and unexecuted code?

Comment: @Dennis As I told Kevin W, "Does it compile/run/execute/whatever? If yes, totally legit. I fully expected flavors of reflection, quines reading the source code, etc., to try and work around the restrictions, and if, in this instance, it means gobbledy-gook code that could be reached but isn't, works for me." ... I didn't explicitly call this out in the question, as I didn't want to overtly suggest that as the only method of doing this.

Comment: Does the output have to consist only of the symbolic characters?

Comment: @Luke Yes, excepting whitespace, newlines, etc. The code shouldn't output any other characters.

Comment: @TimmyD Python doesn't accept `$` in code (i.e. not a literal/comment), so is printing crap to STDERR OK?

Comment: Can we output duplicates?

Comment: @NickT Output to STDERR is fine.

Comment: @slebetman Duplicate characters being output is fine. See the Ruby answer, for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## GolfScript, -153

```
{""''!$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`|~#
}ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Prints

```
{""''!$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`|~#
}
```

Score:

- 97 bytes of source code: **+97**
- Shooting the Sun: **-250**

[Try it online.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=eyIiJychJCUmKCkqKywtLi86Ozw9Pj9AW1xdXl9gfH4jCn1BQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1Njc4OQ%3D%3D)

#### How it works

Since the code block (lambda, anonymous function)

```
{""''!$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`|~#
}
```

does not contain any syntax errors, it will be pushed on the stack and printed verbatim if left on it. The linefeed is required to end the comment that `#` started.

Finally, `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789` is an undefined token; it does nothing.

Answer (score 10):

## C++, 310

Well, I started this without realizing that `@` and backticks are totally disallowed in C++ source. Posting it even though it's a very poor entry as it stands, in case anybody knows a way out. Is there a compiler that would allow these characters in symbol names?

```
#include<IOSTREAM>
int main(int bgjkpqvwxyzBCDFGHJKLNPQUVWXYZ$){\
for(char _='!';_<127;++_){_==48?_=58:_==65||_==98-1.?_+=26:!~_^_&_*_%3,""[0];std::cout<<_;}}//
```

- 160 bytes
- 5 * 30 unique symbolic characters = 150 point penalty

---

## Edit: -90

Leaving the above because it's a little more interesting than the following, which uses an unused `#define` to sneak in the missing symbols.

```
#include<IOSTREAM>
#define bgjkpqvwxyzBCDFGHJKLNPQUVWXYZ !"#$%&'*,-./@[\]^`~
int main(){for(char _=33;_<127;++_){_==48?_=58:_==65||_==97?_+=26:_;std::cout<<_;}}
```

- 160 bytes
- Shooting the sun, -250 points

Comment: Ooof. I'm not aware of a compiler that allows backtick. Have a +1, instead.

Comment: +1 much appreciated! It was still fun even though it crashed and burned before making it to the moon.

Comment: GCC doesn't mind a `#define` with backtick in the definition. But it doesn't like the upper-case `IOSTREAM`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, not even on a Windows platform?

Comment: Didn't even think about `#define`. If that counts I can rethink everything here.

Comment: Yeah, hmm. I suppose `#define` isn't *technically* a comment, since it "does stuff" (and is processed by the compiler). Go ahead and abuse that.

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, -66

```
{'"#$%&()*.+,-/:!;<=>?@[\]^_`|~}""
```

Prints every symbol exactly once, without any extraneous whitespace.

Score:

- 34 bytes of source code: **+34**
- Shooting the Moon: **-100**

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B'%22%23%24%25%26()*.%2B%2C-%2F%3A!%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40%5B%5C%5D%5E_%60%7C~%7D%22%22)

#### How it works

Since the code block (lambda, anonymous function) `` {'"#$%&()*.+,-/:!;<=>?@[\]^_`|~} `` does not contain any syntax errors, it will be pushed on the stack and printed verbatim if left on it.

Since `"` only appears in the character literal `'"`, we also push an emoty string as `""`, which won't affect the output.

Comment: Doesn't that count as a string literal?

Comment: The last two bytes are a string literal. The rest in a block, which is CJam's closest equivalent to a lambda or anonymous function.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, -148

```
p %w{!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ 123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnoqrstuvxyz}[0]
```

Results in:

```
"!\"\#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
```

Produces an array, takes the special characters and inspects them.

102 (bytes) + 0 (penalty) - 250 (shot the sun) = **-148 points**

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Pretty dang slick answer.

Comment: Since `p` wraps the output of a string in quotes, you can leave the `"` out of your code to save a byte. In fact, since it also escapes various other characters, you can leave out `\` as well.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard not if I want to use all the special characters inside my code :/ I was just thinking about that. Leaving out the " or \ prevents me from using all the specials inside the code and shooting the sun.

Comment: Oh yeah... of course. That's the whole point, isn't it.

Comment: Hm, I'd argue that `%w{...}` is still a type of string literal and "Characters inside literal strings, literal characters, or comments do not count for the bonus or the penalty."

Comment: Y'know, @MartinBüttner , I think I'm agreeing with you. The fact that it's producing an array threw my thinking, but it is still an array of strings.

Comment: @TimmyD I see what you mean. Trying to rethink this approach. Just to clarify, in Ruby, most anything could be considered a literal. Is it string and symbol literals that you are really trying to avoid? [virtually everything in ruby is generated with literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html), so I'll plan on working around with ranges or something unless you say not.

Comment: @PotatoOmeletteSandwich Yeah. Tcl has similar limitations, but slebetman got around the restriction by using a variable name, and then generating the output based on that. The restriction for literals is intended to not use the data portion of the literal -- `set x="foo"` and the `"foo"` portion doesn't count.

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-93](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html), -125

Since having code that is never reached is OK, this is deemed an allowed answer.

```
p>g1g:,"}"`#@_g1+00p           #
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
YZabcdefhijklmnoqrstuvwxyz
```

it's 125 - 250, so -125.  I tried to avoid reading the characters in string mode as that seems to violate the rules, but I don't see any violation here.  I just read what every character is in the 1st row until it's ascii value is >125.  I had to change it a bit to have it run properly in the interpreter

Comment: Does the -151 version compile/run/execute/whatever? If yes, totally legit. I fully expected flavors of reflection, quines reading the source code, etc., to try and work around the restrictions, and if, in this instance, it means gobbledy-gook code that *could* be reached but isn't, works for me.

Answer (score 3):

### STATA, -120

```
#d 01256789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZbefgjklmnopqstuvwxyz`!$%&*+,-./:<=>?@[\]^_{|}~'
di "'`!#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~"char(34);
```

Abuses the standard STATA interpreter. The `#d` command (short for `#delimit`) changes the delimiter to ; unless whatever follows the command is "cr". But the spec only specifies what happens when what follows is ";" or "cr".

Score:

- 130 bytes of source code: **+130**
- Shooting the Sun: **-250**

Answer (score 3):

## Beam, <s>-34</s> -47

Now that I've fixed my initial misunderstanding, now to try and get some points back:)

```
'''''>`+++++++)--'''''>`@+@+@+vabcdefghi
/+++)++@+@+@+@+@+@\012^   _?Ps)klmopqrtw
+3456789ABv+@+@`<'''++++++++++<!"#$%&*,.
|CDEFGIJKL(     ^Z\''''>`+++++)+\=@[]{}~
\+`<'''''@<MNOQRSTUVWXYH@+@+@+@+/:;xyzj
```

Using the same logic for scoring as the [Befunge-93](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58889/31347) answer.  216 Bytes - 250 Shooting the Sun.  Now to see if I can compact it a bit more and improve my logic.

Brief explanation:
[image]

```js
var ITERS_PER_SEC = 100000;
var TIMEOUT_SECS = 50;
var ERROR_INTERRUPT = "Interrupted by user";
var ERROR_TIMEOUT = "Maximum iterations exceeded";
var ERROR_LOSTINSPACE = "Beam is lost in space";
var code, store, beam, ip_x, ip_y, dir, input_ptr, mem;
var input, timeout, width, iterations, running;
function clear_output() {
document.getElementById("output").value = "";
document.getElementById("stderr").innerHTML = "";
}
function stop() {
running = false;
document.getElementById("run").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("stop").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("clear").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("timeout").disabled = false;
}
function interrupt() {
error(ERROR_INTERRUPT);
}
function error(msg) {
document.getElementById("stderr").innerHTML = msg;
stop();
}
function run() {
clear_output();
document.getElementById("run").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("clear").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("input").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("timeout").disabled = false;
code = document.getElementById("code").value;
input = document.getElementById("input").value;
timeout = document.getElementById("timeout").checked;    
code = code.split("\n");
width = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < code.length; ++i){
 if (code[i].length > width){ 
  width = code[i].length;
 }
}
console.log(code);
console.log(width);    
running = true;
dir = 0;
ip_x = 0;
ip_y = 0;
input_ptr = 0;
beam = 0;
store = 0;
mem = [];    
input = input.split("").map(function (s) {
  return s.charCodeAt(0);
 }); 
iterations = 0;
beam_iter();
}
function beam_iter() {
while (running) {
 var inst; 
 try {
  inst = code[ip_y][ip_x];
 }
 catch(err) {
  inst = "";
 }
 switch (inst) {
  case ">":
   dir = 0;
   break;
  case "<":
   dir = 1;
   break;
  case "^":
   dir = 2;
   break;
  case "v":
   dir = 3;
   break;
  case "+":
   ++beam;
   break;
  case "-":
   --beam;
   break;
  case "@":
   document.getElementById("output").value += String.fromCharCode(beam);
   break;
  case ":":
   document.getElementById("output").value += beam;
   break;
  case "/":
   dir ^= 2;
   break;
  case "\\":
   dir ^= 3;
   break;
  case "!":
   if (beam != 0) {
    dir ^= 1;
   }
   break;
  case "?":
   if (beam == 0) {
    dir ^= 1;
   }
   break;
  case "_":
   switch (dir) {
   case 2:
    dir = 3;
    break;
   case 3:
    dir = 2;
    break;
   }
   break;
  case "|":
   switch (dir) {
   case 0:
    dir = 1;
    break;
   case 1:
    dir = 0;
    break;
   }
   break;
  case "H":
   stop();
   break;
  case "S":
   store = beam;
   break;
  case "L":
   beam = store;
   break;
  case "s":
   mem[beam] = store;
   break;
  case "g":
   store = mem[beam];
   break;
  case "P":
   mem[store] = beam;
   break;
  case "p":
   beam = mem[store];
   break;
  case "u":
   if (beam != store) {
    dir = 2;
   }
   break;
  case "n":
   if (beam != store) {
    dir = 3;
   }
   break;
  case "`":
   --store;
   break;
  case "'":
   ++store;
   break;
  case ")":
   if (store != 0) {
    dir = 1;
   }
   break;
  case "(":
   if (store != 0) {
    dir = 0;
   }
   break;
  case "r":
   if (input_ptr >= input.length) {
    beam = 0;
   } else {
    beam = input[input_ptr];
    ++input_ptr;
   }
   break;
  }
 // Move instruction pointer
 switch (dir) {
  case 0:
   ip_x++;
   break;
  case 1:
   ip_x--;
   break;
  case 2:
   ip_y--;
   break;
  case 3:
   ip_y++;
   break;
 }
 if (running && (ip_x < 0 || ip_y < 0 || ip_x >= width || ip_y >= code.length)) {
  error(ERROR_LOSTINSPACE);
 }
 ++iterations;
 if (iterations > ITERS_PER_SEC * TIMEOUT_SECS) {
  error(ERROR_TIMEOUT);
 }
}
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Code:<br><textarea id="code" rows="4" style="overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;width:90%;">'''''>`+++++++)--'''''>`@+@+@+vabcdefghi
/+++)++@+@+@+@+@+@\012^   _?Ps)klmopqrtw
+3456789ABv+@+@`<'''++++++++++<!"#$%&*,.
|CDEFGIJKL(     ^Z\''''>`+++++)+\=@[]{}~
\+`<'''''@<MNOQRSTUVWXYH@+@+@+@+/:;xyzj
</textarea><p>Timeout:<input id="timeout" type="checkbox" checked="checked">&nbsp;<br><br><input id="run" type="button" value="Run" onclick="run()"><input id="stop" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="interrupt()" disabled="disabled"><input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear_output()">&nbsp; <span id="stderr" style="color:red"></span></p>Output:<br><textarea id="output" rows="6" style="overflow:scroll;width:90%;">        </textarea><br>Input:<br><textarea id="input" rows="2" style="overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;width:90%;"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: Running this in your provided snippet, I get lots of extraneous characters in addition to just the symbolic characters.

Comment: @TimmyD Whoops sorry, misread the question.  Will delete and fix.

Comment: @TimmyD Think I have got it right this time

Comment: Awesome! But for me, it prints `!"#` and then errors out with `Maximum iterations exceeded`.

Comment: @ETHproductions, Thanks.  There was a bug in the snippet that caused the `_` and `|` to reflect the wrong way.  I had fixed up the snippet else where, but forgot to do this one.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 154 - 250 = -96

Requires error reporting to be off. I hope I'm not breaking the rules by adding the dead code between `$a=33` and `;$a<65`.

```
<?php #
Z:for($a=33,$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYdgijklmnqstuvwxyz_=@``.[!-0/~9%8^3|0&0].''."";$a<65;$a++){echo chr($a+10*($a>47)+26*($a>54)+26*($a>60));}\b;
```

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl, 135-250 = -115

```
set {123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZbcdhkmqwyz!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`|~} 0
puts [join [regexp -inline -all {\W+} [info vars]]]_
```

Explanation: Create a variable named `{123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZbcdhkmqwyz!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^|~}` (basically the entire ASCII sequence minus some alphanumeric characters already in the source) then get the list of all variables in scope (`info vars`) and use regexp to filter out the non-symbols form the resulting list. I believe a variable name qualifies as something that's not a string literal. This is possible because Tcl allows almost any byte sequence for variable and function names (including symbols and even non-printing characters).

Note: Strictly speaking, it's a string literal, which is why it's quoted in `{}` (tcl has two ways of quoting strings: `{}` and `""`). But in tcl, everything is a string literal including the entire program. Tcl is a string-based language after all. So I'm interpreting the "string literal" specification as: "string literal" when used as data.

Comment: +1 nice approach using the variable name. And yes, "string literal" is meaning what you've got for your interpretation -- `set x="foo"` and the like.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, -126

Nothing in string literals or comments. The output ain't pretty since it's `p`-ing an array of strings, but it's all there.

```
p @bdefgjkoqstuvwyz_BCDHJKLMPQSTUWXYZ=[*32..47,*58..64,*91..96,*123..126].map!{|x|x.chr};+-~0?"":(``%nil<$\>''^ARGF/IO&ENV)#
```

Score:

- Bytes: **+124**
- Shot the sun: **-250**

Answer (score 2):

## FORTH, -118

```
: !#$%&'()*+,-/0123456789=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|} ." !\q#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ " ;
```

Forth names are only delimited by whitespace, so the name is just all the shoot the sun characters minus : ." and ;

- Code: 132
- Shoot the sun: -250

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, -143 bytes

```
@echo !"#$%%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
@goto :a
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZbdfijklmnpqrsuvwxyz
:a
```

- 107 bytes of source code: **+107**
- Shooting the Sun: **-250**

I didn't think this would beat anyone. After all it's batch!

Comment: Do `:012345...z` fit the rule?

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), -135

```hs
main=putStr$!do{(x,y)<-"!:[{"`zip`"/@`~";[x..y]}
veRbOsE#%&*+/:>?@\^|~_0123456789ABCDFGHIJKLMNPQTUVWXYZcfghjklqw'=0
```

Score:

- 115 bytes
- -250 shooting the sun bonus

After re-reading I think dead code was ok so this version is shorter.
The main function is borrowed from @xnor's answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85728/60340). It basically takes the 
endpoints and zips them pairwise to transforms them into ranges, being equal to

```hs
putStr(concatMap (\(x,y)->[x..y]) [('!','/'),(':','@'),('[','`'),('{','~')])
```

The other line just defines an unused operator `#%&*+/:>?@\^|~` with long parameter names.

`` (),;[]`{}"'_ `` are the special characters that can't be used in operator names but `_` and `'` can be used variable names. The others are all used in the first line.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIRTElv1qjQqdS00ZXSdEqulopoSqzIEFJ3yGhTsk6ukJPrzK2lqssNSjJv9hVWVVNS1vfys7eISaupi7ewNDI2MTUzNzC0tHJ2cXN3cPTy9vH1y8gMCQ0LDwiMio5LT0jKzunsFzd1uD/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## MS-SQL, 133 bytes - 250 bonus = -117

```
create TABLE[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]]^_`{|}~](DdfGgHiJkPpQqUuVvWXYZz0123456789 xml)
SELECT NAME FROM sys.objects where name LIKE'!%'
```

Uses a system view specific to MS SQL, so not guaranteed to work on other platforms.

Creates a table with a name consisting of the 32 symbols in order. This is normally invalid for a SQL identifier, but we can make it work by surrounding it by brackets. This name is then retrieved from system view `sys.objects` (assuming that no other tables start with `!`).

Alphanumerics not used elsewhere make up the (unused) xml field name.

Make sure to clean up the table when you are done! (not included in score):

```
DROP TABLE[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]]^_`{|}~]
```