# Print all alphanumeric characters plus underscore

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Write a program or function that prints or returns a string of the alphanumeric characters plus underscore, **in any order**. To be precise, the following characters need to be output, **and no more**:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_
```

When printing to stdout, an optional trailing newline after your output is permitted.

**Built-in constants that contain 9 or more of the above characters are disallowed.**

---

Shortest code in bytes wins.

<sub>This is a very simple challenge, which I believe will generate some interesting answers nevertheless.</sub>

---

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=85666,OVERRIDE_USER=4162;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42681/discussion-on-question-by-orlp-print-all-alphanumeric-characters-plus-underscore).

Comment: "Built-in constants that contain 9 or more of the above characters are disallowed" *sighs in 05AB1E...*

Comment: Is duplication of one char allowed?

Comment: @l4m2 No. "To be precise, the following characters need to be output, **and no more**."

Comment: `and no more` can be parsed as "No more kind of chars"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Convex, 9 bytes

New method! Also, I realized that is it pretty much exactly the same as Luis' answer but in Convex, but I came up with this independently.

```
'{,®\W"Oò
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=J3sswq5cVyJPw7I&input=)

Explanation:

```
'{,           Array of chars from NUL to 'z
   ®\W"       Regex to match non-word characters
       Oò     Replace all matches with emtpy string
```

#### Old solution, 10 bytes:

```
A,'[,_¬^'_
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=QSwnWyxfwqxeJ18&input=)

Explanation:

```
A,          0-9
'[,_¬^      A-Za-z
'_          _
```

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes it is equivalent to the CJam code `A,'[,_el^'_`

Comment: Which encoding is this?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ CP-1252 or Windows-1252

Answer (score 16):

## Ruby, 26 bytes

Characters can be printed in any order? Don't mind if I do!

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/n5AaE6)

```
$><<(?0..?z).grep(/\w/)*''
```

Answer (score 11):

### Perl, 20 bytes

Requires `-E` at no extra cost.

```pl
say+a.._,A.._,_..9,_
```

So, my original answer (below) was a bit too boring. The only thing I've managed to come up with is the above, that's exactly the same, but looks a bit more confusing... It's pretty much exactly equivalent to the below:

```pl
say a..z,A..Z,0..9,_
```

I like [@msh210](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1976/msh210)'s suggestions in the comments, but they're just a bit too long!

Comment: +1. Slightly more interesting but longer is any of these, all 27 bytes: `say grep/\w/,map chr,1..122` || `say map{chr=~/\w/;$&}1..122` || `say map{chr=~s/\W//r}1..122`

Comment: @msh210 Still can't shrink this more... Managed a 25 though: `say chr=~/\w/g for 1..255`...

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), 62 bytes

```
_=>String.fromCharCode(...Array(123).keys()).replace(/\W/g,'')
```

Returns `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, so only 6 bytes shorter than a function that returns the string literal. Yes, it sucks.

Comment: You could try finding a string for which [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) returns the required output.

Comment: @gcampbell 60! (60 factorial) strings might take some time to search...

Comment: You could just use `atob`.

Comment: @gcampbell I have to exclude unrepresentable strings somehow.

Comment: @gcampbell It turns out that the btoa version takes 62 bytes anyway: 45 to encode 60 alphanumerics, 3 unencoded chars (including `_`) and 14 for `_=>atob("")+""`.

Comment: Oh, that didn't help then. You could still add it to your answer maybe.

Comment: My approach using `getOwnPropertyNames` of `Math` comes out at 87 bytes, but perhaps it is still interesting: `[...new Set(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math).join(""))].join("")+"456789ABCDFHJKMUVWXYZjkv"` (replace ("") with two graves)

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, 38 bytes

```
'_':['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']++['0'..'9']
```

Nothing to explain here.

Comment: question: what's the difference between `:` and `++`?

Comment: @Downgoat: `++` takes two strings and concatenates them. `:` takes a char and a string and puts the char in front of the string. `"_"++['a'..'z']...` also works, but is one byte longer.

Answer (score 9):

## Cheddar, <s>31</s> 27 bytes

```
->97@"123+65@"91+48@"58+"_"
```

This showcases the `@"` operator well

Non-completing because I finally got aroudn to fixing the `@"` operator. The bug was that it was generating a Cheddar range not a JS range so it couldn't properly work

---

### Explanation

The `@"` operator was designed by @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ, and what it does is generate a string range from LHS to RHS. When used as an unary operator, it returns the char at the given code point (like python's `chr`)

### Ungolfed

```
->
  97 @" 123 +
  65 @" 91  +
  48 @" 58  +
  "_"
```

Answer (score 9):

### brainfuck, 58 bytes

```
+++[[<+>->++<]>]<<[-<->]<<-.+<<++[->>+.>+.<<<]<--[->>.+<<]
```

[Try it online](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrW1s8Kz4tPisrPF0-XTw8Wy08LT5dPDwtLis8PCsrWy0-PisuPisuPDw8XTwtLVstPj4uKzw8XQ).

Initializes the tape to *3·2<sup>n</sup>*, and works from there.

```
+++[[<+>->++<]>]    initialize the tape
                    |   0 |   3 |   6 |  12 |  24 |  48 |  96 | 192 | 128 |   0 |   0 |
                                                                                    ^
<<[-<->]            subract 128 from 192
                    |   0 |   3 |   6 |  12 |  24 |  48 |  96 |  64 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
                                                                        ^
<<-.+<<++           ouput '_'; increment 24 twice
                    |   0 |   3 |   6 |  12 |  26 |  48 |  96 |  64 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
                                                ^
[->>+.>+.<<<]       output aAbBcC ~ zZ
                    |   0 |   3 |   6 |  12 |   0 |  48 | 122 |  90 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
                                                ^
<--[->>.+<<]        decrement 12 twice; output 0 ~ 9
                    |   0 |   3 |   6 |   0 |   0 |  58 | 122 |  90 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 8):

## V, 27 bytes

```
i1122ñYpñvHgJ|éidd@"Í×
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=aRYWMRsxMjLDsVlwAcOxdkhnSnzDqWlkZEAiG8ONw5c&input=)

This answer is *horribly* convoluted. I'll post an explanation later.

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 6916 1631 1b31 3232 f159 7001 f176 4867  i..1.122.Yp..vHg
00000010: 4a7c e969 6464 4022 1bcd d7              J|.idd@"...
```

Explanation:

Readable:

```
i<C-v><C-v>1<esc>                                   "Insert the text "<C-v>1"
                                                    "<C-v> means "literal"
                 122ñ       ñ                       "122 times,
                     Yp                             "Duplicate this line
                       <C-a>                        "And increment the first number on this line
                             vHgJ                   "Join every line together
                                 |éi                "Insert an 'i' at the beginning of this line
                                    dd              "Delete this line
                                      @"<esc>       "And execute it as V code.
                                                    "That will generate every ascii value from 1-123
                                             Í×     "Now remove every non-word character.
```

Comment: :D :D :D Cheddar is tied with a golfing lang!

Answer (score 8):

## J, <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to randomra!*

```
~.u:95,;48 65 97+i."*10,,~26
```

Output:

```
   ~.u:95,;48 65 97+i."*10,,~26
_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

### Explanation

I wont provide an explanation *per se*, but will provide intermediate results.

```
   10,,~26
10 26 26
   i. b. 0
1 _ _
   *  b. 0
0 0 0
   i."* b. 0
   i."*2 3 4
0 1 0 0
0 1 2 0
0 1 2 3
   i. 2
0 1
   i. 3
0 1 2
   i. 4
0 1 2 3
   i."*10,,~26
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
   0 1 2 + i."*10,,~26
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
   48 65 97+i."*10,,~26
48 49 50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48  48
65 66 67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122
   ;48 65 97+i."*10,,~26
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122
   95,;48 65 97+i."*10,,~26
95 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 ...
   u:95,;48 65 97+i."*10,,~26
_01234567890000000000000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   ~.u:95,;48 65 97+i."*10,,~26
_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell v3+, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
-join([char[]](1..127)-match'\w')
```

Constructs a dynamic array `1..127`, casts it as a `char` array. That's fed to the `-match` operator working on the regex `\w`, which will return all elements that match (i.e., exactly alphanumeric and underscore). We encapsulate those array elements in a `-join` to bundle it up as one string. That's left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Comment: Hey, that's not fair. My own solution is identical except I started at `0` ...

Comment: @Joey Gotta go fast. :D

Comment: Especially for the trivial and obvious solutions, I guess ;-)

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 31 bytes

```haskell
do(x,y)<-zip"aA0_""zZ9_";[x..y]
```

The expression `zip "aA0_" "zZ9_"` gives the list of endpoints `[('a','z'),('A','Z'),('0','9'),('_','_')]`. The `do` notation takes each `(x,y)` to the inclusive `\(x,y)->[x..y]` and concatenates the results. Thanks to Anders Kaseorg for two bytes with `do` instead of `>>=`.

Compare to alternatives:

```haskell
do(x,y)<-zip"aA0_""zZ9_";[x..y]

zip"aA0_""zZ9_">>= \(x,y)->[x..y]
f(x,y)=[x..y];f=<<zip"aA0_""zZ9_"
id=<<zipWith enumFromTo"aA0_""zZ9_"
[c|(a,b)<-zip"aA0_""zZ9_",c<-[a..b]]
f[x,y]=[x..y];f=<<words"az AZ 09 __"
```

Comment: `do` notation saves two bytes: `do(x,y)<-zip"aA0_""zZ9_";[x..y]`

Answer (score 5):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/),  <s>85</s> <s>83</s> 73 bytes

Just plain object pascal using a set of chars. Writing a full program instead of a procedure shaves off 2 bytes. Removing the program keyword shaves 10 more bytes.

```pascal
var c:char;begin for c in['a'..'z','A'..'Z','0'..'9','_']do write(c);end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/vyyxSCHZKjkjscg6KTU9M08hLR8ooJCZF62eqK6np16lrqPuCGJEARkGIIYlkBGvHpuSr1BelFmSqpGsaZ2al6L3/z8A)

Comment: I always was and probably will always be confused by the exact classification of Object Pascal. Turbo/Borland Pascal and FreePascal are certainly happy without the useless `program` keyword.

Comment: @manatwork I didn't know that. Oddly enough it now makes pascal competitive here...

Comment: The language I grew up with. I know that it is not yet dead...

Comment: @rexkogitans Yeah I learned it at school, but can't remember anything from back then... I'm playing with some programming again now

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
s:#"\w"0rk\|
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%3A%23%22%5Cw%220rk%5C%7C&debug=0)

Finds all characters in U+0000 to U+007B that matches the regex `/\w/`.

Outputs `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

#### alternative approach: 15 bytes

```
ssrMc4"0:A[a{_`
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ssrMc4%220%3AA%5Ba%7B_%60&debug=0)

basically generates the half-inclusive ranges required: `` 0-:, A-[, a-{, _-` ``.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 50 bytes

Call `f()` without any arguments.

```
f(n){for(n=128;--n;)isalnum(n)|n==95&&putchar(n);}
```

Prints

```
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba_ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210
```

Comment: `isalnum(n)|n==95&&putchar(n)`

Comment: There's UB there. You didn't pass the required arguments.

Comment: @orlp - You used `putc` instead of `putchar`. `putc` expects a stream to write to as well, which you didn't pass. The function itself works fine (try removing your `putc` altogether, and it works).

Comment: @owacoder Oops!

Comment: @ven No, it's not. In C, calling a function without giving arguments leaves the variables uninitialized. Then, in the `for`, `n` is initialized before it's used, so all's well.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes that's wrong. `If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined.` 6.5.2.2/6, see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: If what you said only applies to some ancient C version (my link is the C11 draft), please point out the legalese, I'm interested.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. I just tested it on GCC and it seems to act that way. It might be that way from C89, lemme see if I can dig up the spec after class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it *is* undefined behavior, but what matters is that it actually works with one or more implementations (at least GCC).

Comment: @Ven  Maybe he just needs to say that it relies on undefined behaviour? 
 https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/c-c-golfing-should-undefined-behaviour-be-allowed

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>30</s> <s>19</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 12 bytes

I modified my [original alphabet attempt](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=27630329#27630329) for this latest version. Each character is printed in a loop.

The first line is empty.

```
;
+T\`;w`w_
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CjsKK1RcYDtsYGxf&input=)

**Output:**

```
_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

*Thanks to Leaky Nun for golfing 4 bytes off my latest attempt.*

Comment: I'd say that `w` counts as a constant containing 9 or more of the required characters. You'll probably have to expand the right hand side and replace the `w` on the left with `o`. Although you can save a byte by using `EO` instead of `d` since they only contain 5 characters each.

Comment: @mbomb007 `w` inside the transliteration stage has nothing to do regex. It's a shorthand that expands to a list of the required 63 characters. At least I'd ask orlp about this case specifically, since it's quite different from using `\w` in a regex.

Answer (score 4):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 63 bytes

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_
```

Comment: How is it the valid answer? Looks like it's violating the rules.

Comment: @nicael which rule?

Comment: "Built-in constants that contain 9 or more of the above characters are disallowed."... Am I missing something obvious, @Leaky?

Comment: Yes, that this didn't use any built-in constants.

Comment: Ok, but this is weird at least. Definitely OP doesn't ask you to copy-paste the sequence, that's not interesting.

Comment: @nicael They are *default* constants, not *built-in* ones. You can modify them.

Answer (score 4):

My first attempt at codegolf!

### C#, <s>168</s> <s>152</s> <s>150</s> <s>147</s> <s>130</s> <s>127</s> <s>117</s> <s>116</s> <s>115</s> <s>109</s> 106 bytes

```
for(var a='0';a<'~';a++){Console.Write(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(a+"","\\w")?a+"":"");}
```

Thanks a lot to aloisdg, AstroDan, Leaky Nun and Kevin Lau - not Kenny for all the help in comments.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Feel free to remove all the space! Also check [Tips for golfing in C#](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top) for some tips.

Comment: Also don't forgot `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. It is sad, but we have to use it.

Comment: I can't check right now but I believe that you can save some bytes by using +"" instead of .ToString().

Comment: Can you use `[\w_]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`?

Comment: You are both right, @LeakyNun I need one more \ to escape, but still shorter :)

Comment: What's those spaces there doing?

Comment: `var a=(char)i;Console.Write(Regex.IsMatch(a+"", "[\\w_]") ?a+"":"");` to `var a=""+(char)i;Console.Write(Regex.IsMatch(a,"[\\w_]")?a:"");`

Comment: Great - saved me 2 bytes more. I'm really starting to like this codegolf :)

Comment: Actually saved me 5 bytes - didn't know about ""+ instant string conversion :)

Comment: Try this (117 bytes) using System.Text.RegularExpressions;for(char a='0';a<='~';a++){Console.Write(Regex.IsMatch(a+"","[\\w_]")?a+"":"");}

Comment: Very impressive @AstroDan !

Comment: @Daniel 2 more, try Debug.Write instead of Console.Write (make sure it works with your compiler / ide)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in VS2015. And I'll also have to include System.Diagnostics correct?

Comment: @Daniel Worked for me in LINQPad 4 without System.Diagnostics. But only counts if it works for you. Also if you @ someones name they will get a message directly.

Comment: AFAIK, the `\w` regex class covers the alphanumerics and also `_`, which should make `"\\w"` valid enough for your regex match function.

Comment: You are right @KevinLau-notKenny - Thanks

Comment: Your code should a be function or a full program not a statement. Also use .NetFiddle to share a demonstration of your code :)

Comment: First of all welcome to PPCG! Maybe this challenge in C# isn't the best to codegolf, since just printing everything manually: `Console.Write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_");` (81 bytes) is shorter. ;) Or, even slightly shorter: `var s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";Console.Write(s+s.ToUpper()+"0123456789_");` for 78 bytes. I would also take a look at the link @aloisdg gave you for Golfing tips in C# for future reference. Once again welcome, and have fun here!

Comment: "C# isn't the best to codegolf" I find C# fun enough to code golf. I think it is a great mainstream language to play with. If you are here to win, you will loose. Define your objective as learning and having a good time and you will win all the times.

Comment: @aloisdg I completely agree with everything you've said, but you've taken it out of context. The entire sentence is "Maybe _this challenge_ in C# isn't the best to codegolf". If you look at all my answers you only see Java 7 answers which are usually longer than C# and never win. Why do I post them anyway? Because it's fun, just like you've stated. I was merely stating that this particular challenge it's shorter to just print the hardcoded string, and therefore C# (and Java as well) isn't really suitable for this challenge, imho. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Indeed. Sorry I mistook your words :)

Comment: @aloisdg No problem, I also realized that printing the hard-coded string is a [default loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1063#1063) despite being shorter in C# and Java..

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I figured we should be able to avoid that whole regex ordeal by doing something like this:
`for(var a='/';a++<'~';)if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(a)||a=='_')Console.Write(a);` (75 bytes)
I also removed braces, replaced ternary with if, and shortened the loop.

Comment: @PatrikWesterlund Not bad - will check it out later :)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 58 bytes

```
print('_',*filter(str.isalnum,map(chr,range(123))),sep='')
```

A full program that prints to STDOUT.

The output is: `_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

**How it works**

```
map(chr,range(123))       Yield an iterator containing all ascii characters with
                          code-points in [0,122]...
*filter(str.isalnum,...)  ...keep characters if alphanumeric and unpack into tuple...
print('_',...,sep='')     ...add underscore and print all characters with no separating
                          space
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/xjU0OD)

If string constants were allowed, the following would have been 45 bytes:

```
from string import*
print('_'+printable[:62])
```

Comment: `print('_'+*filter(str.isalnum,map(chr,range(123))))`

Comment: @LeakyNun That throws a syntax error. I thought about doing something similar with `print('_',*filter(str.isalnum,map(chr,range(123))))`, but that prints separating spaces; the OP said in the comments that '...no spaces are permitted in the output at all'.

Comment: Python 2 can save one byte with this approach: `print''.join(filter(str.isalnum,map(chr,range(123)))),'_'`

Answer (score 4):

## bash – <s>47</s> 37 bytes

```
man sh|egrep -o \\w|sort -u|tr -d \\n
```

Output on my system is:

```
_0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ
```

Thanks to Digital Trauma for helpful suggestions.

On some systems you might be able to use `ascii` instead of `man sh` to save a byte.

Comment: `man sh|egrep -io _\|\\w|sort -u|tr -d \\n`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thank you! Experimented and found out `\w` matches `_` and is already case insensitive, so could shorten even more.

Comment: `env` instead of `man sh` should work on most environments. It does on mine. `$ env|egrep -o \\w|sort -u|tr -d \\n` -> `0123456789ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

Comment: There's no `J`. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

## Pure bash, 32

```bash
printf %s {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9} _
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/XQi0ep).

Answer (score 4):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 17 bytes

```
00000000: a854be 2cbc9e 71d597 14bc56 1ad99e 713b           .T.,..q....V...q;
```

#### Output

```
0123456789AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz_
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=YWRkIDQ4CmZ3ZCAxCmFkZCAxMApqbXAKICAgIHJ3ZCAxCiAgICBwdXQKICAgIGFkZCAxCiAgICBmd2QgMQogICAgc3ViIDEKam56CnJ3ZCAxCmFkZCA3CmZ3ZCAxCmFkZCAyNgpqbXAKICAgIHJ3ZCAxCiAgICBwdXQKICAgIGFkZCAzMgogICAgcHV0CiAgICBzdWIgMzEKICAgIGZ3ZCAxCiAgICBzdWIgMQpqbnoKcndkIDEKYWRkIDQKcHV0&input=) Check *Debug* to see the generated binary code.

#### How it works

The binary file above has been generated by assembling the following SASM code.

```lisp
add 48     ; Set cell 0 to 48 ('0').
fwd 1      ; Advance to cell 1.
add 10     ; Set cell 1 to 10.
jmp        ; Set an entry marker and jump to the jnz instruction.
    rwd 1  ;   Retrocede to cell 0.
    put    ;   Print its content (initially '0').
    add 1  ;   Increment cell 0 ('0' -> '1', etc.).
    fwd 1  ;   Advance to cell 1.
    sub 1  ;   Decrement cell 1.
jnz        ; While cell 1 in non-zero, jump to 'rwd 1'.
           ; This loop will print "0123456789".
rwd 1      ; Retrocede to cell 0, which holds 48 + 10 = 58.
add 7      ; Set cell 0 to 65 ('A').
fwd 1      ; Advance to cell 1.
add 26     ; Set cell 1 to 26.
jmp        ; Set an entry marker and jump to the jnz instruction.
    rwd 1  ; Retrocede to cell 0.
    put    ; Print its content (initially 'A').
    add 32 ; Add 32 to convert to lowercase ('A' -> 'a', etc.).
    put    ; Print the cell's content.
    sub 31 ; Subtract 31 to switch to the next uppercase letter ('a' -> 'B', etc.).
    fwd 1  ; Advance to cell 1.
    sub 1  ;   Decrement cell 1.
jnz        ; While cell 1 in non-zero, jump to 'rwd 1'.
           ; This loop will print "AaBb...YyZz".
rwd 1      ; Retrocede th cell 0, which holds 65 + 26 = 91.
add 4      ; Set cell 0 to 95 ('_').
put        ; Print its content.
```

Comment: Wow, I was about to post [a solution very similar to yours](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=YWRkIDQ4CmZ3ZCAxCmFkZCAxMApqbXAKc3ViIDEKcndkIDEKcHV0CmFkZCAxCmZ3ZCAxCmpuegpyd2QgMQphZGQgNwpmd2QgMQphZGQgMjYKam1wCnN1YiAxCnJ3ZCAxCnB1dAphZGQgMzIKcHV0CnN1YiAzMQpmd2QgMQpqbnoKcndkIDEKYWRkIDQKcHV0&input=&debug=on).

Comment: Alike minds think great!

Comment: @LeakyNun Hm, kinda late, but it looks like yours is 3 bytes shorter...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Sesos used to be encoded in a less efficient manner. Both programs are 17 bytes long now.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, well, the TIO cache can be confusing at times.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'm not sure what you mean. The cache cover the last few *weeks* and didn't even exist in 2016.

Answer (score 4):

### PHP, 40 bytes

```php
_0<?for(;$a++^9?$a^q:$a=A;)echo" $a"|$a;
```

[Online Demo](http://codepad.org/zcUbbro6).

Comment: +1 for excellence. Side note: PHP 7.2 yields warnings mentioning that future versions will throw errors for undefined constants. :-(

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 25 bytes

```
"_"w9yrcw"A":"Z"ycL@l:Lcw
```

This prints the following to `STDOUT`:

```
_9876543210abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

#### Explanation

```
"_"w               Write "_"
9y                 Get the list [0:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9]
  rcw              Reverse it, concatenate into one number, write
"A":"Z"y           Get the list of all uppercase letters
        cL         Concatenate into a single string L
          @l:Lcw   Concatenate L to itself lowercased and write
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 18 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
∊'\w'⎕S'&'⎕UCS⍳255
```

prints:

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: @user *Built-in constants that contain 9 or more of the above characters are disallowed.*

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
7W:'\W'[]YX
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=N1c6J1xXJ1tdWVg&input=)

```
7W     % Push  2 raised to 7, i.e. 128
:      % Range [1 2 ... 128]
'\W'   % Push string to be used as regex pattern
[]     % Push empty array
YX     % Regex replace. Uses (and consumes) three inputs: source text, regex pattern, 
       % target text. The first input (source text) is implicitly converted to char.
       % So this replaces non-word characters by nothing.
       % Implicitly display
```

Comment: 2 bytes shorter: `8W:'\w'XX`

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan Thanks! But I think newlines are not allowed as separators. The challenge says " a string of the alphanumeric characters plus underscore... and no more"

Comment: So why couldn't you do `8W:'\w'XX!` which I tried but doesn't work

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan  Very good question! Let me [answer you in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31120487#31120487) so I can use a little more characters

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 11 bytes

*4 bytes off thanks to @FryAmTheEggman and @Dennis!*

```
A,'[,_el^'_
```

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=QSwnWyxfZWxeJ18&input=)

```
A,    e# Push range [0 1 ... 9]
'[,   e# Push range of chars from 0 to "Z" ("[" minus 1)
_el   e# Duplicate and convert to lowercase
^     e# Symmetric difference. This keeps letters only, both upper- and lower-case
'_    e# Push "_".
      e# Implicitly display stack contents, without separators
```

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 12 bytes

```
žyLçá9Ý'_)˜J
```

**Explanation**

```
žyL               # push [1..128]
   ç              # convert to char
    á             # keep only members of the alphabet
     9Ý           # push [0..9]
       '_         # push underscore
         )˜J      # add to lists of lists, flatten and join
                  # implicit output
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb55TMOnw6E5w50nXynLnEo&input=)

Edit: Saved 4 bytes thank to Adnan

Comment: Does this also work: `žyLçJá9ÝJ'_J`?

Comment: @Adnan: Yes of course :) Much better!

Comment: Alternatively `žyLçá9Ý'_)˜J` also works for the same byte count.

Comment: Alternatively, `žj` non-competing.

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, <s>114</s> <s>103</s> <s>98</s> <s>90</s> <s>76</s> 71 bytes

Another <s>trivial</s> (now non-trivial) solution, but this time is BF!

Saved 14 (!) bytes thanks to @primo.

Saved 4 more bytes thanks to @primo's suggestion to generate the range backwards, and I saved another by incrementing before printing for the lowercase letters.

New (recurrence 4, 71):

```
+[--[<+++++++>->+<]>-]<<+++<--<-<-----<++++.+>>>[-<<.+<+.>>>]>[-<<.+>>]
```

Old (values, 114):

```
-[----->+<]>--->++++++++++>--[----->+<]>-------.++>----[---->+<]>++>++++[->++++++<]>++[-<<.+<<.+>>>>]<<<<<<[-<.+>]
```

Old (recurrence 1, 103):

```
++++++++++[[<+>->+<]>+++++++++++++++]<<[<]>>+>++++++++>>----->>-----.++<<<<<[->>>.+>>.+<<<<<]<[->>.+<<]
```

Old (recurrence 2, 90):

```
+++++++[[<+>->+<]>>+++[-<+++++++>]<]<<[<]>+++>-->->----->++++.++<<<[->>.+>.+<<<]<[->>.+<<]
```

Old (recurrence 3, 76):

```
+[[<+++++++>->+<]>+++]<<[<]>+++>-->->----->++++.++<<<[->>.+>.+<<<]<[->>.+<<]
```

Assumes 8 bit wrapping cells and wrapping memory. I used [Try it online](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1stLVs8KysrKysrKz4tPis8XT4tXTw8KysrPC0tPC08LS0tLS08KysrKy4rPj4-Wy08PC4rPCsuPj4-XT5bLTw8Lis-Pl0&input=).

All print out `_AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789`

First, this part

```
+[--[<+++++++>->+<]>-]<<
```

initializes the tape with these values

```
[91, 70, 49, 21, 7]
                 ^
```

This works because the recurrence relation I modeled basically is `f(x) = 7 * (3 * x + 1)`, backwards. See [@primo's Hello, World! Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68494) for an explanation of what a recurrence relation is.

Then, it's fairly simple to change these values to useful ones. (and print the underscore)

```
Code: +++<--<-<-----<++++.+

Tape: [96, 65, 48, 26, 10]
       ^
```

Then, the simple loops use the values to print the rest of characters. I save 1 byte by having an increment before the print.

```
>>>[-<<.+<+.>>>]>[-<<.+>>]
```

<s>I really need to find a shorter sequence generation.</s>

<s>I found a recurrence relation that seems to work well, but there might be a shorter one w/ less hunt and peck.</s>

I used a linear regression calculator to find what should be the shortest possible linear recurrence relation, so I should probably find some other formula if I want to improve.

@primo really improved the recurrence relation a lot, thanks.

Comment: How about a backwards construction? `+[--[<+++++++>->+<]>-]`

Comment: @primo Wow! How does that work?

Comment: 3 is uneven so it will loop a full 256 times. By ending with `>-]`, you can be sure that the final term will be 1 (x7). Actually, you should probably start with `-`, it finishes a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

## F#, <s>50</s> 59 bytes

```
Seq.iter(printf"%c"<<char)(95::[48..57]@[65..90]@[97..122])
```

Output:

```
_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Edit: missed the digits the first time

Edit2, inspired by [this Haskell solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85666/print-all-alphanumeric-characters-plus-underscore/85728#85728) this F# snippet is 67 bytes.

```
Seq.zip"aA0_""zZ9_"|>Seq.iter(fun(x,y)->Seq.iter(printf"%c")[x..y])
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_
```

Answer (score 3):

### Brainfuck, 89 bytes

```
+++++++++[>+++++>+<<-]>+++.>[<+.>-]<+++++++>>+++++++++++++[<+<+.+.>>-]<<+++++.+>[<+.+.>-]
```

[Try it here](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#KysrKysrKysrWz4rKysrKz4rPDwtXT4rKysuPls8Ky4+LV08KysrKysrKz4+KysrKysrKysrKysrK1s8KzwrLisuPj4tXTw8KysrKysuKz5bPCsuKy4+LV0=)

Details:

```
+++++++++[>+++++>+<<-]>+++.  Goes to '0' while remembering a 9 for the 9 other numbers
[<+.>-]                      Simply prints for the next 9 characters
<+++++++>                    Moves it 7 space to the letters
>+++++++++++++               Saves a 13
[<+<+.+.>>-]                 Prints 2 char at a time while making a second '13' space
<<+++++.+>                   Moves 5, prints '_' and moves to the lowercases
[<+.+.>-]                    And again the double print
```

If I could have commented, I would have to improve others answers. But since I can't, I might as well post my own. As I started writing this the lowest BF one was 96 long.

Answer (score 3):

## Hexagony, 33

```
"A}_8_47<='>({a/_x.@.9!\356);');
```

Expanded:

```
    " A }
  _ 8 _ 4 7
 < = ' > ( {
a / _ x . @ .
 9 ! \ 3 5 6
  ) ; ' ) ;
   . . . .
```

Output:

```
aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ1203568479_
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=GiJBfV84XzQ3PD0nPih7YS9feC5ALjkhXDM1Nik7Jyk7&input=)

Note that there is an unprintable character `0x1A` as the first byte of the program. This also makes the first row of the expanded Hexagon look sort of off. Many thanks to Martin for showing me this trick, as well as for suggesting the algorithm for printing the alphabet!

This prints the alphabet by storing `a` and `A` on two edges of a hexagon and the number 26 on the edge of the hexagon that touches the joint between the letters. This looks something like this:

```
A \ / a
   |
   26
```

Then it enters a loops that prints the letters and then increments them, and then decrements the number. After one iteration we would have:

```
B \ / b
   |
   25
```

And so on. The linear code for the initialisation is: `0x1A " A } a`. The linear code for the loops outside of control flow changes is: `; ) ' ; ) { ( ' =`.

Once the counter reaches zero, we follow a different path to print the numbers and an underscore. Written out linearly this is: `x 3 5 6 8 4 7 9 ! ; { @`. This replaces the current memory edge's value with the number 1203568479 (note that `x`'s ASCII code is 120), which contains all of the decimal digits. We print out this number and then we use a neat feature of Hexagony: we print out the number mod 256 as an ASCII character. This just happens to be 95, or underscore.

Answer (score 3):

## [SMBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 29 bytes

```
<[<.-<.->>-]<<-.<[<.->-]9
zZ
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#@28TbaOnC0R2drqxNja6emA@kG3JVRUl9f8/AA)

The last byte is a literal `\x1A` (decimal 26). It shows in the "edit" mode of this answer as a tiny arrow, but cannot otherwise be seen for some reason...

I use literals in the source code to provide a starting value and how many times to loop. 26 times for the loop printing `Z-A` and `z-a`, then subtract and print `_`, then use the newline (decimal 10) to print `9` and subtract, looping 10 times.

**Output:**

```
ZzYyXxWwVvUuTtSsRrQqPpOoNnMmLlKkJjIiHhGgFfEeDdCcBbAa_9876543210
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

Inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85689/80010).

```r
cat(intToUtf8(c(97:122,65:90,48:57,95)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUIjWcPS3MrQyEjHzNTK0kDHxMLK1FzH0lRTU/N/YlJySmpaekZmVnZObl5@QWFRcUlpWXlFZZWjk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vn39AYFBwSGhYeERklIGhkbGJqZm5hWX8fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, PC DOS, 26 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: be12 01ad 918a c1cd 293a cde0 f83c 5f75  ........):...<_u
00000010: f2c3 7a61 5a41 3930 5f5f                 ..zaZA90__
```

Listing:

```
BE 0112     MOV  SI, OFFSET TBL     ; SI to range table
        RLOOP:
AD          LODSW                   ; AL = high, AH = low
91          XCHG AX, CX             ; move to CX
        CLOOP:
8A C1       MOV  AL, CL             ; move current char to AL for display
CD 29       INT  29H                ; write to console
3A CD       CMP  CL, CH             ; high and low char the same yet?
E0 F8       LOOPNZ CLOOP            ; if not, decrement and keep looping
3C 5F       CMP  AL, '_'            ; was last char displayed a '_'?
75 F2       JNZ  RLOOP              ; loop until then
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
        TBL DB 'zaZA90__'           ; handy table of ranges to display
```

Uses a table with a range of chars to display.  Turned out that it wasn't any longer to do it this way than unroll all of the 4 different conditions in code (though I'm positive I can be proven wrong there).

Standalone PC DOS executable (COM) program.

Runtime:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [NoRAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/NoRAL), <s>173</s> 169 bytes

```python
psh 0a1a
sto 0100 41
sto 011a 61
orr 0201 0201
jpz 0220
sto 0134 30
inc 0215
inc 0216
dec 0201
inc 0205
inc 0206
inc 0209
inc 020a
dec 0202
jpz 0235
jmp 0203
sto 013e 5f
```

NoRAL is a toy assembly language I found on Esolangs.org. Let's give it a whirl (using a minimally adapted version of the Python implementation): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVlbc5tGFH7nV5yiaSzFl7IgZNmTeKZNmqdOJtP0qanGg9DKwpGAWZAtp@lvd79dQFy0wthqebBXy57vXPbsuSzxQ7qIQudxLqIVeUJ4DxSs4kik2Q@DjBVf0dvsV//ol6NBPvHFmtBrsjbMwoNlSeqJ9DqaX8ciusF7@e86Wxr7@GNtLBsL1fQySFJMmabhR6t4yVOupoLwJpudcfXeMhKhSI0gnF3nY@rhRyC4n1ISrYXPaZ3wGQUhre4CI/HFtb/wREYd459LPVKyUTSXA/8rQapIPJzQnScCb7rkNI8EAHwv4RSkBPrwhifQqUczPg/CIA2iMKHTfQ/kldDRdez3B5fUi9ep1DkI0yjnRV5CwVyC32OkBFYGTxdccIPwYJ20qDLW1RWNt5Msn3xFtutCJsVrEd1fC34Dm3GRgKdaHQtw7A8qY/MTrC28Fb2L1iGWXpJ5gpdHf19aw80/R2fQe@Wl/dgf1Kj@5CKiD0vv5pKKB3SSyq5QSeGcSZ3yHdzkoU66h9JuUH5WO/MpCjI5WyiHilLZQdHKHeyHmQ2Ceb8fXjmMvHBG4Rtmnw9y4@ARPF2LsP@HWHPFmi8T3nz5wcPkoGpmeBTnYYuNjws3@KxW0vsgiZfeQ@kex2a2XnmZdFQh/as/LiUroL5DZQ7J5SEYbF9KutuSzrErhPKp@LyyrDuiYzB6TY6Nwe2kthgWKq1WUA4aiKVI/kKUq3TCUdOQDQCTtDptFa6b0oTA5qlZyG4e/xXWySv7Ih1Gty0NM1sntGtpnV8FYOhOBpLtrswtDMYnxEb/Kwc2OiF7@B@yUFac8en6poi7HQzpMvtkG9W1wlRjSjDQn96gOPfKGen4LTEVaAX3ZgpdhqtK5DR6c2gQxTiCQYjA2jc/Rr///BvNgyVHOJNcBHJSucr0ztJNaubzc6W@@RgnC7I85iFNRWQhZ9GQ5WPm0YgZkRCEBMXUH@M2/oaBbeVLnCE5Mgn5mGRuMRjBjH62PpuxilfWqBhcFAOvWGzn4I5r3K5iOeMUXDi580dIe5akIoj7gzMEkgAa4xBAE@zGMgi53JB5Zn2cZTnz5RI54gfo2TNl9kH@4gilcj2y64qHaVILJfeRUOlSkuYcGse/mqPLsXIp/JX0sPeZv4wSrrwJLKPwjiPFrkJsWhj4CUGjKPYjZHIVi/M0KPgcCS/0kV2romyZ1OVBxuyrJW@hnDebmRU5pS8VzigzJDNq0svCQ/pWMWlkcQoWKwHDVkBbD6gBwja2ATndgWK/DWj4DKBvbUBud6BEtAGNOgOtors2oPPOQGHUauzxM4DSNqCLzkCIHK2OaXVGitt1Y6w7UrJoReru3KiLWpG6e3eyWLYiDZ@B1G7x7v6NwNuK1N3Bk/W0Fam7hyNhtCJ1d3FknFak7j6O1qo1Vnb38Zt2f7K7@/gsaT0tdncfn4qvbUjtylVLX5mQUYJI4IFEHqp8bNP0IeWaFFjNuU2msqaSOF8u7YkqMHczdE2QJ3Hsy844SqlGNd9DLj1AjSdZG2Vx2iPVBMYIPRihFlr7qgHHi81mQ@pyIBG@KhoTrlptVBu1@wdDXTnUp8i4X6BoJNn/ZVuWXzMomX1UNkzeaGTt03bOnvRkl55w8kR@1SArl1WUpApD3kpUMRwNxhAY8vYBOA2FUNSg8CuKuYxgIj2HWMMh7cKaapWUfJKzgAQo@FH/7XnzoxRnUAPLFu2hyId2QVqjdAoxKjA4IZXGzpcb6kI1VH2WXZ62qnJ2Q7lCnnL8aivOC9mr2trRs3eq3Yt0FIkEEoytoZ6k2n3lr2z1hjVr5y3e/u44E9KRHNEJuHqO7i5H5z/gmKDNGek5jhq7ksS5KwwnhdmB85NyJ41rDCdZxd3Lb9ni7C6nDVLiZe4pT44OTbdPqCXJOtfrcN7iWQd4E6pOssZ6luO6NympQZCSdaEnuNgjY992XTotpw44f9hp1dB6WgmY9eT5@36oxWJpsamefTO2Ya9Pq3vdFKnwB3InLzSGav99vTTNYFThVjXJU96ZMZI5y5rpGTlate26i@@ckmo2US9Y@dLooagmi@v5DTukkFfQfzygq6rV9mSIN28Qeg5ySdTtZM31wro6YWtyPuGxV1eNJc@QC@VD3qbtyFUNitkXiCzN75UmrwJeIsoQoqynRZ@3I8p5h/083VsSnD67JCgp8uGhJYG8CmP6koCNO9U7bLfQYd0rnAPdV17gMad@m1RV4aLT/rDdjWHdd@RAFdDHIS4Ax5sm0XKd8hMqvqZpdbKrmaL8CLf1i1pwElkNvfdk5PQvzSjoHBEmpCuyfiH@QBHL723YnGDlLSlcr6Zc1uezrZl2lGJ70p8UI79k/lWWLvQ@B/2oQOV184EehADORlBhln0jotlayI@exb0333B/LVsDvdzVTNX8BFh/UXy02i1M0OuSZUEENDFhBDuJRk@i7WorUlgDXWlZb0J3hOvtvM0/3@ySbUWv0TQ@VtTIpoJ7Xx//BQ)

There's also a browser-based interpreter [here](http://esolangs.thecoderpro.com/esolangs/NoRAL/) if you want to step through the code.

#### Explanation

Everything in NoRAL is stored in addressable memory, including the output (256 consecutive bytes, displayed as a 32x8 rectangle) and the program itself, which is self-modifying.

```python
# We use two memory locations in the code, 0x0201 and 0x0202, as counters
# Set digit counter to ten (0x0a), letter counter to twenty-six (0x1a)
# The psh instruction pushes something to the stack, which we're not using, so it's
# effectively a no-op
psh 0a1a
# The output section of memory runs from addresses 0x0100 to 0x01ff
# We're going to put A-Z at 0100-0119, a-z at 011a-0133, 0-9 at 0134-013d, and _ at 013e
# Output uppercase and lowercase letter, starting with A (ASCII 0x41) & a (0x61)
# These instructions will be modified later to output the other letters
sto 0100 41
sto 011a 61
# OR digit counter with itself (no-op, but sets the zero flag if counter is zero)
orr 0201 0201
# If the digit counter is now zero, skip next section:
jpc 0220
#     Output digit, starting with 0 (ASCII 0x30)
sto 0134 30
#     Increment memory location and ASCII code in previous statement
inc 0215
inc 0216
#     Decrement digit counter
dec 0201
# Increment letters' memory locations and ASCII codes
inc 0205
inc 0206
inc 0209
inc 020a
# Decrement letter counter
dec 0202
# If letter counter is now zero, skip next instruction:
jpz 0235
#   Jump back to "output uppercase and lowercase letter"
jmp 0203
# Output underscore (ASCII 0x5f)
sto 013e 5f
```

Comment: There's no permalink feature in the interpreter, that's purely awful.

Comment: [...Eh.](http://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/) The thing I found more problematic was that the code disappears out of the input box every time you click Run, but I just kept my code in a text editor and pasted it in whenever I was ready to run it. No big deal.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `dr`, <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
‛\w₇ɾCẎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkciIsIiIsIuKAm1xcd+KCh8m+Q+G6jiIsIiIsIiJd)

-1 thanks to @emanresu A

-1 thanks to @pxeger

Beats almost everything.

```
‛\w122ɾCẎ # Takes no input
‛\w       # The string "\w"
   122r   # inclusive range 1-122
       C  # Cast to character
        Ẏ # Regex groups
          # "d" flag prints the deep sum of the top of the stack
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 11 bytes

```
122ɾCkr↔ṅ\_
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCIxMjLJvkNrcuKGlOG5hVxcXyIsIiIsIiJd)

An alternative solution requiring no regex. Possibly cheating.

```
122ɾCkr↔ṅ\_ # Takes no input
122r        # inclusive range 1-122
    C       # Cast to character
     kr     # Uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and digits
       ↔    # Remove all not found in the second argument
        ṅ   # Join by nothing
         \_ # String "_"
            # "Ṫ" flag outputs sum of stack
```

Comment: Nice! `122` -> `⁺¢`

Comment: You can use `₇` instead

Comment: [Apparently](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/commit/3077dbc35aec014aff7c0c4b92ce69c8b1b47907) someone switched around the order of `Ẏ`, so you now need the `r` flag

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
for i in range(65,123):x=chr(i);print(''if x in'[\\]^`'else x,end='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8xUx9DIWNOqwjY5o0gjU9O6oCgzr0RDXT0zTaECqEw9OiYmNi5BPTWnOFWhQic1L8VWXV3z/38A)

Nice

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 13 bytes

```
150m.C#P)\_+s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=150m.C%23P%29%5C_%2Bs)

Generates ascii 0-150 and filters by alphanumericness and adds `_` to the end

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 62 bytes

```python
r=range
print''.join(map(chr,r(97,123)+r(65,91)+r(48,58)))+'_'
```

prints:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_
```

This could probably be golfed more but I'm not sure how!

Comment: Since the output can be in any order, try fiddling with combining ranges and using slices. You may be able to shave off a few bytes that way.

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript, 18 bytes

```
10,123,65>'[\]^`'^
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 55 bytes

```js
x=>[...new Set(Object.keys(this).join`j345689`)].join``
```

1. The code works correctly *only* when executed inside the global Firefox browser console (tested with Firefox 47.0 on Linux Mint inside a freshly created profile).

   - To be able to open the console, you first have to set `devtools.chrome.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`. (You can then open it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>).
2. Even the most ridiculously small change to the browser will likely break this code. In fact, I'm not sure if it will even work on another operating system.

   - The name of the profile might matter as well. I've named mine *Default User*.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
a=CharacterRange;"_"<>{48~a~57,65~a~90,97~a~122}&
```

Anonymous function. Takes no input and returns the string `"_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` as output. Just concatenates a few character ranges.

Answer (score 2):

### ZX Spectrum, (Machine Code) 27 bytes

start in BASIC with `PRINT "" AND USR 4e4`

```
      org 40000
      dump 40000


      ld b,"z"
      ld a,"_"
      rst 16
nchar ld a,b
      cp "/"
      ret z
      cp ":"
      jr c,ok ; print numbers
      sub "A"
      cp "Z"+1-“A”
      ld a,b ; undo change
      jr c,ok ; print A-Z
      cp "a"
      jr c,fnext ; in between ranges
ok    rst 16
fnext djnz nchar
```

Hexcode

```
067A3E5FD778D641fe1a78380b
413809FE5B3804FE613801D710Ea
```

Output: `_zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210`

Comment: Can we have a hexdump of the compiled version?

Comment: Will make it later.

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 14 bytes

```
“09AZaz_”Or2/Ọ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcMDlBWmF6X-KAnU9yMi_hu4w&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 64 bytes

```lua
s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"print(s..s:upper().."_0123456789")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2FYpMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyiskqpoCgzr0SjWE@v2Kq0oCC1SENTT08p3sDQyNjE1MzcwlJJ8/9/AA)

Comment: I tried your code with [this](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) and it doesn't print numbers.

Comment: @PrzemysławP Just ran it in the demo environment and it ran just fine (printing out `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_`)

Comment: Yes, but question was to output also `0123456789`, right?

Comment: @PrzemysławP Wow, how did I missed that ?! Thanks, it's fixed now, it should be printing `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_0123456789`

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 5 bytes

```
¬ ~Ó×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@39ojULd4cmHp///DwA)

#### Explanation

```
¬ ~                      " Outputs characters in the range " " to `~`
Ó×                       " Removes all non alphanumeric characters
                         " Synonym of vim's :s/\W//g
```

Answer (score 2):

## K, 28 bytes

```
_ci,/(97 65+\:!26),95,48+!10
```

Generates `[97..122]++[65..90]++[95]++[48..57]` and maps the numbers to chars.

Answer (score 2):

## Pure [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>35</s> 29 bytes

***-6 bytes** inspired by @pxeger's Zsh+`coreutils` answer*

```
>{0..z};printf %c [[:IDENT:]]
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpVojy8pKU6XaSrfaQE@vqrZWOTou2srTxdUvxCo2tvb/fwA)</s>

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZ77aoN9PSqaq0LijLzStIUVJMVoqOtPF1c_UKsYmMhaqBKYVoA)

The `[:IDENT:]` character class is exactly this. <s>We use empty fallback `${:- }` to a brace expansion, remove all non-`[:IDENT:]` characters, and then `(j::)`oin.</s>

Turns out it's shorter to use `multios` to create a file for each character, then glob all matching files, joined with `printf %c`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 bytes

Full program.

```apl
'_',∊⍳¨'zZ9'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L96vLrOo46uR72bD61Qr4qyVAcJ/y8AAA)

`⍳¨'zZ9'` "**ɩ**ndices" until each of the three characters

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`'_',` prepend an underscore

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
C,E7~XW
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhbLnXVczesiwiE8qCBMEgA)

#### Explanation

```
C,E7~XW
  E7     2 to the 7th power (128)
 ,       Range
C        Cast each integer in the range to a character
    ~XW  In each character, find the first regex match of `\w`
```

The result is a list of values, some of which are nil, some of which are an alphanumeric or underscore character. By default, Pip outputs lists with no separator, and nil outputs nothing; so the output of the program is simply the requested characters plus a trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <sup><s>27</s></sup> 26 bytes

```
ls>{0..z}|tr -d '
:-@[-^`'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuha7cortqg309Kpqa0qKFHRTFNS5rHQdonXjEtQhCqDqYOoB)

Explanation:

- `>{0..z}`: create files named `0` `1` ... (all the ASCII characters in between) ... `y` `z`
- `ls`: list all those newly created files
- `` tr -d '¶:-@[-^`' ``: remove the additional punctuation characters and the newlines

`ls>` works on arrays (unlike `<<<`), but is shorter than `echo`. (doesn't work if you care about order or duplicates). There's your newly discovered golfing tip of the day!

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <strike>71,</strike> 70 bytes

```java
(b,B)->{B="_";for(b=47;b++<122;)B+=b>57&b<65|b>90&b<97?"":b;return B;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5NS8MwGL7vV7zk4BLaBR3OMtNWiODN044yJOnamZqlJXkzGLO/vUbU0/PA89mrs1r1h8@5sSoEeFXGwXUBMEZtTQMBFSY4D@YAp6TRHXrjjm97UP4YWLL2qYBHNJZ30TVoBselefmj5fOH8qrB1ufwm/zHGrpqpjqXbFVfZUXeiegGT3V1XwidZeXdei2YzCpdb4obXT5svnS9vU1sWzwR8qiFbzF6B1JMs0h/AXaXgO2JDxH5mBbQOtpxNY72QpewzIEQxn6c02KavwE)

Inspired by an answer from dorukayhan this is a `java.util.function.BiFunction<Character, String, String>`

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>54</s> 48 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to @TaylorRaine*

```
=CONCAT(ROW(1:10)-1,CHAR({64,96}+ROW(1:26)))&"_"
```

### Original Answer

```
=CONCAT(ROW(1:10)-1,CHAR(ROW(2:3)*32+COLUMN(A:Z)))&"_"
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnjZQpsxMJUvleHLq?e=lsEV6T)

Comment: If you replace the innards of the `Char` statement with `{64,96}+ROW(1:26)`, you can get this down to 48 bytes

Comment: Thanks.  That's what happens when you get locked in on a way to do something.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
[c|c<-['('..'~'],(_,"")<-lex['a',c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzq5JtlGN1pdQ11PT71OPVZHI15HSUnTRjcntSJaPVFdJzk29n9uYmaegq1CQWlJcEmRQtr/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

Not the shortest answer but I thought of a cute way to solve this: pick out all the chars `c` such that `['a',c]` lexes into a single identifier.

`lex "a("` returns `[("a","(")]` but `lex "ak"`  returns `[("ak","")]`.

The only false positive is `a'` which is a valid identifier in Haskell even though `'` is not `A-Za-z0-9_`.

We can eliminate it by starting the range at `(` (one past `'`).

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 20 bytes

```
95 48:57 65:90t32+vc
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OTUgNDg6NTcgNjU6OTB0MzIrdmM&input=)

This is a very boring and straightforward answer.

Comment: You can replace `95 ` by '_' or by `95c` and then `h` casts numbers to chars automatically, so you save the final `c`. Also, you can replace `32+`  by `ck`. And changing the order allows you to remove a space: `65:90tck95c48:57v`

Answer (score 1):

### [SML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML), <s>70 (lame) bytes, 80 78 71</s> 64 bytes

**I did it!** The lame solution has been defeated by 6 bytes:

```
fun&123="_"| &91= &97| &58= &65| &n=str(chr n)^ &(n+1);print(&48)
```

[Try it online!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smlnj_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdGlmVjh6TllISDg) 
Better readable:

```
fun t 123 = "_"
  | t 91  = t 97
  | t 58  = t 65
  | t n   = str(chr(n)) ^ t (n+1);
print(t 48)
```

Keep reading to see past me whining about not having found this solution yet.

---

```
print"_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

The sad truth so far: I didn't manage to get something shorter than this, and believe me, *I've tried*.

**Straight forward using build-in functions:**

```
print("_"^implode(List.filter Char.isAlphaNum(List.tabulate(123,chr))))
```

Generate Char list, filter, implode (`char list -> string`), add `_`, print:

```
_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Uses 71 bytes and is thereby 2 bytes to long to beat the lame solution. As more or less only keywords remain, I'm pretty sure this approach can't be golfed any further.

**Let's build our own function!**
This approach yielded multiple solutions of which the shortest one

```
fun&26a=""| &n a=str(chr(n+a))^ &(n+1)a;print(&16 32^ &0 65^ &0 97^"_")
```

*also* still needs 71 bytes. At least some a bit more interesting stuff is happening here. Let's name the function `f` instead of `&` and have closer look:

```
1  fun f 26 a = ""
2    | f  n a = str(chr(n+a)) ^ f (n+1) a
3  ;
4  print(f 16 32 ^ f 0 65 ^ f 0 97 ^ "_")
```

- **4** `f n a` returns a string of 26-`n` consecutive ascii-chars starting at char number `a`. `^` concats two strings.
- **1** Pattern matching. If the second argument is 26, return an empty string.
- **2** Recursion: If `n` is not yet 26, get the current char, convert it into a string and append it to the (recursively build) rest of the string.
- **3** Tell the interpreter that we are finished with declaring `f` so we can use it afterwards.

> 26-n? Why not do something more intuitive like
>
> ```
> fun f 0 a = ""
>   | f n a = str(chr(n+a)) ^ f (n-1) a;
> print(f 10 47 ^ f 26 64 ^ f 26 96 ^ "_")
> ```
>
> , would nobody ask here ever.

Because on the one hand this would print

```
9876543210ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba_
```

which albeit correct doesn't look very nice. However, more importantly in this case we have one `0` and two `26` and in the other case two `0` and one `26`, which saves **1** byte.

Nevertheless it's still two bytes to go to underbid the infamous solution. At least for this approach remains a tiny bit of hope to achieve this goal, some time, in a brighter future ...
*But probably not.*

Comment: There's no lowercase `z`. Typo?

Comment: @owacoder Thanks! That was a typical off-by-one error, as `z` is char number 122, but `List.tabulate` has to count to 123 to reach it.

Answer (score 1):

### [MSM](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MSM), 79 bytes

```
;.;.;.;.;.;.:,,_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.
```

There's no shorter way to get all the letters, numbers and the underscore than explicitly writing them down. I also need 62 `.` commands to concatenate all the chars into a single string. These are generated by starting with a single `.` (on the very right), duplicating an concatenating (-> `;.`) 8 times, splitting into 64 single dots again (-> `:`) and dropping two of them (-> `,,`).

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 85 bytes

```
()=>{var r="_";for(char c='/';c<'z';)r+=char.IsLetterOrDigit(++c)?c+"":"";return r;};
```

C# lambda where the output is a `string`.

A full string would be 69 bytes...

Code:

```
()=>{
    var r="_";
    for(char c='/';c<'z';)
        r+=char.IsLetterOrDigit(++c)?c+"":"";
    return r;
};
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LzctRq)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 106 bytes

```
String A(char b){String B="_";for(b=48;b++<58;)B+=b;for(b=65;b++<91;)B+=b;for(b=97;b++<123)B+=b;return B;}
```

Returns `_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` by abusing for-loops.

Making the above function compilable costs 9 bytes, resulting in a 115-byte program:

```
class a{String A(char b){String B="_";for(b=48;b++<58;)B+=b;for(b=65;b++<91;)B+=b;for(b=97;b++<123)B+=b;return B;}}
```

The equivalent monolithic program which prints `_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` is 148 bytes long:

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){char b;String B="_";for(b=48;b++<58;)B+=b;for(b=65;b++<91;)B+=b;for(b=97;b++<123)B+=b;System.out.print(B);}}
```

---

## Java (lambda expression), 91 bytes

```
(b,B)->{B="_";for(b=48;b++<58;)B+=b;for(b=65;b++<91;)B+=b;for(b=97;b++<123)B+=b;return B;};
```

This is a `java.util.function.BiFunction<Character, String, String>`.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit boring, but just manually printing everything: `void f(){System.out.print("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_");}` (94 bytes) is shorter in Java. ;)

Comment: yay under 100 ''void f(){char c=97;String r="";while(c<='z')r+=c++;System.out.print(r+r.toUpperCase()+"_");}

Comment: 91 my final form, void f(){char c=65;String r="";while(c<=90)r+=c++;System.out.print(r.toLowerCase()+r+"_");}

Comment: @KevinCruijssen shorter, as function: `()->"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345‌​6789_"` ("only" 69 bytes).

Comment: 79 void d(){for(char b=1;b<127;b++)System.out.print((b+"").replaceAll("\\W",""));}

Comment: This is missing a semicolon after the 123:   for(b=97;b++<123)

Comment: 74 bytes (b,B)->{B="_";for(b=47;b++<122;)if(b<58||b>64&&b<91||b>96)B+=b;return B;};

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 22 bytes

```
0o#{ £YdÃf@Xf"\\\\w"Ãq
```

[Try it there](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=MG8jeyCjWWTDZkBYZiJcXFxcdyLDcQ==&input=).

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <s>60</s> 48 bytes

**New version that's much shorter!**

```
<?=preg_replace('/\W/','',join(range(' ','z')));
```

[Try it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/oBueEh)

Inspired by TimmyD's solution. Takes a range of all characters from   to `z`, joins them into a string, then replaces all characters that match `\W` (which is any character not specified in this challenge) with nothing.

**Old version:**

```
0123456789_<?php for($i=64;++$i<91;)echo chr($i).chr($i+32);
```

Ungolfed:

```
0123456789_
<?php 
    for($i=64;++$i<91;) echo chr($i).chr($i+32);
```

Anything written outside the `<?php` tag is considered plain text. The for loop in the PHP code echoes the uppercase and lowercase of each letter.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 17 bytes

```
RψΜz@~dpAHd mHLSE
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Us-Izpx6QH5kcEFIZCBtSExTRQ)

### Explanation

```
RψΜz@~dpAHd mHLSE
   z@~             range from 1 to 126
  Μ   dpAH         chars of
 ψ        d mHLS   filter all that don't match "\w+" (LS)
R               E  join by ""
```

Answer (score 1):

## LINQ, 88 bytes

```
from c in Enumerable.Range(0,123)where char.IsLetterOrDigit((char)c)|c==95 select(char)c
```

A LINQ expression (OK it is almost C#) where the output is an `IEnumerable<char>`. You can try it with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck 36 Bytes (96 commands)

```
>++++++[-<++++++++>]+++++[<.+.+>-]<+++++++>+++++++++++++[-<.+.+>]<++++.++>+++++++++++++[-<.+.+>]
```

Explanation:

```
 >++++++[-<++++++++>]    Increment to '0'
 +++++[<.+.+>-]          Print 10 characters (0 to 9)
 <+++++++>               Increment to lower upper characters
 +++++++++++++[-<.+.+>]  Print 26 characters (A to Z)
 <++++.++>               Increment to '_' Print it and move to a
 +++++++++++++[-<.+.+>]  Print 26 characters (a to z)
```

EDIT: Most straightforward solution IMHO, still shorter than the others

Comment: That's not how we count bytes. In brainfuck, this is a 96-bytes solution, because every command is stored in one byte. You could port it to [CompressedFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CompressedFuck) though.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 160 bytes

```
(setq a 47)(loop(setq a(+ a 1))(princ(code-char a))(when(and(> a 56)(< a 64))(setq a 64))(when(and(> a 89)(< a 96))(setq a 96))(when(> a 121)(return)))(princ'_)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.x, 63 bytes

```python
print''.join(chr(a)for a in range(123)if chr(a).isalnum())+'_'
```

[Try it online.](https://repl.it/Cd9J/0)

**Explanation:**

```python
chr(a)for a in range(123)if chr(a).isalnum() # generates a list iterating through ascii 
                                             #  symbols, picking just numbers alphabet characters

''.join(...)+'_'                             # joins a list of items with no spacing;
                                             # appends '_' at the end
```

My first golfing attempt; thanks to [mbomb007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2415524/mbomb007) for the hints

Comment: You can remove some spaces.

Comment: where for example? I thought I got rid of each one I could

Comment: `print''.join(chr(a)for a in range(48,123)if chr(a).isalnum())+'_'`. Quotes and parentheses/brackets are delimiters. You don't have any, but you can also do something like `print 1if 1else 0`. See the [Tips for golfing in Python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python?s=1|1.1465) page.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```c
i;k(){for(;putchar(i%26+"aA0"[i++/26])^57;);puts("_");}
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 21 bytes

```
_ci95,(97+!26),65+!26
```

Answer (score 1):

## O, 40 bytes

```
[[D2*(,]B6*(+{n.84*+}dC8*(C4*.9+mr]{nc}d
```

Answer (score 1):

## C--, 230 bytes

```
target byteorder little;export main;import putchar,isalnum;foreign"C"main(){bits32 v,t;v = 48;T:t=foreign"C"isalnum(v);if (t!=0){foreign"C"putchar(v);}if (v==95){foreign"C"putchar(v);}v=v+1;if (v<123){goto T;}foreign"C"return(0);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
target byteorder little;

export main;
import putchar, isalnum;

foreign "C" main(){
    bits32 v, tmp;
    v = 48;
Top:
    tmp = foreign "C" isalnum(v);
    if (tmp != 0){
        foreign "C" putchar(v);
    }

    if (v == 95){
        foreign "C" putchar(v);
    }

    v=v+1;
    if (v < 123) { goto Top; }

    foreign "C" return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 36 characters

```groovy
print(("0".."z").grep(~/\w/).join())
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ groovy -e 'print(("0".."z").grep(~/\w/).join())'
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 35 bytes

```
()->join(['a':'z','A':'Z',0:9,'_'])
```

Alternative solution, also 35 bytes:

```
()->replace(join('0':'z'),r"\W","")
```

Answer (score 1):

## 16-bit x86 machine code, 26 bytes

In hex:

```
B030B90A00AA40E2FCB05FAA40B11A5040AAE2FC5834207BF4C3
```

Input: `DI`: pointer to an array of at least 63 bytes. Function outputs the sequence

```
0123456789_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

without any termination, since its length is constant.

Disassembly:

```
00: B0 30       mov    al,'0'
02: B9 0A 00    mov    cx,10
_00000005:
05: AA          stosb              ;*DI++=AL
06: 40          inc    ax          ;AL++
07: E2 FC       loop   _00000005   ;Print digits
09: B0 5F       mov    al,'_'      ;0x5f
0B: AA          stosb
0C: 40          inc    ax          ;AX=0x60
_0000000D:
0D: B1 1A       mov    cl,26
0F: 50          push   ax
_00000010:
10: 40          inc    ax
11: AA          stosb
12: E2 FC       loop   _00000010   ;Print single-case letters
14: 58          pop    ax
15: 34 20       xor    al,020      ;Flip "case" bit
17: 7B F4       jnp    _0000000D   ;Repeat if "not parity", i.e. AX is back to 0x40
19: C3          ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 52 bytes

```
FOR I=65TO 90?CHR$(I);CHR$(I+32);
NEXT?1234567890;"_
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 68 bytes

```
puts abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCExKTklNS09IzMrOyc3L7@gsKi4pLSsvKKyytHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjLKwNDI2MTUzNzCMv7/fwA)

---

## tcl, 99

```
time {append s [incr i]} 9
set i 64;time {set s $s[format %c%c [incr i] [expr $i+32]]} 26
puts _0$s
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/KBUF73368)

---

## tcl, 100

```
time {append s [incr i]} 9
time {set s $s[format %c%c [expr [incr i]+55] [expr $i+87]]} 26
puts _0$s
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/NOIG26713)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 70 bytes

```
PRINT'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_'
```

Procedural solutions in SQL are just too long, due to the length of keywords. A couple of my best attempts:

**76 Bytes**, store the alphabet then `UPPER` it:

```sql
DECLARE @ CHAR(26)='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'PRINT'0123456789_'+@+UPPER(@)
```

**100 Bytes**, add *all* chars from 65-122, then strip out the ones I don't want:

```sql
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(99)='0123456789'A:SET @+=CHAR(LEN(@)+55)IF LEN(@)<68GOTO A
PRINT STUFF(@,37,6,'_')
```

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB, 30 bytes

```
['a':'z','A':'Z','0':'9','_']
```

Very simple :)

Or, at the same cost:

```
char(48+[49:74,17:42,0:9,47])
```

or

```
char([97:122,65:90,48:57,95])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
;C+B+9ô ¬+'_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/39pZ20nb8vAWhUNrtNXj//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/), 15B(The Keg SBCS is in Keg wiki.)

```
\_\0\9ɧZAɧzaɧ(,
```

Explanation:

```
\_#             Push _
  \0\9ɧ#        Push range 0-9
       ZAɧ#     Push range Z-A
          zaɧ#  Push range z-a
             (,#Output
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/Jj7GIMby5PIox5PLqxJPLtfQ@f8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

#### x86_16 machine code - 57 bytes

```
B4 0E         MOV AH, 0EH
        LOWERCASE:
B0 61         MOV AL, "a"
8A D8         MOV BL, AL
CD 10         INT 10H
           LOOP1:
FE C0         INC AL
CD 10         INT 10H
3C 7A         CMP AL, "z"
74 02         JE UPPERCASE
75 F6         JNE LOOP1
        UPPERCASE:
8A C3         MOV AL, BL
24 DF         AND AL, 0DFH
CD 10         INT 10H
           LOOP2:
FE C0         INC AL
CD 10         INT 10H
3C 5A         CMP AL, "Z"
74 02         JE NUMBER
75 F6         JNE LOOP2
          NUMBER:
B0 30         MOV AL, "0"
CD 10         INT 10H
           LOOP3:
FE C0         INC AL
CD 10         INT 10H
3C 39         CMP AL, "9"
74 02         JE UNDERSCORE
75 F6         JNE LOOP3
       UNDERSCORE:
B0 5F         MOV AL, "_"
CD 10         INT 10H
            EXIT:
B8 4C00       MOV AX, 4C00h
CD 21         INT 21H
```

Running with DOSBox :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ë½óG╨}S
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=89aba247d07d53&i=)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n>>8?'':(/\w/.test(c=Buffer([n]))?c:'')+f(-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoAgEADA57hLmNcIVOgb1UHMjSLWUKtbX7eG2d3tsk/bWSTHJVTSf9aGjemsED2o6VFtCbmA18NFFBKMPCNa3wuBDYF8GauPnOMR2iOuQIBYPw)

Trivial one

Answer (score 1):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), 35 bytes

```
65~a26(a`+BPa`32++BP!`)10(zP!z)95BP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/38y0LtHITCMxQdspIDHB2EgbSCsmaBoaaFQFKFZpWpo6Bfz/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 41 bytes

```factor
"Aa0_""   \0"[ dupd + [a,b] write ] 2each
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU3d0GBPP3crhezUorzUHIXcxJIMvaLEvPTUYjBbITNfoTi1sDQ1LxkoYr20tCRN1-KmppJjokG8kpKkJGeMgVK0QkppQYqCtkJ0ok5SrEJ5UWZJqkKsglFqYnIGRMMCKAWlAQ)

Comment: I don't know how this lang works, but shouldn't you mention the  `USING: kernel math.ranges math io sequences ;` header somewhere? not necessarily as part of your bytecount, but it doesn't seem like a default, correct me if im wrong

Comment: @thejonymyster Factor is a whole can of worms when it comes to imports. [Factor's byte counting policy for imports](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20512/byte-counting-policy-for-library-imports-in-factor) was painstakingly developed by @Bubbler and others as a balancing act of various factors. Long story short: EVERYTHING has to be imported in Factor. I would have to `USE: math` if I want to add two numbers. No one wants to see that in every answer. Factor is image-based, so I can have any vocabs I want loaded without explicitly loading them.

Comment: The rule is - vocabularies must be mentioned before the byte count unless they are auto-use vocabularies, which most are.

Answer (score 1):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-as ""`, 12 bytes

```
[0-9A-Z_a-z]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVW0km5isZKOklLsgqWlJWm6FmuiDXQtHXWj4hN1q2IhQlCZBVAaAA)

If Regenerate supported character class shortcuts, then `\w` would work as a 2-byte solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 27 bytes

```
'_',⎕UCS∊47 64 96+⍳¨10,2⍴26
```

Comment: Nice answer! I suggest you add a short explanation to help people understand how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

## brainfuck, 105

first code golf attempt using this

```
>++++++[<++++++++>-]++++++++++[-<.+>]<+++++++>>+++++[<+++++>-]<+[-<.+>]<++++.++>>+++++[<+++++>-]<+[-<.+>]
```

ungolfed

```
>++++++[<++++++++>-]         // p1=48
++++++++++                   // p2=10
[-<.+>]<                     // print 0-9, p1=58, p2=0
+++++++                      // p1=65
>>+++++[<+++++>-]<+          // p2=26
[-<.+>]<                     // print A-Z, p1=91, p2=0
++++.++                      // print underscore, p1=97 
>>+++++[<+++++>-]<+          // p2=26
[-<.+>]                      // print a-z
```

Comment: `++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++` That can be done better.

Comment: improved the `+`x26 as well

Answer (score 0):

### R

```
cat(letters,LETTERS,0:9,"_",sep="")
```

I believe this does not count as `letters` and `LETTERS` are built-in constants. But this one should be fine:

```
cat(intToUtf8(c(65:90,97:122)),0:9,"_",sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Actually, 24 bytes

```
"[\]^`""A{"Oix♂c-9ur♂$+Σ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=IltcXV5gIiJBeyJPaXjimYJjLTl1cuKZgiQrzqM&input=)

There's probably a shorter way

Explanation:

```
"[\]^`""A{"Oix♂c-9ur♂$+Σ
       "A{"O              push a list containing the ordinals of "A" and "{"
            ix            flatten the list, end-exclusive range
              ♂c          convert each ordinal into its corresponding character
"[\]^`"         -         remove non-alphabetic characters except "_"
                 9ur♂$+   push range(10), convert to strings, concatenate lists
                       Σ  concatenate strings in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org)

```perl6
put |grep /<alnum>/,'0'..'z'
put |grep /\w/,'0'..'z'
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
put # ｢print()｣ but with trailing newline

# turn the following into a Slip so that there aren't 
# any spaces in the output
|

grep
  /\w/,      # match wordchars
  '0' .. 'z' # in this Range
```

( `grep` returns a List, which puts spaces between each element when stringified )

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 56 bytes

`f()->[X||X<-lists:seq(1,$z),re:run([X],"\\w")/=nomatch].`

---

## Erlang, 57 bytes

`f()->S=fun lists:seq/2,[$_|S($0,$9)]++S($A,$Z)++S($a,$z).`

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 130 bytes

Have fun hitting enter...

```
Sub q()
For i = 1 To 123
If i > 47 And i < 58 Or i > 64 And i < 91 Or i > 96 And i < 123 Or i = 95 Then MsgBox Chr(i)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (Using external library) (105 bytes)

```
_.Range(97,26).Concat(_.Range(65,26).Concat(_.Range(48,10))).Push(95).Write("",x=>String.fromCharCode(x))
```

What this does is gets the char code ranges from a-z, concats with A-Z, then concats 0-9, then pushes the code for _. Write takes a delimiter and joins everything together

Library: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable/blob/master/linq.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```
echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_';
```

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck - 116 commands

```
>++++++++[<++++++>-]>+++[<+++>-]<+[<.+>-]++[<+++>-]<+>>++++[<++++++>-]<++[<.+>-]<++++.++>>++++[<++++++>-]<++[<.+>-]
```

Output: `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

### How it works

`>++++++++[<++++++>-]`
Get yourself up to `\48`, the start of `[0-9]`

`>+++[<+++>-]<+`
Count up 10

`[<.+>-]`
Then print each character and bump it up

`++[<+++>-]<+>`
jump up to the start of `[A-Z]`

`>++++[<++++++>-]<++`
start a counter of 26

`[<.+>-]`
and print and increment 26 values

`<++++.++>`
jump to `[a-z]`, stopping in at `_`

`>++++[<++++++>-]<++`
counter of 26

`[<.+>-]`
and print and increment 26 values

there's got to be a way to simplify that counter to 26 and the print happening twice, but I'm not nearly good enough with brainfuck to do so

Comment: 48 doubled is 96, so you could use replace the initial loop with `>++++[>++++++[>++>++++<<-]<-]` to get both. Probably shorter than two output loops.

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 50 bytes

```
[la1+ddsaPlc>b]dddsb96saC2scx64sa90scx47sa57scx95P
```

This doesn't feel very elegant.

```
[              # Open macro definition
 la 1+         #  Load a, increment
 dd            #  Duplicate a+1 twice
 sa            #  Store a+1 as `a'
 P             #  Print new value of a as a character
 lc>b          #  If c>a, do this again
]              # Close macro definition
ddd sb         # DDDuplicate and store as `b'
96sa C2sc x    # Set lower and upper bounds (`a' and `c') for [a-z] and execute a copy of b
64sa 90sc x    # Set bounds for [A-Z] and execute a copy of b
47sa 57sc x    # Set bounds for [0-9] and execute a copy of b
95P            # Print underscore
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 20 bytes

```
'_0 9
'a'z
'A'Z
,,,,
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Creates a series of charcode ranges and outputs them.

Answer (score 0):

## , 10 chars / 13 bytes

```
Ⓒ…⩥ṻ)ŋ/\W⌿
```

<kbd>[Try it here (ES6 browsers only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=&code=%E2%92%B8%E2%80%A6%E2%A9%A5%E1%B9%BB)%C5%8B%2F%5CW%E2%8C%BF)</kbd>

Translated roughly to ES6:

```
String.fromCharCode(_.range(123)).replace(/\W/g,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 61 bytes

using formule for lowercase'ing from Practical Lisp, namely `(format t "~(~a~)" "ExAMpleStRINg")`

```
(format t"~a~:*~(~a~)0123456789_"'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
```

Ideas for improvement are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>66</s> 41 bytes

Had some coffee and re-read the specs:

```
[65,90|?chr$(a)+chr$(a+32)]?@0123456789_`
```

This prints `Aa\n` all the way up to `Zz\n`, then the literal `0123456789_`.

---

There are quite a lot of ways QBIC can approach this challenge if we want to print the string in the order provided.

By adding all the requested ranges to `Z$` (`Z$` gets printed implicitly), 71 bytes

```
[97,122|Z=Z+chr$(a)][65,90|Z=Z+chr$(b)][48,57|Z=Z+chr$(c)]Z=Z+chr$(95)
```

Printing each range to screen, with ';` to prevent newlines, 67 bytes

```
[97,122|?chr$(a)';`][65,90|?chr$(b)';`][48,57|?chr$(c)';`]?chr$(95)
```

Creates one range, printing only substrings, 70 bytes

```
[48,122|A=A+chr$(a)]?mid$(A,50,26)+mid$(A,18,26)+left$(A,10)+chr$(95)
```

Creating one range, but with modified start of that range, 69 bytes

```
[122|A=A+chr$(a)]?mid$(A,96,26)+mid$(A,64,26)+mid$(A,47,10)+chr$(95)
```

But sadly the best at 66 bytes, just plainly printing this string:

```
?@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_`
```

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 35 bytes

**Solution:**

```
("c"$48+(!)75)except":;<=>?@[\\]^`"
```

**Example:**

```
q)("c"$48+(!)75)except":;<=>?@[\\]^`"
"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

**Notes:**

Turns out I cannot read :) `Q.an` solves this in 5 bytes. I'll try to golf this new solution.

Comment: "Built-ins that contain 9 or more of these characters are disallowed."

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 9 bytes

```
•zR.'\W'-
```

### Explained

```
•zR.'\W'-
•           # Push a space
 z          # Push the character 'z'
  R         # Create a stack of all characters from space to z.
   .        # Concatenate them into a single string.
    '\W'-   # Filter out everything that matches the regex '\W' (Non-alpha-numeric characters)
            # Implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6//9Rw6KqID31mHB13f//AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>60</s> 57 bytes

Shame we can't return an array or set of the characters, I could've saved quite a few bytes there.

```js
_=>[...new Set(Object.keys(this).join`4Z_`+2**29)].join``
```

---

### Test it

The second line is sorted to make it easy to check all characters are included.

```js
f=
_=>[...new Set(Object.keys(this).join`4Z_`+2**29)].join``
o.innerText=f()+`\n`+[...f()].sort().join``
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

Comment: `G` `J` `K` `N` `Q` `U` missing on Firefox 97.0

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran 95, 131 bytes

```
write(*,1)(char(i),i=97,122)
write(*,1)(char(i),i=65,90)
write(*,2)(i,i=0,9)
write(*,1)'_'
1 format(1A,25A,$)
2 format(10I1,$)
end
```

Just because every challenge is improved by a Fortran entry.

You'd think it would be easy to golf this down, but the required variable declarations get expensive very quickly so I think this is about as short as it's going to get.

If delimiters (`\n`) were allowed between characters in the output, this could be reduced to **83 bytes**:

```
print*,(char(i),i=97,122)
print*,(char(i),i=65,90)
print*,(i,i=0,9)
print*,'_'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 39 bytes

```
"AaZ_"o\9:n:?!;1-80.
+}$:@=?\}:o1+}::o1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8kxMSpeKT/G0irPyl7R2lDXwkCPS7tWxcrB1j6m1irfULvWCkj@/w8A)

Fairly simple, prints _, loop prints a, A then increments and compares to Z.
At the end it'll print 9-0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J`, \$12\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 10 bytes

(Actually \$\approx\$ 9.88 bytes but the leaderboard doesn't take decimals)

```
123RCJ"\w"Af
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSl1LsgqWlJWm6FmsMjYyDnL2UYsqVHNMgQlCZBVAaAA)

##### Explanation

```python
123R # range(123)
CJ   # converted from codepoints
"\w" # string "\w"
Af   # regex findall
     # Implicit output, joined
```